# Sandbox archive

Tags: support, sandbox

This post exists purely to house answers formerly attached to [the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). You can safely ignore it.

Answer (score 168):

[image: Roll the ball!]
Works using Markdown...

[image]
...and plain HTML

^---- Animated SVG!

Hmm, does the `data:` URI scheme work?

Not yet, apparently. (it also doesn't work in links)

---

Chrome's throbbers:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Formatting you possibly didn't know about:

`[tag:status-declined]` = [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
`[tag:status-completed]` = [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

- http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html
- [Test1](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Test2](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoAsterisk](http://web.archive.org/web//http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoColon](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http//java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [NoAsteriskNoColonNoHttp](http://web.archive.org/web///java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Properlink?](http://web.archive.org/web/http:/java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)
- [Tor Link](https://dppmfxaacucguzpc.onion/)

M̵̳̙͔̟̱͕̓̀̄̉̅ͧ̋͊͌͑́͌ͪ̒̿̀̚a͔̟̝͔ͥ̈́̏ͮͯ̇͆̊̒ͦͦ͘͢͜y̵̴̢͕̝̩̱͈͕̼̣͕̟̌͗̾ͤ̎͌̄ͣͨ͊ͬb̡̯̰̪̜͙̟̝̠͚̜̥̙̤̃ͨ̋̒̒̊ͧͤ͐̓͋̌̾̇̔̈́̀́͡͠e̵ͯͪ̿̿̂̄ͫ̃҉͏͎̣̹̱̜͉̦̞̪̘̠̝̝͍̼̜̖̥̭͟ ̣̞͙͚̝̰̞̹̗̲̣͙͍͍̀̓͊̂̋ͣ̏̑̍̊͌ͩ͐̎̀ͣͣ̚͟ͅh̛͋̏̍̆ͤ͛͐ͨ̌̋ͤ̎̂ͨ̂̓̑̚̕͟͏̻̣͖̖͚͚͓̲̼̪ȁ̔̅̿͐̑͡͏̝͓̮͚̘̦̰͚͎͔͉͚̮̠̕͜ͅṱ̱̼̖̓̂ͭ̏̅͂ͥ͌ͯ͌͠sͪ̓ͪ̄̌̓ͧ͋͐ͬ̅̑҉̨̪̬͎͍̥̬?̡̮̳͙͓͔̹̘̹͓̘̻̦̣͎̫̐ͤ̐͛́͝ ̧̦̼̘͕̪̠̙͖̦̯̦̘͉͈͕͔̘̻̲͑ͨ̊̈́̐ͫ͐̌ͯ̀͘͝Ḩ̷̸̸̹͉̩̜̹̞ͯ̃̃ͧͬͨ̌̀̾̐̈̇ͧ͛̃͐̀ͦ͞A̴̦̗̬̠͙̭͉̟̺͇̭̰͔͕̯̅̃͋ͪ̈́̉̓̌ͯ̈́͆̋̀ͤ̇̂̿̈́̂͡͡Ṱ̲͎͉̣̳̺̱̜̦̬͕̣͉͇͊̌ͥ͐͒̈́̓́ͥ́́̋͂̅ͬ̆͗ͥ̕͢͡S̍ͧ͗̒͗̂̈ͬ͊̚̚͢͏̗̣̳ͅ!̶̨̡͇͚̙͚̭̱̣̲̳̤̞̫̗̣̦̮̖̞͒͆̿̄͑̃̎͡

Comment: Dude, this is freaking epic

Comment: Now how to find a way to fit that soccer ball into an example while helping someone with a coding problem...

Comment: @PaulPRO: Maybe on the math site?

Comment: Wait what, how do you animate an SVG?  If an SVG is just lines to the computer... how are you animating lines?  :(   Also: Time to make this 1,000,000 by 1,000,000

Comment: @cbroughton:The SVG spec. provides means for specifying animation data - I'm not sure of the specifics though. You would need to consult the spec. for more details.

Comment: Testing links in comments http://google.com. [meta] meta [main], [edit]

Comment: _italic_, **bold**, inline `code`

Comment: accent marks ` stuff `code`.

Comment: It appears that the soccer ball no longer exists :(

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com> [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">SO</a>

Comment: `test`
>test two

Comment: [«](http://example.com)@username testing something

Comment: I like dragging the soccer ball to the furthest edge of my screen, and then letting go. :)

Comment: nice, *bold* and **italic** code is awesome!

Comment: Testing a funny [link here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/)

Comment: @ascii-lime I'm having a hard time rotating my model of a truncated icosahedron.  If only someone could provide a visual, I think I could work the code out from my existing model.  Just kidding. :)

Comment: This is <strike>bad</strike>good.

Comment: ⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: [tag:header-files]

Comment: I'm shutting down Stack Exchange because this user told me ‮doowtA ffeJ‭

Comment: [test link](http://web.archive.org/web/%2A/http%3A//java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)

Comment: [mso] [MSO] [stackapps] [meta] [main] [Meta.SO]

Comment: Here is a link to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77651/160509)"what?" other answer.

Comment: test comment for a thing

Comment: Test Cursor Captuing

Comment: Also testing <space>

Comment: ``'tag'`` some random text.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-stupid-user-mistake-you-should-really-know-better]

Comment: trying `<kbd>CTRL</kbd>` formatting in comment <kbd>CTRL</kbd> ...nope does not work in comment

Comment: test comjhkj hkjh jkh kjh kjh jkh kjh jkh kjh jkh uky kuh kjy iu

Comment: This is only a test of the stackoverflow api.  This should be ignored, only for testing purposes.  Thanks.

Comment: <del>as;dlfkjasdfl</del>

Comment: How to  
insert multiple lines? (Double space after "to" inserted)

Comment: TEST updated **OR deleted**. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/05/09/repeatable-read-isolation-level.aspx)

Comment: Unicode UTF-8 Strikethrough. ̶F̶a̶l̶s̶e̶  True.

Comment: <!>ok<!>ok<!>ok<!>ok<!>ok<!>ok<!>ok

Comment: What are we doing here?

Comment: ™º™´™™´˝™øƒ˝ˇ˛™øƒø™˝

Comment: ‮♦&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: ‮hithis is a test sdkfjasdfkjasdfkjasd‭

Comment: ‭This is a test.

Comment: ‮‭This is a test

Comment: ‮&nbsp;‭This is a test as well.

Comment: ‮;psbn&‭Hello there

Comment: `` this is a test

Comment: this is a  test!!!

Comment: ‮‮Huh This is another test. ‭Hahaha

Comment: Testing?


Hello there.

Comment: _.rotaredom a si resu sihT_

Comment: ‮_.rotaredom a si resu sihT_OBEY ME.

Comment: ‮.rotaredom krowten egnahcxEkcatS a si resu sihT :ETON‭I am a moderator. Fear me.

Comment: ^ That's dangerous lol

Comment: hello trying out multi line  <br/> hello

Comment: [ask] This is how to ask.. [tour]

Comment: [help]- This is help, [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [help/behavior] and [meta-help]

Comment: @Aequitas test the notification thing

Comment: @Chippies first up

Comment: @Chippies edited commente

Comment: @Chippies how bout this one?

Comment: got notification?

Comment: teresting how bout you?

Comment: How does [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxtables) and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libxtables) work?

Comment: [mcve] [ask] [asking] [avoid] [answer]

Comment: Properlink?  Tor Link  M̵̳̙͔̟̱͕̓̀̄̉̅ͧ̋͊͌͑́͌ͪ̒̿̀̚a͔̟̝͔ͥ̈́̏ͮͯ̇͆̊̒ͦͦ͘͢͜y̵̴̢͕̝̩̱͈͕̼̣͕̟̌͗̾ͤ̎͌̄ͣͨ͊ͬb̡̯̰̪̜͙̟̝̠͚̜̥̙̤̃ͨ̋̒̒̊ͧͤ͐̓͋̌̾̇̔̈́̀́͡͠e̵ͯͪ̿̿̂̄ͫ̃҉͏͎̣̹̱̜͉̦̞̪̘̠̝̝͍̼̜̖̥̭͟ ̣̞͙͚̝̰̞̹̗̲̣͙͍͍̀̓͊̂̋ͣ̏̑̍̊͌ͩ͐̎̀ͣͣ̚͟ͅh̛͋̏̍̆ͤ͛͐ͨ̌̋ͤ̎̂ͨ̂̓̑̚̕͟͏̻̣͖̖͚͚͓̲̼̪ȁ̔̅̿͐̑͡͏̝͓̮͚̘̦̰͚͎͔͉͚̮̠̕͜ͅṱ̱̼̖̓̂ͭ̏̅͂ͥ͌ͯ͌͠sͪ̓ͪ̄̌̓ͧ͋͐ͬ̅̑҉̨̪̬͎͍̥̬?̡̮̳͙͓͔̹̘̹͓̘̻̦̣͎̫̐ͤ̐͛́͝ ̧̦̼̘͕̪̠̙͖̦̯̦̘͉͈͕͔̘̻̲͑ͨ̊̈́̐ͫ͐̌ͯ̀͘͝Ḩ̷̸̸̹͉̩̜̹̞ͯ̃̃ͧͬͨ̌̀̾̐̈̇ͧ͛̃͐̀ͦ͞A̴̦̗̬̠͙̭͉̟̺͇̭̰͔͕̯̅̃͋ͪ̈́̉̓̌ͯ̈́͆̋̀ͤ̇̂̿̈́̂͡͡Ṱ̲͎͉̣̳̺̱̜̦̬͕̣͉͇͊̌ͥ͐͒̈́̓́ͥ́́̋͂̅ͬ̆͗ͥ̕͢͡S̍ͧ͗̒͗̂̈ͬ͊̚̚͢͏̗̣̳ͅ

Comment: what in the hell is this above

Comment: Maybe we should learn [ask]

Comment: It's a very good idea

Comment: Just one more with [tour]

Comment: Your answer slows down my scrolling speed significantly, while visible. Using the App on an Android device.

Comment: ```a``` testing

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//meta.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Meta way of saying thank you.

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Comment: ᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎​᠎

Comment: Look at me! I'm a moderator now! ‮ [♦ namsO nahtaN](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman)‭

Answer (score 141):

[Starting to rebuild the castle for modern times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1974).  Looks decent on FF so far.

full block:   |        |
`<kbd>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd>`

half block:   | |
`<kbd>&nbsp;</kbd>`

extra block:  |               |
`<kbd>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</kbd>`

full space:   |          |
`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

half space:   |     |
`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

extra space:  |               |
`&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`

|        |
|          |
| |
|     |

|         |
|               |
|               |

---

open door 1

---

open door 2

---

door top 1

---

door top 2

---

full wall 1

---

full wall 2

---

wall top

---

top window 1

---

top window 2

---

full top wall 1

---

full top wall 2

---

top wall top

---

fin

Comment: testing [tag:tag] in comments [tag:markdown]

Comment: comment!
comment!!
comment!!!

Comment: Backup of castle just in case. [FF 13](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sq5aJ.png)

Comment: test this is a test

Comment: this is also a test @SaifHakim

Comment: `\\` teste sttt

Comment: <kbd>&nbsp;</kbd>
How can I get it? :D

Comment: ‮
Test comment.

Comment: Your full space, half space, and extra space are too small for me. (Firefox 28.0, Windows XP)

Comment: Hmm, fixed now. Mebbe something to do with the mso-mse-split?

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: ‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮

Comment: zero‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‍‍‍

Comment: b(y′)=b(y)+b(x′)[b(x′)≤0]−1

Comment: Sorry, your answer is in [another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 130):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>FATAL ERROR: <kbd> overflow</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: As all my other attempts to get `<kbd>` banned failed: maybe this will finally make it happen ;-)

Comment: There's no reason to ban it... just simply flag answers which abuse it. (This not being one, as it's on the formatting sandbox) :)

Comment: Any [non-castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) use of `<kbd>` is abuse of my poor eyes! ;-)

Comment: holy...wow. I think my brain is leaking.

Comment: My overflow is cooler than yours. :P

Comment: When I refreshed the page it showed this for a second, I thought it was a real error!

Comment: This is art. It clearly belongs in a museum.

Comment: That's just obnoxious

Comment: I love how the Chrome's rendering flickers when you scroll on this slowly :)

Comment: It is too tall!

Comment: @kiamlaluno Nice editing. No it does not take too much time to load. :)

Comment: This is very fun!

Comment: @George my eyes! Ze googles, zey do nothing!

Comment: @geo - Let's not go overboard here, ok? :P Every time you edit this post gets bumped to the top of the questions page... One of the [past edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/114743/2) was to improve the responsiveness of this page. Some browsers on weaker machines have proplems with such shinanigans :)

Comment: This crippled my phone.

Comment: This is great! (test comment)

Answer (score 106):

## ‮NIA‭P‮P ‭RE‮RO‭PARE‮F ‭

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[image]</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: +1 for flashing red eyes

Comment: Test Test Test Test

Comment: Who messed with the flashy red eyes?!?!?!

Comment: @John Apparently the [freehand circle script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor-now-supported-on-every-st) flattens GIFs. I feel violated

Comment: @Michael: Yes.  This is wrong.  What happened to rollback link?

Comment: @Michael: Adding support for animated GIFs is somewhat pointless and much too complicated.

Comment: @George I wouldn't expect you to, I was just explaining what happened

Comment: [ask] [answer] [chat]

Comment: test is a test of test

Comment: test test test test test and test

Comment: ``\`` and  ``\a``, ``\\`` and  ``\\a``

Comment: testing ie8 breaks

Comment: Test comment delete delete

Comment: ‮NIA‭P‮P ‭RE‮RO‭PARE‮F ‭

Comment: ---Test---Test---Test---Test---

Comment: [FAQ] test [faq#anchor] test [meta-faq] test [meta-faq#anchor]

Comment: a link [/formatting-sandbox]

Answer (score 101):

### OMG...

<kbd>from the sp​here I can see it can you see ̲͚̖͔̙î̩́t̲͎̩̱͔́̋̀ it is beautiful t​he f`inal snuf`fing o*f the lie​**s of Man ALL IS LOŚ͖̩͇̗̪̏̈́T A*****LL I​S L**OST th*e pon̷y he come*s he c̶̮om<strike>es he co</strike>**<strike>me</strike>s t*he* ich​**or permeat*es al*l MY FAC*E MY FACE ᵒh god n**o NO NOO̼*****O​O N**Θ stop t*he an​*̶͑̾̾​̅ͫ͏̙̤g͇̫͛͆̾ͫ̑͆l͖͉̗̩̳̟̍ͫͥͨ*e̠̅s `͎a̧͈͖r̽̾̈́͒͑e` n**​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ T**O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ</kbd>

<kbd>**​ot rè̑ͧ̌aͨl̘̝̙̃ͤ͂̾̆ ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ T**O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘**Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝**S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ</kbd>

Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Does t̴͓̭̗̒́̓̉̆h̞͍̙̖͖̪̙͉ͭ̅ͪ̒̕͘ȩ̝̰̲̰͎͙͂̉͊͌ ̶̢̞͙̔͌̓ͤͤ͑̿ä̵̯̩̳̟̒͠b̨̤̖̱͎̬͈ͭͧ̽͛͛̇̇̕͝ͅö͍̙̲̞̫̳̙͕̎ͪ͐͗ͣ͜v̶͉͚̗͙̹̮̠̏ͮͬͮͬͪë̩̮̠̜͡ look [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tHqYH.png) to you?

Comment: @Arjan yep. It's unicode hell, posted to make some point about why RegEx can't be used to parse HTML..

Comment: Sorry, just checking; some are seeing [rendering with squares](http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox). ;-)

Comment: @Arjan I have exactly what Wil has - Chrome on Windows 7 with those additional language support files. :)

Comment: @Arjan Are those Unicode's combining characters?

Comment: [Yes](http://eeemo.net/), @YatharthROCK.

Comment: hello \ world .

Comment: @aja hello back!

Comment: ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ヾ( ´ ▽ `)ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: @Walfie your comment is... [erected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ER35.png)!! :-P

Comment: ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ヾ( ´ ▽ `)ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ヾ( ´ ▽ `)ノส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: I really...just don't understand how this is possible.

Comment: @ChristopherW something about the way the browser handles certain unicode characters, saw a good explanation here on Meta recently but can't find it now. :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, if you ever come across it again hook a brother up.

Comment: @ChristopherW [found it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6579844/447356)! :) It's called "Zalgo text"

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks! This is excellent. I'm going to go have about 10 minutes of fun

Comment: -1 test test test test

Comment: ̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇̇

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞Ẁ̰̲̞̠͇̯̯̟̠͍̻ͬ̐̀̓̓́͆̄̒̉́͢Ţ̐͆ͭ̈́̾͆͂ͧ̿͐͐ͤ̈́ͩͪͪ̒̄̚͟͜҉̫̞͓͙ͅF̶̛͕̫̦̩̳̈̈́̃̇̈ͫ̏̌ͧ͊ͪ̿̍́͜͞

Comment: Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜

Comment: Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜

Comment: Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜Ẅ̢̛̥̠̺̲̟̘̤͚̝̥̣͓̗͖͓̫̞ͮ̌̏̾̍̽͗ͨ̓̆̈ͨ͊ͨͥ̽̐T̛̏͆̓̿̍̐ͣ̓ͩ̇̾͌̐ͨͩ̚͡͏̸̻̘̞̣̣͈̞̮͓̫̦͍̭̘͉͉F̵̡̧̠͕̲̭̬̞̤̘̎͒̒͛ͬ͜

Comment: ส้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Answer (score 95):

Up up and awayy<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Bzzz<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sub>z<sub>z<sub>z<sup>z<sup>z<sub>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</sub></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sup></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub></sub></sup></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sup></sub>

Down down and belo<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>o<sub>ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooow</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Pew pew: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: This is definitely the most intrusive entry. Love it :-)

Comment: I sincerely hope you wrote a script for that, and didn't write it by hand. Side note - `<sup>y</sup><sup><sup>y</sup></sup>` can be just `<sup>y<sup>y</sup></sup>` (which is possibly (slightly) easier to write a script for).

Comment: @Dukeling: Yup: `sup = lambda text, depth=1: ('<sup>' + text) * depth + '</sup>' * depth`. Although it seems like the visible `y`s max out at a height of 102.

Comment: [avp.se] [video.se] [se]

Comment: Looks like someone spoiled this on MSE: the style sheet now has `sup sup sup sup, sub sub sub sub { font-size: 101%; position: initial; }` in it. :( No more sub-sub-sub-sub-scripts for you!

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: is this a [tag]?

Comment: ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ I turned the stun gun into a bazooka blaster. LOL

Answer (score 92):

[image]

Comment: Double bonus: you can get sick staring at that for 2 minutes.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhh. ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH. **has a seizure**

Comment: Pity this is community wiki. It's definitely worth some points.

Comment: ‮‮So.. reversing character?

Comment: @sarnold You can award bounties.

Comment: What, no dancing bananas?

Comment: Ehhh the graphic died?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: Looks like it.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Image revived.

Comment: If you look at it for a while, you can see a face.

Comment: This actually made me spill my orange juice.  I wasn't quite drinking/spitting it yet but still....

Comment: And here I was thinking that the post was loading >.<

Comment: @xiL, How on earth do you do that..

Comment: @JonasCz ‮‮I have no idea.

Comment: @tombull89 you wouldn't bother to *comment* "AHHH"!

Answer (score 82):

Testing a possible bug with flags. Good thing I can flag my own answers.

Mods, ignore flags on this answer if they end up going through.

While I'm here:

``````````
Hello
   World \\
Houston, we've had a problem.
                                    -:://                                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                    :++++.                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                         `-`        .++++:                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                       -////-        +++++                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                       `/////:`      :++++.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                         ://///.     .++++:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                          ./////-     /++++                                                                                                                                                                                                       
               --`         `://///`   :++++.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
              :+++/:.        -/////.  .++++:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
             ./+++++++:.`     ./////:  /++++                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                .:+++++++/-`   `://///`-+++/.                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                   .-/+++++++:.` -////- `                                                                                                                                                                                                         
          `.`         `-/+++++++/-.-`                                                                                                                                                                                                             
          :+++/:--.`      .:/++++/`                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         .+++++++++++//:-..` `-/:                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          ``.-://++++++++++++/:-                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 /+++.            `.--:/+++++++. /+++.                                                       oo:                                                                      .+oyyy  :ooo:                                                               
 /ooo.  `--.....```      ``.-::  /ooo.                   -++                                 MMo                                                                     oMMMMMM  oMMMo                                                               
 /ooo.  -+++++++++++++++///:::`  /ooo.                   oMM                                 MMo                                                                     MMMM+--  oMMMo                                                               
 /ooo.  :+++++++++++++++++++++.  /ooo.        `-::.`   `.sMM...    `.::-.          `-::.     MMo     `...    -+syyys/`  :ssso     -ssso`  -+syyys/`    .sss+:oyyys//+MMMM+++  oMMMo      -+syyys/`  :ssso     oss/    .ssss`                      
 /ooo.        ```...---::::://   /ooo.     `sNMmmmmMNy`-mNMMmmm  oNMNmmmMNh-    .yNMNmmMNh-  MMo    /mMd-  -dMMMMMMMMMy``mMMMo   `mMMMo -dMMMMMMMMMy`  :MMMMMMMMMMymMMMMMMMM  oMMMo    -mMMMMMMMMMy``NMMM+   +MMMM-   yMMMh                       
 /ooo.  //////////////////////   /ooo.     yMd.    `:`   oMM     :s.    `yMM.  -NMs.   `/o`  MMo  -hMm/   `NMMMy:-/dMMMh -MMMN.  oMMMd .NMMN/.`-yMMMh  :MMMMh:-/s. .-MMMM---  oMMMo   .NMMMy:-/dMMMh +MMMm  .NMMMMd  .MMMN.                       
 /ooo.  oooooooooooooooooooooo   /ooo.     yMm:``        oMM             :MM:  mMy           MMo`yMMo     /MMMm    .MMMM  +MMMh -MMMN. sMMMh+++++MMMM- :MMMM         MMMM     oMMMo   /MMMm    .MMMM  hMMM+ hMMNMMMo hMMMo                        
 /ooo.  ++++++++++++++++++++++   /ooo.     `odNMMNNmdo`  oMM     /hmNmmmmNMM:  MMo           MMdNNmMm.    oMMMh     MMMM-  hMMM+dMMM:  hMMMMMMMMMMMMM: :MMMM         MMMM     oMMMo   oMMMh     MMMM` -MMMNoMMM-sMMM+MMMm                         
 /ooo.                           /ooo.         ```.:dMd  oMM    sMN:`    :MM:  mMs           MMMy.`yMN/   /MMMN`   :MMMM   `NMMMMMMs   oMMMy`````````  :MMMM         MMMM     oMMMo   /MMMN`   :MMMM   oMMMMMMs `mMMMMMM-                         
 /ooo:---------------------------+ooo.     :/`      yMN  oMM`   hMh      oMM:  /MM+     :/   MMs    +MMs   mMMMmo+sNMMMs    -MMMMMd    `NMMMd+//odNo`  :MMMM         MMMM     oMMMm++-`mMMMmo+sNMMMs   `mMMMMm`  -MMMMMy                          
 /ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.    -dMMdhsyhNMh-  `dMNhh .mMNhsshNNMM:   :dMNhhhNMm/  MMo     :NMh. `sNMMMMMMMd/      oMMMN.     `sNMMMMMMMMd:  :MMMM         MMMM     `yMMMMMo `sNMMMMMMMd/     :MMMM-    sMMMN`                          
 .-----------------------------------`      `-/++++:`      .:++   ./+++/-.++`     `:+++/.    ++-      .++:    -/+++:.         /++-         -/++++:`    `++++         ++++       `::++-    -/+++:.        /++:     `+++-
``````````

Comment: o_____________O

Comment: Wow. Just... wow.

Comment: Hiya! This here is a test of the API!

Comment: two two two two two two two

Comment: How this was generated?

Comment: 0/10 Advertising StackOverflow; does not disclose affiliation.

Answer (score 80):

⁠            Double-Struck:    
⁠                Monospace:    
⁠               Sans-Serif:    
⁠        Sans-Serif Italic:    
⁠          Sans-Serif Bold:    
⁠   Sans-Serif Bold Italic:    
⁠                   Script: ℊ  ℰℊ ℱℴℴ
⁠                   Italic:   h 
⁠                     Bold:    
⁠              Bold Italic:    
⁠                  Fraktur:    
⁠             Bold Fraktur:

---

## *ℊ  ℰℊ ℱℴℴ*

```
⁠            Double-Struck:    
⁠                Monospace:    
⁠               Sans-Serif:    
⁠        Sans-Serif Italic:    
⁠          Sans-Serif Bold:    
⁠   Sans-Serif Bold Italic:    
⁠                   Script: ℊ  ℰℊ ℱℴℴ
⁠                   Italic:   h 
⁠                     Bold:    
⁠              Bold Italic:    
⁠                  Fraktur:    
⁠             Bold Fraktur:
```

---

Hey there buddy, whadya think of my swell  here? I think it is not just  — it is truly  all over!

---

- 1D6B7 MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL PI
- 1D6D1 MATHEMATICAL BOLD SMALL PI
- 1D6E1 MATHEMATICAL BOLD PI SYMBOL
- 1D6F1 MATHEMATICAL ITALIC CAPITAL PI
- 1D70B MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL PI
- 1D71B MATHEMATICAL ITALIC PI SYMBOL
- 1D72B MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL PI
- 1D745 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC SMALL PI
- 1D755 MATHEMATICAL BOLD ITALIC PI SYMBOL
- 1D765 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD CAPITAL PI
- 1D77F MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD SMALL PI
- 1D78F MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD PI SYMBOL
- 1D79F MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC CAPITAL PI
- 1D7B9 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC SMALL PI
- 1D7C9 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF BOLD ITALIC PI SYMBOL

---

¿əɹəɥʇ ʇno ʎpoqʎuɐ əɹəɥʇ sI

Iꜱ ᴛʜᴇʀᴇ ᴀɴʏʙᴏᴅʏ ᴏᴜᴛ ᴛʜᴇʀᴇ? (Just nod if you can hear me.)

Comment: Works great in Firefox, doesn't work in Chromium.

Comment: `<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>`

Comment: Testing testing [about]

Comment: Safari on Windows doesn't like this. At all.

Comment: Firefox is far happier with it, but doesn't get it all. And my Linux computer is broken, so I can't test there right now.

Comment: @TRiG Do you have George Douros’ Symbola font installed, the one he made for Unicode 6.0 and all the emoji?

Comment: @Shoe testinggg

Comment: _[main]_ comment

Comment: what about custom linking the shortcuts? [main](http://google.com)

Comment: do we need _spaces_tooperat?

Comment: *blah* blah blah

Comment: @thereisnouser hsere

Comment: @Madara just testing this in the sandbox

Comment: @BenCollins: Y U NOTIFY INOBX?!

Comment: @SecondRikudo: Sorry, will not do that.

Comment: *nods* ​​​​​​​​

Comment: ℊ  ℰℊ ℱℴℴ

Comment: @nicael Alas. It’s because there are “holes” in the regular `MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT` set:  –   – –  – –   – –     –             –  –        –           . This is not a problem with the `MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT` set:                                                    .

Comment: @uınbɐɥs Works perfectly on my Chromium 34.0.1847.116 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Doorknob When I left that comment, I was using Chromium on Windows. It works fine in Ubuntu 14.04 for me too.

Comment: Firefox hates me!

Comment: Where is Comic Sans????

Answer (score 74):

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--
```

[image]

(image by http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: aah, Exploits of the mom :)

Comment: Comment may not take without an extra space after the `--`...

Comment: >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ok

Comment: Testing: [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: > quote here? wokring

new line

Comment: `object = {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9};
_.chain(object).toPairs(o).take(2).value()` 
returns:
`[ [ 'a', 7 ], [ 'b', 8 ] ]`

Comment: That's `object = {a: 7, b: 8, c: 9};
_.chain(object).toPairs(o).take(2).value()` 
returns:
`[ [ 'a', 7 ], [ 'b', 8 ] ]`

Answer (score 64):

[image: Vote up if you think graphical trousers are the best]

Comment: Fixed obvious typo.

Comment: *********a**************

Comment: @badp Do not vandalize posts. I will flag you. :P

Comment: **aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa**

Comment: Scripting attack! <noscript>Yes, I did that!</noscript>Linebreak:<br><strong>Going strong to day?!</strong><script type="text/javascript">alert("Test");</script><img src="http://imgur.com/3eeYV.png"><a href="google.com">Click here for free pie!</a>

Comment: Comment link test: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/81709#comment350534_3122

Comment: ...That's an image. ;-(

Answer (score 62):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Blockquote Overflow

Comment: What....on....earth....is....that? :P

Comment: Test this here really"!

Comment: Oh no minitech η♦, this one is too large D:

Comment: ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮

Comment: Editing this post crashes Chrome :0(

Comment: @Moobs: The new Meta StackExchange style added quite a bit of madness to this post. Editing should work fine now.

Comment: Editing now works but clicking "edited X mins ago" now seems to timeout (only on this post). I can still view revisions after clicking edit. Strange

Comment: More `>` are possible.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181841/191655

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2‫17‭‮‭88

Comment: +0

Answer (score 57):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it
>   is [peer reviewed](http://www.foo.bar/foo.asp). Just kidding, your edit was horrible, and nobody cared enough to accept it.

Answer, testing comments, creating a new answer so nobody gets bugged by the inbox

Just testing a [link that I have never visited](http://www.foo.bar/foo.asp).
Just testing a [link that I have visited](https://www.google.com).

---

---

---

[Short Link test](/q/10)
[Full  Link test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/)

Comment: YOU'RE BUGGING MY INBOX :D:D:D

Comment: @OLAFUR, YOU TOO :)

Comment: just testing a [link that I never visited](http://www.foo.bar/foo.asp).

Comment: just testing a [link that I have visited](https://www.google.com).

Comment: This scared me when I scrolled past.

Answer (score 44):

!!‮ This post is seriously messed up now!

Comment: I do not believe this.

Comment: 

Comment: Some "foo *and bar*". Some "foo <i>and bar</i>". Some “foo *and bar*”.

Comment: <$‮ This post is seriously messed up now !

Comment: <$‮ This post is seriously messed up now !

Comment: @George Edison What is this?

Comment: <$‮ This post is seriously messed up now !

Comment: This is a comment‮dilav sa deggalf neeb sah tnemmoc sihT‭

Comment: Wut? Wut Wut is this all about?

Comment: This post is seriously messed up now!

Comment: @hims056: oh my. How did you do that? :o

Comment: @AmalMurali - Just copy my comment and paste it in your comment.

Comment: <$‮ This post is seriously messed up now ! – Mechanical snail Sep 20 '12 at 22:06

Comment: ‮ This post is seriously messed up now

Comment: !!! tnemmoc tseT

Comment: ‮Thpost is serio messed up n

Comment: ‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭

Comment: <! test ok asdas

Comment: How do you type more of that? ‮ This post is seriously messed up now!

Comment: Hint: RTL unicode modifier.

Comment: !!!‮ This post is seriously mes!!!sed up now!!!!

Comment: Nowcan
How do you type more of that? ‮ This post is seriously messed up now! – ʇolɐǝz ǝɥʇ qoq Apr 8 at 3:43

Comment: &gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;

Comment: !!‮ This post is seriously messed up now. I Know, It's really cool, isn't it ? Hmm, it's really hard to read text in reverse, do you agree with me ? I think this unicode RTL modifier trick is seriously cool - i'm going to use it everywhere I can now. Isną̨̧̥̺̄͊͂̆̋̎͆͟͠l̵̲̞͙̲̼̥̲̗̞̂͊̎̽̈̀͐͘̕͜g̵͔̬̭̗̏̉̓̈́̇͌͛͘͢o̰̮̪̠̲̓̆̊͐̄̈̇͊̄͘͜͟ͅ ẗ̵̛͓͇̗͔͖̖̹̘̔̀͒͐̐͜ȩ̴̯͕͈͚̼́̏̒̒̌̾̉͋͟͠ͅx̨̡̹̝̙̱̫̻̺̿̉͗̒̽́͘͜͡͡t̮̟͍͚͈͉͓̮̄̓̏̓͂̎̔̚͜ͅ -̬̞͍̰̠̻̺̄̂̀̀͆̅̌͞ i̸̧̹̖̪̠͔̲̻̰̬̾̉̾̇̇ţ͎̩̜͓̜͙̲͊̂̈̌͑̄̅͒̚'̨̗̥̲̘̂̓̓͛̾̐̓̿̅͘š̶͚͈̣̞̏͒̀̌̚͢ ŗ͕̰̠̟̥͎̀̀̎͌̾̏͒̚͘͢a̭̞̾̒́͗̑̆͌͂͟ć̤̘̙͔̬́̀͋̄͆͟͠ǫ̠̣͈̮̂̍͛́̓ȏ̧̲̯̼͈͓̭͙͙͒̂̇̒͛̋̚͡ͅl̞̠̟̠̭̼̅͂͛̒̇͌̓̚!

Comment: &rlm; does this work?

Comment: !!!‮ This post is seriously mes!!!sed up now!!!! – Arefly Aug 30 '15 at 12:38

Comment: &#8207;testwefwef

Comment: <$‮ ?krow siht seod woH

Comment: ‮7102 ni skrow llits tI

Answer (score 43):

Testing Recursion.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113450/152657) for more details.

> Which came first, this answer or the link to it? :P

Comment: This is awesome! You know what can I do with this??

Comment: Wow... How did you know the URL before you made the post?

Comment: @tbodt http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21788/221866 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9090/221866

Comment: [Recursion at its finest](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=recusrsion&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=recursion&rls=en&spell=1)

Comment: testing the comment

Comment: An actual recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113450/152657

Answer (score 31):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Normal text, <sub><sup>Small text</sup></sub>, <sub><sup><sub><sup>Tiny text</sup></sub></sup></sub>, <sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>YesThisIsNotASimpleLineButByTypingContinuouslyICanSaveTheWorld</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[kbd-abuse](/questions/tagged/kbd-abuse)</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

In-page anchor

Testing tags: [lua](/questions/tagged/lua) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Broken [Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20121130000728/http://www.google.com/)

Comment: _` ` ` ` ` ` ` `_

Comment: ````````````````

Comment: [so], [su], [sf], [metase], [a51], [se]

Comment: [programmers.se], [careers]

Comment: Magic link [edit]

Comment: How the heck do you put tags in an answer???

Comment: ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: you can `enter   some spaced   code`

Comment: ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎ ​‎

Comment: [edit] [edit] [edit]

Comment: YesThisIsNotASimpleLineButByTypingContinuouslyICanSaveTheWorld

Comment: Where is my  
two-spaces triggered line break?

Comment: ​‎ ​‎ ​ ​‎ ​‎ ​ ​‎ ​‎ ​ ​‎ ​‎ ​

Comment: 

Comment:  

Comment:  

Answer (score 29):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[image: Wow]</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: <code>hi</code>

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [Hello this is testing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?page=2&tab=votes#comment-507430 "Hello this is testing")

Comment: `[meta-tag:markdown]` = [meta-tag:markdown]

Comment: [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Rightclick at the center of the "rectangle", chose "Inspect element" and move your mouse up & down in the inspector.

Comment: `\\`like _so_\\`` = \`like _so_\` ??

Comment: Try `edit:` or `[edit:]` instead

Comment: Test [edit:]...

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: testing meta links: `[meta]` = [meta] `[main]` = [main] `[sports.se]` = [sports.se] `[metase]` = [metase] `[metase]` = [metase]

Comment: More testing meta links: `[meta]` is [meta], `[Mathematica.SE]` is [Mathematica.SE], `[faq]` is [faq], `[chat]` is [chat].

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/‮21788‭/‭

Answer (score 26):

#### Runnable Code Blocks Using a User Script

```javascript
var canvas = document.createElement( "canvas" ),
    ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 320;
canvas.style.margin = "0 auto";
canvas.style.background = "rgb( 0, 0, 32 )";
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
out.appendChild( canvas );

for ( var i = 0; i < 1024; ++i ) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba( 200, " + ((128 + Math.random() * 127)|0) + ", 0, " + 0.1 * Math.random() + " )";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc( 320 - 40 * Math.random(), 160 - 20 * Math.random(), Math.random() * 256,
           Math.random() * Math.PI * 1.5, Math.random() * Math.PI * 0.5, true );
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

[image]  <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>**[`[ run with user script ]`](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/run-stackexchange-code-0.0.user.js)**</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

```javascript
$( out ).append( $( "<p>Hello World</p>" ) );
```

[image]  <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>**[`[ run with user script ]`](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/run-stackexchange-code-0.0.user.js)**</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

```javascript
var message = "Hello World",
    messageEl = document.createElement( "p" );

messageEl.textContent = message;
out.appendChild( messageEl );
```

[image]  <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>**[`[ run with user script ]`](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/run-stackexchange-code-0.0.user.js)**</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Want to be able to run your code like that? Just add this line following a code block:

```html
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6KuG.gif" width="480" height="1" /><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>**[`  [ run with user script ]  `](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/run-stackexchange-code-0.0.user.js)**</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
```

Your code's wrapped in a function under the global context, only given the `out` element as an argument.

#### Prevent Scroll Bars From Being Hidden on Code Blocks on Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion"

Here's a code block that's probably scrollable in both directions. If you're using a trackpad with Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion", you can install [this user script](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/scroll-stack-code-0.1.user.js) that uses [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855592/1114) to prevent scroll bars from being hidden on code blocks.

```javascript
atest( "TO FAIL | return false", function () { return false; } );
atest( "TO FAIL | do nothing", function () { } );
atest( "TO FAIL | error", function () { throw new Error; } );

atest( "TO FAIL | don't let more than 2 seconds pass", function ( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) {
  var start = new Date;

  return function poll () {
    assert( ((new Date) - start) < 2000, "two seconds must not pass" );
    return poll;
  }
} );

atest( "return true", function () { return true; } );

atest( "Count to 10 Over 1 Second", function ( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) {
  var val = 0,
      incInterval = setInterval( incVal, 100 );

  function incVal () {
    val += 1;
  }

  toCleanUp(function () {
    clearInterval( incInterval );
  })

  return function poll () {
    return ( val > 10 ) ? true : poll;
  };
});

atest( "Load /", function ( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) {
  jQuery.ajax( "/" ).done(function ( data ) {
    pass( "Loaded " + data.length + " chars." );
  });
});

atest( "Adding even integers doesn't produce an odd one", function ( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) {
  for (var n = -10000; n < 10000; n += 2) {
    assert( n % 2 === 0, "" + n + " is not a multiple of two." )
  }
  pass();
});

/*\
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *  
  atest( name, body( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) );                    *
    Declares an test with the specifed name and body. It will be     *
    run synconously with other tests defined syncronously with it.   *
                                                                     *
  runaTest( body( assert, pass, toCleanUp ) );                   *
    Executes a test body and returns a promise of the result.        *
                                                                     *
  A test body can return true to pass, false to fail or a function   *
  to continue to it asyncronously. This happens with a delay, so it  *
  can be used to poll some state.                                    *
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
\*/

runaTest.timeout = 5000;
runaTest.tickDelay = 100;
atest.cooldown = 250;

function atest ( name, body ) {
  if ( !atest.buffer ) {
    atest.buffer = [];
    setTimeout( triggerTests, 0 );
  }

  atest.buffer.push( [ name, body ] );

  function triggerTests () {
    var buffer = atest.buffer,
        i = 0;

    delete atest.buffer;
    triggerNext();

    function triggerNext () {
      if ( i < buffer.length ) {
        var name = buffer[ i ][ 0 ],
            body = buffer[ i ][ 1 ],
            testRun = runaTest( body );

        testRun.then(function passed () {
          $("<p/>").text( [ "pass [" + name + "]" ].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ).join(" - ") ).appendTo(out);
        }, function failed () {
          $("<p/>").text( [ "FAIL [" + name + "]" ].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ).join(" - ") ).css("color", "red").appendTo(out);
        });

        testRun.always(function () {
          setTimeout( triggerNext, atest.cooldown );
        });

        ++i;
      }
    }
  }
}

function runaTest ( body ) {
  var result = new jQuery.Deferred,
      tickInterval = setInterval( tick, runaTest.tickDelay ),
      timeoutTimeout = setTimeout( result.reject, runaTest.timeout, "Timeout" ),
      active = body;

  return result.promise();

  function assert ( condition, msg ) {
    if ( !condition ) {
      var failArgs = [ "Assertion failed" ].concat( [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
      result.reject.apply( result, failArgs ) ;
    }
  }

  function tick () {
    if ( result.state() === "pending" ) {
      if ( typeof active === "function" ) {
        try {
          active = active.call( result, assert, result.resolve, result.always );
        } catch ( ex ) {
          result.reject( "Uncaught exception", ex );
          $("<p/>").text(ex.stack).appendTo(out);
        }
      } else if ( active === true ) {
        result.resolve();
      } else if ( active === false ) {
        result.reject();
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval( tickInterval );
    }
  }
}
```

[image]  <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>**[`[ run with user script ]`](http://scripts.jeremybanks.ca/run-stackexchange-code-0.0.user.js)**</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

#### Tag Markup Castle

[l](/questions/tagged/l)*[hello-and-welcome-to](/questions/tagged/hello-and-welcome-to)*
                                                                             [l](/questions/tagged/l)**[banks--sand--castle+](/questions/tagged/banks--sand--castle%2b)**
                                                                             [l](/questions/tagged/l)
                                                                             [l](/questions/tagged/l)
                                                                             [l](/questions/tagged/l)
                          [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)    
                         [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                  [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
                          [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                 [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                  [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)  
                         [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                  [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                  [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
                         [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                 [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                  [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)  
[llll](/questions/tagged/llll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)        [llll](/questions/tagged/llll) 
[llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) 
[l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
[llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) 
[l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                  [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
[llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                           [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)
[l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                                          [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
[llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                                           [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)
[l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)                                          [l](/questions/tagged/l) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [l](/questions/tagged/l)
[llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)                                           [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll) [llllll](/questions/tagged/llllll)

Comment: Freaking awesome!

Comment: A sandcastle. Very fitting of a sandbox... This should be the canonicle answer. +1!

Comment: mario's castle :)

Comment: This is terribly borked now.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat The bricks melted and it all fell apart. :(

Answer (score 25):

## [*<kbd>kbd is back!</kbd>*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974)

[<kbd>Castle building will resume in 3... 2... 1...</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974)

Comment: [Hola!](http://www.google.com)

Comment: _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________ _________________________________________________

Comment: ^------ Stack of Pancakes! (**Er...** I mean waffles...)

Comment: Yeap, here: [www.phpclasses.org/classes/1042-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer.html](http://www.google.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803602/396458

Comment: ![image](http://www.computerweekly.com/blogs/inspect-a-gadget/Everything%20Everywhere%20logo.jpg)

Answer (score 25):

### Towers of Hanoi

[Text http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/text](http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/text)

[http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?1)
[http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?2)
[http://hanoi.kurtbachtold.com/hanoi.php/3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?3)

[Reset](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb?reset)

Comment: That. Is. Awesome.

Comment: How on earth did you do that?

Comment: @tbodt: It's done with a link to an off-site php script. Click the edit button to see the answer's source.

Comment: `01
 02
 03
 04
 05
 06
 07
 08
 09
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
 16
 17
 18
 19
 20
 21
 22
 23
 24
 25
 26
 27
 28
 29
 30`

Comment: @tbodt: [Is there any game we can use in our profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163845)

Comment: Aw, new HTTPS requirements broke it.

Answer (score 21):

JavaScript art!

```js
!function(){function o(w,v,i){return w.getAttribute(v)||i}function j(i){return document.getElementsByTagName(i)}function l(){var i=j("script"),w=i.length,v=i[w-1];return{l:w,z:o(v,"zIndex",-1),o:o(v,"opacity",1.0),c:o(v,"color","0,0,0"),n:o(v,"count",40)}}function k(){r=u.width=window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth,n=u.height=window.innerHeight||document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight}function b(){e.clearRect(0,0,r,n);var w=[f].concat(t);var x,v,A,B,z,y;t.forEach(function(i){i.x+=i.xa,i.y+=i.ya,i.xa*=i.x>r||i.x<0?-1:1,i.ya*=i.y>n||i.y<0?-1:1,e.fillStyle="rgba("+s.c+","+s.o+")",e.fillRect(i.x-0.5,i.y-0.5,1,1);for(v=0;v<w.length;v++){x=w[v];if(i!==x&&null!==x.x&&null!==x.y){B=i.x-x.x,z=i.y-x.y,y=B*B+z*z;y<x.max&&(x===f&&y>=x.max/2&&(i.x-=0.03*B,i.y-=0.03*z),A=(x.max-y)/x.max,e.beginPath(),e.lineWidth=A/2,e.strokeStyle="rgba("+s.c+","+(A+0.2)+")",e.moveTo(i.x,i.y),e.lineTo(x.x,x.y),e.stroke())}}w.splice(w.indexOf(i),1)}),m(b)}var u=document.createElement("canvas"),s=l(),c="c_n"+s.l,e=u.getContext("2d"),r,n,m=window.requestAnimationFrame||window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame||window.mozRequestAnimationFrame||window.oRequestAnimationFrame||window.msRequestAnimationFrame||function(i){window.setTimeout(i,1000/45)},a=Math.random,f={x:null,y:null,max:20000};u.id=c;u.style.cssText="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:"+s.z+";opacity:"+s.o;j("body")[0].appendChild(u);k(),window.onresize=k;window.onmousemove=function(i){i=i||window.event,f.x=i.clientX,f.y=i.clientY},window.onmouseout=function(){f.x=null,f.y=null};for(var t=[],p=0;s.n>p;p++){var h=a()*r,g=a()*n,q=2*a()-1,d=2*a()-1;t.push({x:h,y:g,xa:q,ya:d,max:6000})}setTimeout(function(){b()},100)}();
```

Comment: Would be nice to see this as a screensaver :)

Comment: Expanding this snippet looks broken

Comment: @chrki It's still working for me.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ sorry for being unclear, the snippet works but the site layout looks a little broken in expanded view, compared to snippets on SO (tested Firefox and Chrome) https://i.imgur.com/OaTEdig.png

Comment: @chrki hmmm, not for me. It works perfectly on my Chrome 69 (Win10, left nav disabled).

Answer (score 20):

Do formulas work? $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{3} = a \cdot b$

Hmm, no sandbox for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: H̡̫̤̤̣͉̤ͭ̓̓̇͗̎̀ơ̯̗̱̘̮͒̄̀̈ͤ̀͡w͓̲͙͖̥͉̹͋ͬ̊ͦ̂̀̚ ͎͉͖̌ͯͅͅd̳̘̿̃̔̏ͣ͂̉̕ŏ̖̙͋ͤ̊͗̓͟͜e͌

Comment: No MathJax here on Meta.

Comment: Test. Only a test. Carry on.

Comment: testing123: [help/dont-ask]

Answer (score 20):

Testing transparent images...

> [image]

Nope, resized images still can't be transparent.

Original is transparent:

> [image]

Trying to trigger Captcha again... oh no luck

http://www.google.com

Comment: YEZ, I AGREE WIF U. INDED THAR IZ NO FILTR

Comment: @Lix wonder why it has no official documentation though - waiting for some mod/dev to prove [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127073/does-the-quality-filter-apply-to-answers)

Comment: I don't think they will explain the filter - otherwise people would know how to circumvent it...

Comment: @Lix not explain just say "it's not activated here on Meta" :)

Comment: @Henning nope, it's just not enabled on Meta. Try post new crappy question and you'll succeed.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I was trying, unsuccessfully, to get hit by the [edit-summary length limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160771/whats-with-the-10-char-min-for-edit-summaries). (My inital summary of "bah" got gobbled up when I undid the edit because I forgot to wait 5 minutes). No I don't know whether that's because it's meta or because it's CW. Apologies for the ping.

Comment: @Henning all good that's what we have the sandbox for... and CW only means the reputation required to edit it is lower, nothing else. :)

Comment: @Sha: But that (the reputation required to edit being lower) might be exactly why I was allowed to edit here with a short summary. It would make some programming sense to control the summary-length minimum by the same condition that decides whether the edit is to be queued for review or applied immediately.

Comment: Testing comment loading indicator... oh it's still there... but not on edit?

Comment: [faq#on-topic].

Comment: [faq#questions]

Comment: <$&#8238; This post is seriously messed up now !

Comment: Going to see if I can edit a comment on deleted post...editing now... yep. Edited while post was deleted.

Comment: @Michael I was trying to edit quickly, this should indeed trigger Captcha.

Comment: 8.000000072900000663390006036849054935326399911470239194379176668850507686539619‌​947510541522345927853347943465466285535743198375263105214894257455537742845393459‌​893080485027032413745994965088554182305843058983171836746863714396459801007784189‌​170836121454608705236939217656146880670936614105523188360261014078375228113214575‌​830252640055299024503221122979312219111741193916844864643288268253923241110701494‌​107383596377190727032435615995164105555993360559539581091810187935472710212801662‌​936495132722105707771161940717573660529920310822274828482700939192578546652464774‌​37429448290607979444

Answer (score 19):

#### Please test your comments below this line

Comment: _ __test__ _ `_ __test__ _`

Comment: ___test___ `___test___`

Comment: __ _test_ __ `__ _test_ __`

Comment: __test _test_ __ `__test _test_ __`

Comment: __test _test_ test__ `__test _test_ test__`

Comment: _test __test__ test_ `_test __test__ test_`

Comment: _`test`_ `_`test`_`

Comment: _ `test` _ `_ \`test\` _` (Here, I needed to backslash escape the backticks to make the source display correctly.)

Comment: <s>test</s> `<s>test</s>`

Comment: <sub>test</sub> `<sub>test</sub>`

Comment: ` \`test\`` ← ` \` \\`test\\` \`` ← `\` \\` \\\`test\\\` \\`\``

Comment: _test _test_ test_ ← `_test _test_ test_`

Comment: `test `` test` ← `\`test \`\` test\``

Comment: _ `test` _ ← `_ \`test\` _`

Comment: _This `test` works_ ← `_This \`test\` works_`

Comment: `backticks don't work?`

Comment: backtick `backtick`

Comment: `**strong backtick**`, **`strong backtick`**

Comment: **`strong first, backticks inside`**

Comment: this post is tagged **`[sandbox]`**

Comment: **[`google`](http://www.google.com)**

Comment: Testing testing 1.. 2.. 3..!

Comment: Looks like I need to make another comment.

Comment: [Google](http://google.com/)

Comment: [link](http://www.google.com)

Comment: html entities: &pi; &gt; &lt;

Comment: [recursion...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: ←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←←

Comment: H‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍i.

Comment: ̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̤̤̤̤̤̤̤̤̤̤f̤̤̤̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥̥f

Comment: Yeṣ̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣̣

Comment: ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Comment: __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________ __________________________________________________________

Comment: ^-------- The first line above is solid. The second one has breaks in it, but you can't see them because they all fit on the line :P

Comment: [Formated link at last?](http://www.nolesvotes.com). **WOW!!!** Yes, I _finally got it_. Check the code format: `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)`. Did it **_WORK_**? Well, kind of...

Comment: &nbsp; wheeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: ~strike~? <s>strike</s>? <del>strike?</del>

Comment: comment edit test. edit 1.

Comment: @TheUnhandledException at line 32: comment edit test 2 failure.

Comment: @badp Y U FAIL COMMENT EDIT?

Comment: All I have to say: ‮‮

Comment: int main() {
    return 0;
}

Comment: ____________________20 Underscores___________________

Comment: ‮...tfel-ot-thgir gnitseT

Comment: ‮o‮ne t‮w‮o ‮‮th‮ree fou‮r five six‮

Comment: Right‮ to ‮ left‮ test ‮??

Comment: -To the left-‮-thgir eht oT-

Comment: -To the left-**<<‮>>**-thgir eht oT-

Comment: **Right to left test #6** ‮____________________________________________________________________________________________________

Comment: `Right to left test #7-- ‮gnitset` _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Comment: _______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________‮

Comment: Testing                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Line Breaks

Comment: Non-breaking-space &nbsp;

Comment: I did it! I did it! ‮

Comment: ________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Comment: comment with a [tag:tag]

Comment: [ ](http://google.com/)

Comment: [♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦](http://google.com)

Comment: [Click here to go nowhere](https://clients1.google.com/generate_204)

Comment: Just testing...

Comment: And testing again...

Comment: And this can't be seen by dynamic updated not-logged-in users who have already clicked on show <n> comments. Err yes they can...

Comment: <s>Strikeout HTML in comment test</s>

Comment: h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶a̶d̶a̶m̶v̶a̶r̶g̶a̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶/̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶v̶i̶a̶ ̶U̶n̶i̶c̶o̶d̶e̶

Comment: \`test\` `\`test\``

Comment: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

Comment: I did it! I did it! ‮ – Mahnax Aug 21 '12 at 20:17

Comment: this is a test ‮[h](http://google.com)

Comment: [This is a markdown link with a tooltip.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57578/203888 "This is a markdown link with a tooltip.")

Comment: I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go over the comment length limit.! I want to go ov

Comment: code `test = ` tag

Comment: Test `[edit]` [shorthand link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting): [edit]

Comment: pew pew  ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: @n00b [O̜̮̪͎͎̬͎̔ͨ̇͋̆b̦͓̙͕̰͎͕̘̰̏͋̓̽͋ͮͤ̈́l͙͈̗̙̩̬̘͙̆ͨͩ̉ͩ̿̍̐̒ḭ̗͑̃ͣ̏̅͐́̚g̫̙̦͙̲̰̖͉̖̈́̎̆̀ͣͨ̈́a͖ͦṱ̠͈̟̀̏̓ͥó̙̤ͭ͊̈́̎͑r̞̭̩͚̺̘͕͙̐͌̀̏̑ͮͯ̚y̲̺͓̪̼̺̲̠̽̓̿̏ͬͧ͌̋̉ ̦̩̘̟̥̲͔ͥ̿̄̾̍̚X̘͉͓ͨ̅ͤ̈̆̒Ḳ̬̊̾ͅC̺ͦ̽͌ͥ͐̒̓̚D͇̳̭̣̫̥̤̩̟̮̣̠̑ͬͨͨͥͫ̃ͯ͂ͭ́̾̾͆](http://xkcd.com/1647/)

Comment: Magic links: `[edit]` [edit]; `[main]` [main]; `[meta]` [meta]; `[help]` [help]; `[meta-help]` [meta-help]; `[help/dont-ask]` [help/dont-ask]; `[help/on-topic]` [help/on-topic]; `[help/behavior]` [help/behavior]; `[tour]` [tour]; `[meta-tour]` [meta-tour]; `[ask]` [ask]; `[answer]` [answer]; `[so]` [so]; `[su]` [su]; `[sf]` [sf]; `[meta.se]` [meta.se]; `[a51]` [a51]; `[se]` [se]; `[something.se]`: `[astronomy.se]` [astronomy.se]; `[math.se]` [math.se]; `[meta.something.se]`: `[meta.astronomy.se]` [meta.astronomy.se]; `[meta.math.se]` [meta.math.se]; `[chat]` [chat]; `[mcve]` [mcve].

Comment: ᵗᵉˢᵗⁱⁿᵍ ʰᵗᵐˡ ˢᵘᵖ

Answer (score 19):

[image][image][image]

↑ having trouble getting rid of the sliver between the images (wrapping them in a `<h1></h1>` helps.)

Comment: Inadvisable, however, as it isn't very semantic.

Comment: ‮Please do not speak of being messed up until you read this!

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: HOW did you do that?

Comment: @Nyu: O the wonders of Unicode!

Comment: No seriously - how do you flip even the time block?

Comment: @Richard: It's a Unicode trick.

Comment: ...okay, right.

Comment: ‮(= !terces eht meht llet t'nod tsuJ

Comment: @JefMercado: Please?

Comment: ‮...yletanutrofnu ,gnitaehc yb ylno tub ,ti tog I

Comment: I can turn the world inside out!  I'll start with the comment stamp...‮

Comment: ‮At last! At long last!  The secret is mine!

Comment: Ha! I am over here :-P ‮this is a test

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: You could fake a lot of interesting things there.

Comment: I Roamed Under It As A Tired Nude Maori  ‮‮    i roaMed uNder iT As A tIred nUde maoRI

Comment: Yay, I figured it out!! Copy the character inside the codeblock to get it it's a mirroring character. Note that the codeblock may have placed itself after my username. `"‮‮ "`

Comment: Hello, I am Jon Skeet. ‮‮ [teekS noJ -](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)

Comment: ‮If you copy and paste this text into notepad it will appear in normal order.

Comment: See this answer if you want to see how to do it http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131803/174964

Comment: Good utility ‮over there

Comment: ‮‮This is a test

Comment: This is a comment‮dilav sa deggalf neeb sah tnemmoc sihT ‭

Comment: test ‮backwards :-O

Comment: How do you put text in front of the signature?

Comment: ‮‮Can I test it? ‮‮(

Comment: ‮Ben Collins hohoho

Comment: How do you put text after your username?

Comment: ‮spahrep siht htiw ‭I wonder‮

Answer (score 19):

> test

## going 1 `#going 1`

### going 2 `##going 2`

#### going 3 `###going 3`

gone 4 `####gone 4`

gone 5 `gone 5`

su<sup>p</sup>erscript, su<sub>b</sub>script

> More testing
>
> > And More testing
> >
> > > Even More `testing`

I saw somewhere *I think* on this site, the ability to format text so that it looks kind of like keys, for showing key combinations. The notation was something like this:

```
<key>ctrl</key> + <key>C</key>
```

Then the *Ctrl* and the *C* had borders that made them look like little keys.
Does this site have that kind of thing?
Anyone? Bueller?

It's

```
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
```

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

---

Comment: The tag is <kbd>, but apparently it has no styling in Meta

Comment: Because of Pesto's castle, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1974

Comment: lol, that was pretty funny/interesting. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 18):

<sup><sup>This is a foo bar!</sup></sup> test

<sup>sup</sup>
<sup><sup>supsup</sup></sup>
<sup><sup><sup>supsupsup</sup></sup></sup>

### How to add a sizable image:

1. Upload an image as normal.

   - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, select an image, click `OK`.
   - The image will insert, perhaps like `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` and, at the bottom, `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3MU.png`.
2. Delete all the crap except for the image URL.
3. Place the url in a `img` tag like this:
   `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3MU.png" width="100">`

---

- This inserts the image with a width of 100px, like this:
  [image]
- Posts are 640px wide.
- You can add images inline too: [image]
- You can add a tooltip with `title="My tooltip"` (hover over this: [image] ) To add a linefeed within the tooltip use `&#13;`.
- Avoid using the `height` tag since it messes with the Mobile view.
- The `"` quotes are required here even though they aren't required around numbers in *real HTML*.
- Also unlike *real HTML* these tags need to be in the exact order. One mistake or missing quote and the image won't display at all.
- You *can* use both `width` and `height` (in that order) if you want to intentionally change the aspect ratio:  [image]

---

### How to add a *clickable* sizable image:

1. Upload an image as normal.

   - Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, select an image, click `OK`.
   - The image will insert, perhaps like `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` and, at the bottom, `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3MU.png`.
2. Just delete the inner inline image part: `![enter image description here][1]`
3. Replace that deleted inline image with the url placed in a `img` tag like this:
   `[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3MU.png" width="150" alt="cute doggie pic">][1]`

---

- This inserts the clickable image with a width of 150px, like this:
  [image: cute doggie pic]
- Tooltips can be added the standard Markdown way: `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj3MU.png "Click for larger image."`

---

Happy Cod[image]ng!
Happy Cod[image: i]ng!
Happy Coding! [image: paw]

<sup><sup><sup>*(Shhhhh, you didn't see anything!)*</sup></sup></sup>

.

> ### <sub><sub>. . . . Reload page to change captcha's: . . . .</sub></sub>
>
> . . [image] 
>   [image] 
>   [image] . . .

```html
<html><body><frameset cols="17%,33%,50%"><img src="https://www.myid.ca/captcha.php"><img src="https://www.the-art-of-web.com/captcha_old.php"><img src="https://www.the-art-of-web.com/captcha_old3.php"></frameset><br><frameset cols="17%,33%,50%"><img src="//www.myid.ca/captcha.php"><img src="//www.the-art-of-web.com/captcha_old.php"><img src="//www.the-art-of-web.com/captcha_old3.php"></frameset></body></html>
```

### [Jump to Top of Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/314139#top)

Comment: Magic Links: **`[help]`: [help] , `[help/on-topic]`: [help/on-topic] , `[help/dont-ask]`: [help/dont-ask] , `[help/behavior]`: [help/behavior], `[meta-help]`: [meta-help], `[meta]`: [meta], `[main]`: [main], `[edit]`: [edit] , `[tour]`: [tour], `[ask]`: [ask], `[answer]`: [answer], `[so]`: [so], `[su]`: [su], `[sf]`: [sf], `[metase]`: [metase], `[a51]`: [a51], `[se]`: [se], `[chat]`: [chat]**

Comment: I am forever having this.... thanks for the resource.

Comment: @QHarr added more info.

Comment: @QHarr "for the today" eh...  well that's good, whatever that means...

Comment: It was used already once today. ;-) (When ever today was..)

Comment: @ashleedawg FYI, I've updated the post.

Comment: @robinCTS ah, that's an obvious way to demonstrate, that I hadn't thought of!  Also note that combinations of `<sup>` and `<sub>` in different orders have varying (something strange) effects. My now-[archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296077) (I think) post has a bunch of examples.

Comment: Comment to see if there are any winter bash hats for editing comments after posting

Comment: error: not a pony

Comment: mygodwhat have you done to that doggo

Comment: Blah,                                                                                   
Blah,                                                                                   
Blah.

Comment: @ashleedawg How? I cannot make newline in comments. Let's try again...  
Newline here.  
Maybe I do sth wrong? After line i do two spaces and then I press Shift+Enter to go to new line without accepting comment yet.

Answer (score 17):

Tag Presentation  [mytag](/questions/tagged/mytag)

Testing Unicode:  ▛▙▟▜▐▀▄▌▘▛▙▟▜ ▄█▀

```
  _____ _             _     ____                  __ _               
 / ____| |           | |   / __ \                / _| |              
| (___ | |_ __ _  ___| | _| |  | |_   _____ _ __| |_| | _____      __
 \___ \| __/ _` |/ __| |/ / |  | \ \ / / _ \ '__|  _| |/ _ \ \ /\ / /
 ____) | || (_| | (__|   <| |__| |\ V /  __/ |  | | | | (_) \ V  V / 
|_____/ \__\__,_|\___|_|\_\\____/  \_/ \___|_|  |_| |_|\___/ \_/\_/
```

> This blockquote is linked to google. oh no...

Comment: nice :-) Sandbox testing

Comment: ▛▙▟▜▐▀▄▌▘▛▙▟▜ ▄█▀  radp taught me how to do this :-)

Comment: This is **Bold** , this is _italic_

Comment: (To avoid syntax highlighting, use `<pre>` rather than 4 spaces.)

Comment: I tried but didn't work as expected. It didn't keep the formatting. Thanks Arjan :-)

Comment: Ah, you need to encode HTML elements manually then. I replaced one `<` with `&lt;` to fix that.

Comment: That's `figlet` if I ever saw it.

Comment: Meta: [meta] Main: [main] Metaso: [metase]

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Comment: Haha, no way! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40925/do-not-ask-for-confirmation-on-logout/40934#40934

Comment: [​](http://www.google.ca/)

Comment: ` `  ` `  ` `   &nbsp;

Comment: [.](http://www.google.com)

Comment: [`](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Test 1. Test 1.

Comment: Test 2! Test 2 do

Comment: @HoLyVieR How do you do that?

Comment: [tour] [help] [answer]

Answer (score 16):

Testing:

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [beginners-guide](/questions/tagged/beginners-guide)

**Hmmm.  The tags do not properly show in the edit preview.  Still OK in the posted version?**

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Comment: ) ouch my eyesss..

Comment: They are fine on the edit preview now.

Comment: <kbd>test</kbd>

Answer (score 16):

This is another 01/02/34 test altogether

Here is my url

```
https://fb.me
```

whatever.

And this is a test.

And this is an invisible

in the text

Example:

1. This is the first paragraph.

   This is the second paragraph.

   ```html
   <p>
       <span>This is the snippet.</span>
   </p>
   ```

   This is the third paragraph.

   This is the fourth paragraph.

Is it possible to put all the above content, ncluding the last two paragraphs, inside the list item?

By the way, did you know you can make lots of colors with the editor.

Black

[Blue](http://stackoverflow.com)

> Yellow background

```
 Gray background
```

```C#
 Cyan On Gray
```

```xml
 <Dark-Red Light-Red>
```

Oh, and how about this. [] [] []
["�","�"]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJ0_qtBYgMM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cO86Oral5hc

Comment: [image](http://www.computerweekly.com/blogs/inspect-a-gadget/Everything%20Everywhere%20logo.jpg)

Comment: [Page 1 of 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675](htt‌​p://directory.io/)

Comment: Don't mind me! I'm <s>unsuccessfully</s> testing things.

Comment: ["�","�"] for real?

Comment: No, no repro either.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It was a test WRT [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35223206/1016716). Didn't work too well, though. I could click _Save Edits_!

Comment: I know. I was just trying the same. I already noticed your edit here before.

Comment: Testing, never mind me. `SELECT * FROM html WHERE url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613551/combine-result-of-multiple-xpath-in-yql-queries' AND xpath='//*[@id="question-header"]/*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@itemprop), " "), " name ")]/descendant-or-self::*//text()'`

Answer (score 15):

## <sup>M<sub>e</sub></sup><sub>s<sup>s</sup></sub><sup><sub>e</sub>d</sup> up

---

Hellooo<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o<sup>o</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>!

---

<sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>This is the smallest text you will ever see... there is no way you are reading this unless you viewed the page source or edited my answer or something. This is tiny! Impossibly tiny! Yay! I still haven't filled up a single line with all this text :/ I STILL haven't! Wow! Okay now I filled up a line finally. I will just keep typing okay I don't know what to say.</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup>

---

<sup><sub>[a-very-small-tag](/questions/tagged/a-very-small-tag)</sub></sup>

---

*T*`h`**is** i*s* `s`*om**e*** v**e*r***`y` [od](/questions/tagged/od)<kbd>d</kbd>   <sup>[f](/questions/tagged/f)<kbd>o</kbd></sup><sub>[r](/questions/tagged/r)<kbd>m</kbd></sub><sup>at</sup>ti<sub>ng.</sub>

---

O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>O<sup>OO</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O</sup>O

Comment: Nice mOoOstache

Comment: To infinity and beyond!

Comment: [ask] | [edit] | [post] | [answer] | [comment] | [privilege] | [help] | [snippet]

Comment: `Array(100).fill\`abc\`.join\`|\``

Comment: Page can be scaled :D

Comment: Well, this is a *test*™

Comment: Well, this is a *test*tm

Comment: Well, this is a *test* ™

Comment: Well, this is a *test*t

Answer (score 15):

Warning: you must have your cookies allowed; coz the message you enter currently is stored in the cookies. Click "Post message" to send it to the server!

---

[image]

---

[<kbd>1</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=1)[<kbd>2</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=2)[<kbd>3</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=3)[<kbd>4</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=4)[<kbd>5</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=5)[<kbd>6</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=6)[<kbd>7</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=7)[<kbd>8</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=8)[<kbd>9</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=9)[<kbd>0</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=0)[<kbd>-</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=-)[<kbd>+</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=%2B)[<kbd>del</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=bsp)
 [<kbd>Q</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=q)[<kbd>W</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=w)[<kbd>E</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=e)[<kbd>R</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=r)[<kbd>T</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=t)[<kbd>Y</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=y)[<kbd>U</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=u)[<kbd>I</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=i)[<kbd>O</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=o)[<kbd>P</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=p)[<kbd>[</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=[)[<kbd>]</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=])[<kbd>\</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=%5C)
  [<kbd>A</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=a)[<kbd>S</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=s)[<kbd>D</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=d)[<kbd>F</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=f)[<kbd>G</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=g)[<kbd>H</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=h)[<kbd>J</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=j)[<kbd>K</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=k)[<kbd>L</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=l)[<kbd>;</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=;)[<kbd>:</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=:)[<kbd>"</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=")
    [<kbd>Z</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=z)[<kbd>X</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=x)[<kbd>C</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=c)[<kbd>V</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=v)[<kbd>B</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=b)[<kbd>N</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=n)[<kbd>M</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=m)[<kbd>,</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=,)[<kbd>.</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=.)[<kbd>/</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=%2F)[<kbd>?</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=?)[<kbd>!</kbd>](http://justachat.freevar.com/imgw.php?letter=!)

**[Post message](http://justachat.freevar.com/post.php)**

---

*(The messages are appended to the end of the chat, the keyboard is at the top just for "typing" convenience)*

---

[image]

---

Comment: Cool!......... that must have taken some effort! :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Hey, it works, do you see it? :D Stores the text in your cookies and displays as image :)

Comment: dem edit conflicts!

Comment: @bjb Great, thank you! Maybe store server-side, how do you think?

Comment: @bjb Are you working? < and > ? Or I shall do it myself?

Comment: I don't know how shiftkey stuff would work. I'm done for now. Server-side sound good, you could even have it group-editable!

Comment: @bjb Thank you very much :) Going to make a chat of it. As of the shift key,  I'll care about it.

Comment: haha, I used to have this on my profile page for a while - just my own work, not third party tool. Wait, unless this is yours? :-D

Comment: @Sha It's completely mine! :) I've got a free server, written the codes , and you see the result there :)

Comment: cool then @nic, well done! Next game: let users change your avatar by voting. (i.e. put three to choose from, clicking enough times by enough users on one of them will cause auto change)

Comment: Anyway, I was hosted on somee which is 10000% crap, gave up on them after a while. What's your host? Does it support ASP.NET as well? (PHP not for me)

Comment: @Sha http://www.freewebhostingarea.com, dunno if supports asp.net, because don't use it and don't know :D

Comment: Only PHP... oh well, thanks!

Comment: @Sha Wait, avatar? And how is it supposed to work, giving that any image I upload would be hosted on imgur? :( Also, I love my current avatar pretty much :D

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with a POST request.

Comment: @bjb Hey, look! A real chat now :)

Comment: @Sha you can take a look also, I've implemented pushing messages to the server.

Comment: Why not make the image an SVG?

Comment: @bjb I'll try to implement it, great idea!

Comment: WUT IS THIS? Virus?

Comment: @Uni No, a chat :D Self-made chat.

Comment: @nicael Check this out! http://justahack.freevar.com/

Comment: @bjb Made it SVG a year later :D

Comment: @muru The problem was the non-https links. Why have you removed them at all, can't you see that you've screwed the chat, i.e. just removed it entirely? Thanks for reminding me though :D

Answer (score 13):

<kbd><kbd>`</kbd>          <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>

<kbd>Tab</kbd>        <kbd>'</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>=</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>                  

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>              

<kbd>Shift</kbd>           <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 12):

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I'm trying to write multiple spaces. As spaces: `x y  z`. As nbsp: `x y&nbsp;&nbsp;z`. As U+00A0: `x y  z`.

Comment: @Lix - How is it possible? I couldn't find it. :(

Comment: @him - search for the zero width unicode space character

Comment: @Lix - Thanks. [Finally I could write it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?page=2&tab=votes#comment-476297). Got reference [from here](http://superuser.com/q/389087/135529).

Comment: [zero width on a mac](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FzfFo.png) - took some time to find, so I'm short-circuiting the hint

Answer (score 11):

Waffles, waffles, you can edit/delete these things by manually changing the post to /posts/postid/edit

Comment: Congrats for finding a bug

Comment: It messes up your post (but not others) on the desktop site, too. https://i.snag.gy/LyQvmd.jpg And oh man the flagging dialog is toast.

Comment: Did a quick fix. If you're a dev investigating this , Rollback to see the horror

Answer (score 10):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Hi</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

> > > > > > Hi

Look! ↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>↗<sup>Hi this is tiny text and I don't know if you can see this if you can you must have zoomed in or edited my post and saw the markdown or something like that. Pie is good, by the way.</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

http://keyboardfire.com/test.svg

Comment: Your text was too large. This has been fixed.

Comment: In fact, still too large - takes 3-4 px on my 96 DPI screen. With subpixel rendering it's quite readable.

Comment: `" a  b   c    d"` <-a code block with consecutive spaces

Answer (score 10):

Image sizing tests, using Stack Exchange's image host.

Original image on SE's host (`https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLbK3.jpg`) (1920 x 1440):
[image: unsized]

Resize, **Preserving aspect ratio**:

T suffix (`...t.jpg`) (160 x 120):
[image: tiny]

M suffix (`...m.jpg`) (320 x 240):
[image: medium]

L suffix (`...l.jpg`) (640 x 480):
[image: large]

H suffix (`...h.jpg`) (1024 x 768):
[image: huge?]

---

Resize, cropping to **Square aspect ratio**:

S suffix (`...s.jpg`) (90 x 90):
[image: small square]

B suffix (`...b.jpg`) (160 x 160):
[image: big square]

S parameter (`...jpg?s=300`) (300 x 300):
[image: large]
**Valid parameters for s** seem to be:
    16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 300, 500, 512, and 900.

Other values result in the maximum/default resolution.

---

**Custom HTML**:

`<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLbK3l.jpg" width="400">`:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

[w3c explanation of readystate](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#states)

## [very-important-tag](/questions/tagged/very-important-tag)

[status-do-they-validate-tags](/questions/tagged/status-do-they-validate-tags)

[tag:`Oops`] `[tag:Oops]`

[tag:*Test*] *[oops](/questions/tagged/oops)*

[tag:****] **[whoops](/questions/tagged/whoops)** **[whoops](/questions/tagged/whoops)**

[tag:[im-inur-tag](/questions/tagged/im-inur-tag)]

[regular-tag](/questions/tagged/regular-tag)
<sub><sub>[very-short-tag](/questions/tagged/very-short-tag)</sub></sub>

Comment: `<com.davidstuff.gridthing
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    davidstuff:numsquaresX="8"
    />`

Comment: @Shoe testinggg

Comment: `\`` test `\`\`\`` yay `\`test\``

Comment: `# errors`  
`x = Nori.parse(IO.read('filename.txt')`  
`#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `parse' for Nori:Class`

Comment: ``C:\\`` does this work

Answer (score 9):

o
<sup>o</sup>

    <sub><sup>o</sup>
    
        <sub><sup>o</sup>
        
            <sub><sup>o</sup>
            
                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                
                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                    
                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                        
                            <sub><sup>o</sup>
                            
                                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                
                                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                    
                                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                    
                                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                
                                <sup>o</sup></sub>
                            
                            <sup>o</sup></sub>
                        
                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                    
                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                
                <sup>o</sup></sub>
            
            <sup>o</sup></sub>
        
        <sup>o</sup></sub>
    
    <sup>o</sup></sub>

<sup>o</sup>
o
<sup>o</sup>

    <sub><sup>o</sup>
    
        <sub><sup>o</sup>
        
            <sub><sup>o</sup>
            
                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                
                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                    
                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                        
                            <sub><sup>o</sup>
                            
                                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                
                                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                    
                                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                    
                                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                
                                <sup>o</sup></sub>
                            
                            <sup>o</sup></sub>
                        
                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                    
                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                
                <sup>o</sup></sub>
            
            <sup>o</sup></sub>
        
        <sup>o</sup></sub>
    
    <sup>o</sup></sub>

<sup>o</sup>
o
<sup>o</sup>

    <sub><sup>o</sup>
    
        <sub><sup>o</sup>
        
            <sub><sup>o</sup>
            
                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                
                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                    
                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                        
                            <sub><sup>o</sup>
                            
                                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                
                                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                    
                                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                    
                                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                
                                <sup>o</sup></sub>
                            
                            <sup>o</sup></sub>
                        
                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                    
                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                
                <sup>o</sup></sub>
            
            <sup>o</sup></sub>
        
        <sup>o</sup></sub>
    
    <sup>o</sup></sub>

<sup>o</sup>
o
<sup>o</sup>

    <sub><sup>o</sup>
    
        <sub><sup>o</sup>
        
            <sub><sup>o</sup>
            
                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                
                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                    
                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                        
                            <sub><sup>o</sup>
                            
                                <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                
                                    <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                    
                                        <sub><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                    
                                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                                
                                <sup>o</sup></sub>
                            
                            <sup>o</sup></sub>
                        
                        <sup>o</sup></sub>
                    
                    <sup>o</sup></sub>
                
                <sup>o</sup></sub>
            
            <sup>o</sup></sub>
        
        <sup>o</sup></sub>
    
    <sup>o</sup></sub>

<sup>o</sup>
o

o
<sub>o</sub>

    <sup><sub>o</sub>
    
        <sup><sub>o</sub>
        
            <sup><sub>o</sub>
            
                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                
                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                    
                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                        
                            <sup><sub>o</sub>
                            
                                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                
                                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                    
                                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                    
                                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                
                                <sub>o</sub></sup>
                            
                            <sub>o</sub></sup>
                        
                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                    
                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                
                <sub>o</sub></sup>
            
            <sub>o</sub></sup>
        
        <sub>o</sub></sup>
    
    <sub>o</sub></sup>

<sub>o</sub>
o
<sub>o</sub>

    <sup><sub>o</sub>
    
        <sup><sub>o</sub>
        
            <sup><sub>o</sub>
            
                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                
                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                    
                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                        
                            <sup><sub>o</sub>
                            
                                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                
                                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                    
                                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                    
                                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                
                                <sub>o</sub></sup>
                            
                            <sub>o</sub></sup>
                        
                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                    
                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                
                <sub>o</sub></sup>
            
            <sub>o</sub></sup>
        
        <sub>o</sub></sup>
    
    <sub>o</sub></sup>

<sub>o</sub>
o
<sub>o</sub>

    <sup><sub>o</sub>
    
        <sup><sub>o</sub>
        
            <sup><sub>o</sub>
            
                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                
                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                    
                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                        
                            <sup><sub>o</sub>
                            
                                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                
                                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                    
                                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                    
                                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                
                                <sub>o</sub></sup>
                            
                            <sub>o</sub></sup>
                        
                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                    
                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                
                <sub>o</sub></sup>
            
            <sub>o</sub></sup>
        
        <sub>o</sub></sup>
    
    <sub>o</sub></sup>

<sub>o</sub>
o
<sub>o</sub>

    <sup><sub>o</sub>
    
        <sup><sub>o</sub>
        
            <sup><sub>o</sub>
            
                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                
                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                    
                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                        
                            <sup><sub>o</sub>
                            
                                <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                
                                    <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                    
                                        <sup><sub>o</sub>
                                        <sup>o</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>
                                    
                                
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    


    
        
            
                
                    
                        
                            
                                
                                    
                                        <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>o</sup>
                                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                    
                                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                                
                                <sub>o</sub></sup>
                            
                            <sub>o</sub></sup>
                        
                        <sub>o</sub></sup>
                    
                    <sub>o</sub></sup>
                
                <sub>o</sub></sup>
            
            <sub>o</sub></sup>
        
        <sub>o</sub></sup>
    
    <sub>o</sub></sup>

<sub>o</sub>
o

Comment: Hahaha... IE8 quakes at the sight of this... any other browsers have trouble with the helix of doom?

Answer (score 9):

Testing emoji icons for the new Swift programming language:

http://www.globalnerdy.com/2014/06/03/swift-fun-fact-1-you-can-use-emoji-characters-in-variable-constant-function-and-class-names/

### Emoticons ( 1F601 - 1F64F )

```
     Unicode    Bytes (UTF-8)    Description
    U+1F601    \xF0\x9F\x98\x81    grinning face with smiling eyes
    U+1F602    \xF0\x9F\x98\x82    face with tears of joy
    U+1F603    \xF0\x9F\x98\x83    smiling face with open mouth
    U+1F604    \xF0\x9F\x98\x84    smiling face with open mouth and smiling eyes
    U+1F605    \xF0\x9F\x98\x85    smiling face with open mouth and cold sweat
    U+1F606    \xF0\x9F\x98\x86    smiling face with open mouth and tightly-closed eyes
    U+1F609    \xF0\x9F\x98\x89    winking face
    U+1F60A    \xF0\x9F\x98\x8A    smiling face with smiling eyes
    U+1F60B    \xF0\x9F\x98\x8B    face savouring delicious food
    U+1F60C    \xF0\x9F\x98\x8C    relieved face
    U+1F60D    \xF0\x9F\x98\x8D    smiling face with heart-shaped eyes
    U+1F60F    \xF0\x9F\x98\x8F    smirking face
    U+1F612    \xF0\x9F\x98\x92    unamused face
    U+1F613    \xF0\x9F\x98\x93    face with cold sweat
    U+1F614    \xF0\x9F\x98\x94    pensive face
    U+1F616    \xF0\x9F\x98\x96    confounded face
    U+1F618    \xF0\x9F\x98\x98    face throwing a kiss
    U+1F61A    \xF0\x9F\x98\x9A    kissing face with closed eyes
    U+1F61C    \xF0\x9F\x98\x9C    face with stuck-out tongue and winking eye
    U+1F61D    \xF0\x9F\x98\x9D    face with stuck-out tongue and tightly-closed eyes
    U+1F61E    \xF0\x9F\x98\x9E    disappointed face
    U+1F620    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA0    angry face
    U+1F621    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA1    pouting face
    U+1F622    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA2    crying face
    U+1F623    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA3    persevering face
    U+1F624    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA4    face with look of triumph
    U+1F625    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA5    disappointed but relieved face
    U+1F628    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA8    fearful face
    U+1F629    \xF0\x9F\x98\xA9    weary face
    U+1F62A    \xF0\x9F\x98\xAA    sleepy face
    U+1F62B    \xF0\x9F\x98\xAB    tired face
    U+1F62D    \xF0\x9F\x98\xAD    loudly crying face
    U+1F630    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB0    face with open mouth and cold sweat
    U+1F631    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB1    face screaming in fear
    U+1F632    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB2    astonished face
    U+1F633    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB3    flushed face
    U+1F635    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB5    dizzy face
    U+1F637    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB7    face with medical mask
    U+1F638    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB8    grinning cat face with smiling eyes
    U+1F639    \xF0\x9F\x98\xB9    cat face with tears of joy
    U+1F63A    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBA    smiling cat face with open mouth
    U+1F63B    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBB    smiling cat face with heart-shaped eyes
    U+1F63C    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBC    cat face with wry smile
    U+1F63D    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBD    kissing cat face with closed eyes
    U+1F63E    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBE    pouting cat face
    U+1F63F    \xF0\x9F\x98\xBF    crying cat face
    U+1F640    \xF0\x9F\x99\x80    weary cat face
    U+1F645    \xF0\x9F\x99\x85    face with no good gesture
    U+1F646    \xF0\x9F\x99\x86    face with ok gesture
    U+1F647    \xF0\x9F\x99\x87    person bowing deeply
    U+1F648    \xF0\x9F\x99\x88    see-no-evil monkey
    U+1F649    \xF0\x9F\x99\x89    hear-no-evil monkey
    U+1F64A    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8A    speak-no-evil monkey
    U+1F64B    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8B    happy person raising one hand
    U+1F64C    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8C    person raising both hands in celebration
    U+1F64D    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8D    person frowning
    U+1F64E    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8E    person with pouting face
    U+1F64F    \xF0\x9F\x99\x8F    person with folded hands
```

### Dingbats ( 2702 - 27B0 )

```
     Unicode    Bytes (UTF-8)    Description
✂    U+2702    \xE2\x9C\x82    black scissors
✅    U+2705    \xE2\x9C\x85    white heavy check mark
✈    U+2708    \xE2\x9C\x88    airplane
✉    U+2709    \xE2\x9C\x89    envelope
✊    U+270A    \xE2\x9C\x8A    raised fist
✋    U+270B    \xE2\x9C\x8B    raised hand
✌    U+270C    \xE2\x9C\x8C    victory hand
✏    U+270F    \xE2\x9C\x8F    pencil
✒    U+2712    \xE2\x9C\x92    black nib
✔    U+2714    \xE2\x9C\x94    heavy check mark
✖    U+2716    \xE2\x9C\x96    heavy multiplication x
✨    U+2728    \xE2\x9C\xA8    sparkles
✳    U+2733    \xE2\x9C\xB3    eight spoked asterisk
✴    U+2734    \xE2\x9C\xB4    eight pointed black star
❄    U+2744    \xE2\x9D\x84    snowflake
❇    U+2747    \xE2\x9D\x87    sparkle
❌    U+274C    \xE2\x9D\x8C    cross mark
❎    U+274E    \xE2\x9D\x8E    negative squared cross mark
❓    U+2753    \xE2\x9D\x93    black question mark ornament
❔    U+2754    \xE2\x9D\x94    white question mark ornament
❕    U+2755    \xE2\x9D\x95    white exclamation mark ornament
❗    U+2757    \xE2\x9D\x97    heavy exclamation mark symbol
❤    U+2764    \xE2\x9D\xA4    heavy black heart
➕    U+2795    \xE2\x9E\x95    heavy plus sign
➖    U+2796    \xE2\x9E\x96    heavy minus sign
➗    U+2797    \xE2\x9E\x97    heavy division sign
➡    U+27A1    \xE2\x9E\xA1    black rightwards arrow
➰    U+27B0    \xE2\x9E\xB0    curly loop
```

### Transport and map symbols ( 1F680 - 1F6C0 )

```
     Unicode    Bytes (UTF-8)    Description
    U+1F680    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x80    rocket
    U+1F683    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x83    railway car
    U+1F684    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x84    high-speed train
    U+1F685    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x85    high-speed train with bullet nose
    U+1F687    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x87    metro
    U+1F689    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x89    station
    U+1F68C    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x8C    bus
    U+1F68F    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x8F    bus stop
    U+1F691    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x91    ambulance
    U+1F692    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x92    fire engine
    U+1F693    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x93    police car
    U+1F695    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x95    taxi
    U+1F697    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x97    automobile
    U+1F699    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x99    recreational vehicle
    U+1F69A    \xF0\x9F\x9A\x9A    delivery truck
    U+1F6A2    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA2    ship
    U+1F6A4    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA4    speedboat
    U+1F6A5    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA5    horizontal traffic light
    U+1F6A7    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA7    construction sign
    U+1F6A8    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA8    police cars revolving light
    U+1F6A9    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xA9    triangular flag on post
    U+1F6AA    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xAA    door
    U+1F6AB    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xAB    no entry sign
    U+1F6AC    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xAC    smoking symbol
    U+1F6AD    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xAD    no smoking symbol
    U+1F6B2    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xB2    bicycle
    U+1F6B6    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xB6    pedestrian
    U+1F6B9    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xB9    mens symbol
    U+1F6BA    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xBA    womens symbol
    U+1F6BB    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xBB    restroom
    U+1F6BC    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xBC    baby symbol
    U+1F6BD    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xBD    toilet
    U+1F6BE    \xF0\x9F\x9A\xBE    water closet
    U+1F6C0    \xF0\x9F\x9B\x80    bath
```

### Enclosed characters ( 24C2 - 1F251 )

```
     Unicode    Bytes (UTF-8)    Description
Ⓜ    U+24C2    \xE2\x93\x82    circled latin capital letter m
    U+1F170    \xF0\x9F\x85\xB0    negative squared latin capital letter a
    U+1F171    \xF0\x9F\x85\xB1    negative squared latin capital letter b
    U+1F17E    \xF0\x9F\x85\xBE    negative squared latin capital letter o
    U+1F17F    \xF0\x9F\x85\xBF    negative squared latin capital letter p
    U+1F18E    \xF0\x9F\x86\x8E    negative squared ab
    U+1F191    \xF0\x9F\x86\x91    squared cl
    U+1F192    \xF0\x9F\x86\x92    squared cool
    U+1F193    \xF0\x9F\x86\x93    squared free
    U+1F194    \xF0\x9F\x86\x94    squared id
    U+1F195    \xF0\x9F\x86\x95    squared new
    U+1F196    \xF0\x9F\x86\x96    squared ng
    U+1F197    \xF0\x9F\x86\x97    squared ok
    U+1F198    \xF0\x9F\x86\x98    squared sos
    U+1F199    \xF0\x9F\x86\x99    squared up with exclamation mark
    U+1F19A    \xF0\x9F\x86\x9A    squared vs
    U+1F1E9 U+1F1EA    \xF0\x9F\x87\xA9\xF0\x9F\x87\xAA    regional indicator symbol letter d + regional indicator symbol letter e
    U+1F1EC U+1F1E7    \xF0\x9F\x87\xAC\xF0\x9F\x87\xA7    regional indicator symbol letter g + regional indicator symbol letter b
    U+1F1E8 U+1F1F3    \xF0\x9F\x87\xA8\xF0\x9F\x87\xB3    regional indicator symbol letter c + regional indicator symbol letter n
    U+1F1EF U+1F1F5    \xF0\x9F\x87\xAF\xF0\x9F\x87\xB5    regional indicator symbol letter j + regional indicator symbol letter p
    U+1F1F0 U+1F1F7    \xF0\x9F\x87\xB0\xF0\x9F\x87\xB7    regional indicator symbol letter k + regional indicator symbol letter r
    U+1F1EB U+1F1F7    \xF0\x9F\x87\xAB\xF0\x9F\x87\xB7    regional indicator symbol letter f + regional indicator symbol letter r
    U+1F1EA U+1F1F8    \xF0\x9F\x87\xAA\xF0\x9F\x87\xB8    regional indicator symbol letter e + regional indicator symbol letter s
    U+1F1EE U+1F1F9    \xF0\x9F\x87\xAE\xF0\x9F\x87\xB9    regional indicator symbol letter i + regional indicator symbol letter t
    U+1F1FA U+1F1F8    \xF0\x9F\x87\xBA\xF0\x9F\x87\xB8    regional indicator symbol letter u + regional indicator symbol letter s
    U+1F1F7 U+1F1FA    \xF0\x9F\x87\xB7\xF0\x9F\x87\xBA    regional indicator symbol letter r + regional indicator symbol letter u
    U+1F201    \xF0\x9F\x88\x81    squared katakana koko
    U+1F202    \xF0\x9F\x88\x82    squared katakana sa
    U+1F21A    \xF0\x9F\x88\x9A    squared cjk unified ideograph-7121
    U+1F22F    \xF0\x9F\x88\xAF    squared cjk unified ideograph-6307
    U+1F232    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB2    squared cjk unified ideograph-7981
    U+1F233    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB3    squared cjk unified ideograph-7a7a
    U+1F234    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB4    squared cjk unified ideograph-5408
    U+1F235    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB5    squared cjk unified ideograph-6e80
    U+1F236    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB6    squared cjk unified ideograph-6709
    U+1F237    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB7    squared cjk unified ideograph-6708
    U+1F238    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB8    squared cjk unified ideograph-7533
    U+1F239    \xF0\x9F\x88\xB9    squared cjk unified ideograph-5272
    U+1F23A    \xF0\x9F\x88\xBA    squared cjk unified ideograph-55b6
    U+1F250    \xF0\x9F\x89\x90    circled ideograph advantage
    U+1F251    \xF0\x9F\x89\x91    circled ideograph accept
```

Answer (score 9):

### Delete this post if it's obnoxious

<sub>Apparently there's major debate over whether `XOR` is pronounces like [this](https://more-en.howtopronounce.com/xor-in-more-voice-8628651z8628651-x01.mp3) or [this](https://en-audio.howtopronounce.com/xor-in-us1-voice-8628651z8628651-x010501.mp3)...</sub>

<kbd>...or else I'll come play some more another day... 

I'm curious about making a **clickable 
map-type-thing**   with a bunch of little tiled images,
if I can get them to line up properly.</kbd>

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[Crash Your Browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248600/393735)</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

### Testing lining up tiled image patterns

> [image][image]
>   [image][image]

They edges seem to meet horizontally but not vertically, because of the line spacing I suppose.

[image][image][image]  15px
[image][image][image]

...but using the <sub>`<sub>`</sub> tag reduces the gap slightly:

<sub>[image][image][image]  12px

[image][image][image]</sub>

`<sup>`</sup>

`<sub>`</sub> tag combo increases it slightly:   
<sup><sub>![][1]![][2]![][1]  9.6px  
![][2]![][1]![][2]</sub></sup>  
<sup><sub>![][3]![][4]![][3]  9.6px  
![][4]![][3]![][4]</sub></sup>-->



<sub><sub><sub><sub>`<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>`</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub> tag combo squishes it slightly:   
<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>![][1]![][2]![][1]   7.93333px   
![][2]![][1]![][2]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>  
<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>![][3]![][4]![][3]   7.93333px   
![][4]![][3]![][4]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>-->

...but then it gets weird.

- [image]
  [image] (Normal)

1=

<sub>[image]
[image]</sub>

30=

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]
[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

[image: img]

Zorro?

<kbd><sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

<sub>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]<sup>[image]</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub>

<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image]<sub>[image][image][image][image][image]</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></kbd></sub></sub></sub></sub>

  Apparently the large & small boxes are the same line spacing but it sure don't look that way to me.

I don't understand what's going on there, but that's definitely not what I came here for... **back to work.**
LOL ^^

this is a line


this is another line

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Wow I wonder who made that incredible animation with all those tiny blue circles.

Comment: Is that a rube goldburg machine?

Comment: @jraspiprojects - something like that.  It's actually 4 tiles of the same image (I was testing to see how well different sizes of images line up in posts)...   [*The Blue Ball Machine is one of the most frequently-viewed pages on all of YTMND. The site is a patchwork of animated GIFs linked together accompanied by a looping hook of the song Breakfast Machine from the film Pee-wee's Big Adventure. Each image has three balls enter and leave at particular spots at any frame which is a multiple of 30, but otherwise the content is up to the creator.*](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~squire/blueball.htm)

Comment: @jraspiprojects

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: Clearly a narwhal.

Comment: testing the [help/on-topic]

Comment: It's a what?...

Comment: test comment please ignor

Answer (score 8):

> <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>**stack**</kbd>o</kbd>v</kbd>e</kbd>r</kbd>f</kbd>l</kbd>o</kbd>w</kbd></kbd>

Comment: You may like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148662/187824) :)

Comment: @hims056 nice ;]

Answer (score 8):

π = 3<sup>.<sup>1<sup>4<sup>1<sup>5<sup>9<sup>2<sup>6<sup>5<sup>3<sup>5</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: That's not true though.

Answer (score 8):

## I am probably invading someones else answer lalala


Not anymore, was funny while it lasted but I want to comment on my post.

Does normal math work here on meta? $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. No, pittyingly not.

> Hi
>  >! Hello
>  >! World
>  Peeps

---

I'm walking in a hallway...

---

Comment: You can use this method to add a tag to an answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199258/show-a-dropdown-of-tags-that-have-been-placed-into-text

Comment: Lol now it's [messing up the revisions page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/197804/revisions)!!

Comment: `\\ ` <-- attempting to get backticked (<code>) double-backslash.  That did it, albeit with an annoying trailing space: backtick, backslash, backslash, space, backtick.

Comment: Just testing simple `code`

Comment: Testing `multi-line

code`

Comment: Testing ` multi-line

code ` with more text after.

Comment: I haven't played with anyone's code, but AFAICT noone mentioned the possibility of the equivalent of `for(x = 0; x < IMAGESIZE; x++)
{
     dest[x].Red = orig[x].Red;
} for(x = 0; x < IMAGESIZE; x++)
{
     dest[x].Green = orig[x].Green;
} for(x = 0; x < IMAGESIZE; x++)
{
     dest[x].Blue = orig[x].Blue;
}`. In this case, do the simpler loops overtake the bit twiddling?

Answer (score 7):

<sub>(Draft of a potential template for election THC digests. I tried different ways of saying who posted the answer: A bare name, a name linked to the nomination page, a name linked to their profile, a flair image, and a link to the transcript entry of that person's answer to the question. I think a name linked to that user's individual nomination would be best, but there's no anchor for it on the nomination page. There would be one meta post for the THC, with one answer for each question from chat. The names should probably be sorted consistently from answer to answer (alphabetically, or some other way that hopefully minimizes favoritism), so it's easy to read all the answers from a given user. I made a little ∎ at the end of each post that links to the chat transcript (except for the one where the display name itself links there); not sure if that's the best way or not, but some sort of link back is probably a good idea)</sub>

---

### How much time will you be able to spend moderating?

#### [image] Josh K

I have 137 consecutive days on P.SE. So I have enough time. [∎](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/453613#453613)

#### [image] [Mark Trapp](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination)

I currently spend about an hour or so a day checking and following up on flags, or answering on meta. I don't see that changing. [∎](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/453621#453621)

#### [image] [ChrisF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf)

Too much ;) Seriously - I spend most lunch times on the network and a varying amount in the evenings and weekends so I get to see most of what goes on. [∎](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/453625#453625)

#### Anna Lear

I'm here every day, multiple times a day. I'm also generally pretty responsible with my commitments, so I'll be visiting the site more consciously, since with mod powers it becomes a responsibility instead of just this thing I check sometimes. [∎](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/453641#453641)

#### [image] [Renesis](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/453821#453821)

I check the site often throughout waking hours in the US, and that will continue to be the case. I'm not sure how "much" time that will total, but during those hours I should be able to keep on top of most the activity coming in.

Comment: [faq] [faq#vote-differences]

Answer (score 7):

30,000 characters exactly............... adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Sed hendrerit. Morbi ac felis. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi. Nunc nulla. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in, sapien. Donec venenatis vulputate lorem. Morbi nec metus. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat feugiat, eros pede varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. In auctor lobortis lacus. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Fusce fermentum. Nullam cursus lacinia erat. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Quisque id mi. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Vestibulum dapibus nunc ac augue. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce a quam. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Curabitur nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Nam ipsum risus, rutrum vitae, vestibulum eu, molestie vel, lacus. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Mauris sollicitudin fermentum libero. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. Vestibulum rutrum, mi nec elementum vehicula, eros quam gravida nisl, id fringilla neque ante vel mi. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Fusce vel dui. Sed in libero ut nibh placerat accumsan. Proin faucibus arcu quis ante. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Nulla sit amet est. Praesent metus tellus, elementum eu, semper a, adipiscing nec, purus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Suspendisse feugiat. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Nulla neque dolor, sagittis eget, iaculis quis, molestie non, velit. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Quisque ut nisi. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut leo. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Proin pretium, leo ac pellentesque mollis, felis nunc ultrices eros, sed gravida augue augue mollis justo. Suspendisse eu ligula. Nulla facilisi. Donec id justo. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Praesent vestibulum dapibus nibh. Etiam iaculis nunc ac metus. Ut id nisl quis enim dignissim sagittis. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros. Proin magna. Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit. Curabitur turpis. Vestibulum suscipit nulla quis orci. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Duis lobortis massa imperdiet quam. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque commodo eros a enim. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam vitae tortor. Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Aliquam eu nunc. Nunc sed turpis. Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nulla porta dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Sed a libero. Cras varius. Donec vitae orci sed dolor rutrum auctor. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Aliquam lobortis. Donec orci lectus, aliquam ut, faucibus non, euismod id, nulla. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Nam adipiscing. Vestibulum eu odio. Vivamus laoreet. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Phasellus tempus. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Fusce neque. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Fusce fermentum odio nec arcu. Vivamus euismod mauris. In ut quam vitae odio lacinia tincidunt. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Cras sagittis. Praesent ac sem eget est egestas volutpat. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Cras non dolor. Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. Nam commodo suscipit quam. Quisque id odio. Praesent venenatis metus at tortor pulvinar varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Sed hendrerit. Morbi ac felis. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi. Nunc nulla. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in, sapien. Donec venenatis vulputate lorem. Morbi nec metus. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat feugiat, eros pede varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. In auctor lobortis lacus. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Fusce fermentum. Nullam cursus lacinia erat. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Quisque id mi. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Vestibulum dapibus nunc ac augue. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce a quam. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Curabitur nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Nam ipsum risus, rutrum vitae, vestibulum eu, molestie vel, lacus. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Mauris sollicitudin fermentum libero. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. Vestibulum rutrum, mi nec elementum vehicula, eros quam gravida nisl, id fringilla neque ante vel mi. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Fusce vel dui. Sed in libero ut nibh placerat accumsan. Proin faucibus arcu quis ante. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Nulla sit amet est. Praesent metus tellus, elementum eu, semper a, adipiscing nec, purus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Suspendisse feugiat. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Nulla neque dolor, sagittis eget, iaculis quis, molestie non, velit. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Quisque ut nisi. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut leo. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Proin pretium, leo ac pellentesque mollis, felis nunc ultrices eros, sed gravida augue augue mollis justo. Suspendisse eu ligula. Nulla facilisi. Donec id justo. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Praesent vestibulum dapibus nibh. Etiam iaculis nunc ac metus. Ut id nisl quis enim dignissim sagittis. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros. Proin magna. Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit. Curabitur turpis. Vestibulum suscipit nulla quis orci. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Duis lobortis massa imperdiet quam. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque commodo eros a enim. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam vitae tortor. Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Aliquam eu nunc. Nunc sed turpis. Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nulla porta dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Sed a libero. Cras varius. Donec vitae orci sed dolor rutrum auctor. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Aliquam lobortis. Donec orci lectus, aliquam ut, faucibus non, euismod id, nulla. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Nam adipiscing. Vestibulum eu odio. Vivamus laoreet. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Phasellus tempus. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Fusce neque. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Fusce fermentum odio nec arcu. Vivamus euismod mauris. In ut quam vitae odio lacinia tincidunt. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Cras sagittis. Praesent ac sem eget est egestas volutpat. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Cras non dolor. Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. Nam commodo suscipit quam. Quisque id odio. Praesent venenatis metus at tortor pulvinar varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In dui magna, posuere eget, vestibulum et, tempor auctor, justo. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium. Pellentesque auctor neque nec urna. Proin sapien ipsum, porta a, auctor quis, euismod ut, mi. Aenean viverra rhoncus pede. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut non enim eleifend felis pretium feugiat. Vivamus quis mi. Phasellus a est. Phasellus magna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur at lacus ac velit ornare lobortis. Curabitur a felis in nunc fringilla tristique. Morbi mattis ullamcorper velit. Phasellus gravida semper nisi. Nullam vel sem. Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Sed hendrerit. Morbi ac felis. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede. Donec interdum, metus et hendrerit aliquet, dolor diam sagittis ligula, eget egestas libero turpis vel mi. Nunc nulla. Fusce risus nisl, viverra et, tempor et, pretium in, sapien. Donec venenatis vulputate lorem. Morbi nec metus. Phasellus blandit leo ut odio. Maecenas ullamcorper, dui et placerat feugiat, eros pede varius nisi, condimentum viverra felis nunc et lorem. Sed magna purus, fermentum eu, tincidunt eu, varius ut, felis. In auctor lobortis lacus. Quisque libero metus, condimentum nec, tempor a, commodo mollis, magna. Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula. Fusce fermentum. Nullam cursus lacinia erat. Praesent blandit laoreet nibh. Fusce convallis metus id felis luctus adipiscing. Pellentesque egestas, neque sit amet convallis pulvinar, justo nulla eleifend augue, ac auctor orci leo non est. Quisque id mi. Ut tincidunt tincidunt erat. Etiam feugiat lorem non metus. Vestibulum dapibus nunc ac augue. Curabitur vestibulum aliquam leo. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce a quam. Etiam ut purus mattis mauris sodales aliquam. Curabitur nisi. Quisque malesuada placerat nisl. Nam ipsum risus, rutrum vitae, vestibulum eu, molestie vel, lacus. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Vestibulum facilisis, purus nec pulvinar iaculis, ligula mi congue nunc, vitae euismod ligula urna in dolor. Mauris sollicitudin fermentum libero. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. Vestibulum rutrum, mi nec elementum vehicula, eros quam gravida nisl, id fringilla neque ante vel mi. Morbi mollis tellus ac sapien. Phasellus volutpat, metus eget egestas mollis, lacus lacus blandit dui, id egestas quam mauris ut lacus. Fusce vel dui. Sed in libero ut nibh placerat accumsan. Proin faucibus arcu quis ante. In consectetuer turpis ut velit. Nulla sit amet est. Praesent metus tellus, elementum eu, semper a, adipiscing nec, purus. Cras risus ipsum, faucibus ut, ullamcorper id, varius ac, leo. Suspendisse feugiat. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Praesent nec nisl a purus blandit viverra. Praesent ac massa at ligula laoreet iaculis. Nulla neque dolor, sagittis eget, iaculis quis, molestie non, velit. Mauris turpis nunc, blandit et, volutpat molestie, porta ut, ligula. Fusce pharetra convallis urna. Quisque ut nisi. Donec mi odio, faucibus at, scelerisque quis, convallis in, nisi. Suspendisse non nisl sit amet velit hendrerit rutrum. Ut leo. Ut a nisl id ante tempus hendrerit. Proin pretium, leo ac pellentesque mollis, felis nunc ultrices eros, sed gravida augue augue mollis justo. Suspendisse eu ligula. Nulla facilisi. Donec id justo. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Curabitur suscipit suscipit tellus. Praesent vestibulum dapibus nibh. Etiam iaculis nunc ac metus. Ut id nisl quis enim dignissim sagittis. Etiam sollicitudin, ipsum eu pulvinar rutrum, tellus ipsum laoreet sapien, quis venenatis ante odio sit amet eros. Proin magna. Duis vel nibh at velit scelerisque suscipit. Curabitur turpis. Vestibulum suscipit nulla quis orci. Fusce ac felis sit amet ligula pharetra condimentum. Maecenas egestas arcu quis ligula mattis placerat. Duis lobortis massa imperdiet quam. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque commodo eros a enim. Vestibulum turpis sem, aliquet eget, lobortis pellentesque, rutrum eu, nisl. Sed libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam vitae tortor. Morbi vestibulum volutpat enim. Aliquam eu nunc. Nunc sed turpis. Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nulla porta dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Praesent egestas tristique nibh. Sed a libero. Cras varius. Donec vitae orci sed dolor rutrum auctor. Fusce egestas elit eget lorem. Suspendisse nisl elit, rhoncus eget, elementum ac, condimentum eget, diam. Nam at tortor in tellus interdum sagittis. Aliquam lobortis. Donec orci lectus, aliquam ut, faucibus non, euismod id, nulla. Curabitur blandit mollis lacus. Nam adipiscing. Vestibulum eu odio. Vivamus laoreet. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Phasellus tempus. Proin viverra, ligula sit amet ultrices semper, ligula arcu tristique sapien, a accumsan nisi mauris ac eros. Fusce neque. Suspendisse faucibus, nunc et pellentesque egestas, lacus ante convallis tellus, vitae iaculis lacus elit id tortor. Vivamus aliquet elit ac nisl. Fusce fermentum odio nec arcu. Vivamus euismod mauris. In ut quam vitae odio lacinia tincidunt. Praesent ut ligula non mi varius sagittis. Cras sagittis. Praesent ac sem eget est egestas volutpat. Vivamus consectetuer hendrerit lacus. Cras non dolor. Vivamus in erat ut urna cursus vestibulum. Fusce commodo aliquam arcu. Nam commodo suscipit quam. Quisque id odio. Praesent venenatis metus at tortor pulvinar varius. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Int

Comment: So you need here a comment with 600 characters, of course. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no se

Comment: So what's the maximum length of a comment thread? Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequ

Answer (score 7):

[test link](http://asdf.com)

> hidden stuff (spoiler)

---

---

---

---

---

---

Find the text!

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > wut

darn div id portallink does not work

♥▼♥

I am an image link? No

---

I am an image link?
[image]
YES

[image: Clickable as well]

Comment: idk i'm just testing it, the main thing was probably the image link, i was trying to make a clickable image. I'm not too familiar with Markdown.

Comment: @hob - allow me to demonstrate... I prefer using the `<img>` syntax because then I can give a width parameter... Both of the images should be clickable.

Answer (score 7):

Are the mods asleep so I can post ponies? (I know, these are unicorns, but still)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: **No, they're not asleep. You will get suspended!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: **Don't post ponies! You should totally drop that and use jQuery.**

Answer (score 7):

This<sub>is<sub>a<sub>test</sub></sub></sub>

The<sub>real<sub>question<sub>is<sub>how<sub>far<sub>I<sub>can<sub>go<sub>before<sub>this<sub>becomes<sub>INSANE</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>
What<sup>about<sup>applying<sup>the<sup>same<sup>system<sup>to<sup>superscript?<sup>Nothing<sup>like<sup>a<sup>bit<sup>of<sup>markupbreaking</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>I don't even know where the <sub>line<sub>is<sub>after<sub>this<sub>many<sub>subs<sub>:D</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

```js
document.write("M\u0335\u0333\u0319\u0354\u031F\u0331\u0355\u0313\u0300\u0304\u0309\u0305\u0367\u030B\u034A\u034C\u0351\u0301\u034C\u036A\u0312\u033F\u0300\u031Aa\u0354\u031F\u031D\u0354\u0365\u0308\u0301\u030F\u036E\u036F\u0307\u0346\u030A\u0312\u0366\u0366\u0358\u0362\u035Cy\u0335\u0334\u0322\u0355\u031D\u0329\u0331\u0348\u0355\u033C\u0323\u0355\u031F\u030C\u0357\u033E\u0364\u030E\u034C\u0304\u0363\u0368\u034A\u036Cb\u0321\u032F\u0330\u032A\u031C\u0359\u031F\u031D\u0320\u035A\u031C\u0325\u0319\u0324\u0303\u0368\u030B\u0312\u0312\u030A\u0367\u0364\u0350\u0313\u034B\u030C\u033E\u0307\u0314\u0308\u0301\u0300\u0301\u0361\u0360e\u0335\u036F\u036A\u033F\u033F\u0302\u0304\u036B\u0303\u0489\u034F\u034E\u0323\u0339\u0331\u031C\u0349\u0326\u031E\u032A\u0318\u0320\u031D\u031D\u034D\u033C\u031C\u0316\u0325\u032D\u035F \u0323\u031E\u0359\u035A\u031D\u0330\u031E\u0339\u0317\u0332\u0323\u0359\u034D\u034D\u0300\u0313\u034A\u0302\u030B\u0363\u030F\u0311\u030D\u030A\u034C\u0369\u0350\u030E\u0300\u0363\u0363\u031A\u035F\u0345h\u031B\u034B\u030F\u030D\u0306\u0364\u035B\u0350\u0368\u030C\u030B\u0364\u030E\u0302\u0368\u0302\u0313\u0311\u031A\u0315\u035F\u034F\u033B\u0323\u0356\u0316\u035A\u035A\u0353\u0332\u033C\u032A\u0201\u0314\u0305\u033F\u0350\u0311\u0361\u034F\u031D\u0353\u032E\u035A\u0318\u0326\u0330\u035A\u034E\u0354\u0349\u035A\u032E\u0320\u0315\u035C\u0345\u1E71\u0331\u033C\u0316\u0313\u0302\u036D\u030F\u0305\u0342\u0365\u034C\u036F\u034C\u0360s\u036A\u0313\u036A\u0304\u030C\u0313\u0367\u034B\u0350\u036C\u0305\u0311\u0489\u0328\u032A\u032C\u034E\u034D\u0325\u032C?\u0321\u032E\u0333\u0359\u0353\u0354\u0339\u0318\u0339\u0353\u0318\u033B\u0326\u0323\u034E\u032B\u0310\u0364\u0310\u035B\u0301\u035D \u0327\u0326\u033C\u0318\u0355\u032A\u0320\u0319\u0356\u0326\u032F\u0326\u0318\u0349\u0348\u0355\u0354\u0318\u033B\u0332\u0351\u0368\u030A\u0308\u0301\u0310\u036B\u0350\u030C\u036F\u0300\u0358\u035D\u1E28\u0337\u0338\u0338\u0339\u0349\u0329\u031C\u0339\u031E\u036F\u0303\u0303\u0367\u036C\u0368\u030C\u0300\u033E\u0310\u0308\u0307\u0367\u035B\u0303\u0350\u0300\u0366\u035EA\u0334\u0326\u0317\u032C\u0320\u0359\u032D\u0349\u031F\u033A\u0347\u032D\u0330\u0354\u0355\u032F\u0305\u0303\u034B\u036A\u0308\u0301\u0309\u0313\u030C\u036F\u0308\u0301\u0346\u030B\u0300\u0364\u0307\u0302\u033F\u0308\u0301\u0302\u0361\u0361\u1E70\u0332\u034E\u0349\u0323\u0333\u033A\u0331\u031C\u0326\u032C\u0355\u0323\u0349\u0347\u034A\u030C\u0365\u0350\u0352\u0308\u0301\u0313\u0301\u0365\u0301\u0301\u030B\u0342\u0305\u036C\u0306\u0357\u0365\u0315\u0362\u0361S\u030D\u0367\u0357\u0312\u0357\u0302\u0308\u036C\u034A\u031A\u031A\u0362\u034F\u0317\u0323\u0333\u0345!\u0336\u0328\u0321\u0347\u035A\u0319\u035A\u032D\u0331\u0323\u0332\u0333\u0324\u031E\u032B\u0317\u0323\u0326\u032E\u0316\u031E\u0352\u0346\u033F\u0304\u0351\u0303\u030E\u0361 ");
```

On a semi-related note:

Ḯ̴̾ͥ͊ͤͭ͏̴̖̥̮͇͎͓̰̬̗̗͙̙̠͠ͅ ̸̞̣̼̹̦͍ͮͣ͆ͫ͊ͦ̈́̂͞rͪ̇̇ͣ̋̈̊ͭ̿͂͛̏͆͞҉̴̬̫̯̦̞̼̥̥̫̰̭̣͔͓̱́ͅe̻͙̳͙̯̥̟̳ͧ̋̈́ͨ̑̓̅͑̋ͦ͋̈͂̉͊̀͡ḁ̛̻͇͇͉̫͓̜͓̟͎͖̫͚ͬ̅ͧ͌̔͐ͦͣ̀l̵̴̢̦͙͖͇̩̰̟͑ͫͩ̂͂ͅļ̵͉̬̲͇̞̣͇͉̙̮̘̯͉̹̖̯̦̩̝̄̃̇́̅͡y̋̊͛̈̎͂̇̚̚͏̨̡̧̤͇̺̺͎̜̦̩ ̨̧̛͙̞̬̣̝̮̼̞̗̯̤͕̙͉̦̅̏ͯͭ͐͊ͦ̌̓̈́̋̐̽̎̔̚̚ͅḑ̡͓̖̮̻̮̻̥̺̯͖̤̣̜͍͎̰͓ͮ̆ͪͤ͊͋͒͆ͪ̂̈́͠oͯ̿̓̂͐ͣͬ̈́ͩͯ͋̍̾̃͋̊͊͏̸͎̮̬͇̖̠̱̞͟ͅṉ̡͓͚̫̈͒̆͊̚͢'̡̨̎̋͆͌̽͗̃͑ͬ̿̏͌҉̗̫̻̥̠̭̤̟͍̲̼͚͔̝̪̣̦̤̮t̴̛̬̥̤̭͇̒̈́͂̿ͤ ̨͒̂̊̈ͬ̎̍̉ͥ̏̚҉̜͍̳̯͍̘̫̖͔͓̻͚̮̼̤͞k̨͔̜͙̠̞̗̞̔̾͐͛̍̊́ͬ̃͗ͭ̽͛͞ņ̶̹͎͚̦̙͊̈̉ͤ̽͢͟͞ö̢͇̺̼̩̮͔̹́̓ͧ͗ͮ͌̊͌̿̽͛̀̚͠w̾͒ͦ̈́ͬͦ̌̅̈̃͘͞͏̢͉̺͈̪͈͚͈͓͍͍̠̰̪͡ ̴̛̱͚̟̯͖͉̫̞̗̖͈̼͕̘̣̄ͨͬͣ̊ͯ̈̓̈́̊͐̋̓͑ͤ̓̀͠w̸̧͓̠̯̭͇͖̣̯̫̱̻̙ͤ͛̆̈́͑͂̉̾ͦͬ̄ͨ͒͗̈̒͊͜͜h̴̶͈͖̗͙̿̆̀ͭ͘͜y̸̱̟̗͈̮ͬ̊ͮͫ̅ͦͭͩͧ͞ ̴̖̤̰̝̟̭̖͚͖̖͓́̽͊̏ͥ͗͛̏ͫ͞͠I̸̛̲̱̘̮̯̻̱̩̩̘͈͗̾̈̍ͧ̂̓̅̚͘ͅ ̶̠̤̼̭̣̠̩͔̖̼̙͖̥̗̻͙̝̺̃̂͒̊̐̃ͥͨͣ̚͝s̲̰̬̗͇͔͈̻̳͖̰͈͓̭̻̥̭̰̘͗͌̇̊̀͡͞p̵̆͂ͯͯ̔̓̎͆̽͏̺̲̝̫̹͚̟̦̝͉̼̻̱ḝ̶̧̜̩͖̝̗͎̭͈͍͔͙͇̼̦̝̯ͫ̀͗̄ͪ͐ͭ̇͆͒͟͠ǹ̴̸̵̡̻͎̠̘̦̜͉̜̱̗͎̤̺͈̜̲̐̃ͤ͗̍̏ͥ̄ͭ̇͂ͫͪ̃ͫ͝ͅd̢̻̲̩̳̤̜͕͈̯͚̖̟͖͈̞̖̗̗͐ͭͥ͌̂̈̓̾̃̈́̀̕ ̶̵̶̧̢̣̲̰̟͍̜̺͍̘̬̞͍̣̈̋̊ͣ̏ͧ̏ͣ̃͌ͥͭ̅m̸̡̢̗̙͔̝͚͓̯̤̼͚̗̱̳͐̏̐̄̇ͩ͒͐ͦ̚̕͡y͛̿͒͗ͬ͆̐̆̉͂ͣ͆͏̷̣͍͎̱̜͔̘̲̗̦̝̜ ̛̙̜̬̳̻̩̪͖̿͑̄̄̾ͦͯ̇̊̃t̵̗̹̣̼̱͈͚̤̥ͤ͂̍ͯ͆͋̐ͯ̓̏͌̂ͬ̔͟͞͠͝i͊͐͌ͦ̎͐̓͒̒́͞͞҉̴̰̬̼͍͇̺͇̪̝̰ͅͅm̶͚̱̳͉͎̯͙̱̥̜͕̹̥͂͂͂ͪ̌͗ͫ̏̓͛͒̾̊̐̄ͨ͗̐́́͘͞ͅę̸̹͕̹̖͇͖̟̰̲͙̠̦̬ͦͥ̑ͦͯ̒͋͐ͩ͑ͪ̽̒̍̀ͮͬ́̚̚͟ͅ ̡̢̙̼͈̤̻̩̻̦̫̝̭̭̗͎̫͑ͦͯ̓͋͗̈̌̚͜͞ȍ̸̸ͨͦ͑̐̍̄̊̏͗͊ͧ͋ͤ̊̾ͪͦ̀҉̛̪̮̩̯͇̼͙̤n̴̩̘̤͍͎̼̟̂ͮͦ͌ͮ̍̿́͋̇̊͟͝ ̅ͪ͐̔̏̅̚҉̧̻̖̯͇̬̩͈͍̝͝t̷̢̙̣̮̺̙̤̞͚̟͔͓͙̿̃̌̉̊͐͐̓̍͋̑́͟͞ͅh̢̋͑̿ͭ̀̇ͯ͗ͥ͛͋̋̇̑ͭͤͦͨ̀̚͢҉͉̹̻͍͇i͚̩̬̤̼͎͍͇͙͙͇͎ͭ̉͂ͯͩ̽̾ͯ̃ͧͦ̄ͤ͂͜͝s̞̳̳͓̤̮ͣͫ̄̍̔̀́͠ ̊͊ͯͮ̒̿̆͏̴̢̱̩̲͉̞͕̮̻͖̫͙͈͟ͅ:̵̘̦̝͔̜̮̗̣̜̺ͥ̇͋̊̇ͭͧ̒͐̆ͅD̬̭͖̜̬͑ͯ̔͗͒̈́ͥ̽̄̅̏ͤ̐ͬ̈̿͠͝

But then again, it's worth mention`ing` that ev̥̊ͥ͛̑̌̇er̳̱͕̲̟̽͊̌̈͆y̼̱̥͒̆͗ s͋̈̒ͩ̌̈́ȋͮn̎̒ͬģͥ̇l̛ e̲͍͓͆̊ͬ͘ ̸̾̈́͋̓́̃̉͝ͅl̲͍̓͑̃͒ͯ̔ͩ͆́͢͡iͦ͒͆̉ͯ̾͊̉́҉̥̘͝`̛̰͈̫͎͎̘̞̩̓̃̀ͭ͑ͦ̒̓ͅn͔̤̫̥̥̼̠̭͖̔̇̔̈́͆ͣ̀e̛͙̰̲̙ͦ̒͗͢`̢̦͚̒ͨ̑̎̌͑͑̑͡ ̷̨̪̠͚͔̠̟̏ͦc̹͍̞̠̄ͬ͗̓ͮͅ*͖͎̼͈̗̜͖ͨ̅̍ͯ̂̒*̛̱̑͂̌ͪͭ̽ͫ͝o̵̵͔̦͎̲͑͂̆͊͜u̖̪͙͐ͨ͒̐ͦ*̛̲̠͈͍͋̿̀̇̎ͤ̿̓*̴̗̻̗ͭ̂͛̉̄̌ͤn͎͔̞͍͂̀t͂̊ͬ̅͘ͅ*̶̹̺̤͒̓͘s̢̗̔̔*̼̲͚͚̰̀ͫ̉̇͋͊ ̸̭̬͕͎̮̌̒ͥ̂̿̀͝ã̹̊ͧ̔ͮͦ̒͠s̞͖̮̱̹̘̥͆̊ͦ̑́ ̨̲̪͚ͮ̋͌̆ͧ̾ͩ̇ͅW̶͚̤͎̻̻͆́͞E̡̹͇̗̱̱ͩ͒͠͡L̞̙̀̏ͨ̑͊ͦ͑ͣ͜`̑̔̌ͮ́̄̈͏͈̪͍ĺ̵̨̯̟̦̣̰͋̊͋̋͗̕`̧̟͓̮͓̻̘̙̯̼̌̍̄

T̸͈̯̦̝̩̳͈̊̑͐ͫ̂͡h̸̺͙͔̠̣̪ͤ̅́̆̊̕͟ó̬̺̙ͤ́̊̚͜͞u̞͖̤̞̱̺͓ͧ͛͋͋͑ĝ̶̟̹̞͇̭̒̊̕ͅḥ̵̢̩͕͓͙̂ͣ̒ͧͥ<sub>T̆͡͏̤̹̰͢H͓̣̻̘͈͎͙͔ͧ̄ͧ͆͘I̫͍̮̤̬̙͇̩̹͐̑͡S̞ͥ<sub>c̴̫͕̬͎̜͒̋ͦͣ̃̍̄̂̀o̳̞̦͉̬͍̲͋̄ű̲͖̳̗̰̺̗̦ͤ͑͂ͬ͐́ͅl͗̾ͭ҉̤̯͘d̶̷̺̬̄͒̈̆̋͡<sub>b̸̶̰͓̹̙̳̃̿ͫ̎͒ͩ̏e͔͈̱͚̥ͦͤͦ̌<sub>i̵̗͇͚̱̙̪͆̈͛̎͂͡ṅ̡͌͛̄ͬ̍̅̚͏͕̙͙͇ͅt̻̣͕͓̀͗͑̒e̞̖͍̼̣͉̬̙̱ͥ̃̕͞r̡̬̗̗̦͈̪͎̙̤̓ͥͦ̊̏̿͂ͨe͈̳͎ͩ̕͠ṣ̡̟͔̖ͫ̅̕ţ̪̟̠͉̮̻̳̇͂̔͛ͣͯi̷̞̪͓̺͎ͣͦͬ̇̔̏̐n̶̫̤̰̻̘̯̓̾̉̓̌̕g̸̿͠҉̯̤̯̗̼̼̭ͅ</sub></sub></sub></sub>

<strike>Never mind</strike>

Underline

**Broken little markup line**

More broken text, mkay

Ị̵̢̧̢̡̡̢̛̮̹̘͔͍̺͖̥̩̖̮͎̟̩͉̱͙̲̹̣̺̺̙͖͙͖̥̱̦̟͚͍̯̞͚̬̗̠̹̱̱̙͔̻̱͚̝͙̇͌̃͂́̅̏͌̅̎͗̉̀́̆͒̓̾͊͋̄̎̐͒̽͆̃́̈́͋̀̽́̐̇̉̉͐̏̈́͂̉̽͛̕͘̕̕͘͘̕̕͜͝͝͠͝ͅͅ ̸̢̧̡̨̡̛̼͇̰̦̠̼͙͖̲̬͔̣̩͎͇̥̻̖͉̘̱̲̟͇̺͈̳̮̟̥̮̲͇̣̻̺̦̻̣̲̳̞͎̭̱̺̪̲͕̦̂̅̀̏̀̂͑͆̈̄̓̈͐̓̀̋́̊̎̐͆̑̀̀̓̈́̀̈́́̏̓̄͊̇͌̏̿͗̇͗̓̐̇͆̿́̐̔͘͘͘̕̚͘͘͜͜͝͠ͅD̴̨̡̛̠̻̝͔͇͈̮͔̮͉̪̦͔̲̺͓̻̘̖͙̙̝͈̻̞̹̦̰̥̱͈̘͍̼͖̟̙̱̲͉̘̮͖̺͔̠͔͕̘̞̠͈̼̰͐̑͐̓̑̓̃̀̍͐̉̓̍̃͐̊̀̌͐͊̋́́̓͗̋̈́̃̇͑̂͊̉̾̎̓́͒̃̈́̿̔̋̈́̋́̾̒͗̌̕͘̕͜͝͝͝͝ͅỜ̶̧̨̧̢̘̼̯͉̬̗̤̟̱̫̬͓͔̖͚̱̯͎̤̬͔̪͈̞̘̜̲̥͇̘͍͓̭̙̬̺̲̯͕̙̯̙̫̺̰̲̬̗̼͈̱̂̈́̉̈́̃̐́̽̓̆͌̊́̍̍͌̅̾́̏͊̀͋͌̾̈͒̑́́̈́͗͒̉͊̂̊̆͋̾́̇̎̈̿͐̅̆͊̚̕͜͜͠͠͠͝͠ͅṈ̴̡̨̨̡̡̡̢̛̛̰͕̖͕͚̺̜̮̗̲̼͍͍͎̗̲̯͔̗͎̙̺͚̳̞̰̻̗̺̬̮͔͇͉̖̝͎̦͕͙̪̭̳̗̟̝̯̊̇̆̊̌̊̈́͑̄̓̔̐̆͋̿̾̓̾̊̈̑͌̃̒͐̊͊̈́͂̉̀̉̐̎̃̓͂̿̌̆̌̈͋́̈́͊̃̀̀͗̚̕̚͜͜͠͠͝ͅ*̷̨̧̧̡̨̨̢̛͔̻̹̻̜̭̜̭̫͎̱͚̯̦͕͉̰̣̮̠̼͚̙̯̬͓̼͇̯̼͙͖͔͈̯͓͕͇̯̹͓͎͚͎̭͍̗̫͒̇̓̈́̀͛̀͆̃̔̆̈̂̋̍͋͊́͋̓̈͂͆͂̃̽͒͗͌̄̉͗̅̿̒̌̒́̔̈́̄̏̓̈́̓̄͘̚̚͘̚͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅṪ̸̡̧̢̨̢̧̛̛̯̮̻͙̘̲̻͚̞͇̥̜̫̰̣̦̱̬̟̪̣̖̦̪̩̞̰̗͕̠̣͔̱͕͉͈̩͎̝̙̦͎͚̬͎̫͍̹̪̅͛́̈́͗́̽̆́̄̃̓̽̔̈̌̋̅͋̂̃̑̏̋̀͑́̂̋͐̇̅͑̂̒̃̑̀̄͋̌̈́͋́̿̚͘͘̚̚̚͜͝͠͝͠ͅͅ ̷̢̨̡̨̛̖̺̲̘̭̰̬̩͖̪̱̬͖̬̯̫̭̠͖̼̠͔̞̘͓̦̳̹̹̟̟͍̤̩͉͚͇̻̙̳̠̯̙̥̯̰̫͓͈̙̖̲̆̇͗̑̂͆̌̀̔͆̈́̏̄̈́̉͊͋̃͋́̿̒͑̍̓̋̋̐̍̆̍͒̂͑̐̈́͂̍̉͂̀͗͑̎̃͑͐͘͘͘͘̚͝͝͝͝ͅͅK̶̡̡̢̩͓̖͔̠̦͓̯͈͔̫͎͕̝̦̼͙̥͉̱̯͈͉͖͚͔̰͙͚̥̝̩̳̮̟͍͇̪͉̪͚̺̙͔̲͓̟̥̠̲̻̖̅̄̀͆͐̎̈́̉̐̊͊̿̓̑́̌̈́͐͐̆̈̂͊̆̉͒̂̔͒̅̉̈́̈̆͛͆̾͛̔́͊̽̓̈́͗̍̔̂̍̅͘̚̕͜͜͠͠͝͠͝ͅN̶̢̡̡̡̨̛̛̩͇͔̩̣̳̫̥͎͇̜͇̹̦̺͎̭͔͖͕̣̖̻̫̯̮̩̼͍̥̺̲̲͓͈̪͚̫̙̣̱̜̯͕̖͕̪̥̯͉̣͊͆̈́̍̋̊̉͆͑͆́̀̉̈́̊̀̏̂̈́̾͌̂͊̉̽͂͗̎̂̊̑̏͂͊͌́̀̔͑̀̓͗͋̋͊͂̊̅͌̏́̕̕͝͝͠ͅͅỚ̶̡̧̢̢̧̡̧̨̨̡̨̹̟͖͖̥̝̩̝̹͈͙̝̞̠͍̺̰̹̫̝̘͉̯̪̤̞̤͎͇̹̠̤̠̦̗̥͖̙͎͈̹̪̩̦͍̓̃͆͂̈́̍̆̒͐̋́̽̐͐͗̏̀̓͆͊̌̅̇́͒̋͂̾̏̂̇͒́̔͐́͛̉̒́̈́̌̏̌̀̍̋̈́́̕͜͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅW̸̡̨̢̢̨̨̳̗̗̞̯͈̝̱͙̮̤̣̪͉͎͙͔͔̟̹̹̣̖̫̪̜̳̜̭̺̯̭̞̖̞̖͚̠͇̼̻͔̙͕̗̞̤͎̞͖̍͆́̌̄̈́͊̾́̃͂̀̾͛͐̑̇̓͛́̿̓̓̄͛͌̑͒̓̃̈́̌̄̀͌̀̋̂̔̇͋͊̅̔́̎̆̈́̔͘̚̕͘͜͠͝͝͠͝ͅ ̶̨̨̢̢̡̦̰̲̱̟̥̩̬̰̞̱͚̭̠̣̳̤͇͔͈͕̣̩͍͇͚̜̦͉͈̘̘̫̙̦͎͖̜̮̘̯̟̘̼͔̜̞̰͑͊̇͊̋̈́͊̒̋̉́͐̂͆͒́̒̓͋̉̈́̈́̌̏̓͆̊͗̄̓̑̓̀̾̑͂͊̽̍͋̐́̀̊͘̚̕̕̕̕̚̚͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͠͝͝ͅW̴̨̧̡̢̢̧̛̛̘̪̠̫̦̟̼̼̭͍̩̭̲͇̝̤͇͙̘͚̪̝̱̫͍̬͙͔̳̫̼͙͕͉͇͍̝̗̬̼̫̫͕͙̞̘̬͌͐͂̎̈́̈́͗̿̍̀̎́̄͊̈̔͌̆̈́̐̎͂͌̃͂͛̎̏́̒͗̽͌͒͋̓͊̀̿̆͋͆̿̌͗̚̕̕̚͜͜͠͠͝͠͠͠͠ͅͅͅḦ̸̨̢̛͕͕̙̼͉͍̗̞͎̠͍͇̫͍͓͉̱̤̻̙̣̫̻̟̗̠̲͎̜̲̰̮̭͎̞͉̹̹͓̦̙͙͍̝͈̹̮̭̯̬̲͚̙̹͓̍͐̈̑̇̓̒̏̀̽̐́͐̋̋̃̊͌̍͑̐͒̒̾̇̉̔̔̈́̒̉̒̈́̎̍̑͐̅͒̆̃͐͊͗̎͒̅̓͘͘͘̕͘̚͘͜͝Y̵̡̨̢̧̨̛̱̗̝͇̯̠̲̬̜̯̳̹̤̳̞̭̻͚̣͉͉͇̙̯̮̞̬̜̻̟̰̞̮̪̝̰̻̳̜̗̦͈̦̖̣̞͈̜͔͔̠̠͒̓̑̈́́͐̀͗͌̉̑̃̏̀͌͗̃͌͑̍̄̒̌̓̋́́̑͐̈̉̔̅́̈̑͒́̈́͌̇͛͗͑̈́̾̉͊̊̐́̚͘͜͝͝͠͠ ̷̢̡̨̧̛̭̼͎̞̣̫̜̼̪̬̯͕̭͚̖̼̳̬̦͍̜̳̳̖̺̞͕̞̞͓̤͎̫͉̗͈̞̖̖̦̭͔͔͚̹̩̳̠͙̞̟̯̗̟͂̎́́͌̔̇̈̈̔̊̌̿̆͒̃̈́̊̓̐̋̔̉̄͛̇́̿͑͛͆͂̅̒͑͊͒̅̐̎̆͐͋̒͒̆̓͛̅̀͛̂̕͝͠͝͝Ǐ̵̧̢̢̨̢̡̧̨̢̛̪̻̝̗̜͉̗̼̯̫̫͚͔̖̦̟̖̘̰̠̜̦͈̱̖̱̹̯͔̣̹̲̠̥̖̪̣̲̦̬͉͙̦̯̳͈̼͋͆̄̀̃̀̍̎͌̌̌̈́̀͑͂͌͂̊͋̍̅͛͑̌̽͆̈̊̈́̄̃́́̒͆͊̋̇́̂̔̐̉̏̅͗̆̍͘̚͘̚̕͘̚͜͝ͅ'̵̨̡̧̢̢̡̬̱̩̟̗͉̗̳̦͓̹̤̙͇̹̯̭̟͇̠͙̮͈͓̰̬̝͇̹̞͈͔͎͈͓̻͎̰͚̫͍̫͈̦̞̝̤̺̩̱͋̐͆̃̃̔̇̆͊̍̅͂͌̓͑̈́̈́̈̇͐̒̃̉͌̒̍͊̐͊̏̄̏̍̒̈́̉̆̓̀͗̒̀͗̌̑͑̎̅̚̚̚͘͘͜͝͝͝͠͝ͅM̶̨̨̨̧̨̛̛̛͕͇͇̘͍̯̹̣̬̲͖͓̪͔͚̠̫̫̟͉͙̟̩̰̹̩̗̞͉̟̟̘̞̻̲͕͕̫̪̤̣͉̗͉̥̫̯͔͚͖͔̈́̅̓̇̅̄̉͋̎̾̌͆̎̏̏̄͒͆̃́͗̔͐͐̀̋͊́̎́̍̓͒̎̂̈́́̊̈́͐͋̍̅̈́͑͋͆̾͘͘̚̚͜͝͠͝ͅ ̶̡̧̛̛̛̛͔͔̞̖̞̟͍̬̻̻̣̝̹͚̼̙͙̗͉̩̥̙̠͙̣̙̝͍̹̝͇̻͍̜̱͙̩̦̪̹̰̱̠̰͙̣̫̪̣̟͈̙̘͎̟͔̍̀̄͗͒̔̀̈̐̍̌͋̈́̔̊̈́̀̿͗̍͂̏̑̃̉̌̔͌̈́͂̓̀͐͂̈́͊͆̾͊̓͌̊̐͌̈́͌͛͐͌̕̚͠͝͠M̶̧̧̧͖̖̮̼̩̠̹̮̞̜̞̖͚͙̪̟̙͓̤͙͕̜͓͚͇͓͍͖͕̞̗̪̬̰̜̹̰̪̣͚̬͇͕̞͚͕͍͙̳͕̟̿̉̋͌̀̔̈́̂̓̑͋̅̈́̒̊̀͂́̿̏͒̉̈́͑͐͗͂͐͊̒̏̔͊̀̓̿͌́͐̅̍̇͗̋̋̊̂͌̂̎̄̍̀͌̚͘̚͜͝ͅͅͅA̵̧̨̢̛̘̠̫̞̪̖̻͙̬̜͓̲̘̣̮̜̜̲͈̭͖̮̲̹̺̟̞͎͉͓̠̪͓̹̤͉͚̤̜̺̣̩͖̻̲̞͎̫̤̺̥̻̓̆̍̇̈́̓͒̈̾͂̏̓̊̂͗̍̇̾̏̀̇͛̍̾̀̏͂͗̓͋̒̂̊͛̾́̿̍̃͛̂̂͒̈̋̽̅̆̓̑͑̕̚͜͜͝͠͠͝ͅḴ̸̢̧̨̧̧̛̛̛̛̭̣͕͈͚̰̲̣͓̜̹̭̗̭̯̯̠̺̥̰̣̤͈̗̺̪̬͍̮̣̟̯͈̞̺͇͕̠̦͚͉͚͓̲̯̪̠̈́̄̈́̅͆̎̐̀̋̅̃̆̀͋̂̈́̀̂̆̄͋̉̄́͑͒͂͗̊̎̇̅͋͊̃̌́̿̃̔̓̒̿̿̽̏̕̚̕̕̕͜͜͝͠͝ͅͅͅĮ̸̧̡̢̡̨̛̥̟̳̺͓͎̗̹̟͕̭̘͙̦͙̱̲̹̘̻̤̟͕̤̳͔͕̟̙̱̱͔̫̝̲̻̘͇̩͙̲̞̘̱͖͕͔̦̍̊̄̓̓̅͂͋̄͛͑̾̀̍̒̇̇̿̔̂̔͑͒̈́̃͑̄̓͐̆͒̋͐̓̍͆́̃̈́̅́̾͊̔̍̊̊̉͋̄̾̕͘͘̚͜͜͝͠ͅͅŃ̷̡̢̢̡̛̯͙̻͕̥͇̥̣̟̪̫̻̳̜̬̝̳̮͎̻̮̱̮̺͉̩̯̗͚̖̳̠̤̲̯̼̜͕̖̟͚̟̼̠͓̼̲͓̤̭̖̭̬͊́́́̌̃̑̃͑͊͛̒͐̽̂̾̊̇̿̀̈́̇̀̌̒̌̅̂̀̍͛͒̿̋̓͌͆͆̽̅̇̂͘̚̚̕̕͘̕͘͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅG̵̢̡̡̨̻̩̣̠͓̞̱̮̯͉̱̪̠͇̫̭̳̥͇̝̜͉̳̝̖̯̦̬̦̰̪͈̫̟̬̫̗̺͖̘̘̘͇̝͎̖̤̟̖̈́̓̊̓͒͒̌̉͊̿̅̌̿̎͊̑̆͊̆̇̓͆͐̏͊̋̆͒̾͋͐̑̓̎͗̑̓͂̓̂̃̍͊̅̾̒̈͛̈́͑͊̓̾̚͘̕̕͜͠ͅͅͅͅ ̴̡̛̛̲̝͙̭̭͖̘̲̤̟̤̰͖̟̗̝͕͍̫͚̪̰̗͔̗̭̬̹̦̰͉͖̺̟̻͕̲̼͔̩̬̦̭̯͎͖̯̫̰͉͍͇̩̎̐̍͗͌̿͂̈́̄̐͛́̄̽̌͑̃̓̾̄̑͒́͗͒̈͂͌̓́̌̇̋͌̀͂̎̈́̃̾̈͌͋͊̈́̏̀͑͘͘͘̚͜͜͝͠͝͠ͅͅŢ̵̡̧̧̛̱̺͖̱̥̻͉̦̳̮̭͖̲̪̭̳̠͓̩̖̙̯̝͍̲̞͉̬͔͚̮̮͖̭̭̺̠͈̯̼͙̩̯̠̘͎̟͖̥̰͇̼̣́͊̉̅̾͌̑͑͋̍̂̈́̃͌͋̋̿͛̓̊̃̆̔̎͂͊̿͐̉̾̓̅̒̃͐͂̌̈͌͑͐́̽̈̿̈̈́͘̚̕̕͘͜͠͝͝͝͝Ḫ̶̡̧̨̨̢̢̛̛̭͉̳͚̣̼̻̻̫͚̞͉͎̜̠̜̳͍̹̱͉̠̺͓̞̫̳̭̩̲̬̳̩̜͖̘̼͇̩̯̼̥̭̬̪̣̟͓̦͇̀̊̒́̎͒̀̽͌̓̈́̔̎̒̇̒̾̉͒̾̂͊́̈́̒͆̔̓̑̍́̔̓̂͒̈́͗̉̓́̾̀̎̓̎͑̃͗̇̅̂̚͘͘̚͝ͅI̵̧̧̢̨̡̛̛̝͔̫͈̯̥͚̼͓̮̫̱̱͓͇͇̠̻̹̥̩̱̰̩̱̱̠̩̹̰̠̩̘̮̻̗͈̭̖̗̯̜̩͚͉̖͚̥̙͈͉͊́͆̅̋͋̂́̆̏̔̈́̓̆̔͂́̊͒̍͒̽̈́͋̈́̂̃̔͐͑̈́͐͒͒̽́́̉̎̇͑̑́͛̐̆͘͘̚̕̚͜͝͠͠͝͝ͅS̵̨̧̢̨̛̫̥̖̣͙̟͖͉͈̻̜͖̪͈̼̺͓̬̤̺̥̝̭̟̩͇͖̞̪̝̻̝̣̺̩̯͈̻̫̖͍͓̰̭̜̥͎͚̫͔̐̌̃̓̃̀̒͛̓̓̀͊͊̃̎͗̃́̃̄́̿̄͑̒͐͐̆͂̽̿̃̂̑̈́̅̾̆̿̿̈̍̇͆̀̒̆̄̋͑̕͘͘͜͜͜͜͠͠͝͠ ̸̨̡̢̛͚͔̝̱̰͓͖͈̘̠̥̯͕͙͕͙͎̱̘͍̣̟̞̙̥̭̳̰̫̠̫̗̩̪̭̗̱͔͙̯͈̦̼͍̳̮͚̠̙̩͙͍̠̳͚̿̑́͒̂̓̅̆͂́̈́͐̿̏̽̈́̀̃̈̓̓̊̇̋͑̏͒̅́̔͋̄̅͊̽̇̂̔͌̾̈́̋̉́͛̈́͋̆͘͘̕͝͝͝͠͝͠Ş̸̧̢̧̧̡̨̰͓̘͉̤̣̟̠̺̮͈̩̣̟̩͈̦̞̥̗̖̲͔̠̫̤͙̙̺̣̭͕̙̼̠̠̩̞̘̯̠̲̘̬͎͈͈͇̰̘̐͂̒̈́̒͛̓̄̀̀́̍̌̀͂̇͗͛͋͑̏̍͒̃̋̉̌͒͂͆͂́̽̆̆̌͆̈́̋͒̓̈͊̈́̽̀̌̏͛͒̕̕͘̕̕͜͝͠͝Ơ̸̡̢̡̨̡̧̨̛̛̛̛̪̭̗̦̹̼͚̤̹͉͔̠͙̮̗̻͈̼̲̣̭͖͈̣͙̖̯̫̬͈̝̺̟̟̲̖̜͔̬̦̹͎̬̟̬͔͙̫͂̿̑͗̂̀͒́̈́̀̈́̏̑͑̎̿̿͆̾̀̆̂̋̎́̓̃̆̊̏̓̏̃̈͌͆̇̐͆̿̇̊͋͋̏͗̒͛̍̕̕͜͝͠ͅͅ ̴̡̢̡̧̡̛̛͓̯̻͍̞͕̺̜̯̼̤̭͈͓͖̯̠̼̺̳͎̺͈͕̥̹̲̲͕̺̯̤̟͙͖͚̜͖͚͇̣̱̮͕̹̙̖̙̘͒͛̊̂͊̓̆͒͒̾̋̔͋̅́̓́͛̍̄͂̆́̆́̐̓͌̋͂͑̀̌͒̌͗͂͂̄̃̈́̀͌͐̈́̓̽͂̕̕͘̚͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝M̷̨̧̨̢̢̡̧̡̢̨̨̢̛̜̻̱̩̪͚̺̹͎͖̮͕͇͉̬͈̳͇̩͇͓̱̮͕͖̣̲̫̞͇̮͚̥̮̗͈̭̗̘̱̙̮̰̠̆̉̌́̉͑̉̑̌́̃͌̈́̌͒̿̊̐̀̈̉̂́̇͗̆̀̑͂̌͒͌̈́̀̾͊͐͌̈́̑̎̔̅̊̉̔̇̌̋̊̚͘͜͜͝͝͠͝͝A̴̢̨̡̡̡̡̨̛̛̛̘̬̱̰̺͚̩̬̜̣̤̳͇̱̗̲̼͍̻̫̭̫̻̣̻͎̳̬̣̪̲͉̤̖̼͙̩̠̦̮̘͇̞͙̠̙̪̦̪̾͂́̈̊̇̏̈́́̔̒̐̾͂̑̏̃̽̓̎̂̏̆͌͗̂͂̾̇͆̉͒́͑̓̿̏̾͌̔̿͛́̾̇̈́̐̐́͘͘̚̕͘͜͝ͅS̵̨̢̢̡̠̪̘͕̳͇̳̩̼̹̦͖̙͙̰͍̞̯̫̰͍̟̯̫̼̬͚̙̜̠͈̰͎̱̱̥̖̜̺̯̗̣̯͕̪͎̲̦̩̘̩̘̥͊̓̈́̐͂̈̈́͑͗͑̊̐̔̾͂̓̆̌̅̅̈́͑̒̆͆̾̃̍͌͂̇͑̈̀̿͗̀͊͗̐͒̓̉̌̈͂̎̇̐͊͑̚̚͘͠͠͠͝ͅS̴̢̢̨̧̨̢̨̛̙̭͈̠̟͈̭̤̬̣̰̠͈͔̭̮̝̩̞̗̳͎̲͙͕͖̪͕̖̳͕͉̘̖͕̹͉̬̪͎͙̗̰̘̙͇͈̏͊̈̓̆̄͑̆́͋̑́̈̈͗̌̈́́̈́͗͑̋͗̂̐́̔̐̇̂͂̊̊͛͑̀́̎̀͂̆́͐̃́̿̐̑̄͘͘̕̕̚͜͜͜͠͝͝ͅỈ̷̡̧̡̛̬̺̫̬̮͙̜̹͖̝̱̫̱̪̦̥̝͈͍͍̟̰̟̗͉͈͇̫̣̪̖̩̙̪̯̺̳͕̥̖̥̩̮̝̺̼̻̤͎͍͈̑͛̓̈́̀̓͋̾̀͋̋̏̿͑͌͆͑̂́̈͒́̃͌̇̋̅̑͐̏̂͋̄̐̈́̅̈̓̌̽̽͐͗͋̑̕͘̚̕͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͠V̴̨̢̧̧̡̧̢̛̼̰͓̜̘̳͍̪̤̯̱͙̥͚̳̥̱̭͔̩͙͓̖̤͍̤̞͔̹̰͚̳̙̺͙͓̦̝̮̘̦͕͉̫̪̝͓͔͛̈́̐͆̇̈́͑̃͂̈͂̈́̈́̓̄́̄̽̓͂̈́͗̄̽̊͂̌́̃̑̌̊̀̂̓̂̑̅̎̒͐̇̇̿͊͛̐̔̏̋͑́͐̕͜͜͝͝͠ͅȨ̵̢̧̧̲͉͇̱̬͓̱̬͚̬̞̜͍͙̪͕̤̯̲̣̦̭̼̳̫̭̫̩͇̲̳͎͇̩̘̝̜̺͇͖̫͎̭̲͉̬̖̥̀́͗̊̽͗̾̋͌̆̊̊͌̈̆̇́͆͗̓͆̏̅̎̏́̆̀̂͋̓̊̍͂̆̇͛̾̇͆͊̔̎̈́̿͌̀̎͊̓̐́̽̚͘̚̕͜͜͜͝ͅͅͅ

And of course, a completely normal embedded code snippet:

```js
function yay() {
  var count = 1;
  document.write("Please stand by.");
  document.write("Working..");
  var timer = setInterval(function() {

    switch (count) {
      case 1:
        document.write("Heh");
        break;
      case 2:
        document.write("shouldn't have done that >;)");
        break;
      case 3:
        document.write("NEVER PRESS STUFF IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT IT DOES");
        break;
      case 4:
        document.write("You got lucky this time though");
        break;
      case 5:
        document.write("Because...");
        break;
      case 6:
        document.write("This script");
        break;
      case 7:
        document.write("Happens");
        break;
      case 8:
        document.write("To consist of PUPPIES! :D");
        break;
      case 9:
        document.write("<img src=\"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1368/5523/t/2/assets/slide_2.jpg?17610422950068712765\"");
        break;
      case 10:
        document.write("<img src=\"https://i.imgur.com/BD7F5YW.jpg\"");
        break;
      case 11:
        document.write("TODO: insert more images. Don't let anyone see the script until that");
        break;
      case 12:
        document.write("Whoops!");
        break;
      case 13:
        document.write("Guess there's only one thing to do now...");
        break;
      case 14:
        document.write("Ḩ̴̧̨̧̡̛̛̛̛͉̣̮̳̹̗̞̜͎̬̣̪̱̫̩̹͍͖̮̻̞̙̱̹̳͕̬̖̩̟̫͍͕̼̘̥͕̘̬̼͓͔͍͇̘̙̺͉͎̟̪̗̗̭̞̯͚͔̤̣̣̺̙̱̣̱͚̤̯͈̲̺̤͚̤̤̺͇̞̠̬̦͖̬͙̝͇̲̗̙̬̀͒̅̾͂̄̃̈́̈́̈̌̍̾̅̃̓̉̈͋̆̈́̈́̂̏̽̈̆̋̈̾͂̐̅̽̐͐̓͆̈́̍͂͂̋̅̀͐͑̐͆̈́̾̆̒͛̅̆̈́͊́͂̓̀̐̋̑̂́̋̄̑̓̄̃̈́̇̄̂̽̓͑̎͊̍̓̑̀̕̕͘̚̕͝͝͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅȉ̷̡̡̢̢̡̨̡̛̛̬̮̮͖͎̦̱̹̼̲̙̥̻̬̥̹̣̠͔̤͍̪̜͖̠̘̺̜͎̗͙̤̙̘̜͚̥̝͉͕̗̩̙̙̜̩̟̠̫̣͙̘̻͖̩̙̼͕͇̳̪̝̩̦̺̯̼͙̫̞̖̞̲̤̮̖̰̳͔̹̻̜̺͈͓͙̜͍̭̤̣͌̈̐̌͗̒̆̃̄̈̀̇̓̄́͗̂̌̾͑̽̈́̏̐̈́̊̈́̈́͆̊̓͆͛̂́̈̌͛̿̉͆̿͌̿̎̏͐̽͋̃͐̎̌͐̇̌̿̊̿̑̀͆̂̈̿̔̔̎̈́̀̈́̄̓̀̔̃̒̓̽̾̈́̑̆͛̆̈́̓̈́̚̚̚͘͘͜͝͝͝͠ͅd̶̡̡̨̧̛̛̛̛̦̘̣̬̫̲̟̥̤̜̹͈̦̱̼͍̞̳͙̘̗̭̫̠̰̮͔͕̹̯̝̳̤̘̲̯̯̣̪̟̗͚̜̘̦̤̞̼̗̥̼̮̣̺̬̥̲̰̥̬̪̳̲͈͚̭̥͈͈͙̪̗͉̥͙̤̻̹͕͍̝̹̩͇̤̥̺̬̞̥͕͙̱̂̉̐̈́́̆͛̄͌̌̊̓̿̅̓̀̉̐̒̇͐͊͐͒͛̀̇̎̈́̉́̆̽̀̇͛̑̆͌̆̌̐̈́̈́̋͋̎̈́̍̏̌̒́̎͊́̑̊̈͐̾̂̈́̌̈́͂͐̄̉̎̉̓̿̑́͆̈́̚̚̚̚͘͘͘̚͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅȩ̶̡̨̨̧̛͕̪̝̖̱͈̭̹̥̼̺̫̙̙̲̤͈̫̪͔͎̻̼̤͖̳̯͉̱͉̗̣̻͈̙̖̫̱̘͔̤̖̣͈͓̜̬̱̫̤̙̠̪̟̙͇͓̖̙͙͖̩̜̤̠̳͕̣̙̫̺̫̞̪̪̜̲̝̜̺̜̩̠͖̘̖̤͉̘͖̀͗͆̑́̋͂̈́͒̆̀́̂̋̄̔̀̐̑̓̀̊̉͛̌͌̓̀̇̉̎̉̊̑̅̏̈̏̍̅͂̔͊̍͌̇̑̆͋̊̈́̃̀̅̓̄̂̿̌̅̔̒̐͊͗͆͆̊̍͊̎͂̔͛̈́̆̈̓̐̀̀̂̆̐̕̚͘̕͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅ ̴̡̨̡̢̡̡̡͙͔̥̟̫̩̘̝͚̩͖͙͉̱̻̮͕̬͈͇̞̪̠̻̟̪͖̤̻̯̼̜̣̜͔̲̳͇̼̹̝̭̞͕͉̪͇̹͎̗̘͓̲͔̲̯͈̱̖̘̞̱̹͈̜͎̩͉̤̪̬̩̞̼͙̣̹͙̱̫̜̖̲͍̩͚͓̈̂̀̇͗͗̈͋̈́̀̀͂́̀͂̋̈́̏̿̈́̈́̈̈́̓̐͒̆̄̓̏̀̍̔̌̍̑̅̀͑̐̎̈́̾̿̃̐̀͂̀̄̌͌͒͛̀͊͌̿͋̏̉̔̀̑̄͆̆̃̀̉̑̃̒̅̔̽̐̏͌̇͗̂́̕̕̕̚̕̕̕̚̚͘̕̕͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͠ͅį̷̨̧̧̢̨̢̛̛̜̯̹̝̰͕̬̪͖͕̜̗̞̗̠͔̦̼͎̝̳̞̫͉̻̦͕̗̮̭̻̲̥̰̻͉̤͓̻̭̯̭̲͙̘̞̠͙̗͎͈̲̣̯̻͎̱̯̳̬̯͙̟̭̮̼̪̬̭̬͍̙̭͎͎̻͖̦͚̘̙̦̺̹͚̹̑̌͂̅̅̓̌̐̒͊̾̉̀̄̔̇̽̽̌̀͑̃̐̃̾̑̽̅̎͊̽̾͛̇́̾̔̅̔̔̅͛̑̈́͛̅̒̌̓͌̉͂͑̅̇̄̓̀̓̓̎͆̅̍̽̉̍̈͂̔͆̆͆̈́̉̆̌̓̏̈́̓͂̎̈́̑̄̀̅̈̕̚͜͝͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅţ̸̧̢̨̢̨̢̧̢̡̧̢̛̛̛̛̝̥̭̙͔̲͇͈̠̗̭͕̳͇͙̲̼̩̮̖̥̯̳̗̫̲̲͔̤̗͍̭͉̖̠͇̖̣̥͉͔̜̪̩̱̱̗̻̬͓̣͕̪̼̙͇͖̞̭͎̼̠̹̺̬̪̗̹̩͕̫͓̲̲̱̟͍̗̰̞̱̬͉̭̲́̌͆̓̌̽̽̀̈́̌͋̋̈́̍̽̃̈́̏̈̾̐̑̋̇͐̅̋̆̆̈́̈́͋͑̍͒͐͆̒͑̎̈́̂̄̄͌̄̂̈́̎͂̾̏̃̑̈́̓͐͐̿͒͛͊͆̀̊̈̋͌͋̒̒͌͛͆͆̏̓̎̐̂̓̾͒͘̕̕̚̕̚͘͜͝͠͝͝͝͠ͅͅ ̴̡̢̢̨̡̢̢̛̛̛̛̰͔͙͈͎͚̲̺͖͍̮̺̗͎͓̝̫͖̯̹̘̺̭̺͖͚̥͙̘̭̦̰̥̮̝̯̹̜̝͕̣̫̜̟̩̰̥̹̳͕͍̭̱̠͇̬̫̖̘̪͕͚̫̳̣͙̭̟̝̰̘̭͎̫̲̲͖̥̹̥̯̹̥̯̞̱̖̒̊̈́̽̈́̌̅̄̇̿̀̃̋̔͐̅̌͋̔̅̾̽͆̄̏̾̋̐̀̌͗̽̈́̂̈́̓͗̀̃̈͗͒̈̈́͛̆̃̌͗̉̅̈́̾͛̓̂̆̈́̏̔͊̂͐̉͛̈́̊͗́͂͐͑̑̒͊̑̌̽͋̕͘̕͘͘̕͘͘̚͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅą̵̡̧̧̢̢̨̧̨̧̡̛̛̛̥̹̻̤͙̦̞͎͓̥̝̲͓̯͉͕̦͎̯̲̻̼̰͈̺̺̞͈̭͈̝͇̣̬̭̟̪͔͔͉̟̤̖̗̰̩̦̰̗͔̭͓̹̤̹̙͙̳͇̳̟̖̥̮͎̖̦̖̣̫̰͉͓͚̪̺̦̱͇̺̫̻̯̪͊͒͐̈̑͂͒̈́̿͑̽̆̽̑͐͒̽̃̐̾̈́͗̾͒̒̓̊̐̎̈́̔̏̉̑͌͑͒͐͑̓́̅̍́͊̓͌̈́̾̈́͋͆̍̂̅͊̓̈̊͋̆͗̄̍̎͋̈̄̈́̅̽̓̍́̿̽̉̉̇̈́͌̅̅͑̈̏̕̚͘̕̕̚̚͜͜͜͝͝͝͝ͅͅĺ̵̨̨̡̢̨̧̛̛̛̛̛͍̟͈̗͙̺̯̖͈͇̗̳͉̜̦̠̩͉̮͓̯̻͍̟̟̠̪̣̖̥͈͓̺̦̼̘̭̮̜̱̟̪̘͓͓̬̺̤͓͕͖͎͖̤̫̱̟̱̖̭̼͇͎̯͈̬͇͍̯̗͓̺̲̦̥̦̠̼̭͇̺̟̜̞̠̰̼̹̮͛̀́̌̾̄͂̓͛̃̑̐̒͆͆̓̓̊̏̒̃͗̆̈́̾͗̄̏̌̀̋̄̈́̑͑͑̓́̄̎͑̉̀̈́͐̀͂̑̌̒̃͛̀͐̑̈́͐̈̾̈́́͒̌͆̒̌͂̿͊̏̆̉̇̀̅͒̊̋̉̍̋̚̚̕͘͘͘̚͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅl̸̨̢̡̡̢̨̡̢̡̛̘̫̦̠̦͙̮̰̟̤͚͈̜͍̘̫̯̥̣̞̦͖͉͓̬̰̬̜̺͖͔̙̙̘̯͍̟̞͍̪͓̘̜̭͇̳̪̥͇̭̲͙̪̰̼͓̬͎̤̤̻̬̠̖̘̥̲͉̰͍̥̜̼̟̦͕̞̝̤͖̟̘͔͚̳̞̻͎̐̍̈͐̂͗̀̄̀͗̌̂͌̔͂͑͑͂̂̐̾̅͐̑̿̄̽̋̀͆̈́̑͌̏͌͒̀̄̈́̀̒͌̀̍̒̒́̎̓̑̎̀̈͒̀͑̅̈́̽̈́̉̓̓́͋́̎̊̓̅͊͂̃̀̍̀̿̀͒̓͛͐̋͊̋̀͑͘̕̚̚̕̕͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅͅ,̶̨̧̨̨̡̢̧̡̛̛̛̛̠̣̖͈̱̖̦͕̗͖̘͓͎̗̫̟̣̫̙͓̯̯̩͉̗̬̮͙̻͔̫͇̮̟̻͎͎̞̫͙̫̦̪̬̜̞͙͎̦̜̼̻̘͕̪͕̟̜̞͎̩͙̬̜͓̣̹̠̝͍̯̣̗̩̠̻̝̬͎̤͈̯̣̠͚̆̃͐̊̑͆͐̌́͌̐̓͒͗͒̓̈́̌͒͐́̍͂̇̇̄͌͂͒͑͑̈̉̒̄͋̾̒̆̾̐͂͒̉̀̿́̽̋͆̀̒̔̎̀̈̐̊͑̓͋̊̇̏̊̇̽́͒̐̉̈̆̌̚̕̕̚̚̕͘͘̕͜͜͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅ ̵̨̡̧̡̧̨̛͎̤̹̙̞̦̼̺̬͔̙̪͎̭̭̖̖̹͓͔̹͕̣̤͇̼̫̘̘͚͇͙̰͎̰̯̳͎̪̟͖̝͎̮̱̦͇͕̦͔̳̦͎̞̩̩̦̼̝̦̮̤̼̭̞̪̣͍̗͔̦̲̯̦̲̫̗̤̗͕̺̳̠͕͔͔͓̺͚̺̮̳͇̿̉̓̈́͋̆̌̊̂̽͒̓̾̅́̉͂͆̂̐̂͒̐͛̒͋̅́͐́̓̎̍͆̈́̌̐̉́̓̊͑͌̇͆͒́̀́̔͊͌̆̈̑̓̈͆͗͌̄̃̊͗̓̇̊̌̑̽̏̾͗͗͐́̾͌͌̈́̇̆́̾͐̈̌̽̚͘͘̚̕͜͝͝͠͝͝͝ŕ̷̡̡̢̧̧̡̢̛̛̛̛͖̬̣͚͚̝̺͚̼͇̳͎̤̳͓͕͈̳̭̜̼̣̟̳͈̙̠̼̫̼̘̞͖̤̟͓͚̭̱͇͎̦̙̗̟͓̬̭͈̥̭͓̬̠̞̯͖͇̲͎͔̹̳̖̖̺̠̩̼͍̟͈̰̮̻̰̗͙̹̘̬̼͓͕̖̠̣͇̦̇͊̅̆̓͌̀͒̇̓̀̈́̾͛̍̓̂̋͆̐͂̋̅͌̑̊̃̉̌̆͛̆̈́̏̽̃̽͑̏̾̍͐̇͋̋̆͛̾̀̋̃̀̀̀̽͑͒́̈́̃̉͆̉̈̔̓̇̏̄̀͗̇̓͊́͗̆̓̾̃̀̆̀̓̀̒̕͘̕̚͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅṷ̶̡̨̢̧̧̨̞͈̠̼̥͓̼͕͉̖̼̝͕͇̤̮̳̩̣̥̪̹̝̳̝̺͙̠̜̞̻͉͖͈̱̱̹͓̰͈̮̗̹̟̤̪̙̲̜̦͚͇̤̖̜̞͙̯̪͕̖̯̗̘͓̬͔̪̼͔͇̜̩̤̬̬͙̣̞̮̯̥̮̗̝̹͚͇͐̀̈́̀͂̄̈́̌͐̌̌͂͋̈̓̈́̈́͆̾̂̐͗͛͊̔̉̓̅͋̈̈́͒̉̔̌͗͛̾̐̒̀̀̋̒̾̊̽̔̓͋͒͛̊͋̏͆̆̄̊̽̔́͌̅̅̇͐̈́͗͂͊́́̽̋̔̌̎͛̊̉̏͌̿̈́̕̚̚̕͘̚͘͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͠ͅͅn̶̢̡̨̛̛̛̛̹̞͈͙̬̘͖͕̥̰̮̤̭̜̙̲͔̫̯̲̣̮̺͈̲̩̤̪̣̜͎̯̫̻̹̙̤̩̝̦̪̬̙̗͔̩̝̦̯͈͔̻͍̱̝̮͉̩̯͇͖̻̻͙͈̰̙̠̠̹͙̪̞͙̙̖̹̫̘͔͕̞͍͙͙̘̼͚͈̥͍͈̪͍̓͋̒͋́̍̍̍͂́̂̉̿̇͐͂͌͌̓͋̀́͆̀̓͋̄̐́͋̽̈́̔̽̅͂͊̉͂̈́͒̍̃̎̈́̉̄͐̅͒̆̓̍̈͐̉͛͂̋̅͑̈́̈́̎̀̊͐̀̐̋̀̄̔̉̒̾̀͂͗͒͆̇̊̋͐̓̕͘͘͘͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝ͅ ̴̧̧̡̡̧̡̨̢̧̢̢̢̳̝̜̻̜͔̜̝̲̬͕̟̺̺͎͇͈̮̦̳̺̦̞͕̠̦̥̳̯̪̰̘̦͇̣̻̗͎̯͇̱͚͇̲̞͕̯̣̟͙̰̯̠̗͇̩̤̺̯̥̯̝͍̤͈̥̥̰͇̖͖̼̞̗̮͈̠͓̬͎̲̙̱̥̏͐̇̎͒̔͆̈́̂͂́̈́̈́̊̌̾̽̃͌̇̒́̀̈͑̂̏̑̋̆̄͌́̓̾͋̈̓̉̋̒̅͆͋͌̑̈́̽͌͒̈́͌̎̉̀̽̄̓́̆̿̎́̐̎̒̂͗͗̽͊̑̈́̾͋͒̅̀̈́͋͌̐͆̅͒̕̕̕͘͘̕̚͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅͅä̴̡̢̨̨̡̢̡̧̧̛̛̛̯̤͎̯̫̝̬̰̮̺̻̜̹̞͙͔͇̭̝̥̜̤̜̹̺̣͔͓̤̰̮̥̫̩͎̱͔̖̝̫̩̦̰̯̣̹̝͓̩̥̰͍͖͉͚̬͖̫̘̬̖͉̖̰̖̰͎͕̱̭̤̩̖͇̟͕̬̰̳͇̺͚̯͍̪̱̞̐̂́̇̏́̈́̄́̏̈́̿̑̎͑̅̊͊̀͂̅̓͗̓̔̈͌̉̎̓̈́̏̆̉̽̾̀̒͗́̌́̂͛̒̃̈́̆̔͊͊̒̏̅̎̌̽̊͛̄̽͛͗̀̎̾̿͑̐̈́̄͑̈́̓͋͛̀̅͋̚̚͘̕͘͘̕͘͜͜͝͝͝͠͝͝͝ͅͅw̶̧̡̡̡̨̛̛̛̜̗͔̰̙͈̫͙̜̬̠̭̻͔̼̜̯̫̥̼̜̫̤̹̖̣͇̰̠͈̞̳̟͉̘̜̻̤̣̱̝͓͔͉̦̹̣̠͕̥̻͖̪̟͚̘̖͙͎͔͖̭̯̹͍̩͕̳̗̰̖̠̩͚̝̠̘̤̮̹̘̜̠͙̯͚̬͚̫̟͐̇̎̿͋̐̈́̒̈́̄̎̀͒̂́́͋́̈́̏͛͐̏͊̿̀̒͒̍̀̋̈̈͑̾̒͛̈́͊̇̈͒͑̿̈́͌̄̋͊̈̒̉̌͋͐͂͌̐̈́̆̀͗̈́́͆̅̓́̈͋̋͗̔̿̑͑̈́̽͐̉́̈́̆̕̚͘̚̚̕̚̕͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝ͅa̴̡̧̢̢̨̢̨̧̧̡̢̡̡̛͎̯̬̗͚̯͖̜̫̜͓̖͖̟̣̺͎̲̜̝̞̤̤̦̹͔͕̲̗͉̬͚͈̫̮̼͙͕̫͎̺̬̥̰̜̤͔̥̰͎͔̼̥̦̜̲͎̳͇͎̮͍͓̣̮͓͙͍̭̼̟̝̫̱̙̤̪̞̘̥̹̺͍͓̔́͛̈̊̈́̓̿̀͂̃́͌̀͛̉̈́̊̌́̄́͒̾́̋́̆̈́͌̋̆͆̀̋͐͑̍̀͗͒̐͆̈́͂̇̌̌̋̽̓͐̂̾̊̽͒̒͆̑̐̀̓̾̑̌̿̈͑͗͂͑̌̃̀̄̔̋́̌́͛͐̎͌̓̏́̌̚̕̕̚̚͜͜͠͝͠͝͠ͅỹ̸̢̨̧̨̡̧̢̛̛̛̺̼͈͚̼̫̗̼̟̬̱̭̫̫͙͓̰̪͎͔̳̱͓̙̞̘͓̣̣̰̭͉̮̣͈̦͔̦͓̣̤̞̪̙̠̣̱̞̰͎̦͇̲̱̺͍̺̟̦͈͇̥͙͓̦͚̬̱̱͓̼̲̥̲̯͓̺̪̯̠͕͚̱̻͕̠̥̤̖̔́̓͋̈́͗̋͊͌̉̈́̍̾̏̽̅̋͌̍̃̈́̽̐̎̂̿͐̿̔̂́̄͋̈͒̂̈́͂͒̉̈̈́͛̀̓͗̊̉̔́̇̎̆̌͂̆́̑̍̒͗͗̎̇͌͋͌͂́̌̽̔̿̒̉́͊͘͘̚͘͘̚̚̕͘͘͜͜͜͠͠͝͝͠͠͝͠͝ͅ ̸̡̢̢̨̧̢͎̣̝͔̤̝͖̪̺̬̯̠̰͎̝̞̟̬̬͓͇̳͈̠͖̘̦̫̼̲̳̰̱͉̫̰̫̻̥̯̰̹̰̗̘̤̲̫̬̩͕̺̖̬̤̯̘͔̙̺̟̰̲̹͍̼̬̺̮̹̜̝̥̪̯̹͔͓̫͍̪͙̰̖̰̜͉̯̖͓̹̃̅̀̍̾̀̀̏̐̂̍̎̂͗̌́͛̎͌͌̊̍̈́̃̈́͐͆́͑͗̃͊̽̂͌͒̑́͒͊̿̈́̉͒͂͂̂̄̔̀̀̔̾́͌̿̆̐̂̏̃̉̀̅̑́̿͒͆̓̔̒̒̽̐̍̒̀͛̓̏͒̑̌͋̈́̈́͊́͊̂͛̚͘͘͘̚͜͠͠͠ͅͅã̵̡̨̧̛̛̭̗͖̣̟̗͉̯̤͖͍̳͖̜̼̙̤͈̬͎̗̤̥̥̮͇̤̩̯͎͓͔̪̣͉̼̰̺̰̟̼͕̫̗͙̭̪͍̭͖̭͚̳̺̥͔̙̯̗͍̟͍̖̪̣̟̣͈͉͎̫̩͎͉̺̲͈̹̤̰̖͙̘͍̲̫̖̙̾̽̈́̂̀̾͑̌̅̊̈͒́̊̂͊̔̈́͑̑͛̒̊̀̈́̈̓̊̎͋̏̈́̔̂̏͋̄͗̔̄̈́̊͗̇͂̈́͂̋͋͗̾͋͂͛̍̿̈́̍̇̇̓̑̏̇̓́̾͐̂̀͐́͛͌̑̉̌̋̑̽͂͗̈́͛͆͘̚̚̚̕͜͜͜͝͠͝͝͝͝͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅn̵̨̨̨̡̧̛̛̛̛̙͓͙̖͚̯̣͙̠̦͉̬̤͈͍̞̦̘̗̩̺̟̝̗͕͚̠͙̼̖̺̼̹̳͚̫̟̹̦͈̯̫̯̖͍͈͕͈͍̹͙̖̟̻̟͉͍̞͔͖̣̤͈̤̭͍̳͚̩̭͔͎̘̩͕͍̰̘̜̬̝̙̬̼͓̭͇̳̻͖̱͛͑̃̇͆̓͊̃̔̈́͐́̒͆͊̈̽͑́͆̑̔̈̾̿͌͑͒̌̀͂͆̿͗̊̆͂͐̐͑̉̌̃͛̈́̑̏̈́̑̏̏̂̇̎̋́͑̾͌͛̀͛̄͐̈́͋͗̾̓͊͊͋̀͌͗̽́͋̈̉̈͘͘̚̕̕̕̕͘̕͜͜͝͝͝͠͠͝ͅͅd̶̨̡̢̡̡̨̢̛̛̳̟̙̺͓̰̳̟͎̙̣̜̰͓͔̝̮̭̜̻̦̬̱̯̳̱̦̯͎̖͔̥̖̟̯͙̞̫̩̠̜̜̩͚̹͍̹̮̮̪̺̬͓͍̰̯͔̜̦̲̮̖̤̝̰͍͖̗̱̥̞̜̗̮͈͕̮͍͎̻͔̟̘̣̤͎̭̋̓̆͂̔̑͑̋̈́͋̔̓́̈́͊̌̄̎͂͋́͛̄́̀̅̎͒́͊̎͂̅̈́̋͆̋͒͊͊͌̅̓̏̈́͑̈́̔͌̾͗̑͛̓̓͐̄̽͌͋̈́̓̌̽͗͂͛͊̏̄͆͊͂̏́̋͋̎̈́̈́͒͒͂̂̅̽͑̕̚̚̚͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅ ̸̢̨̧̡̢̡̨̢̛̗̻̜̣̯͙̫̤̗̙͓̲̝͕͉͖̞̜͉͉͍̱͇͔͎̺͉̻͔̠̝̺̲͈̪̟̝̪̯̤̗̜̤̪̩̖̖͕̰̘̠͎̳͎̰̜̝̤̖͈̳̻͚͕̜͇̩̟̝̰̭̗͓͎̲͇̙̠̖͎͖̝͇͇̥͙̱͓͂͑̀̓̄̇͊̃̅̔́̓̈́̿̂͑͂̒͒́̉̒̽͒͊̑̿̿̀̂̽͊̅̉́͌͂̐̂̊̀̔̈̈̃͑̆̓̈́̈́̓̓͂̉́̎̀͛̈̀͛̓̌̀͒̽̈́̓̀̋̍̋͋̽̾̾̈̅̑̂̈́̎̍̚͘̚͘̚̚͜͜͝͝͠͝͠͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅh̸̢̨̧̡̡̧̧̡̛̛̼̲͍̭̟̺̺̜̠̝̮͖̯͖̦̯̖̝̳͓͈̪͍̝͈̳̩̝̯̰͔̩͉̤̜̜̲̭̻̖͙͕̱̟͚̞̹̖̩̼̜̳̫̝͖̗̦͉̠̺̩̗͕͓͉̭̹̘̤̤̭͚̣̤̼̮̝̰̜̥͓̯̳͓͔͂͆̊̔͌̂̽̉̒̌͆̾͗̓͐̌̾͌̋͆̐̅̉͐́̓͐́̍̉͗͒͆̀̾̄̑̇͂̽̈̊̏̈̋̋̎̾̽̋̿͆̊̔̈́̈́̃̆͂̈́͂̅̽̏̑͊̇͑̆̾͌̏͊̅͋̋͌̆̈́͑̃̏͒̓̑͊͌͘͘̚͘͘̚̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͠͠ͅǫ̸̨̧̧̢̧̡̢̧̧̢̛̛̛̛͔̯͎̖̪͇̖͎̹̼̳̺̝̭̖̦̤͖̺̠̤̜̻̝̬͚̘̠̘̖͍̱̺̺̱̬̞̰̰͎̻̩̳̣̜̖̳̭̥̠̞̮͉̲̳̦̟̮̤̟͇̜̠̥͙͍̙̹̤̠̦̟̰̱̭̤̟̜͈̹̭͈̜̣͕̊̅̃̓͑̂̆̿̿͌͊͂̊͊͑̂̈́̽̾̊̽̆̆̑̉̂̎͂́͗̊̃͋̅̂̂̑́͛̍͂̃̏̍̃̏̂̾̂̃͌̉̄̎̀̽̈́̂̓̓̈́̌͆̄́̈́̓̔͂̅̄̋̎͆̓͑̊̓͌̏̈́̋̆̍̊̚̕͘̚̕͘̚͜͜͠͝͝͝ͅͅp̷̨̡̢̡̛̛̦̺̤̯͖̜̰̠͓͍̬̼̳̲͈̱̝̯̱̘͕̺̩͉̪̫̰͓̳͔͔̲̥̹͇̲̠͖͕̮̘͈͈̪̫̣͎͔̠̞̼͓̻̖̦̼̯̙̖͉̰̖͎̲̫̫͓̺̖̲̣̤̼̰̫̺̻͖͇͉̬̣̲̤̗̗̼̮͚͔̪̞̻̽̉̌̂̃̿́̈́̒̎͋̈̾̽̆̾̐̀̌̄̽͋̎̉̏͐̿̋̈̈͒̈͗̊̀̾̆̆̃͌̽̍͛͑̋̑̉̇̓͌͑́̌͌̾̃̒́̆̈́̋̃͊͋͆͋̈́̀̈́̅͊͆̒̄̿͆̌͆̊̏̀͘̚̕̚̚͘͘̚͜͜͜͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ḙ̶̡̡̢̡̢̢̡̛̛̛̯̲͖̜͔͇͕̟̞̪̱͇̲̬̞̖̼̲̖̫͕͖̟̦̞̜̠̱͈̣͕̲̮̯̺͕̹̙̳͇̩̭͖̖̣͉͓͖̝̖̩͈̠̤̥͚̤͚̥̯̤̭͚̠̯̰̜̮̤͇̭͖͔̠͓̤̞̞̦̻̝̙̮̮̘̈́̓͛̂̒͐̑͐̉̆̒͂̀̒̅̏̀͋̀͑̈̓̓̎̽̆͒̈̂́́̈́̉̓̈́͊̿͌͐́́̈́͌̆͊̌̿̐̆̌̔̉̑̓̓̍͌̌̉̀̐͑̉̈́̉̈́̐̋̎̅͐̔̌̒̀͆͒̊̑͆̚̕͘͘͘̚͜͝͝͝͝͝͠͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅ ̵̢̨̨̢̡̡̨̧̢̨̡̧̧̧̡̛͇̯̠͈̲̻̤̥͇͎̹̯̹̟̪̝̹̪̻͉͈̳̦̮͇̱̰͍͙̥̤͈̠̥͍̝͔̮̻̦̥̪̜̩̺̜̙̞̬͙̩̦̘̘̬̯̞̪̬͔̞̹̥̖̜̤̜̪̝̘͈̥̣̘̣̪̝̠̜̯̆͒̔̆̃̇͋̀̀̏̇̓̅͌̐̇̈́͆́̇͆̊̾͑̊̅̐͐̑̃̐̏̄̍́͗́̓̔̒̓̀̈́̈́̈́̓́͋͌́̊̋̅̇̈̿̇́̽́͌̽̎̈́͐̽̔̈́̄̍̽́̓́̋͋̒͊̿̈̄́̐͋̋̕̚͘͘̕̚̕͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅͅf̶̨̡̢̧̡̧̡̡̛̛̖̮̱͕̭̪̗̗̤̦̥̩͓̥̥͈̞̥̜͉̬͙̬̺̼̙̯̙̟̼̺͉͖͎̰̟̘̮̼̯̥͓͔̝̱̜͇̝̦͖͕̲̘͖͙̥̺̥̬̠̗̬̜̦̮͇͇̹̺̖̰͍̯͕̙̙̟̭̞̞̰̰͍͈͎̪͚͊̍͐̈́̎̽̆̍̂̊̅̈̈͂̇̑̏̇̍͑̐̃̆͐͗̽̊̾̂̾̃̽̽̉̔͌̾̀͒͋̀̅̌͑̎̽̍̃̏͌̿̀̃̎̿̾̀̅̑͆͒̐̏̌̿̎̈́̈́́̐͒͊͛̏̑̌̓̿͋̈́̏̀̈́̎͗̔̈͌̏̚̚̚̕̕͜͜͜͝͝͝͝ͅͅọ̷̧̧̢̨̧̡̱̬̲̞̼͍̗̻̗͚͈̞̯͕͉͉̫͓͔̜̤̘̲̠̦̮̦̪̹̫̭͔͕̳̮̙͚̜̼̟̗̦͎̠̯̫̦̟̘̤̝̜̜̮̹̗͓̦̗̰̩̰̳̤͔̘̼̭͍̦̹̻͈͍̠̯͙͕̟͉̬̤͙͔̮̳̥̝͉̔͑̂̎͆̄̆̑͋̎̎̊̄́̈͗̾̃̃̌̇̎̈̋̇͂̏̿͋͆̈́̊̅̈́̈́͐̔̉͐́̐͛́͑̐̈͂̽́̀͗̀͑͋̑̄̒̈́͐̈̐͛̽̂̆̒̓̅̀̐́̈́͛̏̓̌̄͂̉̄̓͛̑̓̔̂͘̚̕͘͜͜͝͝͠͠͠͝͝͝͠͠ͅͅŗ̴̧̢̧̧̧̢̢̧̛͓̝̠͇͖͈̼͉͓̟̟̲̼̠͇͙͎̟̰̘̠͓͈̮͓͔̥̺͚̤͕̗̖͚̗̭͇̥̟̯̣͕̝̜̟̻͍̭̥̟͕̦̠̝̠̭̯̯͎͖̲̻̮̼͇̦̙̫͎̘̪͈̮͚̲̯̤̬͕̞̜̟̙̠̰̫̪̅͒̈́̀̒̔̄̈̾̾̅̇͛́͊̒͆̃̎̊̇͊́̅̇́̂̏̈́̓̋͂͒̒͛̉͆̅̅̄͋͂͛̌͑̀̏̓̇́̇̒͗͂̿͑̅̾̑̌̉̔͐̅̋̾͂͛̓͋̈́̔́́͊̇̀̔͒̌̔̔̀̅́̿̚̕̚͜͜͠͠͠͝͝͝͝͝͝͠ͅͅ ̵̨̢̨̨̢̡̡̡̢̢̡̧̢̛̲̤̗̰̗͎̻̤̫͎͓̬͙̞̞̘͉̱̜̜̦̟͓͎͕̪̠̯̮̤̻͇͖̬̦̟̬̫̲̤̜̲̠̩̮͉͔̤͕͎̺̪̯̜͈̠̩̣͙̭̼̰̻̭͙̺̪̗͓̺̹͖̳̩͎̰͎̯͚͍̱̙̣̬̌̍̇̃̽̔̈̈́́̆͛̾̽̽͐̀̿̈̀͐̏̿̋̆͆͛͌͊̒͗̒̂̓̔̃̂̋̌̄̓̊̄̀̑̎̑̊͑̌͂̍̍͌̈́̏̌̑́͐̓͂͗͛͑̈͆͗́̄́͌̈̇̉̏̌̊̓̒̈́̕͘͘̚̚͘̕̚͘͘͘͜͜͠͠͠͠͠͝͝͝ͅt̶̨̨̡̧̡̢̛̛̗͕̫͖̻͎̱̩̦͓̩̠͙͔̭̟̠̺̺̟̱̭͚͓̜̣͉͖͙̭̼̟̯̯̗͇̟̫̺̟͓̗̠̦̗͙͔͈̯͇̟̘͕̥͓̭͚̭̹͔̹͔͖͕̪̞͔̞̩̙̭̖̟͍͓̱͖̼͉̞̼̹̜̣͕̫̩̦̼̣̣͗̓͋̂̑͛̑͂̆̌̍͑̾͋̾̆͛̓̈́̽̅͊̃͒̿͊̑̉͗͗̾́͛̊̈́͛͛̎͗̇̈͆̀͌̈́̍̎̂͌̌̿̓͒̍̉̋̐̍̉̀̊͑̀̄̌̏̐̓̆̀̆̎̉̈́̋͑̌̒̈́͛̅̈́́͋̏͘̕̚͘̚͘̕̕͘͜͜͜͠͝͝ḩ̶̧̧̧̢̡̛͉̹̝̣̬̬͕͇̯̣͎̘̩̻̞͓̜̩̞̟̻̥̪̹̟̫͖͓̱̟̪̗̼̤̰̝̯̭̫͖̗̥̺̗̱̥̹̮̲͖͉̲̦͎͔̰̟̤̲̼͈̭̝̳͉̮͉̠͓̥͍͓̦̼̜̣̤̘̯͔̯̟͎̘̤̘̇́̂̒̌͋̉́̈́͗͆́̀́̈́͐̽̋͐̒͗́̔́̀̈́̍̿̌̐̽̈̀̈́̐̅̾̈͂̒͂́͗̍̈́́̀̑̋̊̈͐͆̀̔̈́̒̈̆͋̔̅̄̓͂̀̇̓̔͆̊̈́̉̾̃̎͆̀̌͂́̈́̈́̉̐̈́̏͛́̽͂̿̀̄̚̕͜͜͠͝͠ͅͅͅͅͅͅȩ̵̢̡̡̛̛̛̛͔͔͉̯̮̹̥͕͔͙̥̝̤̹̙̣̖̼̹̮̫̤̺̻͈͈̩̬̲̲͕͙̜̻̦͍̖͎͉͍̭̙̟͖͈͈̦̦͈̪̱̙͓̗̠̗̰̣̺͓̹͉̼͙͙͖̳̤͉͎̪̰͙̱͔̭̥̳̠̤̠̦̜͇̱̹͍͈̗̫͔̻̃̇̎̐̂͊̃̒͑͋̈́͐̎́̈́͒̔̓̂̑͋̓̏̂̐̄̎̊̋̾̈́̌̆̽̒̾̈̌̂́̿̾̀̄̏́̈̈́̽͋͆̽̋̔̎̂͊̆̿̀̾̓̈́͌̈̔́̂̈́̆̋̈́͐̾̑̉̂́̓̒͋̓͐̀͘̚͘͘̚͘͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͝ͅ ̵̡̡̢̡̧̡̢̛̛̛̛̛̛͎̪̮͖̪͎͇̦̠̬͍̭̬̥̰̬̳̼̯͖̬̗̹͖̙̪͚̲̟͉͙̞̩̘̟͔̘̬͚͎͚̪̖̳͇̪͍͇̬̮̞̩͕̭̣̘̗̲̺̰͙̤̦̪͙̟̗͓̣̣̺̤͚̘̼̭͓̹̙̰̦̲̮̫̺̘̻͇͔͌̇̎͆̀͐́̈́̓̈̋͒͊̈́̂́̔̔̐̅̾̓̾͑́͂̓̈́͂͊̃̍̉̅͋̄̾̒͗͂́͒̉͑̀̎̊̽͛̃̽̂̌͂͆̑͊̿̏̿̔͑̔́̈́̿̑̀͂͌͊̿̀͋͋̒̾̀̋̑̄̔͌̎̒͐͘̚̚͜͝͠͠͝͝ͅͅͅb̶̨̢̡̢̢̧̡̨̢̨̨̡̢̢̛̛̛̛̛̳̞̱̳̳̺̦̻͉͎̳͈̤͙͚̱̩̭̭̦͚̰̖͎̖͎͍̬̩̻̯̺̠̞̥͈̤͉̬̥͔̙̜̥̼̘̖̺͔̯͚̟͓͓̖̻̤͚͍̞̱̣̩͇̲͚̟͇̲̣͙̱̰͔̼̖̭̭̣̫̰̪̠̂̌̈͆͗̏̄̍̃́̔̿́̃͌̀̑͗͐̔͒̏͐̈̍̃̌̑̏̉̃͋̅̓̐͗͒̌̓́͑͊̀͊̈̏̃̽̎͊́̈̿͂̈́̇̍́̌͊́̒̓́͑̄̌͛̏͂̓̈́̈̐̅̉̎̓̿̽͊̋̊̈́̀̆̓̕̚̚͘͠͠͝͠ͅͅͅe̶̡̧̡̨̛̛̛̛̛͓̖͉̠̱̤̬͔̝̣̠͙̯̮̳̬̹̜͔̣̰̯͈̣̯̥̠̲̝̺̥̗͉̝̟̬̫͚̣̤̦̝̳̝̰̩̬̱̺͙̜̗̯͍̫̩͍̪͚͓̦̰̮̞͙͖̙͎͍̼̪̘̘̜̭̙̟͖̭͕̲͍̫̜͓̫̺̗̻̞̳̞͂̑͌̎̊̽͆̇̔̒̀̾̽̂̿̀̂̈̐͊̓́͒̉̽̀̔̿̄̉̈́͋͑͛̀͌̄̌̀̉͆͑̉͂̆̎͌̓̈̇̈́͑͊́̓̐̆͒̀̆̂̀͒̈̀̆̋͐̈̎̈́̿̓̿͛̅̋̆͑̽̈́̃̏͘̕̚̚͘̕͜͜͜͠͝͠͝͝͠ͅs̵̢̧̢̧̡̢̨̢̡̫͉̙̼̹͓͖̗̠̞͙̙͓̻̹̲͓͚̠̪̥̯͙̱̰͍͚̞̗͎̣̼̟͉̺̳̰̙͎͚̫̘͓̥̣̭̟̩̠̞͙̗̭̩͎̪͍̼̺͍͇̳̰͔̼̻̳̗̻̱͇̤̱͚̬̦̘̰̩͓̼̫̪̳͚͇̥͖͑́̓͑̄̾͛̈́͛͂̈́̓̓̃̔͛̇͑̊͒̀̒̾̍͆̈́̄̌̂̔̅͊̌̎̽̿́͗̀̈͊̓͋̍̓̂̏̆̄̇͐̐́̓́̔̃̈́̈̑̈̄̓̐̾̈́̄͒̂͌̏̀͌͐͌̑̅͗̆̉̄͊̋̈́͘̚̕̕̚̚̕̕̚͘͜͜͝͠͝͝͠͝ͅţ̷̢̨̨̨̨̧̧̢̧̢̨̢̛̛̛̯̣͈͓̬̙̦̱̪̝̗̪̥̝̜̯̝̫̯̥̰͈̤̯̙̩̠̰͇̗̣͙͇͙̪̺̙͓͉͚̖̮͖͍̝̻̲̗̱̻̩̗̯͇͓̬̘͚̱͔̣̪̗̠͙̞̦̹̮̫̮̪͖̦̝͖͓̣̱͎̠͔͔̓̉̈̀̇̀͌̅̌̑͊͌̄̎̎͗̒̄̎͌̐̒͐͌̀̿̀͋̉͋̃̏́̈̇͒̅́͐̑̓̄̌͗̀̔̾̈̓͋̍͛̓̔͛̈̓̋̀̐́̉̌̐̓͊̑̌̏͛͐̓̈́̾̀̀̎͊͛̇̀̾́͘̕͘̚͘̕͜͠͝͝͠͠͠͠͝ͅͅͅ!̷̧̨̡̡̨̧̨̡̨̛̛̼̼̖̩̯̭͔͍̫̫̖̳̮̤͉̪̳̘̮̼͉̮͎̪̩͇̝̲͕̗̫̟͚̝͔͇͎̦̺͎̪͈̣̼̟̥̹̬̯̱̦̺̱̥͚͈̼̺͎̻̮̩̩̣͇͇͖̪̙̺̯͚͓͈͈̣̮͇̗̤̳̠̹̭̝̙̓̐́̾́̀͛̀̇̀̊̑̽͛̽̾́̎̏̃͒̈́͌͒̑̈̀͌͐̋̓̂͒͌̄͂̂͑͑̈́͌̽̍̍̂͋͗̔̓̿̀̆̀̽̆͐̅̊̅̇̈̈̀̀̐̍̋̈́̋̒̀͛̉̓̀̋̿̃̕̕̚̚̕̕̕̚̚͘̕͜͜͜͠͝͝͠͠͝͠͝ͅͅ");
      default:
        clearInterval(timer);
        break;
    }
    document.write("<br>");
    count++;
  }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<!-- It's more fun if you don't read the code first :D Spoilers ya know-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<a id="#trigger" href="#" onClick="yay();return false;">Click me fur sumtin awsum</a>

</html>
```

[I really hope the mods are asleep so they don't see the pony...](http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31400000/Random-MLP-pics-my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic-31481527-485-333.jpg) :P

Unrelated: Iframes don't work. Trying to style the text using e.g. text-align doesn't work.

Out of curiosity:

https://stackoverflow.com

So no, it's not like in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/721/conversation/like-in-chat) where the image pops up instead

What about questions on other sites?

[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)

As expected. I think it's broken on some sites though. Anyways, internal ones:

[A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/a-terms-of-service-update-restricting-companies-that-scrape-your-profile-informa)

work as well.

At **l**e*as*t it isn**'t** HT̾M͛ͥ͊̅̈́L ̃p̎̐̒ͮaͫ̄̌ͯr͋̿̍͊͊̅ͪs̏͌̆̈͌ͣ̐i͂́ͩ̚n̾ͮ̄̑̀̏̔ğ̐̎̽̆͊̚ ̀̂̿wi̫͎͉͚ͪͤͥ̿̀ͤͨ̓̈t̯̘̔̿͊̉ͤ̆́ĥ̪̺̙̗ͯ̃̈́̿̌ͩͥ̉ ̠̳̪̮̉̊̂r̵̦͉͔̹͔̝̪̘͎̜̬̗̦̣͎͚̈́ͯͨ́̒ͣͥ͆́̀̕͜ȩ̼̱̪̪̯̹͍̤̭̟̌ͯ̈̊͂ͥ̐̒ͩ̀ͧͅͅg̴̷̴̵̭͈̮̩̙͕̠̼ͫ͊̃ͫ̍̈͌̚̕e̷̛̛͇̜̠̖͈̳̖͍̥̻̭̫̻̎̂͋ͧ̇̓̑̑̾͗̋͗̽̓ͣ̐̕͡ͅx̸̢̦̻̖͇͓͍͕̻͙ͫ̎̾ͦͣ̋̽̊̊ͫ͐̀̚ O̧̪͎̖̜͎̠̻̩̳͓̪̭̻ͦ̅͌͂ͦͮ͗̄̆̏̈͗͛̚͜H̸̷̜͖̻ͨ͌̑͂ͬ͂̍͛͗́̎̏ͮ̋̿͐͗͜͞ͅ ̨̻̳͍̞͉̫̖̦̱̖ͫ̂̒̍ͪ́͛ͮ̚͟͜G̸̛͖̮͓̣͕̳̹̱̺̘͈̥͇̤̥͓̿̍͛ͩ̎͌̀ͭ̄ͩ͠ͅỎ̸̟͚͍̟͎̟͓̹̺͈͓̟̪ͫ͒́̾ͩ̍̈ͨͬ̏ͧͣͨ̏̐͆ͨ͜͢͝D̵̨̠̝̬̩̫̗̖̭̞̘͉̬͊ͭ͋̅͑̉̓ͤ́ͥͣͫͤͮ́ ͐͗̈ͩ̄ͦ͠͏̶̴͚̝̝͍̟̯͜İ̷̧̧̛̠̫̟͎̯͔̥̻̠̣͎̼̟̺́̾̎͊̚T̷̻̬̤̖̟̟̮̫̬̗͓͕̽̽̈ͤ͛͂́̅͒͢'̶̸̡̲̠̮̘͈̻̋̊̿̌̑̀S̡͒̓̏̄ͩ̏̎̔͗̒ͣͭ̾̉̚҉̶̼͓͉̰̰̫̼̭̣͙̤͖̮̱͇̣͞ ̨̥̲͔͔̞̘̜͈̤̼̿̔́̂ͩ̔̓̓̏͋̾̃ͨ̃͢͠ͅḦ̨̪͔̫̖̪̳̻̖̗̣͉ͥ̀͋͒̄̓ͯ̊̄͐̚̕͝͝T̴̸̵̩͓̭͖̜̈́̒ͪ̐̌͐ͭ͑M̜͖̩͚̣̜̙̗͚͙̣̜̮̟͙͐̂́ͯ̽́́ͭ͒͂͂̏̌ͦ͂ͬ͗͒̈́̕͟͠ͅL̸̡̡͕͉̬̜̤̙̮̱̟̹̼̲̪͇̲͍͇ͦ͌̎̽ͫͪ̾͂̔̋ͯ́ͅ ̧̯̲̲̹͉̘͕̘͉͛̊͐͆͊̓̔̈́̾̑͊̑̉͒͌ͯ̃ͦ͟P̸̡͈̺͈͕̤̠̞̫̞̳̩̘̙ͬ͌̋́̊̏͆͂͂̓̍͛ͪ̀͐ͩ́ͅA̷͖̭̟̫̣̩̝̞̙̳͖͈̗̜͈̩ͦ͊̊ͥͨ̎R̴̢͓̫̯̪̎ͤͤ͐̓̔̌̈̂̅̕͞S̷̛̤͚͈̪̿ͮ̑̍̌̈I̷̓̋̑̓̿͡҉̴͍̼̮̪͖͖͓̹̘̱̼̞͉͇ͅͅN͓̼̘͇͓̬̤̻̫͉̥̜̟͖̗͚̳͑́ͫ̿̅ͨ̌̍ͩͤ̌̐̔̾̏͘͞ͅḠ̶̴͈̳̣̟̪̰̎̌ͯ̒̌̆̄̔̉ͥ̐̐́ͅ ̶̶̞̝͍̗̳͎̪͈̫̳ͨͯͮͤ̀͌̒͗̈́ͮ̈́ͫ̚̕͜Ẁ̧̮̘͙͕̳̗̼̰͍̺̪͖͍̍̀͛ͥ̄̍ͯ̈́̚͢I̧̎̇̓̎̈́̂̄͏͏̢̻͙̗̦̤̰̪͚͎͓̝͍̙̩͚̙͓̮̫T̐ͭ̆͊̐̒͊ͦ̽͆̈͆̅́̚̚̚͏̣͕̗̮͎̭̙̤͇̭̼̬̠͖͓̟̣͉H͎̫̯̝͇̤͓̣ͤ̑͑̄ͮ͆ͣ͐͘͢͠ ̡̫̪͉̞̻̼̻̱̙̋̿͂̈ͯ̊͑͊̀͘͜R͑ͪ͛̌ͥͫ̋̍̅͗ͫ̿̌̚͝͏̳̟̭̲̹̻͘͡E̢̤̻̗̟̅͗ͨ̈̍ͩ̋̿͋̃ͨ̊̃̔̇͂͠G̷̡̓̾̊̍͛̃ͨ̓́͏̛̩̰͕͉͚̪Ěͫ̈̓ͯ͐̎̽ͯ̌̎̏͛̐̈́̆ͬͯ͏̩͚̦̹X̴̵͈̰̝̰̳͓̗͕̆ͦ̀̒̒̐͂͊͗̂͆̓ͥ͒̇̒̑̓͐͘͝!̵̷̡̮̲͎̰̖̻͎̳̳̻͉̯̩̰͙͙̝̑͂͐̈͗ͥ̔͛̍ͫ͛͐́̽̀̚͠ ͊ͫ̍̀̂ͩ͑ͦͥ̄̏̍͐̍҉͖̻̫̞̹͕̺̯͕͚̦͕̠̺ͅW̙͎͍̜͎̝̪̼̘̞̭͚̳̺͂̔͌͐̅̀͘E̗̣̮̩̥͔͎̲̦̪͚̮͌̑̀͗̈́͌͂̊͗͋̍̐͗̎̈́̃ͬ͐̀͡'̷̛̊͑͌ͭ͑͌͗ͭͮͩͨ̉̂́̚͏҉̤̥͈̼̝̠̫̥̗̥̮̝R̶̨̺̣̬̜̲͖̫̞͕̘̊ͨ̐̊̒̎ͬ̅̐̓ͅE̸ͪ̀̀̊̋͊͛ͬͥ̃̈͆͏̧҉͇̦̞̰̰̝̮̞͚̜̖̘̟̬ͅ ̴̢̧̛̫̹̬͍͎̰͇̲ͥ̓̈̒ͪḐ̖̤̣̱͓͕͑͂́̆̆̾̇͒͆̊̆͆̒ͭ͂̕͜͜͞Ò̪̝̺̰̦̫͈͓͇̻̞͌ͪͩ̓̉͠O̴̶̥̳̦̠̙͇̼̯̺̓̓ͬ̀ͩ́ͮ͛̌ͮͤ̀͠M̯̪̩̺ͫ̃͐̔̈́̿̋̌̌ͭ̓ͨ͒̿ͩ̇͒͟͡E̶̢̠̖̥͚̯͇̝͙̰̩̟̜̖̣͇̤ͥ͗̔̅̕D̶͖͚̩̲̖̩͍̪̄̎̓̿̈̔̀͘͜!̸̢ͥ̈́̌͐̅͒ͯ̓ͦ͐̇̽ͨ̄͠͏̨̻̠͈͕͖͍͔͉

How about the blog?

https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/02/08/information-architecture-navigating-stack-overflow-enterprise-stack-exchange-sites/

[Nope](https://mlpforums.com/uploads/post_images/img-3448907-1-fc,550x550,lemon.jpg).

z̷̢̢̢̨̨̡̨̢̡̢̢̛̛̮̦̩͖͚̝͍͎͓͙̯͍͓̞̪̭̺͈̦̱̺͉̞̰̳̘̜̱̰̬̥̗̞͓͎͖̦̪̦̠̳͖̥̪̤͚̮̠̫͈̠̭̩̼̘͔̤̤̖̘̭̖̹̯̪̤̤̣̦̼̮͖̦͇͙̗̜̻̗͇͖͔̫̟̥̮̖͎̭͔͉̣̣̳̻̪̜̯̱̫͉̭̤̦̗̞̠̤̭̩̰̯͓̯̳̝̗̠̗̝̻̫͇̻͇͎͈̖̤͖̝͙͙̗̯̤̯͎͙̈͗̌̓̈̎̀̌̔́̈͑̉̽͒͂̈́͌͐̂͐̓́̾̂̊̏͑͋̄̎̈́̍͆̿̅̓̂͒̅̈́̇̈̽̀́̏͒́̐̅́̔̿́́̌̌̆̍̇̈̄̈́̉̈́́̑̄͌͌̂̊̂̌̿̓̉̊͑̀̆͐͂̀̃͒̒͂̆̅͐͌́̄̽̓̍̃͋͑͛̾̍̋͌̌̓̌̅̂̊͐̊͋͌̑̋̅̇͑́̉̂̀͒͑̈̀̎͌͘̚̕͘̕͘̚̚̕͘̚͘͘͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅà̷̡̢͉̜̻̹͉̟̻̪͕̟̭̜̖̤͇̙͎̯̙͍̬̋̐̒̅͆͒̐̂̎́̾͛̀͒͌͑͠͠ͅl̸̡̧̢̨̢̢̢̧̧̨̨̨̢̧̨̨̡̡̨̡̧̨̛̛̗̠͙͓̘̲̤̭̦͎͉̞̥͎̻͖͍͎͔͖͕͍̹̼̩̤̩͓̘͍̘̺̫͈͓̞̠̩͖͈̝̖̼͚̤̥̗̹̙̣͉͎̞̘̥͇̣͖͍͕̮̗͍͇͙̻̬̺̯̙͓̰̫͓͍͈͖̗͙͎̜̦̪̥̰̜͕̳̜͉͕̮̻̺̭̜͖͎͓̻̳͈̻̖̫͎̲̫̼̫̙̠͉̪͕̜̟̭̩͕̳̟̺̠̮͖̟̭̘̦̦̜̪̠͉͙̟̘̭̥̪͚̲̺͕͉̰̬̯̰̯̠̦̄̍̏̈́͂̋͗͌̊͋͋̿̈́̐͛̊̎͋̑̐̀̈́̿̓͌̀͒͂̇͛̓̐̏́͐̈̌͒̒́̈́́̄͒̾̂̊̒̐̍̇̈́̊̊͌͑́̿̅͑́̐̅̊́͌̿̔͋̉̐̀͌̋̏̎̀̈́̔͗͋͐̑̒̚̕̕̚̕̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͠͝͝͝͠͝͝ͅģ̶̨̡̧̨̡̡̧̢̡̧̡̨̢̧̧̨̡̧̛̛̛̛̛̛̘̙̝͖̱̱̞͉̝̥̜̬̥̱̱̦͚̦̥̪̰͓̣͖̩̬͔̻͕̜̼̩̲̠̩̟̖͎̦͉͉̲̥͖̻̭̰̟͎̭͇̥̮̘̫͇̲̱̦̰̰̣̰̗̼̙̩̹̝̻̹͉͚̣̪̭̗̺͓̲͉͓͙̜̘̳̹̟̻̰̙̺̞͕͔̬̤͉͖̙͍̠͖̼̗̜̻̺͎̯͙̜̯̖̠͙̟͇̟̹̺̮̦̗̩̣͔͕̮̤͓̟̣̳̘̘͔͔̜͚͓͙̖̲̠͇̺̝̻̻͓̥̹̙̠̲͕̭̻̼͙͎̞̞̙̳̬̩͈͔̭̖̰͍̤̪͍͍̱̦̦͔̝̥̥̺͉͚͍̭̪̰̙̞̦̭̗͉̉̄̈́̌͋̋̀́̎͛̍̿̾̈̊̌̓̀̿͂͒͗̅̓͛̉͊̋̓͆̾̊̓̄̓͗́̀͛̓̃̀̓̏́͆͛̐̓̀́͆̌̏̄̈́͒̋̏̈́̌͒͌̄̓̈́͛̑̿͐͋̌̋́͒͂̒̑̈́̇͐̓̄̔̍̎͐͊͊́͋́̂̓͗̊͋̈́̋̿̇͊̇͒̉̃̌̃͂͗̋͌̏͑̉͋́̈̄͆̎͂͂̈̒̂͐̅̑̎̓̈́̈́̐̊͐̂̀̓͆͌̓͂̑̈́̈́̿̈́̔̑̎̓̋͆̉̓̍̐̄͊̅̍̃̆̿͌̎̊̓̈́͒̽͒͑̈̿̑̇͗̍̈̍̽̒̏̏̋̓̌̍͌̎̃̔͋͛̍̕͘̕͘̕̚̕̚̚͘̕̚̕̕̚͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͝͠͝͠͝͝͝͝͝͠͠͝͝͝ͅͅǫ̸̨̨̢̧̢̧̡̨̡̢̨̧̛̛̜̗͈̞̥̯͙̗̯͚̩̬̦̟̘̥̬̹̻̞̬̣̖̬͉̙̹̠͖͍͍͉̥̮̲̟̩̱̟̜̺̤̯̥͚̤͉̙̝̱̳̤̦̟̝͓̜̦̥͖̖͇̞̺̣͙̜̱̗͓͈͖̜͚̞͎͖̳͕̫̤͍̙̟̻͕͖̯̺͙͖̭͇̘̫̲̙̺͖͈͉͍͍͇̯̦̪̦̯̲̤͔̦̣͚̭̙̮̱̘̩̗̗̜̮̬̦̠̞̬̦͇̥̖̳̮̺̯͍͕̙͉̯̻̬̼͙̫̦͍͖̤̮̞̒̔̄͋̂͛̾̈́̏͗̀́̃̽̀̊́͗̐͆́̈̊̆̿́͑̄͑̾́͗̽̿̐͗̈́̎̑̍̑̐̀̏̓͗͑̒̂͂̐̀̃͋̀̂̏̃͛̽́̚͘͘͘͜͜͜͜͝͝͠͝ͅͅͅͅͅͅ

*cough*

Theoretically red text

Comment: Nice ones . . .

Answer (score 7):

Yeah I know I'm posting another answer. But I needed to, just like you needed this cat programmer meme:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

*test*ing <- Markdown `*test*ing`
**test**ing <- Markdown `**test**ing`
__test__ing <- Markdown `__test__ing`

*test*ing <- HTML `<i>test</i>ing`
**test**ing <- HTML `<b>test</b>ing`
***test***ing <- HTML `<b><i>test</i></b>ing`

if ac, does b get sterilized?
what about a < b and b > c?

dependency_links.txt

Comment: `… *p*=100 and *q* something else …` renders as “… *p*=100 and *q* something else …”

Comment: >this is a test

Comment: Do <!-- HTML comments --> work in comments?

Answer (score 6):

Why does `a     b` not render properly? (5 spaces between `a` and `b` in the source!)

But this works fine:

```
a     b
```

Comment: Because you've used inline code formatting, rather than block code formatting. Spaces are not respected in the former, but *are* respected in the latter it appears.

Comment: @Cody: It's the same in comments. I answered something like `sed 's/ /  /g'` to someone, so as to replace one space by two spaces. Figured out after that that the rendered command was kinda stupid.

Comment: Was thinking about starting a new thread, but found this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30020/167500, lost in so's limbo.

Comment: Looks like the spacing issue mentioned in this post has since been fixed.

Comment: @Steven: Indeed. It was still broken not long ago.

Answer (score 6):

http://so.mrozekma.com/yesno.png

Comment: [This should be flagged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110165/152657)

Comment: Should it be flagged? [It says whether or whether not to flag it here.](http://so.mrozekma.com/yesno.png)

Answer (score 6):

Test answer <kbd>CASTLE BUILDING TIME</kbd> <kbd>[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)</kbd>

asdfsgnrjgagblbfgjkadsbnjkbgljuawbgj d van gjksandvjlsldjkgfwbgasdjvn fjgbadmbgjskdbaglkjsbdfgTest answer <kbd>CASTLE BUILDING TIME</kbd> <kbd>[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)</kbd>

asdfsgnrjgagblbfgjkadsbnjkbgljuawbgj d van gjksandvjlsldjkgfwbgasdjvn fjgbadmbgjskdbaglkjsbdfgTest answer <kbd>CASTLE BUILDING TIME</kbd> <kbd>[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)</kbd>

asdfsgnrjgagblbfgjkadsbnjkbgljuawbgj d van gjksandvjlsldjkgfwbgasdjvn fjgbadmbgjskdbaglkjsbdfgTest answer <kbd>CASTLE BUILDING TIME</kbd> <kbd>[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)</kbd>

asdfsgnrjgagblbfgjkadsbnjkbgljuawbgj d van gjksandvjlsldjkgfwbgasdjvn fjgbadmbgjskdbaglkjsbdfg

rejriw b qg rbqguwbdvjrn vjrgrgaqfdvsfgr MOAR KEYBOARD GOODNESS

Using `<kbd>` now.  <kbd>sorry</kbd>

Using `<key>` now.  sorry

[Your approximate location http://shaquin.tk/projects/location/location.png](http://shaquin.tk/projects/location/location.png)

> checking disappearance!
>
> ## Done

<s>cutting my own words!</s>

hats are fun

Answer (score 6):

ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ಠ_ಠ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Comment: ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้ ಠ_ಠ ก็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็็ กิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิิ ก้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้้

Answer (score 6):

‽

‽
‽

￰￰￱￲￳ﳌ࿌ᄑ∢㌳䑄啕晦睷袈香ꪪ뮻쳌

```
NUL     SOH     STX     ETX     EOT     ENQ     ACK     BEL     BS  HT  LF  VT  FF  CR  SO  SI
0010    DLE     DC1     DC2     DC3     DC4     NAK     SYN     ETB     CAN     EM  SUB     ESC     FS  GS  RS  US
0020    SP  !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /
0030    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?
0040    @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
0050    P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z   [   \   ]   ^   _
0060    `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o
0070    p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }   ~   DEL
0080    PAD     HOP     BPH     NBH     IND     NEL     SSA     ESA     HTS     HTJ     VTS     PLD     PLU     RI  SS2     SS3
0090    DCS     PU1     PU2     STS     CCH     MW  SPA     EPA     SOS     SGCI    SCI     CSI     ST  OSC     PM  APC
00A0    NBSP    ¡   ¢   £   ¤   ¥   ¦   §   ¨   ©   ª   «   ¬   SHY     ®   ¯
00B0    °   ±   ²   ³   ´   µ   ¶   ·   ¸   ¹   º   »   ¼   ½   ¾   ¿
00C0    À   Á   Â   Ã   Ä   Å   Æ   Ç   È   É   Ê   Ë   Ì   Í   Î   Ï
00D0    Ð   Ñ   Ò   Ó   Ô   Õ   Ö   ×   Ø   Ù   Ú   Û   Ü   Ý   Þ   ß
00E0    à   á   â   ã   ä   å   æ   ç   è   é   ê   ë   ì   í   î   ï
00F0    ð   ñ   ò   ó   ô   õ   ö   ÷   ø   ù   ú   û   ü   ý   þ   ÿ
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0100    Ā   ā   Ă   ă   Ą   ą   Ć   ć   Ĉ   ĉ   Ċ   ċ   Č   č   Ď   ď
0110    Đ   đ   Ē   ē   Ĕ   ĕ   Ė   ė   Ę   ę   Ě   ě   Ĝ   ĝ   Ğ   ğ
0120    Ġ   ġ   Ģ   ģ   Ĥ   ĥ   Ħ   ħ   Ĩ   ĩ   Ī   ī   Ĭ   ĭ   Į   į
0130    İ   ı   Ĳ   ĳ   Ĵ   ĵ   Ķ   ķ   ĸ   Ĺ   ĺ   Ļ   ļ   Ľ   ľ   Ŀ
0140    ŀ   Ł   ł   Ń   ń   Ņ   ņ   Ň   ň   ŉ   Ŋ   ŋ   Ō   ō   Ŏ   ŏ
0150    Ő   ő   Œ   œ   Ŕ   ŕ   Ŗ   ŗ   Ř   ř   Ś   ś   Ŝ   ŝ   Ş   ş
0160    Š   š   Ţ   ţ   Ť   ť   Ŧ   ŧ   Ũ   ũ   Ū   ū   Ŭ   ŭ   Ů   ů
0170    Ű   ű   Ų   ų   Ŵ   ŵ   Ŷ   ŷ   Ÿ   Ź   ź   Ż   ż   Ž   ž   ſ
0180    ƀ   Ɓ   Ƃ   ƃ   Ƅ   ƅ   Ɔ   Ƈ   ƈ   Ɖ   Ɗ   Ƌ   ƌ   ƍ   Ǝ   Ə
0190    Ɛ   Ƒ   ƒ   Ɠ   Ɣ   ƕ   Ɩ   Ɨ   Ƙ   ƙ   ƚ   ƛ   Ɯ   Ɲ   ƞ   Ɵ
01A0    Ơ   ơ   Ƣ   ƣ   Ƥ   ƥ   Ʀ   Ƨ   ƨ   Ʃ   ƪ   ƫ   Ƭ   ƭ   Ʈ   Ư
01B0    ư   Ʊ   Ʋ   Ƴ   ƴ   Ƶ   ƶ   Ʒ   Ƹ   ƹ   ƺ   ƻ   Ƽ   ƽ   ƾ   ƿ
01C0    ǀ   ǁ   ǂ   ǃ   Ǆ   ǅ   ǆ   Ǉ   ǈ   ǉ   Ǌ   ǋ   ǌ   Ǎ   ǎ   Ǐ
01D0    ǐ   Ǒ   ǒ   Ǔ   ǔ   Ǖ   ǖ   Ǘ   ǘ   Ǚ   ǚ   Ǜ   ǜ   ǝ   Ǟ   ǟ
01E0    Ǡ   ǡ   Ǣ   ǣ   Ǥ   ǥ   Ǧ   ǧ   Ǩ   ǩ   Ǫ   ǫ   Ǭ   ǭ   Ǯ   ǯ
01F0    ǰ   Ǳ   ǲ   ǳ   Ǵ   ǵ   Ƕ   Ƿ   Ǹ   ǹ   Ǻ   ǻ   Ǽ   ǽ   Ǿ   ǿ
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0200    Ȁ   ȁ   Ȃ   ȃ   Ȅ   ȅ   Ȇ   ȇ   Ȉ   ȉ   Ȋ   ȋ   Ȍ   ȍ   Ȏ   ȏ
0210    Ȑ   ȑ   Ȓ   ȓ   Ȕ   ȕ   Ȗ   ȗ   Ș   ș   Ț   ț   Ȝ   ȝ   Ȟ   ȟ
0220    Ƞ   ȡ   Ȣ   ȣ   Ȥ   ȥ   Ȧ   ȧ   Ȩ   ȩ   Ȫ   ȫ   Ȭ   ȭ   Ȯ   ȯ
0230    Ȱ   ȱ   Ȳ   ȳ   ȴ   ȵ   ȶ   ȷ   ȸ   ȹ   Ⱥ   Ȼ   ȼ   Ƚ   Ⱦ   ȿ
0240    ɀ   Ɂ   ɂ   Ƀ   Ʉ   Ʌ   Ɇ   ɇ   Ɉ   ɉ   Ɋ   ɋ   Ɍ   ɍ   Ɏ   ɏ
0250    ɐ   ɑ   ɒ   ɓ   ɔ   ɕ   ɖ   ɗ   ɘ   ə   ɚ   ɛ   ɜ   ɝ   ɞ   ɟ
0260    ɠ   ɡ   ɢ   ɣ   ɤ   ɥ   ɦ   ɧ   ɨ   ɩ   ɪ   ɫ   ɬ   ɭ   ɮ   ɯ
0270    ɰ   ɱ   ɲ   ɳ   ɴ   ɵ   ɶ   ɷ   ɸ   ɹ   ɺ   ɻ   ɼ   ɽ   ɾ   ɿ
0280    ʀ   ʁ   ʂ   ʃ   ʄ   ʅ   ʆ   ʇ   ʈ   ʉ   ʊ   ʋ   ʌ   ʍ   ʎ   ʏ
0290    ʐ   ʑ   ʒ   ʓ   ʔ   ʕ   ʖ   ʗ   ʘ   ʙ   ʚ   ʛ   ʜ   ʝ   ʞ   ʟ
02A0    ʠ   ʡ   ʢ   ʣ   ʤ   ʥ   ʦ   ʧ   ʨ   ʩ   ʪ   ʫ   ʬ   ʭ   ʮ   ʯ
02B0    ʰ   ʱ   ʲ   ʳ   ʴ   ʵ   ʶ   ʷ   ʸ   ʹ   ʺ   ʻ   ʼ   ʽ   ʾ   ʿ
02C0    ˀ   ˁ   ˂   ˃   ˄   ˅   ˆ   ˇ   ˈ   ˉ   ˊ   ˋ   ˌ   ˍ   ˎ   ˏ
02D0    ː   ˑ   ˒   ˓   ˔   ˕   ˖   ˗   ˘   ˙   ˚   ˛   ˜   ˝   ˞   ˟
02E0    ˠ   ˡ   ˢ   ˣ   ˤ   ˥   ˦   ˧   ˨   ˩   ˪   ˫   ˬ   ˭   ˮ   ˯
02F0    ˰   ˱   ˲   ˳   ˴   ˵   ˶   ˷   ˸   ˹   ˺   ˻   ˼   ˽   ˾   ˿
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0300     ̀   ́   ̂   ̃   ̄   ̅   ̆   ̇   ̈   ̉   ̊   ̋   ̌   ̍   ̎   ̏
0310     ̐   ̑   ̒   ̓   ̔   ̕   ̖   ̗   ̘   ̙   ̚   ̛   ̜   ̝   ̞   ̟
0320     ̠   ̡   ̢   ̣   ̤   ̥   ̦   ̧   ̨   ̩   ̪   ̫   ̬   ̭   ̮   ̯
0330     ̰   ̱   ̲   ̳   ̴   ̵   ̶   ̷   ̸   ̹   ̺   ̻   ̼   ̽   ̾   ̿
0340     ̀   ́   ͂   ̓   ̈́   ͅ   ͆   ͇   ͈   ͉   ͊   ͋   ͌   ͍   ͎  CGJ
0350     ͐   ͑   ͒   ͓   ͔   ͕   ͖   ͗   ͘   ͙   ͚   ͛   ͜   ͝   ͞   ͟
0360     ͠   ͡   ͢   ͣ   ͤ   ͥ   ͦ   ͧ   ͨ   ͩ   ͪ   ͫ   ͬ   ͭ   ͮ   ͯ
0370    Ͱ   ͱ   Ͳ   ͳ   ʹ   ͵   Ͷ   ͷ           ͺ   ͻ   ͼ   ͽ   ;    
0380                    ΄   ΅   Ά   ·   Έ   Ή   Ί       Ό       Ύ   Ώ
0390    ΐ   Α   Β   Γ   Δ   Ε   Ζ   Η   Θ   Ι   Κ   Λ   Μ   Ν   Ξ   Ο
03A0    Π   Ρ       Σ   Τ   Υ   Φ   Χ   Ψ   Ω   Ϊ   Ϋ   ά   έ   ή   ί
03B0    ΰ   α   β   γ   δ   ε   ζ   η   θ   ι   κ   λ   μ   ν   ξ   ο
03C0    π   ρ   ς   σ   τ   υ   φ   χ   ψ   ω   ϊ   ϋ   ό   ύ   ώ   Ϗ
03D0    ϐ   ϑ   ϒ   ϓ   ϔ   ϕ   ϖ   ϗ   Ϙ   ϙ   Ϛ   ϛ   Ϝ   ϝ   Ϟ   ϟ
03E0    Ϡ   ϡ   Ϣ   ϣ   Ϥ   ϥ   Ϧ   ϧ   Ϩ   ϩ   Ϫ   ϫ   Ϭ   ϭ   Ϯ   ϯ
03F0    ϰ   ϱ   ϲ   ϳ   ϴ   ϵ   ϶   Ϸ   ϸ   Ϲ   Ϻ   ϻ   ϼ   Ͻ   Ͼ   Ͽ
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0400    Ѐ   Ё   Ђ   Ѓ   Є   Ѕ   І   Ї   Ј   Љ   Њ   Ћ   Ќ   Ѝ   Ў   Џ
0410    А   Б   В   Г   Д   Е   Ж   З   И   Й   К   Л   М   Н   О   П
0420    Р   С   Т   У   Ф   Х   Ц   Ч   Ш   Щ   Ъ   Ы   Ь   Э   Ю   Я
0430    а   б   в   г   д   е   ж   з   и   й   к   л   м   н   о   п
0440    р   с   т   у   ф   х   ц   ч   ш   щ   ъ   ы   ь   э   ю   я
0450    ѐ   ё   ђ   ѓ   є   ѕ   і   ї   ј   љ   њ   ћ   ќ   ѝ   ў   џ
0460    Ѡ   ѡ   Ѣ   ѣ   Ѥ   ѥ   Ѧ   ѧ   Ѩ   ѩ   Ѫ   ѫ   Ѭ   ѭ   Ѯ   ѯ
0470    Ѱ   ѱ   Ѳ   ѳ   Ѵ   ѵ   Ѷ   ѷ   Ѹ   ѹ   Ѻ   ѻ   Ѽ   ѽ   Ѿ   ѿ
0480    Ҁ   ҁ   ҂    ҃   ҄   ҅   ҆   ҇   ҈   ҉  Ҋ   ҋ   Ҍ   ҍ   Ҏ   ҏ
0490    Ґ   ґ   Ғ   ғ   Ҕ   ҕ   Җ   җ   Ҙ   ҙ   Қ   қ   Ҝ   ҝ   Ҟ   ҟ
04A0    Ҡ   ҡ   Ң   ң   Ҥ   ҥ   Ҧ   ҧ   Ҩ   ҩ   Ҫ   ҫ   Ҭ   ҭ   Ү   ү
04B0    Ұ   ұ   Ҳ   ҳ   Ҵ   ҵ   Ҷ   ҷ   Ҹ   ҹ   Һ   һ   Ҽ   ҽ   Ҿ   ҿ
04C0    Ӏ   Ӂ   ӂ   Ӄ   ӄ   Ӆ   ӆ   Ӈ   ӈ   Ӊ   ӊ   Ӌ   ӌ   Ӎ   ӎ   ӏ
04D0    Ӑ   ӑ   Ӓ   ӓ   Ӕ   ӕ   Ӗ   ӗ   Ә   ә   Ӛ   ӛ   Ӝ   ӝ   Ӟ   ӟ
04E0    Ӡ   ӡ   Ӣ   ӣ   Ӥ   ӥ   Ӧ   ӧ   Ө   ө   Ӫ   ӫ   Ӭ   ӭ   Ӯ   ӯ
04F0    Ӱ   ӱ   Ӳ   ӳ   Ӵ   ӵ   Ӷ   ӷ   Ӹ   ӹ   Ӻ   ӻ   Ӽ   ӽ   Ӿ   ӿ
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0500    Ԁ   ԁ   Ԃ   ԃ   Ԅ   ԅ   Ԇ   ԇ   Ԉ   ԉ   Ԋ   ԋ   Ԍ   ԍ   Ԏ   ԏ
0510    Ԑ   ԑ   Ԓ   ԓ   Ԕ   ԕ   Ԗ   ԗ   Ԙ   ԙ   Ԛ   ԛ   Ԝ   ԝ   Ԟ   ԟ
0520    Ԡ   ԡ   Ԣ   ԣ   Ԥ   ԥ   Ԧ   ԧ                                
0530        Ա   Բ   Գ   Դ   Ե   Զ   Է   Ը   Թ   Ժ   Ի   Լ   Խ   Ծ   Կ
0540    Հ   Ձ   Ղ   Ճ   Մ   Յ   Ն   Շ   Ո   Չ   Պ   Ջ   Ռ   Ս   Վ   Տ
0550    Ր   Ց   Ւ   Փ   Ք   Օ   Ֆ            ՙ   ՚  ՛   ՜   ՝   ՞   ՟
0560        ա   բ   գ   դ   ե   զ   է   ը   թ   ժ   ի   լ   խ   ծ   կ
0570    հ   ձ   ղ   ճ   մ   յ   ն   շ   ո   չ   պ   ջ   ռ   ս   վ   տ
0580    ր   ց   ւ   փ   ք   օ   ֆ   և       ։    ֊                  ֏
0590         ֑   ֒   ֓   ֔   ֕   ֖   ֗   ֘   ֙   ֚   ֛   ֜   ֝   ֞   ֟
05A0     ֠   ֡   ֢   ֣   ֤   ֥   ֦   ֧   ֨   ֩   ֪   ֫   ֬   ֭   ֮   ֯
05B0     ְ   ֱ   ֲ   ֳ   ִ   ֵ   ֶ   ַ   ָ   ֹ   ֺ   ֻ   ּ   ֽ  ־    ֿ
05C0    ׀    ׁ   ׂ  ׃    ׄ   ׅ  ׆    ׇ                               
05D0    א   ב   ג   ד   ה   ו   ז   ח   ט   י   ך   כ   ל   ם   מ   ן
05E0    נ   ס   ע   ף   פ   ץ   צ   ק   ר   ש   ת                    
05F0    װ   ױ   ײ   ׳   ״                                            
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0600    ؀   ؁   ؂   ؃   ؄       ؆   ؇   ؈   ؉   ؊   ؋   ،   ؍   ؎   ؏
0610     ؐ   ؑ   ؒ   ؓ   ؔ   ؕ   ؖ   ؗ   ؘ   ؙ   ؚ  ؛           ؞   ؟
0620    ؠ   ء   آ   أ   ؤ   إ   ئ   ا   ب   ة   ت   ث   ج   ح   خ   د
0630    ذ   ر   ز   س   ش   ص   ض   ط   ظ   ع   غ   ػ   ؼ   ؽ   ؾ   ؿ
0640    ـ   ف   ق   ك   ل   م   ن   ه   و   ى   ي    ً   ٌ   ٍ   َ   ُ
0650     ِ   ّ   ْ   ٓ   ٔ   ٕ   ٖ   ٗ   ٘   ٙ   ٚ   ٛ   ٜ   ٝ   ٞ   ٟ
0660    ٠   ١   ٢   ٣   ٤   ٥   ٦   ٧   ٨   ٩   ٪   ٫   ٬   ٭   ٮ   ٯ
0670     ٰ  ٱ   ٲ   ٳ   ٴ   ٵ   ٶ   ٷ   ٸ   ٹ   ٺ   ٻ   ټ   ٽ   پ   ٿ
0680    ڀ   ځ   ڂ   ڃ   ڄ   څ   چ   ڇ   ڈ   ډ   ڊ   ڋ   ڌ   ڍ   ڎ   ڏ
0690    ڐ   ڑ   ڒ   ړ   ڔ   ڕ   ږ   ڗ   ژ   ڙ   ښ   ڛ   ڜ   ڝ   ڞ   ڟ
06A0    ڠ   ڡ   ڢ   ڣ   ڤ   ڥ   ڦ   ڧ   ڨ   ک   ڪ   ګ   ڬ   ڭ   ڮ   گ
06B0    ڰ   ڱ   ڲ   ڳ   ڴ   ڵ   ڶ   ڷ   ڸ   ڹ   ں   ڻ   ڼ   ڽ   ھ   ڿ
06C0    ۀ   ہ   ۂ   ۃ   ۄ   ۅ   ۆ   ۇ   ۈ   ۉ   ۊ   ۋ   ی   ۍ   ێ   ۏ
06D0    ې   ۑ   ے   ۓ   ۔   ە    ۖ   ۗ   ۘ   ۙ   ۚ   ۛ   ۜ  ۝   ۞    ۟
06E0     ۠   ۡ   ۢ   ۣ   ۤ  ۥ   ۦ    ۧ   ۨ  ۩    ۪   ۫   ۬   ۭ  ۮ   ۯ
06F0    ۰   ۱   ۲   ۳   ۴   ۵   ۶   ۷   ۸   ۹   ۺ   ۻ   ۼ   ۽   ۾   ۿ
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0700    ܀   ܁   ܂   ܃   ܄   ܅   ܆   ܇   ܈   ܉   ܊   ܋   ܌   ܍        ܏
0710    ܐ   ܑ   ܒ   ܓ   ܔ   ܕ   ܖ   ܗ   ܘ   ܙ   ܚ   ܛ   ܜ   ܝ   ܞ   ܟ
0720    ܠ   ܡ   ܢ   ܣ   ܤ   ܥ   ܦ   ܧ   ܨ   ܩ   ܪ   ܫ   ܬ   ܭ   ܮ   ܯ
0730    ܰ   ܱ   ܲ   ܳ   ܴ   ܵ   ܶ   ܷ   ܸ   ܹ   ܺ   ܻ   ܼ   ܽ   ܾ   ܿ
0740    ݀   ݁   ݂   ݃   ݄   ݅   ݆   ݇   ݈   ݉   ݊           ݍ   ݎ   ݏ
0750    ݐ   ݑ   ݒ   ݓ   ݔ   ݕ   ݖ   ݗ   ݘ   ݙ   ݚ   ݛ   ݜ   ݝ   ݞ   ݟ
0760    ݠ   ݡ   ݢ   ݣ   ݤ   ݥ   ݦ   ݧ   ݨ   ݩ   ݪ   ݫ   ݬ   ݭ   ݮ   ݯ
0770    ݰ   ݱ   ݲ   ݳ   ݴ   ݵ   ݶ   ݷ   ݸ   ݹ   ݺ   ݻ   ݼ   ݽ   ݾ   ݿ
0780    ހ   ށ   ނ   ރ   ބ   ޅ   ކ   އ   ވ   މ   ފ   ދ   ތ   ލ   ގ   ޏ
0790    ސ   ޑ   ޒ   ޓ   ޔ   ޕ   ޖ   ޗ   ޘ   ޙ   ޚ   ޛ   ޜ   ޝ   ޞ   ޟ
07A0    ޠ   ޡ   ޢ   ޣ   ޤ   ޥ    ަ   ާ   ި   ީ   ު   ޫ   ެ   ޭ   ޮ   ޯ
07B0     ް  ޱ                                                        
07C0    ߀   ߁   ߂   ߃   ߄   ߅   ߆   ߇   ߈   ߉   ߊ   ߋ   ߌ   ߍ   ߎ   ߏ
07D0    ߐ   ߑ   ߒ   ߓ   ߔ   ߕ   ߖ   ߗ   ߘ   ߙ   ߚ   ߛ   ߜ   ߝ   ߞ   ߟ
07E0    ߠ   ߡ   ߢ   ߣ   ߤ   ߥ   ߦ   ߧ   ߨ   ߩ   ߪ    ߫   ߬   ߭   ߮   ߯
07F0     ߰   ߱   ߲   ߳  ߴ   ߵ   ߶   ߷   ߸   ߹   ߺ                    
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0800    ࠀ   ࠁ   ࠂ   ࠃ   ࠄ   ࠅ   ࠆ   ࠇ   ࠈ   ࠉ   ࠊ   ࠋ   ࠌ   ࠍ   ࠎ   ࠏ
0810    ࠐ   ࠑ   ࠒ   ࠓ   ࠔ   ࠕ   ࠖ   ࠗ   ࠘   ࠙   ࠚ   ࠛ   ࠜ   ࠝ   ࠞ   ࠟ
0820    ࠠ   ࠡ   ࠢ   ࠣ   ࠤ   ࠥ   ࠦ   ࠧ   ࠨ   ࠩ   ࠪ   ࠫ   ࠬ   ࠭        
0830    ࠰   ࠱   ࠲   ࠳   ࠴   ࠵   ࠶   ࠷   ࠸   ࠹   ࠺   ࠻   ࠼   ࠽   ࠾    
0840    ࡀ   ࡁ   ࡂ   ࡃ   ࡄ   ࡅ   ࡆ   ࡇ   ࡈ   ࡉ   ࡊ   ࡋ   ࡌ   ࡍ   ࡎ   ࡏ
0850    ࡐ   ࡑ   ࡒ   ࡓ   ࡔ   ࡕ   ࡖ   ࡗ   ࡘ   ࡙   ࡚   ࡛           ࡞    
0860                                                                 
0870                                                                 
0880                                                                 
0890                                                                 
08A0    ࢠ       ࢢ   ࢣ   ࢤ   ࢥ   ࢦ   ࢧ   ࢨ   ࢩ   ࢪ   ࢫ   ࢬ            
08B0                                                                 
08C0                                                                 
08D0                                                                 
08E0                    ࣤ   ࣥ   ࣦ   ࣧ   ࣨ   ࣩ   ࣪   ࣫   ࣬   ࣭   ࣮   ࣯
08F0    ࣰ   ࣱ   ࣲ   ࣳ   ࣴ   ࣵ   ࣶ   ࣷ   ࣸ   ࣹ   ࣺ   ࣻ   ࣼ   ࣽ   ࣾ    
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0900    ऀ   ँ   ं   ः   ऄ   अ   आ   इ   ई   उ   ऊ   ऋ   ऌ   ऍ   ऎ   ए
0910    ऐ   ऑ   ऒ   ओ   औ   क   ख   ग   घ   ङ   च   छ   ज   झ   ञ   ट
0920    ठ   ड   ढ   ण   त   थ   द   ध   न   ऩ   प   फ   ब   भ   म   य
0930    र   ऱ   ल   ळ   ऴ   व   श   ष   स   ह   ऺ   ऻ   ़   ऽ   ा   ि
0940    ी   ु   ू   ृ   ॄ   ॅ   ॆ   े   ै   ॉ   ॊ   ो   ौ   ्   ॎ   ॏ
0950    ॐ   ॑   ॒   ॓   ॔   ॕ   ॖ   ॗ   क़   ख़   ग़   ज़   ड़   ढ़   फ़   य़
0960    ॠ   ॡ   ॢ   ॣ   ।   ॥   ०   १   २   ३   ४   ५   ६   ७   ८   ९
0970    ॰   ॱ   ॲ   ॳ   ॴ   ॵ   ॶ   ॷ       ॹ   ॺ   ॻ   ॼ   ॽ   ॾ   ॿ
0980        ঁ   ং   ঃ       অ   আ   ই   ঈ   উ   ঊ   ঋ   ঌ           এ
0990    ঐ           ও   ঔ   ক   খ   গ   ঘ   ঙ   চ   ছ   জ   ঝ   ঞ   ট
09A0    ঠ   ড   ঢ   ণ   ত   থ   দ   ধ   ন       প   ফ   ব   ভ   ম   য
09B0    র       ল               শ   ষ   স   হ           ়   ঽ   া   ি
09C0    ী   ু   ূ   ৃ   ৄ           ে   ৈ           ো   ৌ   ্   ৎ    
09D0                                ৗ                   ড়   ঢ়       য়
09E0    ৠ   ৡ   ৢ   ৣ           ০   ১   ২   ৩   ৪   ৫   ৬   ৭   ৮   ৯
09F0    ৰ   ৱ   ৲   ৳   ৴   ৵   ৶   ৷   ৸   ৹   ৺   ৻                
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0A00         ਁ  ਂ   ਃ       ਅ   ਆ   ਇ   ਈ   ਉ   ਊ                   ਏ
0A10    ਐ           ਓ   ਔ   ਕ   ਖ   ਗ   ਘ   ਙ   ਚ   ਛ   ਜ   ਝ   ਞ   ਟ
0A20    ਠ   ਡ   ਢ   ਣ   ਤ   ਥ   ਦ   ਧ   ਨ       ਪ   ਫ   ਬ   ਭ   ਮ   ਯ
0A30    ਰ       ਲ   ਲ਼       ਵ   ਸ਼       ਸ   ਹ           ਼       ਾ   ਿ
0A40    ੀ   ੁ   ੂ                   ੇ   ੈ           ੋ   ੌ   ੍        
0A50         ੑ                              ਖ਼   ਗ਼   ਜ਼   ੜ       ਫ਼    
0A60                            ੦   ੧   ੨   ੩   ੪   ੫   ੬   ੭   ੮   ੯
0A70    ੰ   ੱ   ੲ   ੳ   ੴ    ੵ                                       
0A80        ઁ   ં   ઃ       અ   આ   ઇ   ઈ   ઉ   ઊ   ઋ   ઌ   ઍ       એ
0A90    ઐ   ઑ       ઓ   ઔ   ક   ખ   ગ   ઘ   ઙ   ચ   છ   જ   ઝ   ઞ   ટ
0AA0    ઠ   ડ   ઢ   ણ   ત   થ   દ   ધ   ન       પ   ફ   બ   ભ   મ   ય
0AB0    ર       લ   ળ       વ   શ   ષ   સ   હ           ઼   ઽ   ા   િ
0AC0    ી   ુ   ૂ   ૃ   ૄ   ૅ       ે   ૈ   ૉ       ો   ૌ   ્        
0AD0    ૐ                                                            
0AE0    ૠ   ૡ    ૢ   ૣ          ૦   ૧   ૨   ૩   ૪   ૫   ૬   ૭   ૮   ૯
0AF0    ૰   ૱                                                        
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0B00         ଁ  ଂ   ଃ       ଅ   ଆ   ଇ   ଈ   ଉ   ଊ   ଋ   ଌ           ଏ
0B10    ଐ           ଓ   ଔ   କ   ଖ   ଗ   ଘ   ଙ   ଚ   ଛ   ଜ   ଝ   ଞ   ଟ
0B20    ଠ   ଡ   ଢ   ଣ   ତ   ଥ   ଦ   ଧ   ନ       ପ   ଫ   ବ   ଭ   ମ   ଯ
0B30    ର       ଲ   ଳ       ଵ   ଶ   ଷ   ସ   ହ            ଼  ଽ   ା    ି
0B40    ୀ    ୁ   ୂ   ୃ   ୄ          େ   ୈ           ୋ   ୌ    ୍       
0B50                             ୖ  ୗ                   ଡ଼   ଢ଼       ୟ
0B60    ୠ   ୡ    ୢ   ୣ          ୦   ୧   ୨   ୩   ୪   ୫   ୬   ୭   ୮   ୯
0B70    ୰   ୱ   ୲   ୳   ୴   ୵   ୶   ୷                                
0B80            ஂ   ஃ       அ   ஆ   இ   ஈ   உ   ஊ               எ   ஏ
0B90    ஐ       ஒ   ஓ   ஔ   க               ங   ச       ஜ       ஞ   ட
0BA0                ண   த               ந   ன   ப               ம   ய
0BB0    ர   ற   ல   ள   ழ   வ   ஶ   ஷ   ஸ   ஹ                   ா   ி
0BC0    ீ   ு   ூ               ெ   ே   ை       ொ   ோ   ௌ   ்        
0BD0    ௐ                           ௗ                                
0BE0                            ௦   ௧   ௨   ௩   ௪   ௫   ௬   ௭   ௮   ௯
0BF0    ௰   ௱   ௲   ௳   ௴   ௵   ௶   ௷   ௸   ௹   ௺                    
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0C00        ఁ   ం   ః       అ   ఆ   ఇ   ఈ   ఉ   ఊ   ఋ   ఌ       ఎ   ఏ
0C10    ఐ       ఒ   ఓ   ఔ   క   ఖ   గ   ఘ   ఙ   చ   ఛ   జ   ఝ   ఞ   ట
0C20    ఠ   డ   ఢ   ణ   త   థ   ద   ధ   న       ప   ఫ   బ   భ   మ   య
0C30    ర   ఱ   ల   ళ       వ   శ   ష   స   హ               ఽ   ా   ి
0C40    ీ   ు   ూ   ృ   ౄ       ె   ే   ై       ొ   ో   ౌ   ్        
0C50                        ౕ   ౖ       ౘ   ౙ                        
0C60    ౠ   ౡ    ౢ   ౣ          ౦   ౧   ౨   ౩   ౪   ౫   ౬   ౭   ౮   ౯
0C70                                    ౸   ౹   ౺   ౻   ౼   ౽   ౾   ౿
0C80            ಂ   ಃ       ಅ   ಆ   ಇ   ಈ   ಉ   ಊ   ಋ   ಌ       ಎ   ಏ
0C90    ಐ       ಒ   ಓ   ಔ   ಕ   ಖ   ಗ   ಘ   ಙ   ಚ   ಛ   ಜ   ಝ   ಞ   ಟ
0CA0    ಠ   ಡ   ಢ   ಣ   ತ   ಥ   ದ   ಧ   ನ       ಪ   ಫ   ಬ   ಭ   ಮ   ಯ
0CB0    ರ   ಱ   ಲ   ಳ       ವ   ಶ   ಷ   ಸ   ಹ            ಼  ಽ   ಾ   ಿ
0CC0    ೀ   ು   ೂ   ೃ   ೄ       ೆ   ೇ   ೈ       ೊ   ೋ   ೌ   ್        
0CD0                        ೕ   ೖ                               ೞ    
0CE0    ೠ   ೡ    ೢ   ೣ          ೦   ೧   ೨   ೩   ೪   ೫   ೬   ೭   ೮   ೯
0CF0        ೱ   ೲ                                                    
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0D00            ം   ഃ       അ   ആ   ഇ   ഈ   ഉ   ഊ   ഋ   ഌ       എ   ഏ
0D10    ഐ       ഒ   ഓ   ഔ   ക   ഖ   ഗ   ഘ   ങ   ച   ഛ   ജ   ഝ   ഞ   ട
0D20    ഠ   ഡ   ഢ   ണ   ത   ഥ   ദ   ധ   ന   ഩ   പ   ഫ   ബ   ഭ   മ   യ
0D30    ര   റ   ല   ള   ഴ   വ   ശ   ഷ   സ   ഹ   ഺ           ഽ   ാ   ി
0D40    ീ   ു   ൂ   ൃ   ൄ       െ   േ   ൈ       ൊ   ോ   ൌ   ്   ൎ    
0D50                                ൗ                                
0D60    ൠ   ൡ    ൢ   ൣ          ൦   ൧   ൨   ൩   ൪   ൫   ൬   ൭   ൮   ൯
0D70    ൰   ൱   ൲   ൳   ൴   ൵               ൹   ൺ   ൻ   ർ   ൽ   ൾ   ൿ
0D80            ං   ඃ       අ   ආ   ඇ   ඈ   ඉ   ඊ   උ   ඌ   ඍ   ඎ   ඏ
0D90    ඐ   එ   ඒ   ඓ   ඔ   ඕ   ඖ               ක   ඛ   ග   ඝ   ඞ   ඟ
0DA0    ච   ඡ   ජ   ඣ   ඤ   ඥ   ඦ   ට   ඨ   ඩ   ඪ   ණ   ඬ   ත   ථ   ද
0DB0    ධ   න       ඳ   ප   ඵ   බ   භ   ම   ඹ   ය   ර       ල        
0DC0    ව   ශ   ෂ   ස   හ   ළ   ෆ               ්                   ා
0DD0    ැ   ෑ   ි   ී   ු       ූ       ෘ   ෙ   ේ   ෛ   ො   ෝ   ෞ   ෟ
0DE0                                                                 
0DF0            ෲ   ෳ   ෴                                            
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0E00        ก   ข   ฃ   ค   ฅ   ฆ   ง   จ   ฉ   ช   ซ   ฌ   ญ   ฎ   ฏ
0E10    ฐ   ฑ   ฒ   ณ   ด   ต   ถ   ท   ธ   น   บ   ป   ผ   ฝ   พ   ฟ
0E20    ภ   ม   ย   ร   ฤ   ล   ฦ   ว   ศ   ษ   ส   ห   ฬ   อ   ฮ   ฯ
0E30    ะ   ั   า   ำ   ิ   ี   ึ   ื   ุ   ู   ฺ                   ฿
0E40    เ   แ   โ   ใ   ไ   ๅ   ๆ   ็   ่   ้   ๊   ๋   ์   ํ   ๎   ๏
0E50    ๐   ๑   ๒   ๓   ๔   ๕   ๖   ๗   ๘   ๙   ๚   ๛                
0E60                                                                 
0E70                                                                 
0E80        ກ   ຂ       ຄ           ງ   ຈ       ຊ           ຍ        
0E90                    ດ   ຕ   ຖ   ທ       ນ   ບ   ປ   ຜ   ຝ   ພ   ຟ
0EA0        ມ   ຢ   ຣ       ລ       ວ           ສ   ຫ       ອ   ຮ   ຯ
0EB0    ະ   ັ   າ   ຳ   ິ   ີ   ຶ   ື   ຸ   ູ       ົ   ຼ   ຽ        
0EC0    ເ   ແ   ໂ   ໃ   ໄ       ໆ       ່   ້   ໊   ໋   ໌   ໍ        
0ED0    ໐   ໑   ໒   ໓   ໔   ໕   ໖   ໗   ໘   ໙           ໜ   ໝ   ໞ   ໟ
0EE0                                                                 
0EF0                                                                 
U+  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F
0F00    ༀ   ༁   ༂   ༃   ༄   ༅   ༆   ༇   ༈   ༉   ༊   ་   ༌   །   ༎   ༏
0F10    ༐   ༑   ༒   ༓   ༔   ༕   ༖   ༗   ༘   ༙   ༚   ༛   ༜   ༝   ༞   ༟
0F20    ༠   ༡   ༢   ༣   ༤   ༥   ༦   ༧   ༨   ༩   ༪   ༫   ༬   ༭   ༮   ༯
0F30    ༰   ༱   ༲   ༳   ༴   ༵   ༶   ༷   ༸   ༹   ༺   ༻   ༼   ༽   ༾   ༿
0F40    ཀ   ཁ   ག   གྷ   ང   ཅ   ཆ   ཇ       ཉ   ཊ   ཋ   ཌ   ཌྷ   ཎ   ཏ
0F50    ཐ   ད   དྷ   ན   པ   ཕ   བ   བྷ   མ   ཙ   ཚ   ཛ   ཛྷ   ཝ   ཞ   ཟ
0F60    འ   ཡ   ར   ལ   ཤ   ཥ   ས   ཧ   ཨ   ཀྵ   ཪ   ཫ   ཬ            
0F70        ཱ   ི   ཱི   ུ   ཱུ   ྲྀ   ཷ   ླྀ   ཹ   ེ   ཻ   ོ   ཽ   ཾ   ཿ
0F80    ྀ   ཱྀ   ྂ   ྃ   ྄   ྅   ྆   ྇   ྈ   ྉ   ྊ   ྋ   ྌ   ྍ   ྎ   ྏ
0F90    ྐ   ྑ   ྒ   ྒྷ   ྔ   ྕ   ྖ   ྗ       ྙ   ྚ   ྛ   ྜ   ྜྷ   ྞ   ྟ
0FA0    ྠ   ྡ   ྡྷ   ྣ   ྤ   ྥ   ྦ   ྦྷ   ྨ   ྩ   ྪ   ྫ   ྫྷ   ྭ   ྮ   ྯ
0FB0    ྰ   ྱ   ྲ   ླ   ྴ   ྵ   ྶ   ྷ   ྸ   ྐྵ   ྺ   ྻ   ྼ       ྾   ྿
0FC0    ࿀   ࿁   ࿂   ࿃   ࿄   ࿅   ࿆   ࿇   ࿈   ࿉   ࿊   ࿋   ࿌       ࿎   ࿏
0FD0    ࿐   ࿑   ࿒   ࿓   ࿔   ࿕   ࿖   ࿗   ࿘   ࿙   ࿚                    
0FE0                                                                 
0FF0
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `<blockquote>` gives you output like this (overflow)

> std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st,

Using `<Blockquote>` with single enter gives you output with auto-wrap (Here **B** is capital in `<Blockquote>`)

> 

std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > > const&)': ogrewidget.cpp:(.text._ZNSt8_Rb_treeISsSt4pairIKSsSsESt10_Select1stIS2_ESt4lessISsEN4Ogre12STLAllocatorIS2_NS7_22CategorisedAllocPolicyILNS7_14MemoryCategoryE0EEEEEE10_M_insert_EPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseSG_RKS2_[std::_Rb_tree, std::allocator >, std::pair, std::allocator > const, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >, std::_Select1st,

Comment: backtick escape (`\`\\`\``)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: this is possible: `SELECT '20' FROM 'table'`

Comment: `SELECT \`20\` FROM \`table\``

Comment: `huh` (10chars)

Answer (score 6):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>


<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>test</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: This is really weird (click edit to see).

Comment: @WesleyMurch I know, `<kbd>` does not have a limit to how many `<sup>`s it can handle :D

Comment: @Doorknob: Lol, when my answer is directly above yours, all the [test] buttons prevent me from being able to click edit on my *own* post :P

Answer (score 6):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ## THIS IS A REALLY BIG BUTTON!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a robot! Beep beep beep. Please gimme some rep.

I can detect spam, report it, and dance badly.

Comment: [No rep for you!](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: I'm arranging for that one, @Nathan.

Comment: @Undo you're a *savage*.

Comment: @Nathan unless there is a bounty awarded here.

Answer (score 6):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer rejected][1].

[removed bits that were breaking the page as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361565/208518)]

Comment: Does this affect comments too? (No.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy Grab your mobile phone and view this question on a browser (Not the SE app!)

Comment: On the mobile site after the question everything changed to this `code` font. Why?

Comment: **ATRIBUTION TO MY SIMILAR ANSWER WOULD HAVE BEEN NICE (EVEN THOUGH NOT REQUIRED):  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/297160#297160**

Comment: How come all the font after this answer on mobile is in `this font`?

Comment: wtf just happened here o.o

Comment: this is a test to see how the question title shows if you paste the "long" url: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network but they do not for the "short" url: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/209901

Answer (score 6):

## This is a heading!

### This is also a heading! (albeit a smaller one)

#### ...You get the point.

**Let's get some bold text in here.**

**Maybe some more?**

*Italicized text. Use for emphasis.*

*Markdown offers many gifts!*

<s>Text with a line through it.</s>

[Here's a link.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) (It's also a rickroll.)

[image]

[image: Some title text for you.]

> Here's some text highlighted in yellow.

> Here's some hidden text highlighted in yellow!

`Inline code. Don't use for sentences like this.`

```
"Some Foo code with no syntax highlighting."
```

```py
print('Some Python code with dedicated syntax highlighting.')
```

- Here's
- a
- list.

1. Numbered lists
2. are a thing too!

- Let's

  - nest!
- And also

  1. mix
  2. them
  3. up.

Break this...

---

...sentence up with a line.

<sup>And an ellipsis.</sup> <sub>Maybe two.</sub>

<sub><sup>I'm hacking this tiny text together.</sup></sub>

Comment: Ooo i didn't know you can use comments to separate list...

Comment: Do image title texts actually appear anywhere?

Comment: @Fabian I think it shows up if the image doesn't load.

Answer (score 6):

I am a sock of [angussidney](https://stackexchange.com/users/5869449/angussidney).

I need to make this post to use as part of an automated test for [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/charcoal-se/smokedetector)'s !!/allspam command. In this test case, the user needs to have between 1 and 15 posts and <100 rep.

<s>**Please don't upvote this**, it will break my testcase and I'll be very annoyed.</s> Ha. It's a community wiki post. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 6):

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: This is the shortest answer.

Comment: It's even shorter now :)

Comment: 0-width chars??

Answer (score 6):

Shhh... don't wake the mods
[image]

Comment: **Hey mods! MODS!!! Wake up. You have users who posted ponies to suspend.**

Comment: Oh on! The mods are going to arrest me! **Protect me, Pony the Pony!!!**

Answer (score 5):

test test test test test test test test

Ha! This is now mine!

```
Code Intention Test
    Yes, this is intended...
    At least I think so.
Not sure how that works.
    Typoe
```

---

```
This is intended with one tab
    This with two!
        This with three!
    Two again!
one!
```

---

```
Mixed! Spaces
Tab
    Two Tabs...
    Spaces + Tabs
    Tab + Spaces
```

Comment: test * * * * * * * * * *

Answer (score 5):

[formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting)

[support](/questions/tagged/support)

[support](/questions/tagged/support)[formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting)

I guess you can't combine them:

[tag:formatting support]

[tag:support OR formatting]

How about:
[support+formatting](/questions/tagged/support%2bformatting)

or:
[support+or+formatting](/questions/tagged/support%2bor%2bformatting)

Comment: testing a comment yep testing

Comment: /q/82146/ does this give me a link? Nope.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/860656/57237

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860656/using-c-how-does-one-figure-out-what-process-locked-a-file

Answer (score 5):

Do non-breaking spaces work? Yes!

**Normal space**

1000000 megabyte, 2000000 megabyte, 4000000 megabyte, 8000000 megabyte, 16000000 megabyte, 32000000 megabyte, 64000000 megabyte, 128000000 megabyte, 256000000 megabyte, 512000000 megabyte, 1024000000 megabyte, 2048000000 megabyte, 4096000000 megabyte, 8192000000 megabyte, 16384000000 megabyte, 32768000000 megabyte, 65536000000 megabyte.

**Non-breaking space**

1000000 megabyte, 2000000 megabyte, 4000000 megabyte, 8000000 megabyte, 16000000 megabyte, 32000000 megabyte, 64000000 megabyte, 128000000 megabyte, 256000000 megabyte, 512000000 megabyte, 1024000000 megabyte, 2048000000 megabyte, 4096000000 megabyte, 8192000000 megabyte, 16384000000 megabyte, 32768000000 megabyte, 65536000000 megabyte.

Comment: Likewise: soft hyphens, though not too well [in tables in Firefox 4](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2399/comments-are-not-wrapped-continued-on-other-side-of-page/2403#2403).

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>[q](/questions/tagged/q)</kbd><kbd>[w](/questions/tagged/w)</kbd><kbd>[e](/questions/tagged/e)</kbd><kbd>[r](/questions/tagged/r)</kbd><kbd>[t](/questions/tagged/t)</kbd><kbd>[y](/questions/tagged/y)</kbd><kbd>[u](/questions/tagged/u)</kbd><kbd>[i](/questions/tagged/i)</kbd><kbd>[o](/questions/tagged/o)</kbd><kbd>[p](/questions/tagged/p)</kbd>
<kbd>[a](/questions/tagged/a)</kbd><kbd>[s](/questions/tagged/s)</kbd><kbd>[d](/questions/tagged/d)</kbd><kbd>[f](/questions/tagged/f)</kbd><kbd>[g](/questions/tagged/g)</kbd><kbd>[h](/questions/tagged/h)</kbd><kbd>[j](/questions/tagged/j)</kbd><kbd>[k](/questions/tagged/k)</kbd><kbd>[l](/questions/tagged/l)</kbd>
<kbd>[z](/questions/tagged/z)</kbd><kbd>[x](/questions/tagged/x)</kbd><kbd>[c](/questions/tagged/c)</kbd><kbd>[v](/questions/tagged/v)</kbd><kbd>[b](/questions/tagged/b)</kbd><kbd>[n](/questions/tagged/n)</kbd><kbd>[m](/questions/tagged/m)</kbd>

And Dvorak!

<kbd>[p](/questions/tagged/p)</kbd><kbd>[y](/questions/tagged/y)</kbd><kbd>[f](/questions/tagged/f)</kbd><kbd>[g](/questions/tagged/g)</kbd><kbd>[c](/questions/tagged/c)</kbd><kbd>[r](/questions/tagged/r)</kbd><kbd>[l](/questions/tagged/l)</kbd>
<kbd>[a](/questions/tagged/a)</kbd><kbd>[o](/questions/tagged/o)</kbd><kbd>[e](/questions/tagged/e)</kbd><kbd>[u](/questions/tagged/u)</kbd><kbd>[i](/questions/tagged/i)</kbd><kbd>[d](/questions/tagged/d)</kbd><kbd>[h](/questions/tagged/h)</kbd><kbd>[t](/questions/tagged/t)</kbd><kbd>[n](/questions/tagged/n)</kbd><kbd>[s](/questions/tagged/s)</kbd>
<kbd>[q](/questions/tagged/q)</kbd><kbd>[j](/questions/tagged/j)</kbd><kbd>[k](/questions/tagged/k)</kbd><kbd>[x](/questions/tagged/x)</kbd><kbd>[b](/questions/tagged/b)</kbd><kbd>[m](/questions/tagged/m)</kbd><kbd>[w](/questions/tagged/w)</kbd><kbd>[v](/questions/tagged/v)</kbd><kbd>[z](/questions/tagged/z)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](https://google.com).

---

> > > > 

---

## <kbd><kbd><kbd>[kbd](/questions/tagged/kbd)</kbd></kbd></kbd>

---

\ | / */*
[bang](/questions/tagged/bang)
*/* / | \

---

## h1 - [works](/questions/tagged/works)

---

### h2 - [works](/questions/tagged/works)

---

#### h3 - [works](/questions/tagged/works)

---

h4 - [doesnt-work](/questions/tagged/doesnt-work)

---

h5 - [doesnt-work](/questions/tagged/doesnt-work)

---

h6 - [doesnt-work](/questions/tagged/doesnt-work)

---

In the preview, `[tag:-]` shows as [[undefined](/questions/tagged/undefined)].

Test: [].

---

Do

> not

hover over the empty box!

---

> [image: Stack Overflow]
>         Stack Overflow

---

When editing, links show while the rest of the box doesn't, but the effect is lost when viewing the post normally.
Click `edit` to see the intended effect, then click `cancel`.

> Normal words [don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link1#152745) appear until you [hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link2#152745) [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link3#152745) them, but [any](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link4#152745) links in [boxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link5#152745) will show, whether [you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link6#152745) have hovered over them or not. You [will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link7#152745) have read this by now, unless your browser is so slow that it's about to [freeze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link8#152745).

The above box is supposed to look like this:

> [don't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link1#152745)                  [hover](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link2#152745) [over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link3#152745)           [any](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link4#152745)          [boxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link5#152745)                    [you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link6#152745)                                    [will](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link7#152745)                                                                          [freeze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/152745?link8#152745)

---

## ***Test comments welcome.***

Comment: `[so]`: [so] [so]. **Fatal [so] Exception**

Comment: ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: ![Images don't work in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/apple-touch-icon.png)

Comment: _______________

Comment: These‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: are‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: test‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: comments.‍‍‍‍‍‍

Comment: >!blah blah blah

Comment: Date/time: ‮ !thgir eht no m'I !!!ah aH‭

Comment: one                                                                                                                                                       two                                                                                                                                                       three                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             Ha! I can make multiline messages!

Comment: [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so] [so]

Comment: 

Answer (score 5):

## HTML Comments

**Source**: `<!-- this is a typical comment -->`

Result:

**Source**: `<one odd way to comment>`

Result:

**Source**: `< but it doesn't work with a leading space>`

Result: < but it doesn't work with a leading space>

**Source**: `<!- this is another odd way to comment -->`:

Result:

**Source**: `<!- too lazy for more dashes ->`

Result:

**Source**: `<-- but you need the exclamation point -->`

Result: <-- but you need the exclamation point -->

**Source**: `<the most lazy comment`

Result:

Answer (score 5):

> [image]
>   Imgur scaled [image]

[[image]no target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwwwn.png)

[image]target blank

Comment: This effect is only working here on meta?

Comment: -1 for disrupting the answer above

Answer (score 5):

<sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub><sup><sub>[.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfVsfOSbJY0)</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: `<sub>` and `<sup>` allow you to disregard content length limitations.

Answer (score 5):

Comment: A better question is: Should comments even be allowed in an answer? What purpose can they *possibly* serve?

Comment: (*answer is no, `<!` comments have absolutely no purpose.*)

Comment: <! related test ?>

Comment: ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​



   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​





   

    ​






    ​

Comment: Howd you do that one @Mateo ?

Comment: unicode zero width space >​
< there is one between those marks utf-8 format

Comment: makes it possible to say:

Comment: Yes​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [Weird](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215693/241700) @Mateo

Comment: ​ ​ ​   ​ ​​​ ​​  ​​ ​

Answer (score 5):

**This post *is meant*** to test comments.

Comment: [answer]       ........

Comment: [help] ........

Comment: [edit]...........

Comment: <strike>test</strike>

Comment: Ʌ ꓥ  ٨   ꛎ  ᐱ   ⴷ ۸  Λ Л 

Comment:  ం ಂ ം ං օ    ᴏ ᴑ     ဝ ⲟ  ഠ  ﮦ ﮧ   ﮨ ﮩ ﮪ ﮫ ﮬ ﮭ  ℴ    ꬽ о ھ ο ၀ ہ σ ه ｏ ๐ ໐     ە   ס   ٥ ० ੦ ૦ ௦ ౦ ೦ ൦ ﻩ ﻪ ﻫ ﻬ  o  ۵    ჿ

Comment: • ･ ⋅ · ‧ ᐧ ᛫ ꞏ ⸱ ∙  ・

Comment: The [original sandbox answer to test comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57578).  [Other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297159) [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258936) [test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152745) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79857).

Comment: Please someone ping me, so I can test something on the inbox. Thanks

Comment: @BigBadCat Here. You. Go

Comment: [so] [puzzling.SE]

Answer (score 5):

```js
var main = document.getElementById("test");
var box = document.createElement("p");
var btn = document.createElement("a"),
  count = 0;
btn.innerText = "Hit me";
btn.href = "#";
btn.className = box.className = "foo";
btn.onclick = function() {
  count += 1;
  box.innerText = String(count);
};
btn.addEventListener("click", e => e.preventDefault());
box.innerText = 0;
main.appendChild(btn);
main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
main.appendChild(box);
```

```css
.foo {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.3rem;
  background-color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0);
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 0.6rem;
  transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Testing SE Links:

`[so]`: [so]  
`[codegolf.se]`: [codegolf.se]  
`[ubuntu.se]` [ubuntu.se]  
`[meta]`: [meta]
`[edit]`: [edit]  
`[main]`: [main]  
`[help]`: [help] 
`[mcve]`: [mcve]
`[meta.se]`: [meta.se]

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `[metaso]`: [metaso]

Comment: this is an [edit] link

Comment: [metaso][metase][meta.so][meta.se][meta.stackoverflow]

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>
`Ctrl+Z`

Here is a code block with language code as hint:

```js
function greet(person) {
    return "Hello " + person;
}
var user = "John Doe";
alert(greet(user));
```

Answer (score 4):

Answer for Popular Demand so my tests don't clog up other people's global inboxes.

---

Looks like this answer [is still needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127290/autogenerated-links-truncate-a-final-closing-bracket).

Bare: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography) ← doesn't work
%29: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography%29 ← link functions but looks ugly/wrong

---

> From [Please improve the auto-linking to allow square and round brackets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2323/131713)

For example, this won't work with the linking feature:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[], int)

If I try and [link it][1] this is the result.

[1]: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[], int)

Comment: fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfasd

Comment: Bare: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography) - %29: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography%29

Comment: Add dummy # after ) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)#

Comment: ‮Well, Alt08238, Alt8238 and Alt+202e don't work, but there's always [cheating](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/browsertest.htm).

Comment: [Meta question #145299](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145299)

Answer (score 4):

hello guys hai hi guys hi dear hey guys hai hey hey guys hey hey hello guys guys guys guys hai dear hiya hiya hey dear dear hello hiya hi hello hello dear hello hi hi hi hai dear dear hai guys hi hi hey hai dear hiya hai dear hey hello hey hey guys hello guys hai guys hello dear hey dear hai hey hello guys dear hello hello hi hello hello hey hello hiya dear hiya hai hai hi hai dear hey guys hi hiya hello hey hiya hello hey guys hey hiya hello hello dear hai hi hiya hiya hai dear dear hello hiya hiya hi hiya hai hiya hi hello hi hiya hiya hello hiya hey hey dear hello hello hiya hai hey hiya hey hi guys hi hey dear hai hi hiya hi hiya dear hello hiya hello dear hey hey hey hai hello hi hey hiya hai hey guys hey guys hey dear guys hiya hiya dear hiya hello dear hai hai dear hi hiya guys hey hey hi dear hey hai hiya hai hey hai guys hello hai guys dear hiya hai hey hey hai hai hi dear hello hey hello hey guys guys hai hello hello hello dear hai hello hello hey hi hello hey hiya hey hey hello hey hey hey hi hai hiya hi guys hello hello hello hiya hiya hi hi hello hello guys guys hey hai hiya hi hello hey guys hey hello hi hello guys guys hi hi hi hiya hi hai hello hai hello oh hai!

Comment: Hheheh, it works :)

Comment: oh god it burns....it burrrrrns.

Comment: I don't get it. :PPP

Comment: @DantheMan, not sure I do anymore either. I think I was testing a quality filter which blocks if you start with hello...

Comment: @Benjol Oh. Haha

Answer (score 4):

Trying to have a code block as the first paragraph of a list item:

1. naive way
2. ```
   using html
   ```
3. as second paragraph works fine

   ```
   code test
   ```
4. html comment doesn't force it
5. ```
   with a blank line between
   ```

---

1. ```
   using explicit html there is still no number
   ```

Comment: The missing numbers (2. and 5. in the first list, and 1. in the second list) do [show in my Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hxf5i.png) (though a bit ugly). But [not in my Chrome and Safari](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qB6q2.png), on a Mac.

Answer (score 4):

This is my answer...there are many like it, but this one is mine.

Anyway, here take some bricks and build a castle:

<kbd>another</kbd>      <kbd>brick</kbd>

<kbd>in</kbd>

<kbd>the</kbd>                            <kbd>wall</kbd>

Comment: What were you trying to test, if I may ask? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113339/this-site-checking-code-is-broken).

Comment: Yeah, most likely such filters are not applied for users with rep more than [X] amount - I'd say 200 is probably good limit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I only had that idea *after* my testing. ;) Additionally, that filter might not be active on Meta.

Comment: Good point, not much code here on Meta.. BTW can I loan some bricks? :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Sure, go ahead. I can get more from all the Keyboard-Shortcut-Questions on Super User. :D

Answer (score 4):

Comment: [so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so]

Comment: sosososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososososo

Comment: Edit test foo bar

Comment: [se] test test test

Comment: 

Answer (score 4):

[image: I like my waffles toasted ^_^]

Answer (score 4):

- [Song of Solomon 2:3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16446#v3)
- [1kgs 1:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15885#v2)

---

Can I get text to properly flow around images?  We'll the raw HTML suggested in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images) doesn't seem to work.  And the regular way to embed images doesn't flow correctly, so I'm not sure what to do.  Ask a meta-question, I guess. [image]

Comment:   

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>[test](/questions/tagged/test)</kbd>

yay keyboard tag

+̈

```
+̈
```

`+̈`

Answer (score 4):

This is a test for <strike>strikethrough</strike> and the `<dl>` tag.

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>Black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>White cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

Renders as:

Coffee

Black hot drink

Milk

White cold drink

---

That is, [the tags are allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/148310), but they are not formatted well by SE.

Desired format is:

> [image]

Comment: @Awesome think you found a bug, the CSS rules remove margin and padding from  the tags, hence break their usage. Fix is trivial, so better start a bug report.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I was just testing.  I've never seen a need for `<dl>` in an SE post and don't want to bother with a bug report for this.  There's a cr*pton of other things (all upvoted) I'd like to see first. (`<table>`s for example)

Answer (score 4):

> [This is a test](http://www.google.com) To see if [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers) works.

[This is a test](http://www.google.com) [to see if it is possible to hide hyperlinks.](https://stackoverflow.com/)

This is a test [to see if nested hyperlinks](http://www.example.com/) are acceptable. This doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Does this still work?

[it does, and I removed it because it was breaking the page]

Comment: How the hell did you do that??

Answer (score 4):

## Waffles!

Hot off the <kbd>-waffle iron!  (Sorry, not [that one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404)).

Answer (score 4):

<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup><sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>y<sub>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub><sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>y<sup>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

```
                   ``                   
                 `.,:,.`                
               `.,:::::,.`              
             `.,:::::::::,`             
            `,::::::::::::,.`           
          `.,:::::::::::::::,.`         
        `.,:::::::::::::::::::,.`       
      `.,:::::::::::::::::::::::.`      
     `.::::::::::::::::::::::::::,.`    
   `.::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::,.`  
  `,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.  
   `.................................`
```

```
                      ``                
                    `.::.               
                  `.,;;:.               
                `.,;;'':.               
               .:;;:,:;:.               
               .,,.``,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `,;:.               
                    `.,,`
```

```````````````````````````````````
   ``````````````````````````````````   
  `,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::.  
  `.,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::,`  
    `.,:::::::::::::::::::::::::::,.`   
      `.::::::::::::::::::::::::,.`     
        `,:::::::::::::::::::::.`       
         `.,:::::::::::::::::,`         
           `.,:::::::::::::,.`          
             `.::::::::::,.`            
              ``,:::::::.`              
                `.,:::.`                
                  ``.`
```````````````````````````````````

```
                                         ``   
                                        .::`  
                                      `,;;:`  
                                    `.:;'':`  
                                   .:;'''':`  
                                 `,;'''''':`  
                               `,:;''''''':`  
                              .:;''''''''':`  
   ``                       `,;;'''''''''':`  
  `::.                    `,:;''''''''''';:`  
  `:;;,`                 .:;'''''''''''';:.   
  `:'';:,`             `,;'''''''''''';:.`    
  `:'''';:.`         `,:;''''''''''';;,`      
  `:'''''';,`       .:;'''''''''''';:.        
  `:''''''';:,`   `,;'''''''''''';:.`         
  `:''''''''';:.`,;;''''''''''';;,`           
  `:''''''''''';;;'''''''''''';:.             
  `:;''''''''''''''''''''''';:.`              
   .:;'''''''''''''''''''';;,`                
    `.:;''''''''''''''''';:.                  
      `,;;''''''''''''';:.`                   
        .:;'''''''''';;,`                     
         `.:;''''''';:.                       
           `,;;''';:.`                        
             .:;;;,`                          
              `..`
```

Answer (score 4):

Comment: ‮my name backwards

Comment: comment comment comment‮            ‮‮‮

Comment: hello there this is a very long commenthello there   hello there this mdbnsjkdbvjzdbj      hhh         hhhh   hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Comment: this is a comment‮‮ dmhm  ‮‮‮

Comment: hello this is a comment ‮[worromot](http://google.com)

Comment: I figured this ‮

Comment: Hello there ‮rere ‮

Comment: hello there this is a very long commenthello there hello there this mdbnsjkdbvjzdbj hhh hhhh       dmf s ‮[dmhM](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/243287/mhmd)

Comment: helkasjdbak sjdhf kjas hflk adfjhakjhflkajflkasjdlkjaslkfdjaklsjas hfkjahskfljalkfjalkfsdfsd  kjfksejlfjsdkljflksd ‮hdjsdf‮

Comment: This is a comment ( ‮[kraM](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/225663/mark) (‭

Comment: testink links : [link](http://javascript:document.cookie)

Comment: [testlink](http://javascript:alert())

Answer (score 4):

## Header 1

### Header 2

**Bold** *Italics*

```
public void StackOverflow() { StackOverflow(); }
```

The `StackOverflow()` function calls itself, causing a StackOverflowException or StackOverflowError (.NET and Java respectively).

Breaking the workflow:

[image: There are probably children out there holding down spacebar to stay warm in the winter! YOUR UPDATE MURDERS CHILDREN.]

*There are probably children out there holding down spacebar to stay warm in the winter! YOUR UPDATE MURDERS CHILDREN.*

> That
>
> > Block
> >
> > > Quote

THE Tags:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

Answer (score 4):

```
function $$(selector, el) {
    //hello!
}
```

function $$(selector, el) {
    //hello!
}

Comment: cats and dogs...

Comment: Hair, cats, and dogs

Answer (score 4):

Test: Unicode characters:

Unicorn:

Answer (score 4):

Let's see how high this can get.

let's see if [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249842/editing-on-mobile-ui-duplicated-my-answer-instead-of-editing-it) happens here as well...

Another try from mobile device...

Comment: All the way up, apparently.

Comment: Yup. Cool, but unlike the `<sub>` trolling, it can't block any functionality. :)

Comment: How is this done?

Answer (score 4):

**‮tset**

```
‮tset
```

‮http://www.google.com

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > ‮tset

### This actually threw console errors when I added some more.... Too many blockquotes causes javascript to run into a recursive loop and throw an error... not sure how.

Comment: Also, more testing unicode. ‮

Answer (score 4):

## Q: [Transmute all humans on this planet into Manshu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/278264#278264)

> Two solutions. 
>   (Alchemists had to discover the second after accidentally
>    regressing Manshu to humanoid form.)

Spoiler 1:

> ```
>              h     u     m     a     n     s
>                     '. .'             '. .'
>                      .'.               .'.
>              h     m'   'u     a     s'   'n
>               '. .'       '. .'       '. .'
>                .'.         .'.         .'.
>              m'   'h     a'   'u     n'   's
>              :      '. .'       '. .'
>              :       .'.         .'.
>              M     a'   'h     n'   'u     s
>               '. .'       '. .'       '. .'
>                .'.         .'.         .'.
>              a'   'M     n'   'h     s'   'u
>               '. .'             '. .'
>                .'.               .'.
>              M'   'a     n     s'   'h     u
> ```

Spoiler 2:

> HumansHumansHuMansHuMansHuManshuManshu

Comment: What is this, and what about that profile picture with old puzzling.SE pic o.0

Comment: @ABcDexter This is an architectural design by humn. And before graduation, I had in mind to put the profile picture of old PSE logo. I love that logo more than the new one. More at [The troll](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39978/the-troll)

Comment: Yes, this new one is similar to another SE site, i think 'workplace'. I miss the old one...

Comment: Hey I came here after following the code in your profile. No idea what to do, bye :)

Comment: ⇑  someone else has solved your profile, @manshu  ⇑  maybe they too want to be assimilated into you but don't know how to proceed

Comment: @manshu Please at least use something better than **just binary**.

Answer (score 4):

1. hello
2. world
3. how are you?
4. oh my...
5. that is weird.

Answer (score 4):

S<sup>o<sup>m<sup>e<sup>t<sup>i<sup>m<sup>e<sup>s <sup><sup>y<sup>o<sup>u <sup><sup>j<sup>u<sup>s<sup>t <sup><sup>w<sup>a<sup>n<sup>t <sup><sup>t<sup>o <sup><sup>a<sup>b<sup>u<sup>s<sup>e <sup><sup>a <sup><sup>v<sup>e<sup>r<sup>y <sup><sup>s<sup>p<sup>e<sup>c<sup>i<sup>f<sup>i<sup>c <sup><sup>f<sup>e<sup>a<sup>t<sup>u<sup>r<sup>e<sup>, <sup><sup>d<sup>on't you?</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 3 bytes

```
i¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@595aA3j//8A)

Comment: Flagged as migrate to PPC... oh wait.

Comment: +1 for using my favorite language. :P

Answer (score 4):

First answer with new sandbox, what Markdown does StackExchange render?

`*italics*`
*italics*

`_italics_`
*italics*

`**bold**`
**bold**

`__bold__`
**bold**

`***bold italics***`
***bold italics***

`___bold italics___`
***bold italics***

`~strikethrough~`
~strikethrough~

`~~strikethrough~~`
~~strikethrough~~

`<s>strikethrough</s>`
<s>strikethrough</s>

`----strikethrough---`
---strikethrough---

`![inline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DHO6.gif)`
[image: inline image]

`[![inline image with link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DHO6.gif)](https://i.imgur.com/)`
[image: inline image with link]

```
| Markdown | Tables   |
|----------|----------|
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
```

| Markdown | Tables |
| --- | --- |
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| Column 1 | Column 2 |

`MathJax: $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$`
MathJax: $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$

`/pony/`

[image: pony]

`/waffles/`

[image: waffles]

`/easteregg/`

[image: easteregg]

logo? 

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/FMMMOtk.gif

Comment: @JasonC HAHAHAHAHA

Comment: Just FYI, MarkDown does not seem to support strikethrough with tildes

Comment: @iBug it doesn't support strikethrough at all, except in chat, IIRC.

Comment: So strikethrough support is handled by SE and is only enabled in chat, right? I checked MD's documents and found no traces of strikethrough.

Answer (score 4):

`an edit has been made to this post; click to load`

493     18      48k       [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

<sup>votes</sup>  <sup>answers</sup>  <sup>views</sup>      [support](/questions/tagged/support) [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox)                      <sub>modified 35 seconds ago [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) ♦ 1</sub>

---

0      505     1.4k      [Sandbox archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive)

<sup>votes</sup>  <sup>answers</sup>  <sup>views</sup>      [support](/questions/tagged/support)  [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox)                                          <sub>modified Oct 19th at 9:57 [Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) ♦ 1</sub>

---

Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support) [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox) or [ask your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Nice. In the beginning I thought the whole post was a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Embed a widget in a post?

```html
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=VBA&year_start=1980&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVBA%3B%2Cc0" width=900 height=500 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

### Ⓠ How to make a tooltip without a link?

<sub><sup>hover for tooltip 0

hover for tooltip 1

**[hover for tooltip 2](//) `→ Ⓐ` `<a href="//" title="Tooltip!">hover for tooltip 2</a>`**

hover for tooltip 2½

[hover for tooltip 3](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

[hover for tooltip 4](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/309173)

[hover for tooltip 5](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/309173)

**[hover for tooltip 6](//) `→ Ⓐ` `[hover for tooltip 6][6]`    `[6]: // "tooltip!"`**</sup></sub>

Comment: This is a test comment

Comment: hello please see this test link [meta]

Answer (score 4):

Comment: cool and awesome

Comment: Looking at the edit history: Inline, you get nothing. Side by side, you get a gap. Then you go to side by side markdown, and... You see everything!

Comment: awesome and cool

Answer (score 4):

> > > > > >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>http://x

Comment: [so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so][so]

Comment: `\\` test test test

Answer (score 4):

### No-spaces!

Answer (score 4):

Everyone seems to be obsessed with waffles at the moment. However, I realized what the best breakfast food was long ago, and I hope everyone else will soon realize that pancakes are far superior to waffles.

[image]

There's a [waffles](/questions/tagged/waffles) tag now, but it will soon be burninated and be replaced with [pancakes](/questions/tagged/pancakes)! **You can never win, waffles!**

Comment: **I agree.** But... I wanted the waffles hat, so I commented about waffles anyway. *Don’t worry, though.* The pancake hat **must** come in **full glory** next year, and when it does it shall *tower over the waffles hat* and **show the world** who is **the best breakfast** *once and for all!* Just *look* at those *glorious* pancakes! *No* waffle can challage that! Pancakes **shall rise again**! **They must!**

Answer (score 3):

`code with \`embedded`` backticks`

See [Can we get rid of the default text "enter image description here"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88756/can-we-get-rid-of-the-default-text-enter-image-description-here) for details

---

As an aside: Chrome and Safari would show it too, but only if it can fit the text. Both do actually increase the width of the image to match the length of the text, but still won't show the text unless that width is also explicitly specified... So: that requires one to increase the default dimensions a bit, like `<img src="http://not" width="184" height="48" alt="enter image description here">` does show it. Not sure if that's specific to the Stack Exchange CSS? (Like *maybe* some other dimensions from the SE CSS are used, when image dimensions are missing.)

```
![alt text](http://not)  
<img src="http://not" height="48" alt="alt text">  
<img src="http://not" width="44" height="48" alt="alt text">

![enter image description here](http://not)
<img src="http://not" height="48" alt="enter image description here">
<img src="http://not" width="184" height="48" alt="enter image description here">
```

[alt text http://not.here.com](http://not.here.com)
[alt text http://not.here.com](http://not.here.com)
[alt text http://not.here.com](http://not.here.com)

http://not.here.com
http://not.here.com
http://not.here.com

Odd.

In Chrome on my Mac the above looks like:

[image: Missing images in Chrome]

In my Safari:

[image: Missing images in Safari]

And in my Firefox shows [no image placeholders at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAWi5.png).

Comment: We detected an invalid domain linked in your post. This is likely caused due to sample code not being in a code block. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Comment: Community always makes me laugh.

Comment: [help/how-to-ask] [help] [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 3):

[▛▙▟▜▐▀▄▌▘▛▙▟▜ ▄█▀](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/72773#72773)  u know u want em :)

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: @athspk Unicode :)

Comment: I tried \u00A9, but i guess i am doing it wrong because it doesn't show

Comment: @athspk I, er, just copy pasted the characters straight from charmap :) The point of this answer, by the way, was seeing if I could post it and/or what its quality score would've been.

Comment: @radp Very Nice :-)

Comment: ふふふっ - lovely to see

Comment: ▛  ▜  <br/>
▙  ▟---------    How to do line breaks in comments?

Comment: @mplungjan You can't.

Comment: What a pity.                                                                                                                                                                     That would be useful sometimes.

Comment: Test
Test
Test
Test<pre>blah</pre>

Comment: @toscho: How does everyone figure out all the cool comment stuff?

Comment: @Ullallulloo trial and error

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Comment: `\\` xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: `dsfsdfsdfsdfsd\\` xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Be quiet, ---@Community---, dumb bot

Comment: ▛ ▜ <br/> ▙ ▟--------- How to do line breaks in comments?

Comment: Test Test Test Test<pre>blah</pre>

Comment: @user13267 no line breaks in comments.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I don't think the auto comment will be removed automatically since the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: @hims056 yeah, whatever job that was responsible for this is long time dead. Oh well! Think we should flag the comment? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Yeah, flag as an *obsolete*. May be? Oh well. Flagging it as an obsolete gives [this error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KbUEL.png) message: *This comment will be automatically removed by the system when the post is corrected*

Comment: @hims056 wow, must try it myself! LOL! Well, bug report? Since this will never be removed automatically...

Comment: > What *does* guarantee that a field is conservative is that you can express it as the gradient of a scalar function. In more general mathematical terms, if there exists a function $f$ such that $\nabla f = \vec{v}$, then $\vec{v}$ is said to be **exact**. An exact vector field is absolutely 100% guaranteed to [be] conservative.

$\newline$
What about vector fields of the form $\nabla \Big(\frac{k}{ \;|\,\vec{r} \, |\,^2 } \Big)$? I find this v. confusing: we have potential, but isn't the resulting field only locally conservative (& therefore this condition doesn't guarantee exactness always)?

Answer (score 3):

- Nested

  - lists
  - are

    - fun!
    - cool!
  - is

    - nice!
    - <s>unsupported!</s>  supported, so long as your markdown indents lists by **2+** spaces.

Answer (score 3):

This is without a `language:`:

```
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

This is with `language: lang-sh`:

```sh
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

This is with `language: lang-c`:

```c
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

This is with `language: lang-xml`:

```xml
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

This is with `language: lang-none`:

```
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

This is with `language: lang-i-am-a-banana`...

```i-am-a-banana
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

... which falls back to `language: lang-default`

```
# comment me
echo "sjngm"
var="foo"
num=80
for line in (`cat bar.txt`) do
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Comment: will @ jcolebrand be removed from the start - yes it will. can I use &reg; in comments? No I cannot. Drat! Alt-0174 ®works

Comment: don't mind me, just testing (:  [String(byte\[\],Charset)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff ok. As you say.

Comment: Problem with `\ ` Do I have a problem? This string is `marked`

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</kbd>

<kbd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</kbd>

[this is a link](http://www.google.com)

This is a `line with some code`
This is another `line with some code`
[This is a `link` with code in it](http://www.stackoverflow.com)
This `is more code`

This CSS overlapping is really starting to piss me off.

<strike>This is strike through</strike>
<s>This is also strike through</s>
<del>As is this</del>
---How about chat formatting?---

[Does it work in a <s>Link</s>?](http://www.example.com)

[<link>](http://www.thing.com)

[<link>](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: [this is a link](http://www.google.com "and this is a mouse over")

Comment: [this is a link](http://www.stackoverflow.com "and this is a mouseover")

Comment: `[this is a link](http://www.stackoverflow.com "and this is a mouseover")`

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [x](http://www.example.com)

Comment: <code>This is a test</code>

Comment: Does it work in a <s>comment</s>?

Comment: Does this work in a <strike>comment</strike>?

Comment: Does this work in a <del>comment</del>?

Comment: `oh hai
     this is a multi
           line comment
     this world is doomed`

Comment: @mikeTheLiar HTML doesn't work in comments, you have to use markdown.

Comment: [tour] [help] [so] [meta.so]

Comment: [|](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 3):

Testing lists with large code blocks

1. Test

   ```
   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   11
   12
   13
   14
   15
   16
   17
   18
   19
   20
   21
   22
   23
   24
   25
   26
   27
   28
   29
   30
   31
   32
   33
   34
   35
   36
   37
   38
   39
   40
   41
   42
   43
   44
   45
   46
   47
   48
   49
   50
   ```

   Next one has no leading text
2. ```
   0
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
   11
   12
   13
   14
   15
   16
   17
   18
   19
   20
   21
   22
   23
   24
   25
   26
   27
   28
   29
   30
   31
   32
   33
   34
   35
   36
   37
   38
   39
   40
   41
   42
   43
   44
   45
   46
   47
   48
   49
   50
   ```

Answer (score 3):

[Markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables)? Who needs 'em?<sup>1</sup>

```
╔════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║         Major Column 1         ║    Major Column 2   ║
╠══════════╤══════════╤══════════╬══════════╤══════════╣
║ Mn Clm 1 │ Mn Clm 2 │ Mn Clm 3 ║ Mn Clm 4 │ Mn Clm 5 ║
╠══════════╪══════════╪══════════╬══════════╪══════════╣
║          │          │          ║          │          ║
╟──────────┼──────────┼──────────╫──────────┼──────────╢
║          │          │          ║          │          ║
╟──────────┴──────────┼──────────╫──────────┴──────────╢
║                     │          ║                     ║
╟──────────┬──────────┴──────────╫─────────────────────╢
║          │                     ║                     ║
╚══════════╧═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Too bad the vertical spacing's a little off though...

---

*1*<sub>Just kidding. Markdown tables would be great. As would be footnotes, now that I think about it. Or even just small text so I don't have to abuse `<sub>`</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Test [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) persian. comment here by `Arabic`/`Farsi` language. for example:

## الله اكبر

Comment: Test utf-8 tag: [tag:سعدي] insteas of [tag:saadi]. WOW, utf-8 tag is not formatting.

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaadsaasda asd a sd as

Comment: يا علي مدد..........1

Answer (score 3):

The original standard for `mailto:` links, [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738), says this:

> A mailto URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> mailto:<rfc822-addr-spec>
> ```
>
> where `<rfc822-addr-spec>` is (the encoding of an) addr-spec, as
> specified in RFC 822 [[1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738)].

Under that definition, no proper name could be included.

But the `mailto:` section of RFC 1738 has been superseded by [RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368), which allows (among other things, including predefined subject lines) for an [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) mailbox specification—which includes a proper name.

TL;DR: `mailto:Fred Foo<foo@example.com>` should work (and does, for me; you may have to encode the space, *i.e.*, `mailto:Fred%20Foo<foo@example.com>`).

Comment: Well it worked...

Answer (score 3):

italicboldness!

th*i**s*** *i**s** **it***a**li**c**b****ol**d**n**e****ss (**I *do***ub****t t**h**a**t ****i*s*** a **w**o**r*d**)**

generated by:

```
gets.chomp.gsub(/./) {|x| '*'*rand(3)+'<!---->'+x+'<!---->'+'*'*rand(3)}
```

---

A different test:

I am going to take these backticks ````````` ` `` ``` ```` `````` ``````` ```````` ````````` and RULE THE WORLD!

source:

`````````
I am going to take these backticks ````` ` `` ``` ```` `````` ``````` ```````` ````` and RULE THE WORLD!
`````````

Comment: I can edit and share and flag the question!

Answer (score 3):

Look at me!

I **HATE** `<br>` tags!

Answer (score 3):

Testing keyboard tag overflow

<kbd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus aliquam aliquet dui quis pretium. Nam viverra risus quis magna varius, non tempor quam sagittis. Aenean sed lacinia nisi. Nullam aliquet faucibus est. Cras porta condimentum pellentesque. Proin ultricies diam id nibh eleifend, vitae euismod dui varius. Phasellus facilisis laoreet eros eget rhoncus. Praesent vel nisi ipsum.</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

This is a really long answer.... err, It's going to be.

---

### Table of contents

Chapter 1

---

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Morbi adipiscing convallis tortor, vehicula hendrerit nunc vulputate eu. Nam sollicitudin urna sit amet libero suscipit rutrum. Phasellus viverra mauris sed nisi eleifend, sed pulvinar purus congue. Donec porttitor eros mattis quam aliquam, et congue orci ultrices. Phasellus gravida cursus ullamcorper. Suspendisse euismod lectus in nisi volutpat, ac ullamcorper orci malesuada. Duis ut tincidunt enim, vitae suscipit risus. Aliquam vel elit a est adipiscing scelerisque eu sed magna. Duis auctor massa nisi. Phasellus molestie accumsan luctus. Integer interdum nisl non pulvinar pulvinar. Donec augue lorem, tincidunt quis consectetur id, suscipit quis risus.

In ultrices gravida massa eget venenatis. Morbi sagittis posuere enim, in tincidunt metus. Sed posuere nibh ut tempor fringilla. Donec enim ante, aliquam at molestie ut, gravida vitae diam. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sem et porta. Aliquam porta, felis vel euismod lobortis, eros ipsum elementum libero, et mollis enim ante ut nisi. Fusce tristique ligula et ante fringilla aliquam. Vivamus eget accumsan massa. Mauris quis enim quis lacus mattis luctus. Pellentesque eu nunc sem. Donec consequat nisl a enim suscipit ornare. Nunc id aliquet enim, in adipiscing felis.

Cras id feugiat metus, sed venenatis nisi. Cras venenatis purus a lobortis vehicula. Nulla lacinia interdum purus, non blandit sapien laoreet sit amet. Integer non elit elementum metus tristique semper. Vivamus vehicula lectus ut justo facilisis rutrum. Nunc quis felis faucibus, blandit mauris et, ultrices ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla feugiat mi ut elit commodo ultrices vel vitae tortor. Donec nec porta nulla, sed mattis lorem. Vestibulum fermentum ultrices erat.

Vivamus posuere semper hendrerit. Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum. Duis aliquet mi consequat nunc pharetra, in congue lacus elementum. Nulla id nisi in nisi ornare rhoncus. Aliquam dapibus vehicula tincidunt. Fusce quis arcu nunc. Pellentesque pulvinar egestas vehicula. Vestibulum id ante ligula. Pellentesque ac condimentum velit, et volutpat erat. Nulla congue condimentum eros, sed viverra sem tempus a. Curabitur enim lorem, imperdiet vel vulputate vel, auctor eu lacus. Proin varius neque sed nulla pharetra aliquet. Maecenas placerat pharetra interdum.

Mauris blandit diam velit, a semper nisl tristique id. Sed a lectus elit. Curabitur faucibus id leo quis tempor. Cras lectus leo, tristique a eros a, vulputate vulputate augue. Nulla urna massa, porta sit amet consectetur vitae, laoreet sed diam. Nullam vel laoreet lorem. Proin porta accumsan lacus vitae lobortis. Morbi et neque faucibus, accumsan neque quis, commodo leo. Pellentesque feugiat et nibh id convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque placerat justo vel nunc molestie elementum. Morbi ac urna dictum, volutpat mauris sed, facilisis velit. Donec id iaculis purus. Cras nec vestibulum dui.

Comment: -1 for bad Latin Grammar on line 327 ! Really, you should be more careful.

Comment: @HowardPautz Give my apologies to your ears, I do know what bad grammar sounds like.

Comment: my ears accept your apology, but the Latin part of my brain is still SO ANNOYED, especially when it found " Proin in lectus ut arcu varius rutrum"  - I'll remember that next time someone offers me a cigarette --- I'll have to tell them, "no thanks, it isn't pretty enough!" Never forget what Mick Jagger really said: "Latinum in rutrum lectus ut idem artifices qui non fumigant sicut me." So there!

Comment: @HowardPautz *bows*

Answer (score 3):

Triggering new edit grace period

Now let's see if this sets off a bug

Comment: Testing IME: Sun = 日

Comment: Testing IME again: Sun = 日

Comment: Still testing IME: Sun = 日

Comment: Testing IME with SOUP: Sun = 日.

Comment: Testing markdown: **bold _bold italics_**

Comment: **bold *bold italics*** **bold _bold italics_**

Comment: [meta] [main] [edit]

Comment: [graphicdesign.se] [anime.se] [philosophy.se] [so] [su] [sf] [se] [meta.se] [meta.japanese.se]

Comment: *italic* *more italic*

Comment: Testing IME ~in the future~: Sun = 日.

Answer (score 3):

List of canonical questions from the main site (for closing questions as dupes). These are mostly the ones I use (and putting them in my Formatting Sandbox post just makes it easier to go back to)

Java:

- [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [Scanner issue when using nextLine after nextXXX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx) (and variants: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint/13102066#13102066), [Scanner nextInt() and hasNextInt() problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791211/scanner-nextint-and-hasnextint-problems/20791278#20791278))
- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)
- [Floating point arithmetic not producing exact results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661273/floating-point-arithmetic-not-producing-exact-results)
- [Why does the toString method in java not seem to work for an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060016/why-does-the-tostring-method-in-java-not-seem-to-work?rq=1)
- [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)
- [Access variables from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123979/access-variables-from-another-method)
- [What's the difference between ".equals" and "=="?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643067/whats-the-difference-between-equals-and)
- [Boolean and == vs =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399205/boolean-and-vs)
- [What is the difference between '==' and '='?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007255/what-is-the-difference-between-and/1007306#1007306)
- [Division of integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220681/division-of-integers-in-java?s=6|1.1352)

C:

- [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)
- [Why does this division result in zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568337/why-does-this-division-result-in-zero?rq=1) (and other "integer division then shove into float/double" questions)
- [C++ String Length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905355/c-string-length) (A C++ question, but you can get to an equivalent C question fairly quickly from there)

One thing that I want to add later: something related to "what every programmer should know about floating point" to both languages.

Comment: Testing adding tags [meta-tag:discussion]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: You can't vote for your own comment.

Answer (score 3):

## NUMBERED LIST TESTING

### Unexpected

```
 1. Item1

 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

### Crap

```
 1. Item1
<!-- -->
 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

### WTF

```
 1. Item1

<!-- -->
 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1

1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4

### Useless

```
 1. Item1
<!-- -->

 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

### Misleading

```
 1. Item1

<!-- -->

 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1

1. Item2
2. Item3
3. Item4

### BEST CHOICE

```
 1. Item1
<br/><br/>
 1. Item2
 1. Item3
 1. Item4
```

1. Item1
2. Item2
3. Item3
4. Item4

Answer (score 3):

Testing character limit (I rather like this character):
ﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺﷺ

Comment: test comment 1.

Comment: test comment 2.

Comment: test comment 3.

Comment: test comment 4.

Comment: test comment 5.

Comment: test comment 6.

Comment: test comment 7.

Comment: test comment 8.

Comment: test comment 9.

Comment: test comment 10.

Comment: You have posted too many comments on this answer. Please post a comment expressing remorse.

Answer (score 3):

## Horrendous {mis|ab}use of direction overrides

---

```
This is some normal text to lull you into a false sense of security.
```

This is some normal text to lull you into a false sense of security.

---

```
{RTL}This text is standard-grade messed up with a `U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE`.{LTR}
```

‮This text is standard-grade messed up with a `U+202E RIGHT-TO-LEFT OVERRIDE`.‭

---

```
This text is {RTL}hospital-grade messed up with {LTR}an intervening override.
```

This text is ‮hospital-grade messed up with ‭an intervening override.

---

```
If I {RTL}pu swohs ti ,sdrawkcab etirw {LTR}forwards.
```

If I ‮pu swohs ti ,sdrawkcab etirw ‭forwards.

---

```
This text is industrial-grade messed up - {RTL}it spans paragraphs!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit.

Brain melted {LTR}yet?
```

This text is industrial-grade messed up - ‮it spans paragraphs!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit.

Brain melted ‭yet?

---

```
{RTL}!sliated eht ni si rorroh eht tub ,lamron skooL{LTR}
```

‮!sliated eht ni si rorroh eht tub ,lamron skooL‭

---

Answer (score 3):

Heh, the bash syntax highlighter is broken.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -ge 1 -a -f "$1" ] && input="$1" || input="-"
cat $input
```

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**#** test</sub>

**^** test line 2

<sub>**#** test added 2 spaces</sub>

**^** test line 2

try adding fixed spaces      |

|added space      | 1      |
|                            |       |

<strike>strike</strike>

```
DECLARE @origUserName varchar(max)
```

This is a unity3d test...
<kbd>C</kbd>

```sql
alternative to code layout
   if 
   we can work this
out
```

`alternative to code layout
  if 
  we can work this
out`

```
alternative to code layout
if 
we can work this
out
```

[image]

Comment: What were you testing, if I might ask? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I try to see if there is more upload capacity within the current limits...

Comment: oh, nice... and? (is there?)

Comment: Well, if imgur wouldn't convert my bmp to png I would say yes...

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​A​

Comment: <kbd>test</kbd>

Comment: Took you over three years to learn about <kbd>? :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry, I didn't know learning time was restricted. It won't happen again, promised.

Comment: @rene now go build a castle with the <kbd> that was the first thing I tried (and miserably failed) - and if it wasn't clear enough I was just kidding/teasing you. :-D

Comment: [iphone configuration utility](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#iphone%20configuration%20utility)

Comment: `<s>strike</s>` also works. Less to type. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard hehehe ... I was typing I don't know how many dashes around a word while wondering why it didn't work. Only to realize later that only works in chat.... I must be spoiled ... ;)

Comment: Yeah, many heros fell in face of the markdown difference between chat, comments, and posts. :D

Comment: lorum ipsin tewtsc iedjc

Comment: ccccc cf ff ff rfrr rf

Comment: fjkfjj jfjfjf jfjj jfjfj

Comment: f ff  rrr rr  r  r

Comment: test again for comment

Answer (score 3):

> This is a blockquote. I think.
>
> > This is a double blockquote.
> >
> > > This is a triple blockquote.
> > >
> > > > And this is a quadruple blockquote.

**Here's some bold text.**

*Here's some italic text.*

***Here's some bold italic text***

[Here's a link](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

```python
print("Here's some code.")
```

Here's
some
newlines.

[image]Here's an image.

Here's a [tag](/questions/tagged/tag).

Here's some in-text `code`.

Here's some emojis: .

Here's Arabic numbers? ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩٠

You can hit a <kbd>key</kbd> to perform an action.

Here's a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) meta tag.

I **love** to `<code>` *a lot* in [python](/questions/tagged/python) on my [raspberrypi](/questions/tagged/raspberrypi).

Here's an ***unordered*** list.

- Cheese is good.

  - Don't try the smelly kinds though.
- Doge is love. Doge is life.

  - Once you accept this fact, life is glorious.

<s>This is a strike through</s>

<sub><sup><sub><sup>Oooah, I'm tiny :)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: List is unordered, by the way ;-)

Comment: @nicael Sometimes I just forget I'm not talking about programming...

Comment: If you would talk about programming your list would be unordered anyway...

Comment: @nicael Wow. I think I need my morning coffee before I start writing comments on SE.

Comment: So edit your answer! :D What are you waiting for?

Comment: @nicael Edited my answer and have had my morning coffee!

Comment: Whats happening?!
‮ ‮ Good night... :)  ‮

Comment: ‮ ‮5  ‮ ‮6  ‮ ‮7  ‮ ‮  ‮ ‮  ‮ ‮  ‮ ‮  ‮ ‮

Comment: @leacin What on earth are you doing?

Comment: ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮  ‮Nothing. It is sandbox. You noticed something strange?

Comment: It is sandbox ;-) Don't forget

Comment: @nicael, I know, there's just some weird things goin' on here....

Comment: But whats happening?.. Whats wrong???

Comment: @nicael leacin is posting some weird things. Oh well.

Comment: lol :D who is leacin?

Comment: ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮  ?driew stahw ‮?ereht gnorw stahw

Comment: @leacin How you're able to make the end of a comment be at the- wait a minute...

Comment: Minute passed :D  ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮

Comment: Still some misunderstandings?

Comment: @leacin stop confusing me and DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms. :D really, how did you manage to make the date appear before the comment???

Comment: @nicael wait, is it a secret?! :D  ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮

Comment: A- I'm really confused now. I'm going to let you talk to yourself through backwards comments for a while...

Comment: ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ????uoy sesufnoc tahw ,teg t'nod I

Comment: شقيمحضخيهتصنيخينباتثصههبتصهذعثتيهيعصتهيسههصنصتصتتبايعصعصترصتيهيهثعصتزلطتستصتضرصربتينهصنصررصهنصريتصهصنربنصخصكصججسحضعضعيزذرميحصحضه

Comment: It is usual unicode... Is it arabic?

Comment: @nicael I think, it's just a keyboard I happened to put on my iPhone's keyboard.

Comment: ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮ ‮

Comment: It was a test ;)

Comment: `if(life.lifestatus == lifefeelings.awesome && life.problems == Null) {System.out.println("YAY!")}`

Comment: Love it :-). However it should be `if(life.status==kLifeStatusTypeAwesome && lifefeelings==kLifeFeelingsTypeAwesome && life.problems == Null){System.out.println("YAY!")}`

Comment: @nicael How on earth do you know whenever I put a comment on this?

Comment: Don't you know what is "notifications"? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, but I thought only the post author was notified, additional users had to be notified through the use of "@". Not you apparently. Simply because you knew when I commented that bit of code.

Comment: And know now ;-). Because I have some [powerz](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234717/mobile-web-refresher/234723#comment772024_234717) that don't have another people (jjjoke ;D). Ever seen this my [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234791/i-can-add-moderator-only-tag-via-a-suggested-edit-and-i-got-no-diamond)? I simply suggested an edit adding a mod-only tag. And it got approved. I officially made a post featured. :DD

Comment: Actually only me and you are talking there so any your comment system understand as reply to me. ;-) Simple!

Comment: I recently tested my ability to answer closed question - it works! :D

Answer (score 3):

> (TESTING LONGER ALL-CAPS ANSWER THAT MIGHT NOT TRIP BOT QUALITY FILTER)

FIRST, LOOK AT THE WHOLE PROGRAM

```
10 N=2000
20 PRINT "ARMSTRONG NUMBERS"
25 PRINT "BETWEEN 1 AND 2000"
30 PRINT
40 FOR 1=1 TO N
50 S=O
60 K=I
70 Q=INT(K/10)
80 R=K-10*Q
90 S=S+R*R*R
100 K=Q
110 IF K<>O THEN 70
120 IF I<>S THEN 130
125 PRINT I
130 NEXT I
140 END
```

FIRST, WE INITIALIZE THE VARIABLE "N" TO 2000, THEN WE PRINT SOME INTRODUCTION TO THE USER. NEXT, THERE IS FOR-LOOP FROM 1 to N (2000). THE LOOP IS DOING IT'S JOB WELL DONE, UNTIL IT REACHES LINE 110. SOMETIMES IT LOOPS, SOMETIMES IT DOESN'T, BUT ANYWAY IT MAY LOOP FROM 70 TO 110. THIS IS ACTUALLY A WHILE-LOOP THAT WILL STOP AFTER "K" IS EQUAL TO "O" (DON'T ASK ME WHY). NEXT, IF "I" IS EQUAL TO "S", THEN IT'S AN ARMSTRONG NUMBER, SO IT WILL BE PRINTED ON THE MONITOR. OTHERWISE, IT WILL BE SKIPPED AND CHECK THE NEXT NUMBER.

Comment: Reading this now hurt my eyes...

Comment: YES, READING THINGS ALL IN CAPS IS ***SO*** ANNOYING.

Answer (score 3):

Posting an answer so I can post a comment so I can test a theory.

Comment: Big bang theory?

Answer (score 3):



Answer (score 3):

This answer should be submitted:

https://serverfault.com/questions/2147483647

This ID onwards, you cannot submit this answer.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> <kbd>F4</kbd> <kbd>F5</kbd> <kbd>F6</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> <kbd>F11</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd><kbd>[PrtScr](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd><kbd>[ScrLk](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd><kbd>[Break](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>

  <kbd>`</kbd>   <kbd>1</kbd>   <kbd>2</kbd>   <kbd>3</kbd>   <kbd>4</kbd>   <kbd>5</kbd>   <kbd>6</kbd>   <kbd>7</kbd>   <kbd>8</kbd>   <kbd>9</kbd>   <kbd>0</kbd>   <kbd>-</kbd>    <kbd>←</kbd>      <kbd>Ins</kbd>  <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>PgUp</kbd>

  <kbd>⇥</kbd>   <kbd>Q</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   <kbd>T</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>   <kbd>U</kbd>  <kbd>I</kbd>  <kbd>O</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd>  <kbd>[</kbd>  <kbd>]</kbd>   <kbd>\</kbd>    <kbd>Del</kbd>    <kbd>End</kbd> <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

 <kbd>[Caps](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>S</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>    <kbd>G</kbd>   <kbd>H</kbd>  <kbd>J</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  <kbd>L</kbd>  <kbd>;</kbd>  <kbd>'</kbd>    <kbd>Enter</kbd>   

    <kbd>[Shift](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>      <kbd>Z</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>   <kbd>B</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>   <kbd>.</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>     <kbd>[Shift](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>    

 <kbd>[Ctrl](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd> <kbd>[Fn](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd><kbd>[❖](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>  <kbd>[Alt](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>                                                        <kbd>[Alt](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>   <kbd>[▤](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd>      <kbd>[Ctrl](http://askubuntu.com)</kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Hello

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

this is a test answer for the Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit, at least for the auto-editor part.

i hope u like ur answer.

```
Code should remain untouched. Hello. Thanks!
```

There are several lines with variable amounts of spaces just above this one.

im sure `all code survives. thanks in advance.`

Python started with correct capitalization... but apache did not.

hope it helps somebody!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a test to try out grace period editing.

Due to new logic, the grace period ends if a new comment is added. But what happens if that comment is deleted?

**Edit Log**

```
v1 - #1 - Initial Post
v1 - #2 - Edit in grace period (normal)
v? - #3 - Edit after comment added by another user and deleted
```

So the conclusion is that a comment will stop ninja edits, but only if they are around.

Answer (score 3):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 3):

Comment: I knew it! `<!--` and `-->` can be used to circumvent the "each post must be at least 30 chars long" rule!

Answer (score 3):

1. Here's a numbered list with others inside it.

   ```
   Here's a code block that's a part of it.
   ```

   - Here's a bulleted inner list

     ```
     And here's another code block belonging to it.
     ```

     5. It keeps happening!

        ```
        I warned you about indents bro!
        ```

Answer (score 3):

­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: [­](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/298222#298222)

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: [ ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299497/how-can-i-prevent-my-trivial-answer-from-being-converted-to-a-comment)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to test some of the reputation features here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to have raw DEL character (<kbd>del</kbd>) on answer submit, but not edit submit.

Comment: (I don't understand why should it be converted to keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

Sandbox post to test [ExpandShortLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js) userscript.

There is a link in the dots below, can you spot it?

---

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [.](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [.](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js) . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

---

If you can't find it yet, then [install ExpandShortLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js)

Comment: This userscript also works for comments[.](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js "WOW you found a third!!!")

Comment: . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: Smokey detects linked punctuations :)

Comment: Mostly dots in body: Body - 500 out of 1000 characters are dots.

Comment: use javascript embed: var userscript=document.createElement('script');userscript.src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/master/ExpandShortLinks.user.js";document.head.append(userscript);

Comment: nope can't find it

Comment: I found the second one first.

Answer (score 3):

This is made out of curiosity how linked posts in the sidebar work. I will take two random posts from the site 315373 and 315416.

One is linked directly in the answer: [Vertical alignment of tags differs between Ask page and inline tag editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315373/vertical-alignment-of-tags-differs-between-ask-page-and-inline-tag-editor) 
The other one is linked just in a comment.

After this both questions have this one (sandbox) among their linked questions in the sidebar.

Then I have added a comment containing both links. Some ten minutes later I have deleted the second comment (the one containing both links).

Some time after that both those questions have sandbox among linked questions.

I am pretty sure I saw different behavior - also it was in cases when one of the comments was posted *before* introducing linked questions in the sidebar. I will try to make some experiment with such links - to have a bit more data - and then I will post a bug report.

Comment: Here is the comment with the link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315416/remove-at-least-one-tag-is-required-near-the-tag-field

Answer (score 3):

Attempts to trigger the "unformatted code in question" bug on save.

```js
function showInnerHtml() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('questionField').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<input id="questionField" type="text" value="420">
  <button type="button" onClick="showInnerHtml()">Button</button>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the quality filters are turned off on meta sites, or more likely turned on only on SO.

Comment: yep, I realized that soon after posting.

Comment: 420, the best number ever. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

short                                               answer

Comment: Visit mine:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316847/366626 . The SE's shortest answer ever.

Answer (score 3):

Don't run this snippet. It contains a virus!

```html
<marquee>Influenza</marquee>
```

In any case, my advice is to avoid marquees like the plague.

Comment: Do you know another thing you should really avoid like the Plague? The Plague.

Answer (score 3):

> [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

If you can see there's a tag over there without hovering, then you gotta be careful!

This is a useful test for [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

[Introducing HTML5 http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41z0FVu9ZhL._SL500_AA300_.jpg](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321687299) and [HTML5 For Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/)

Comment: **Please don't** *actually* edit this answer, it's needed in its current form for a [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324416/295232).

Answer (score 3):

```
this isn't a real language (language: thisdoesnotexist)
```

```thisdoesnotexist
this isn't a real language (language: lang-thisdoesnotexist)
```

```
this isn't a real language (lang: thisdoesnotexist)
```

```
this isn't a real language (lang: lang-thisdoesnotexist)
```

---

When... did code fences start working / not looking terrible?

```rust
fn foo() {}
```

```rb
def foo
end
```

```
fn main() { a[] }
```

Answer (score 3):

`print('hello world')`

`print('hello world')`

So `<code>...</code>` is equivalent to just simply using

```
`...`
```

But like:

```
print('hello world')
```

Is different.

Answer (score 3):

## How to put a plain hashtag (#) in a post

When you type a # at the beginning of a line in a post and try to put text immediately after it in a post using markdown, it creates text in a header:

## Text

If you want actually put a # in the post, you must use a backslash to escape it:

#Text

Here is the plain text for the heading text:

```
#Text
```

and for the text with an actual hashtag:

```
\#Text
```

Answer (score 3):

## That spoiler formatting has been biting me. Time to see how it works.

First up:

## markdown lists in a spoiler:

#### Formatting:

```
>! 1. one
2. two
```

#### Result:

> ! 1. one
>   2. two

#### Formatting:

```
>! 1. one
>! 2. two
```

#### Result:

> 1. one
>  2. two

## HTML lists in spoiler:

## Inline

#### Formatting:

```
>! <ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></ul>
```

#### Result:

> - one
> - two
> - three

### Not-inline HTML lists in spoiler 1:

#### Formatting:

```
>!<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

#### Result:

> !
>
> - one
> - two
> - three

### Non-inline lists in spoiler 2:

#### Formatting:

```
>!<ul>
>!    <li>one</li>
>!    <li>two</li>
>!    <li>three</li>
>!</ul>
```

#### Result:

> - one
> - two
> - three

Answer (score 3):

**Happy new year!**

#### Happy new year!

### Happy new year!

## Happy new year!

### Happy new year!

#### Happy new year!

**Happy new year!**

## It's 2019!

Comment: A happy new year too!

Answer (score 2):

http:\//www.example.com/index.php

Comment: This is a test.

Comment: Perhaps, definitely not. Maybe*!*

Comment: Is it a test or not. Seems to be a infinite loop question.

Comment: testing highlight...`testing`.

Comment: Test failed....

Comment: This is a lie...

Comment: [help/on-topic] [help/behavior] [help/promotion]

Answer (score 2):

## Stack Exchange HTML Div ID Jumping

[Clicking here should (ideally) send you to a `<div>` at the bottom of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144454/160519#bottom)

the bottom

Comment: Stackexchange can use js to mangle/hash user-supplied div ids so they are globally unique

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[B](http://google.com)[o](http://yahoo.com)[w](http://bing.com) [d](http://youtube.com)[o](http://stackoverflow.com)[w](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)[n](http://ruby-lang.org) [b](http://perl.org)[e](http://en.wikipedia.org)[f](http://alexa.com)[o](http://facebook.com)[r](http://twitter.com)[e](http://amazon.com) [m](http://blogspot.com)[y](http://msn.com) [l](http://ebay.com)[i](http://microsoft.com)[n](http://tumblr.com)[k](http://ask.com)[s](http://pinterest.com)[!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178401/180276)

**Each character** in the above sentence, *including spaces and puntuation*, is a valid link. My link density RULES ALL! :D

Answer (score 2):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>[image: Wow]</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: That's the creepiest pyramid I've ever seen....

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - [This is even more...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148662/187824)

Comment: Thanks for crashing my browser, asshole :)

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is write-protected*

(think so? no.)

[click me to edit!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/213841/edit)

[To see comments click here and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/213841#comments-link-213841)

To un-protect the answer (temporarily, only for you) in Chrome, right click the whitespace below, choose "Inspect Element," find the first `<sub>`, click it, and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>***** this is a footnote that prevents editing or sharing or flagging this question</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

**edited**

Comment: You forgot to "protect" the downvote button ;-)

Comment: Hmm.... looks like they fixed this "bug" at some point. /cc @Arjan

Comment: @ShadowWizard Edited it.

Comment: @Peanut of course, as I said in previous comment they fixed the bug causing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a test for editing via the API.

Test Images (from https://stackexchange.com/about/logos):

[image]

(freehand added by [Freehand Circles Drawing Tool](https://stackapps.com/q/6353/26088) (Freehand Circles Drawing Tool) - install to add freehand drawings to any image on any SE site with ease! :)

Comment: Lol, and why freehand? Nobody sees it in sandbox, needs another target :D

Comment: @nicael http://stackapps.com/questions/6353/freehand-circles-drawing-tool. BTW it only works on answers FOR NOW - I'll fix it in a bit!

Comment: Great! Come here https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta! That's fun.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>T</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>h</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>s</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                        
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>b</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>u</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>t</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>o</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>n</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>s</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        <kbd><kbd>g</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>o</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>w</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>i</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>n</kbd></kbd>
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>g</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>e</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>x</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>o</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>n</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>e</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>n</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>t</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
        
    
    
        
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>i</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>a</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>l</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>l</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>.</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        <kbd><kbd>W</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>h</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>a</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>t</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>s</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>h</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>o</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>u</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>l</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>d</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        <kbd><kbd>I</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                        
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>d</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>o</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>?</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
            
            
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>?</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>?</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>?</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>?</kbd></kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        <kbd><kbd><kbd>?</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>?</kbd></kbd>
                        
                    
                    
                        <kbd><kbd>?</kbd>
                        
                        <kbd>?</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 2):



Answer (score 2):

<sup><sub>This is a super-subbed text.</sub></sup> But why?

o<sup>h<sup>i<sup>s<sup>e<sup>e<sup>h<sup>o<sup>w<sup>t</sup>h</sup>t</sup>h</sup>i</sup>s</sup>w</sup>o</sup>r</sup>k<sub>s<sub>n<sub>o</sub>w</sub>!</sub>

Comment: [tag:bug] Tags in comments! Amazing!

Comment: I [tag:support] this.

Comment: Er... putting [tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags) in comments is super easy.

Answer (score 2):

> **Thanks for your edit!**
> This edit will be visible only to you until it is [peer reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44444).

Utf+8 is really great.

Ûʧ÷ȣ ıŝ ŗèǟƖʅȳ ĝʀȇατ.

ȏͥȏ̂ͥpͪšͭ͂ ͆ĭͥͮ̏̔ͣ ͦ̈ͨ͗m͛̍̆eͬ̃̽͋ͪ͛̀sͬ͊ͪ͌̎̈s͋̀ed͐ i͒ͨ̄tͮ͂͂ͩͣ ̈́̔̆̃ủṗ̓͂ͬ

w͒̐̀̔̄ͣ̉<sup>h̰̙̖̹̖̬̳͙̣<sup>e̙̣̜<sup>nͤ́̋̐</sup> ̝͍̯̼̳̼y̙̤̪̠̪</sup>oͩ̇̋̏̑̋ͨ̋̊͋̈́͋</sup>u̳̥̭̱̫ ̭̼̝̮͔͖<sub>c͔̮̣̤͕̣͖<sub>o͓͔̝̬̩̟ͅ<sub>n̮̖̳̩͔̮̜</sub>v̤̮̬</sub>e͎̠ͅ</sub>r̟͖̻͕̗̦̼<sup>t͇̫̭̪̹̪ <sup>̦̱͍̼̫̠͎͉s̝̪͚̮̺͙̳̤<sup>t͈̘̙̲̟̲</sup>u̜̥͙̞̫̺͙ͅ</sup>f̙̩̮̙̬̳̟</sup>f̹̪͍̳̹͓ <sub>̮͇t̹̟̟̝͙̞̫<sub>o̰̰ͅ <sub>̹͚̹o̬̦̤͕̠̣</sub>t̺̬͕͓͔̖̯̤</sub>ẖ͎͓̩</sub>e̺̘<sup>r͕̼̖̘̣ <sup>ͅs̟̪<sup>t̳̦</sup>u̮̟̖̯̥̝͈̫</sup>f̦̮̤</sup>f̺͙ <sub>͖̺̙͕̮i̜̱̗̣<sub>t̺ <sub>̥t̰͙̦̞̗̱͇̺̲</sub>u̜̺̯̯͖͈̱</sub>r̻̳̗̞̭̥̞̝̜</sub>n͔͚̫̘<sup>s͇͍̰͇ <sup>͙͖ͅo͚̭̰̮̬<sup>u̠̯̰̤̞̠̲̙</sup>t̲̘̘̺̙͕</sup> ̺͍̲̻͉͉w̫̥̲͉̗</sup>e̬<sub>i͎͓̹͈̹͇̦̰<sub>ȑͧͮ̑ͦ̂ͮ̎̎͗̌ͮ̾̚<sub>d̪̣̺̦͔͓̜̯</sub></sub></sub>
W͟͠a̵͜͟i̢̛͢͡͠t͘ ̶̛͜͠͠ẁ̸̨͢h͞a̢͠͝t͏̵̕'̨̛́͡s̵̶͟ ̢͜͝͝͠h̸͡a͜p̶̢͝͝p̶͏̵͝ę͡n͟͜i̛͢͡ńg̶̢͠

W̯̦̙͇̻̟̠̯̟̠͇̺̬̬̭͍̱̒̈́̿̌̄ͦ͆̀ͭ̐ͯ̌͋ͮ̆̽̍̃̎͝H̡̡͔͎͈̘͍̪̥̪̱̗͕̼̫͇̘͒͐ͭ̈́ͦ͢͞͝ͅY̵̷̡͎̣̜̫̰̘̪̝͈̝̙̠̙ͩ̎ͭ̎͆̔̏̾ͮ̋̅ͭ̓̿́͡ ̷̢̺͉̼̫̗̣͚̀̅̆̈́̉ͥ̎͛͞͞M̧̒̽̽̏̋ͬ̐͆͂̕҉̨̜̣̻̻͚̲̝͚̼ͅU̱̱̜̬̥̖̜͉̩͙̹ͪ̓͌͂͂ͭͧ̐ͣͯ͆ͯͭ́͟͟͡͠ͅS̈́̀̄͆̃͐̈́́ͩͨͦ̓ͩͩ͐̇͆͋̚̕҉̳͈͙͍̬̗ͅT̷͕͓̰̱̼̠͈̲̩̟͕̰͕̘͓̫̞̬̯̀ͩͦ̿ͥͧͪͫͩ͑͌̒͜ ̴͓̥̩̠͎͖͓̞̲̥̩̺̤̗̟͐͛̊ͪ́̃̒̃ͥ͊ͣͭͭ͘͢͠ͅT̶͚̜̩͉͕̥̞̠̳̿́̈́̌̈̇̐͐͛̕͘H͇̱͕̭̺̼͕̻̬̗̞̮͓̙͇̫̬̤͗̓̄ͩ̾̌ͧ̑̀͢͢͠ͅI̷̡̗̹̱͍̹̖̣̹̪̮͇̙̝͍̲͕ͥ̋ͥͬ̓͌̍ͫ͑͂ͪ̚͡ͅS͕̥̻̪̠̮͍̞͉̀ͧ̆̒ͧ̔̄̂̚͘̕͢͞ ̌͌̉̇̀ͥͬ͒̈̽ͩ̍ͯͧ̽͋ͧ͏͉̻͈͔̰̠͖̪̩͔̫͚̝͎̺͍͍̤ͅW̛͖̺͉̗̱̩̤̱͚̰͕̓̌͊̀̉͋͛ͨ̐̒̇͗̍̚̚͜O̧ͨ̎̑ͧ̓҉̨͚̰̳̯̭̻̳̖̕R̴̙̞̝̪̖̀̽̐ͮͤ͋ͤͣ̈́̃ͮ̒͠L̘̰͚̼͈̗͍̲͖͚͍͇͊̾̓̽̉̓̉͐̈̀͢D̓̊̑͌ͧͩ̌̿̂͌ͮ̅̇̉̒̅̈́͝҉̞̝̥͎̖̞̗͈̺̟͖̺͈͖̫̤͘ ̷̛̛͖̮̪̙̮̟̣̥͇͓͍̗̀ͯ̿͂ͤ̅̏ͪ̂̔͆̔̀͋T͑̎̌͐ͣ͊̊ͬ͐͊҉̫̣̼̩̺̬̗̫̝̰̗̫̪̼̣̬͎̳͘͟͠O̲̤̼̳͓̟̲̘̬̹̣̺͈͊̏̆̇́̈́́̆͐̊̔̐ͪ͟͠ͅȐ̶̝͕͇̭̿̾ͨͣ̔̑Tͦͧͧ̀̿̓̕͠͏̺̙̱̞͢U̹̖͔̖̻̺͙̮̙̝͎̟͚͉̍̇͆͛͆͐̈̕͞͠R̵̨͕̬̻̥̭̼͎̪͍̘͑̓͂͑̈ͣͫ̔͋͛̓̈̇̓͂̊̐͒́͜Ȩ̅̉ͭ̀͛ͥ́̚҉̸̼̗̬̦̼̭̝̼̣̙̗̦͇̩̱̙͜ͅͅ ̼̙̣̬͓͔̫̖͇̥̑̑ͭ̇̏̍ͧ̒̐̾ͧ̓ͤ͗̆̀̉͐͑̀͜͡͞M̆́͊̎̋̑̆̐ͦ́͆ͤ͆͘͏̘̥̤͎̰̙̣̗E̢̨̥̭̥̣̟͖̺͙̜̙̞̘͎̞̭̓̇̾ͫ͘̕͠ͅ

`ooh, code overrides the xraziness`

Comment: W̧̨̰̦̪͌̄͗͂͟͠T̸̡̤͚̪̹͍͔̣͔̤̮͉̣͐̆̊ͣ̈́̔̉̎̆͒ͨͮͣ̅̒͗̈́ͣF̸̬͍̜̺̼̬̪̣̟̙̬̻̗͇̼̤̺͎̽̒͒͐̌͜ͅW̷̹͍̥̦͇̹̖̜̙͚̯͇̟̘͕͔̩̽ͪ͑̀͂̋ͪ͐ͩ̒̾̎̒ͮͮ͑̃ͦ͛͢͟͝͠T̸ͣͭ͐̓̀̽̇̽ͬ̀̀͏҉̸͕̪͎͉͚̘͓̤̞̞͚̪F̶̨̬̝̥̙̻̼̲̹̭͋̑̈ͪ̓̾̀͋̊͑͌̂̔̈̀̏͌̋̚͟W̶̜͚̙͕̬̹̹̦̹͙̹͇̺͉̣̃̔̓͑̋̌̃ͪͤ͊̆̍͑̇̊ͭ̔̄̂̀̕͝ͅT̨̤͚͚̺̰̬̩̤̜̮̅̓ͤ͊̀̂̋̆̊̎ͬ̕͟F͛̄̅̎́̄̄ͪ͆̊͆̏̀̊̚̚͝͏̸̷̨̩̩̤̜̮͉͕͖͎W̸̡̪̖̼̳̫̘̱̔̈̿͛ͬͮ͊ͮ̊ͨ̆ͬͤ̀̚͡T̢̤̞̹̤͈̳̹̲͎̪̮͓ͫ̈̒͑̈̀͢͡F̨̛̝̩̼͈͚̠̙ͬ͑ͯ͐ͫ͌̽̋͐̉̓̉ͫ͛̇̀̚̚W͌̏ͣ̐ͪ̂̊͞҉̖̜͖̰̰̫̰̞̹̲̤̼͈̘̜̟̠͎͟͡T̫̠̭̹̘̰͙̞̗̮̬̪̾̈́ͤ̐̂ͨͫ̓̇͛̐͠F̆̓̀̆͋ͥ͂̐͑̎ͮ̉ͥ̚҉̵̨̠͙̮͖͈͙̤̖W̵ͥ̈́̌̆̆̑̒͌̈́́̆ͧ͆ͫ͐͏̴̸̣̰̼̭̦̥̲̼̼̥̮̦̠̹̹ͅŢ̴̱̪̼̦̬̟͖̰͈̻̦͍͂̽̿ͬ͋̇ͭ͐̍̐ͣ̽̉̿̈ͩͣ̎͢F̌̑̀̓̅͏̴̹͙̺̱̝̗͝W͔͙̭͍͔̰͙͔̤͒̈ͭ̎ͤ̎̈͛ͥ̔͊͋̎̏ͭ́͞Ţ̸̩̰̦̤̳̭̖̤͎͙̊͛͐ͭ͂ͮ̄̿̅̑ͥ̕͜F̴ͮ̿̊̇̄̈́͘҉̠̣͈͇͎̭͍̙̱̰̜͓̣̠̖̦̩

Comment: W̷̠̩̜̩͎̘̹͛ͧ́́̊̎̃͒ͮ̃̽̒̅̉̇̇͋̚͢T̵͆̌ͨͥ̊ͬͦͯͪ̍ͣ̉͂ͯ͏̧͎̞̖̞̭̭͠F̸̛̙̦̗̭͙̞̞̠͙̖̙͆̄ͤ̐̏̐̌́͜͠W̷̛̟͕͚͙̯̪̞̫̃ͬ̾̆ͩͮͥ͢͞Ṯ̴̢̛̮̦̗͉̰̠͎̰͔̲͔͓̯̺̭̱ͯ͊̍̈́͛F̴̜̜̤͇̗̦̤̞̗̭̰͍͙̻̃̈́̂ͪ͑̂ͨ̊͑̊͋ͧ̃̍̈͜͞͡W̸̡̘̬̦͚̖̗͕̝̪̥͙ͭ̓ͨͥ͗͋̔ͥͤ͆ͪ͂̎̀̚T͌͗͛͐̈́̑̀̐̑͋̈҉҉̸͇͈͎̝͠F̏̃ͨͮ́̏̄̐̾̒͆ͪ͟҉̠̻̖̘͚̦̲̺̤̰͘W̑̍̀͊ͫ̓ͧ̋̆ͥͮ̆̊̈́̽͏̴͡҉̳͓̝̱̟̲̝̦͕T̟͎͔͍̩̼̮͎̤͎̝͍̼͑̑̅̐̇͗͑ͮ͊͑̍̑͒͂ͪ͒̀̕͝͞͠ͅF̷̷̧̫̝͕͇̮̗̉̔ͣ̑̇̐̓̒̊̓ͭ̎̍̓̒ͦͯ̀́͘W͖̰̹͙̠̥̳̻̩̼͇̤̯̺̺͉̑̈́̔ͨͫ̅ͪ̕͜ͅT͑͛ͥ̑ͩ̐͐̆ͩͧ͆ͯ̈̈́ͤ̈́͛͊̄͏̷̞̙͙̦̲͍̱͓̼̯̬̪̬̬ͅF̹̹͔̲́̐͆̑ͥͥ͗̑̌̓͊̽ͫ̓̓͑͊͒͢͞Ẁ̦̣̱͈̘̲̭͓̝ͫ̊̐̏ͦ̈̑ͬ̃͒̓̀̀̚͜Ţ̸̱̙͕͉̙̓̉̅͗F̢̫̻̞͕̖̘͕̩̟͕̬̤͒̆ͣͩ̾̈͋͋̂̓̌̚̕͘͟ͅẆ̴̱̮̱͇̼̯̹͈̘̹͎̼̝̟ͣ́̍̅̔͊̎ͬ͐̆ͥ͐ͫͥ́ͦ̔ͪ́͢͝ͅT̸̬̤̯̪̻̳̼̹͈͕̙ͯ̊̇͆́̇̾̐͋͋ͮ̃ͥͥ̉̏͋̕͟͜͡Fͫͧͤ̔͞͝͏̱̗̩̱͕̩̱̣̳͡

Answer (score 2):

deal with it: no more zalgo that overflows the entire page

Answer (score 2):

This is too short for a post.

Answer (score 2):

```
              *     *  *       +     *      *     *    *
         *       *      *     ###       *           *
            *      *         #####            *      *      *
    *     *      *     * * ####o### * *    *      *
              *      * ####|###########  *
           *     *  *   * ####"##o## *    *               *       
      *             #################|####        *        
            *    ## *  ###|###o########  *             *
    *    *     *  ##############|###o##"####                  *
                    *###"###o#############           *      
        *      * ***  * ###########|## *  *** *       *
                ####|###o #####o##############      *     *
        *** *     ###############|##o#####    *      *
        *****   *     #      ####      #    *     *
      *********      *   *   ####     *        *       *
    ************************######************************ ******
```

Answer (score 2):

[Testing search for accented characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289001/is-search-able-to-find-accented-characters-entered-as-html-entities-such-as-fra): Gâteaux, François, Gödel, Pólya, Čech.

Answer (score 2):

Test to see how IE reacts to a large image in a `<kbd>` tag.

[image]

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

No more breaking the page please.

Answer (score 2):

```
    alert("Hello World!");
    body{
        color:blue;
        text-decoration:underline;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello World!</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            Hello World!
        </body>
    </html>




A|B|C
-†-†-
D|E|F
-----
G|H|I
```

Answer (score 2):

## ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

## Am I the center of the universe?

Comment: Just the center of the post :)

Answer (score 2):

#### Does ```` ``` ```` formatting work to make a code block, like a four-space indent?

`foo
bar`

Apparently not.

(But see the code of this paragraph or the heading, for what consecutive `` ` ``s actually do.)

Comment: The backticks are for inline code, whatever is between two of those is formatted as code, but without prettify. It `also works in comments`.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes. I assumed it would *not* work to create a code block, but wanted to [test the claim that it did](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40248743#40248743)--which is apparently true only for some other dialects of Markdown--just in case I had missed something big [in that post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17165/syntax-highlighting-in-pre-block/17167#17167).

Answer (score 2):

iOS 11 allows me to add Red Freehand Circles™ to screenshots! Rejoice!

[image]

Comment: Why are your name here "Stephen Leppik" but actually "Car Insurance"?

Answer (score 2):

#### How to Post Duplicate Answers

1. Duplicate your post content in one post.
2. Take an image capture of any "0 score" votes plus voting buttons for the duplicate answer.
3. Create a mock-up of the share/edit/flag links, plus the "answered at" complete with GMT timestamp, "community-wiki", and link to show revisions.

<sub>[share](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304164) [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/304164/edit) [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3122/formatting-sandbox/304164#)                                                            [edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/304164/revisions) Jan 5 at 1:20                                community wiki</sub>
                                                                                                                     <sup>[5 revs, 2 users 97%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/304164/revisions)</sup>
                                                                                                                                                  <sup>[rgettman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/203888/rgettman)</sup>

---

<sup>[image]</sup>     <sup>4. (Optional) Create a comment mockup. – [rgettman](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/203888/rgettman) Dec 8 '17 at 0:56</sup>

---

<sup>[add a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/304164/#)</sup>

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### How to Post Duplicate Answers

1. Duplicate your post content in one post.
2. Take an image capture of any "0 score" votes plus voting buttons for the duplicate answer.
3. Create a mock-up of the share/edit/flag links, plus the "answered at" complete with GMT timestamp, "community-wiki", and link to show revisions.

Comment: 4. (Optional) Create a comment mockup.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Is striekthrourh spornted?</s>

Thankfully, yes.

Comment: <s>but not in comments</s> ---this does not work either---

Comment: You have a reasonably small program. You can debug this one yourself, using these excellent suggestions: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ *(warning: these are simple steps, but it still might not be easy going)*

Comment: You have a reasonably small program. You can debug this one yourself, using [these excellent suggestions](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). *(warning: these are simple steps, but it still might not be easy going)*

Comment: In case someone is wondering about Jon Arndt's comments above, see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/83735960

Comment: While this strikethrough may answer the question, it is better to include the reasons for crossing out parts of the answer here and provide the strikethrough for reference. Strikethrough-only answers can become invalid if markdown support is removed.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[This is fixed now :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306265/350567)

---

Tags on mobile looks a bit worse these days...

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)

### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)

#### [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)

**[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)**

*[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)*

<s>[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)</s>

<sup>[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)</sup><sub>[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [meta](/questions/tagged/meta)</sub>

[Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19499#19499)

Answer (score 2):

I woke up with a beer bottle in one hand the below code in a petite notebook in the other hand...

```js
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]](([][[]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+[+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]])()[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+((+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]])+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]])+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+!+[]+[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+[!+[]+!+[]]+[+[]])+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[])[(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[!+[]+!+[]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]]+(![]+[+![]])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[!+[]+!+[]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]((!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+[![]]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+!+[]]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(+(!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]]+[+!+[]]))[(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(+![]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(+![]+[![]]+([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]](!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+!+[]])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])()(([]+[])[([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]()[+[]])[+[]]+(!+[]+!+[]+[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]])+[])+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]])()
```

Comment: Stack Snippets don't support BrainF*ck

Comment: Wow, that code actually does something. The beginning is equivalent to `[]["filter"]`, which is equivalent to `new Array().filter`. It uses stuff like the fact that `![]` evaluates to `false` and `+[]` evaluates to `0`, so `(![]+[])[+[]]` becomes `'f'`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a little JavaScript, this will do what you want. The img is in the vertical middle of the section at first, but it will stay in place when the size of the section changes.

```js
document.querySelector('.abs').dataset.top = document.querySelector('.abs').offsetTop;

document.getElementById('more').onclick = function() {
  //console.log('start');
  var img = document.querySelector('.abs');
  if (document.getElementById('more').checked) {
    img.style.top = img.dataset.top+'px'; img.style.margin = '0';
  }
  else {
    img.style.top = ''; img.style.margin = '';
  }
  //console.log('end');
};
```

```css
section {position: relative;}

#more ~ p {display: none;}
#more:checked ~ p {display: block;}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; height: 40px;
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
  eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
  <input id="more" type="checkbox"><label for="more"> Show more</label>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
  nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</p>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/150x40" alt="150x40" class="abs">
</section>
```

Comment: By the way, the HTML src attribute is not the same as the JavaScript src property. If you set the src to, say, http:​//example.com, then `.getAttribute('src')` will report 'http:​//example.com', while `.src` will have a slash appended.

Comment: `.getAttribute('src')` will report example.com.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>

<kbd>caps</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>~</kbd>

<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>m</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>?</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>

Comment: I've often wished you could do this in comments...

Comment: To format as code, select it then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Interstate 85</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Test case for maximum clique problem

Input: vertices: {1, 2, 3}, edges: {(1,2), (2,3)}
Output: {1,3}

Illustration image: (black: vertex, blue: edge, red: edge in the found maximum clique)

[image]

---

Test case for traveling salesman problem

Input: vertices: {1, 2, 3, 4}, edges: {(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4)}, weight: (1,2)→2, (2,4)→2, (3,4)→2, (1,3)→2, (3,2)→6, (1,4)→5
(each edge here represent two opposite edges in a connected graph)
Output: {1,2,4,3}

Illustration image: (black: vertex/edge, red: edges on the found circuit)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

lemme submit an answer..........

Answer (score 2):

This is just a simple test. `:D`. Testing to see if extended comment discussion triggers waffle hat.

Edit Double edit

Comment: OK, so now keep commenting. Your turn

Comment: tag.  **:D :D :D**

Comment: OK another one!

Comment: tag is like this @Fabby

Comment: I'm not *that dumb!*  **:D ;-)** @AnkitSharma

Comment: @Fabby ok sorry for assuming

Comment: No apologies needed! I was just pulling @dylan's leg

Comment: I think @Dylan is also here

Comment: We are continuing out conversation from another Answer... @dylan

Comment: Or you're smoking aromatic herbs @Dylan

Comment: @Dylan ia m amoking my insomina

Comment: OK, if more than 2 people are conversing, the extended discussions tag is not showing up apparently.

Comment: @Fabby Honestly I think thats probably enough. Now we wait and see what happens. Im pretty sure that should do it if this is it.

Comment: If everyone is here, let me tell you gusy Aquaman is awesoem film

Comment: I think we need the "comments are not for extended discussions"  Move to chat? ***needs to come up***

Comment: Here's one more comment.

Comment: Huh... Not coming up in sandbox.

Comment: MuSt JoIn ThE fUn

Comment: did it came yet

Comment: @WELZ welcome to fun

Comment: Hey, what's going on here?

Comment: This comment war is real

Comment: Did someone say *COMMENT WAR*?

Comment: Player 3 has joined the chat.

Comment: And i don't have the money to buy another

Comment: _short-comment_

Comment: :0 how dare you bump me?

Answer (score 2):

☺❤⭐✨⚡☀❗❓✌☎⚾⚽✈⚠⭕❌®©

Answer (score 2):

Bug report from [Why doesn't URL appear in this question's rendered output?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1597/why-doesnt-url-appear-in-this-questions-rendered-output)

---

Testing posting a link with the French accent (i.e. capital H that disappears!?)

- Normal link: `https://www.example.com` → https://www.example.com
- Capital "H" link: `Https://www.example.com` →

Answer (score 2):



Answer (score 2):

I am trying to test a bug relating to the revision history of a post. This was quite enlightening. We saw that the first and second edits were combined into one revision with the summary from the first edit. Now the question is what will happen if we do this again *outside* of the grace period. It has been more than five minutes since the third edit, so now we will see if the fourth edit (i.e. this one) will by default keep the revision summary of the third edit or if it will generate a new one.

Comment: This accomplished my goal. Bug report coming up. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

I'm bored, so I'm trying to make marquee art:

```html
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
<marquee>@@@@@@@@@@</marquee>
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int,int> m;
}
```

<sub>Testing two edits without a second edit summary. This is the first edit.
This is the second edit. A third unsummarised edit.</sub>

Comment: **Bold text** = Bold text and _Italic text_  = Italic text or *Italic text* = Italic text

Comment: A not-logged-in user can't click on the dynamic "show <n> comments" when it was previously the no link "add comment (requirements)".

Comment: Another comment

Answer (score 1):

If MathJax is not supported on your site:

Me ∈ Testers

Testers ⊂ Users

Answer (score 1):

Test edit

This is a spoiler:

> A normal spoiler.

Code:

```
>! A normal spoiler.
```

Test if we can get spoilers with code

> they
>      do not
>       work in preview;
>        they show as text;
>         they don't work at all

Code:

```
>!     they
>!      do not
>!       work in preview;
>!        they show as text;
>!         they don't work at all
```

Test to see if we can trick the parser not to render this as a spoiler:

> !Latex Error

Where the code is:

```
> !Latex Error
> <br>
```

This is the normal blockquote:

> Some text

And some more text to check for distortions...

```
Month    Week    Year    Concat    Hours    Total_Hours
  1       2      2011    122011      8           12
  1       2      2011    122011      4           12
  1       2      2010    122010      7            7
  1       2      2009    122009      5            5
```

test test 2

#### Broken Image:

[image: inline image]

Comment: This is a test comment

Comment: This is a test comment

Comment: [test](http://code.google.com/p/es-lab/wiki/Talks#Changes_to_ECMAScript,\_Part_2:_Harmony_Highlights_-_proxies_and)

Comment: Hmmm, test test

Comment: dat [](jfalkdasfd)

Comment: [Cool](http://hahgay.com)

Comment: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox` [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122) ([Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122)) [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72879) [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122)

Comment: Hmm http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160474/editing-comments-using-an-iphone

Comment: [Editing comments using an iPhone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160474) fdfd

Comment: [Formatting Sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72879)

Comment: [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72879)

Comment: This is a test comment

Answer (score 1):

> ! Trying to get Markdown to nest multiple paragraphs in spoiler tags
>
> ! Looks unsuccessful.

However:

> #### Omg, a title!
>
> - And a list too!
>
> ## <sub>What <sup>is <sub>this <sup>HTML <sub>trickery?</sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: add a `!` on the blank line...

Comment: Indeed, that kind of expects the users to understand the two-spaces-for-br trick (though that is still not the same thing). Also the exclamation mark keeps one from using lists and other Markdown options. But well, guess one cannot have it all!

Comment: @Arjan Yes, unless...

Comment: You win :-) I find it actually a bit odd that SE allows for HTML and meanwhile tries to stick with the Markdown specs as good as possible. Markdown not supporting any spoilers, I like the added `>!` syntax, which still allows other Markdown parsers to render that without breaking too much. But allowing for mixing with some subset of HTML kind of defeats that quest. Or at least in theory.

Answer (score 1):

**Testing.**

## add(num1, num2) {…}

*Markdown source:*

```
#add(num1, num2) {…}
```

**Escaped `#`:**

#add(num1, num2) {…}

*Markdown source:*

```
\#add(num1, num2) {…}
```

**Wrapped in backticks (`` `code` ``):**

`#add(num1, num2) {…}`

*Markdown source:*

```
`#add(num1, num2) {…}`
```

**Indented by 4 spaces:**

```
#add(num1, num2) {…}
```

*Markdown source:*

```
    #add(num1, num2) {…}
```

---

**Testing.**

I ain't* here.

- am not

*Markdown source:*

```
I ain't* here.

*am not
```

**Escaped `*`:**

I ain't* here.

* am not

*Markdown source:*

```
I ain't\* here.

\* am not
```

**Superscript (`<sup>`):**

I ain't<sup>1</sup> here.

<sup>1</sup> am not

*Markdown source:*

```
I ain't<sup>1</sup> here.

<sup>1</sup> am not
```

**Clarify on hover:**

I [ain't](http:///) here.

*Markdown source:*

```
I [ain't][1] here.

[1]: http:/// "am not"
```

---

**Testing.**

Hello, world!

*Markdown source:*

```
<div id='myDiv'>Hello, world!</div>
```

**Wrapped in backticks (`` `code` ``):**

`<div id='myDiv'>Hello, world!</div>`

**Indented by 4 spaces:**

```
<div id='myDiv'>Hello, world!</div>
```

*Markdown source:*

```
    <div id='myDiv'>Hello, world!</div>
```

---

Made for
[Should Markdown be opt-in?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27645/should-markdown-be-opt-in)  **No.**

Comment: We detected an invalid link in your post, please correct it. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Comment: @Community Very funny.

Answer (score 1):

> ! Spoiler block testing!
>   Hello world
>
> ! Spoiler block testing!
>   Test me
>
> !Spoiler block testing!
>   Yet Another test
>
> ! Spoiler block testing!

Hello world

> Spoiler block testing!

Test me

> Spoiler block testing!

Yet Another test

---

block with paragraph breaks testing-

> Spoiler block testing!
>  √√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√√                                  　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
>  
>   hm, It's cheating I know...

Answer (score 1):

Testing markdown. Thanks Arjan

[image: valid XHTML]

<strike>unfunny</strike>.

<strike><sub>unfunny</sub></strike>.

Oh gee look, you can *so too* underline in Stack Exchange sites:

̲u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲ ̲

̳u̳n̳f̳u̳n̳n̳y̳

̳u̳n̳d̳e̳r̳l̳i̳n̳e̳ ̳

```
  ̲̅M̲̅C̲̅M̲̅X̲̅C̲̅I̲̅X̲̅ ̲̅

  ̲̅m̲̅c̲̅m̲̅x̲̅c̲̅i̲̅x̲̅ ̲̅
```

Comment: Need some help?

Comment: @Arjan Sure... Looking in the markdown manual I wanted to see what the checkmark did. Also I want to post linebreaks in comments

Comment: The `[checkmark]` is a named reference, just like `[1]` which is inserted when using the Insert Image button (which is to be preferred, to ensure that the image is uploaded to the Stack Exchange Pro account at Imgur, which does not expire images). So, you need `[checkmark]: http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10` as well, as shown in that example. And you could rename `checkmark` to anything you like, as long as it's unique. Comments do not allow for newlines. (Though hitting Shift-Return might get you a newline while editing. It won't display though.)

Comment: See the "Basic Links" section in the help for many ways to define URLs for links, which also applies to images. Like the following would work too: `![valid XHTML checkmark](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10)`

Comment: Still not funny? ;-) Enjoy!

Comment: `M̲M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅M̲̅`atress springs!

Answer (score 1):

None:

```
while True do
begin
  struct := 7; { Hallo }
end;
```

Pascal:

```
while True do
begin
  struct := 7; { Hallo }
end;
```

Delphi:

```
while True do
begin
  struct := 7; { Hallo }
end;
```

C:

```
while True do
begin
  struct := 7; { Hallo }
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think code blocks are working correctly after a bulleted list

- one
- two

  This is indented with 4 spaces, but isn't showing as a code block

Paragraph

```
another code block
```

---

- point.
  more on that point.

  ```
  some code for that point
  ```

```
some pointless code.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void test() {
     String temp = "MyOddCodeTest";
     int idx = 0;
 }
```

Here's a spoiler'd code block that looks like a quote:

> !     function foo() {
>          var bar = "hi";
>      }

Here's a spoiler'd code block that looks like code:

> ```
> public void test(){
>     String temp = "MySpoilerCodeTest";
>     int idx = 0;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int i = 0;
```

Testing editor I thing

Answer (score 1):

will the "hai" in the beginning be removed?

Original: `Hai, will the "hai" in the beginning be removed`

Yes!

How about on edits?

Yes!

Ref: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989)

Comment: Why did "hai" return?

Comment: Reason: an HTML comment was prepended.

Comment: &#8238;&#8238;&#8238;

Answer (score 1):

Trying to figure out the proper way to format italic_NONITALICFORWARDSLASH_italic with no spaces:

`*macro*/*conditional*` - *macro*/*conditional*
`*macro*\/*conditional*` - *macro*/*conditional*
`*macro*//*conditional*` - *macro*//*conditional*
`**macro*/*conditional**` - **macro*/*conditional**

This is already done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62728/185025):
You need HTML-formatting `<i></i> or <b></b>`
`<i>macro</i>/<i>conditional</i>` - *macro*/*conditional*

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe, with the amount of rep that you have, that you would consider simply linking to another question is all it takes to make a good answer?

**If your answer to question A can be used in question B, that suggests that B is a duplicate of A and can be closed as such.**

If they are **not** duplicates, then you should be *answering the question*.  Tailor your code to answer the actual question asked.

It has been well established that answers which contain nothing more than links will likely be deleted.  They may be converted to comments, or they may not.  There are plenty of related discussions here.

Answer (score 1):

`await something;`

Comment: <code>**await** something</code>

Answer (score 1):

This should be code:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'P5' => {
    'E' => '06' => [100, 200, 95]
    'B' => '23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]
```

},
      'P2' => {
        'C' => '24' => [18, 23, 2300, 3456]
      },
      'P1' => {
        'A' => '12' => [24, 25, 3200, 5668]
        'D' => '15' => [168]
      }
    };

Comment: If I click edit today, first part is code, rest not: `    $VAR1 = {
      'P5' => {
        'E' => '06' => [100, 200, 95]
        'B' => '23' => [20, 1000, 05, 30]
      },`

Answer (score 1):

I am a crazy editing person.

Third try.. fourth.

Verified through attempts to revert this post that I am unable to do so via mobile. selecting the original in the list has no effect at all.

trying to go beyond the edit grace period to add another item to the list...

I am able to see the edits in the list, but I can't [do anything with them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/119802/vote/3).

Comment: this is merely a test I would not rely on it.

Comment: In fact, if I were you I would ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Just some test for comments...

http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture
`<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture" width="50">`

`http://10.0.0.10/example.com` - [apparently this is not allowed anymore :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI5Gb.png)
    &&

123

Comment: one two three four

Comment: ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄

Comment: [What you did there](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/000/681/what-you-did-there-i-see-it.thumbnail.jpg) :P Trying to get multi-line comments... I've seen  them before... But they elude me :P

Comment: It was not intended to look like multiline; it's more like ① superscript and ② subscript. And, as usual, it's just playing with some  . Unfortunately, you never know what the reader sees...

Comment: heh... yea... my stack exchange chrome notifier doesn't like any of those characters at all :P I know of the zero space character hack for character limits... I wonder if there are any other special chars that I can hack about with...

Comment: There are zillions of them, simply as many don't show, like on my Mac emoji is not shown on Stack Exchange  On the other hand: the characters do have categories defining their use, which might make filtering easy. But things like [MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d538/) are just categorized as a capital letter... ;-)

Comment: ([Screen capture of what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QtjOu.png))

Comment: (And [even less luck on Android](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BEccq.png).)

Comment: [I can see everything other than the emoji character...](http://i.imgur.com/B50By.png)... (chrome on ubuntu)

Comment: And the  looks much better for you! But the emoji is not "whitespace", too bad ;-)

Comment: @com - oh anonymous mod of mods - yes I am aware of this new limitation :)  Hence testing it in the sandbox!  I'm a big fan of your work BTW... Those duplicate link blocks on closed questions are simply gorgeous!  Are you available for some freelance projects? ;)

Comment: So, the links are not allowed, but still, er, allowed?

Comment: @arj - [what happened after I tried to edit](http://i.imgur.com/VteNE.png)

Comment: `\​`​​​​​​​​​​​​  \

Answer (score 1):

Test for edit comment within first grace period.

Edit 1, with edit summary
Edit 2, with edit summary
Edit 3, no edit summary
Edit 4, with edit summary
Edit 5, with edit summary
Edit 6, after 9 minutes, with edit summary
Edit 7, after 9 minutes, with edit summary, overwriting previous summary
Edit 8, after 10 minutes, no edit summary

[Editing within grace period no longer remembers previous edit reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138223/editing-within-grace-period-no-longer-remembers-previous-edit-reason)

Answer (score 1):

This is a test of how to use tables

<kbd><kbd>This is

the

first

column</kbd>
<kbd>And this is

the

second

column</kbd></kbd>

Test links
[foo](http://foo.com)
[foo](https://foo.com)
[foo](http://foo.com/subdir?whowhat=1&nix#anchor)
[foo](https://foo.com/subdir?whowhat=1&nix#anchor)

Testing lists.

1. This is a list followed by indented text

   This is the indented text
2. This is a list followed by `[]()` and indented text

```
This is the indented text
```

3. This is a list followed by `<!-- -->` and indented text

```
This is the indented text
```

4. This is a list followed by `&#x200B;` and indented text

​

```
This is the indented text
```

5. This is a list followed by `&#x200C;` and indented text

‌

```
This is the indented text
```

6. This is a list followed by `&#x200D;` and indented text

‍

```
This is the indented text
```

7. This is a list followed by a pasted 200B and indented text

​

```
This is the indented text
```

Comment: This is a comment to a ball of yarn, or yar​​​​​​​​​​​​​n, or even yar n, as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tabs FTW
```

And this is just some padding text so I can actually answer.

Comment: I would use an HTML comment as padding :-)

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff: That doesn't work anymore, I don't think.

Comment: It does work, I just tested it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152869/193648).

Answer (score 1):

This is a test of a broken hyperlink: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/blahbllabh http://www.iana.org/domains/example/blahbllabh http://www.google.com/blahblabhalbhablahbal

Answer (score 1):

Testing to see if equations (TeX) are supported using any of the longhand environments:

[ x^2 ]

$$
x^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

<table>attempting to inject a *not supported tag</table>

<p>or an allowed one?</p>

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/179635

**edit:** it is pointless, they are escaping `&lt;` and `&gt;` correctly

but well, I managed to find a way to prevent them to stripe off non supported tags :)

Comment: </p><<i>div>this will obviously fail but i want to try anyways<<i>/<i>div>

Answer (score 1):

On my E8200 box this doesn't occur, but on my Atom N450 netbook (both running OpenSuse 11.2), whenever I read the CPU's TSC, the returned value is mod 10 == 0, i. e. it is without remainder divisible by 10. I'm using the RDTSC value for measuring times that interesting pieces of code take, but for the purpose of demonstration I've made up this little program:

```
        .text
        .global _start

_start: xorl    %ebx,%ebx
        xorl    %ecx,%ecx
        xorl    %r14d,%r14d
        movb    $10,%cl
loop:   xchgq   %rcx,%r15          # save to reg
        cpuid
        rdtsc
        shlq    $32,%rdx
        xorq    %rax,%rdx          # full 64 but of RDTSC
        movq    %r14,%r13          # save the old value
        movq    %rdx,%r14          # copy current
        movq    %r14,%rsi          #  argv[1] of printf()
        subq    %r13,%rdx          #  argv[2] (delta)
        leaq    format(%rip),%rdi  #  argv[0]
        xorl    %eax,%eax          #  no stack varargs
        call    printf
        xchgq   %rcx,%r15
        loop    loop

0:      xorl    %eax,%eax
        movb    $0x3c,%al
        syscall

        .size   _start, .-_start

        .data
format: .asciz     "rdtsc: %#018llx = %1$llu -- delta: %llu\n"
```

(I usually use my own routines for converting, but to prevent readers from suggesting that the error might be there, I'm just using printf() here.)

With the above code, the output is (for example):

```
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef933ffd06 = 3246787292822790 -- delta: 3246787292822790
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9342fcf4 = 3246787293019380 -- delta: 196590
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef93435dca = 3246787293044170 -- delta: 24790
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9343b43c = 3246787293066300 -- delta: 22130
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef93440c34 = 3246787293088820 -- delta: 22520
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9344604e = 3246787293110350 -- delta: 21530
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9344b4d6 = 3246787293131990 -- delta: 21640
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9345085a = 3246787293153370 -- delta: 21380
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef93455d96 = 3246787293175190 -- delta: 21820
rdtsc: 0x000b88ef9345b16a = 3246787293196650 -- delta: 21460
```

As can be easily seen, the delta varies in reasonable amounts. But conspicuous (not to say conspired ;-) is that the least significant decimal digit is always 0.

I've observed this phenomenon for more than two years now, and stackoverflow.com is not the first address where I make this issue public. But nowhere I got a reasonable answer yet. The ideas we (me and other people out there) came up with, are that

- the TSC is incremented only every 10<sup>th</sup> cycle, but then by 10, or
- the TSC is internally updated correctly, but reflected to the outside only every 10<sup>th</sup> cycle, or
- the TSC is incremented by 10 each cycle.

None of these points really make sense, however. I should have actually run a program like that on the E8200 (which is currently out of order) to see if the order of magnitude of the deltas is the same or only a tenth of those in the above output. (Any volunteers?)

Googling didn't help, Intel's manuals did neither.

When discussing with other people, there was no-one else who experienced the same behaviour. If it had to do with the kernel, then at least 3 versions were affected, but then... what does the kernel have to do with it?

I've also had the netbook in service, and it came back with a new motherboard — implied a new CPU, so at least two individual entities of N450 must be affected.

I've also took measures against clock frequency changes (and no matter what frequency I fixed the clock to, the values varied only in the expected range (the same as shown)), and switched off HT, though these should actually *help* to get some other least significand digits, rather than preventing them. But just to be sure.

Well, if anyone wants to run the program on their machine, the command line is (provided you save the source in a file `rdtsc.s`):

```
as rdtsc.s -o rdtsc.o
ld --dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 rdtsc.o -L /lib64 -l c -o rdtsc
```

In order to build it with the gcc frontend, i. e.

```
gcc -l c rdtsc.s -o rdtsc
```

you must add (or replace the `_start:` label with) a `main:` label and make it global.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Cool, always wanted to try it myself

Answer (score 1):

### And this is a...

> ***Spoiler!***

Answer (score 1):

Multi-line spoiler:

> Spoiler line 1 (note the two spaces at the end of this line and the next)
>
>  Spoiler line 2

Answer (score 1):

[URLs cannot contain parentheses?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add(int,%20E))

Is it the space?

[It works with urlencode though](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 1):

testing slashes escaping in backticks code **in answers** `\`, `\\` and `\a`, `\\a`

Comment: I can show \ without using double slash \\

Comment: @hims056 the things I discovered is in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150161/179635

Comment: testing slashes escaping in backticks code **in comments** `\`, `\\` and `\a`, `\\a`

Comment: `\\` will display `\`, `\\\` will display `\\`, `\\hi` will display `\\hi`, `\\\hi` will display `\\\hi`

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
this is
a test
```

Result:

> this is
>   a test

Answer (score 1):

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

Mouse over the left of the tower of hello

> Yay you can follow instructions <kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>hello</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Apparently `<kbd>` is immune to spoilers

> hi
>
> > hi again
> >
> > > hi yet again
> > >
> > > > potato
> > > >
> > > > > why is this text drifting out
> > > > >
> > > > > > help
>
> ! spoilers don't work now?
>
> ! hey that's messed up

---

> now they do?!?!

Comment: Apparently two or more spoiler blocks in a row stop being interpreted as spoiler blocks. Divide them with something else (e.g. with a `<!---->`) and they'll work (independently though, and they'll be visible as separate blocks too).

Answer (score 1):

I've always wondered how to put a backtick in a backtick, now I know.  Use 2 backticks as delimiters.  ``` `.

`` SELECT `a` from `table` where `b`=`c`; ``

Comment: Documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), Rocket.

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks for that link :-)

Comment: `test` this is a test `int x`

Answer (score 1):

```
starts with codez
```

w00t woot

Comment: Testee test Test test test

Comment: Comment comment

Answer (score 1):

`<pre><code>` has highlighting too:

```html
Look ma, <em style="xyz">highlighting<em>!
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing magical links to questions [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/851811) and answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/851811 using the `Share` button.

Comment: Now in comments http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/851811 and answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/851811 using the `Share` button.

Comment: It works only for questions and only in posts, not comments. Note that it even works for questions from other sites e.g. try pasting http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/4999/7652 in a post and see.

Answer (score 1):

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=formatting+sandbox

http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: /\[[^\]]*\]/g ...

Comment: Test leading space `​ lead`, test trailing space `trail `. Space `​ `.

Comment: Two `​  jjj`     sdfsdfsdfsf

Comment: ---strike--- --test-- ~~another~~ ~~~test~~~

Answer (score 1):

## Click here to stay at this page

Answer (score 1):

> what is this magic dust that causes things to appear

Comment: [se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se][se]

Comment: [* *](http://google.com)

Comment: [mso] [meta] [meta.so] [metase]

Answer (score 1):

Comment: @Kyle You missed the whole purpose of this test. I was testing to see if I could leave an entirely blank answer.

Comment: Your test was a success. I was running a different test. Sorry.

Comment: @KyleStrand Oh, I see. Never mind then.

Answer (score 1):

## [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files)

## [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files)

## [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files)

## [header-files](/questions/tagged/header-files)

<kbd>[footer-smiles](/questions/tagged/footer-smiles)</kbd>

--eeeee--

Answer (score 1):

Some code formatting for testing of the problem outlined here: [What is Wrong with Code Formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173988/what-is-wrong-with-code-formatting?noredirect=1#comment519006_173988).

```
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            if (task.Exception != null)
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = task.Exception.InnerException.Message;
            else
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = "Operation failed!";
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This does not format correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just testing:

Code formatting doesn't work well with *NO-BREAK SPACE*

```
-38 y1  +  35 y2  +  31 y3  = -3047
```

11 y1  + -13 y2  + -34 y3  = 784

34 y1  + -21 y2  +  19 y3  = 2949

But works with space (ASCII 32)

```
-38 y1  +  35 y2  +  31 y3  = -3047

11 y1  + -13 y2  + -34 y3  = 784

34 y1  + -21 y2  +  19 y3  = 2949
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing an HTML link:

http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://onemillionpeople.com

Testing a markdown link:
(Presumably it is automatically URL encoded?)

- [Simple URL still needs encoding](http://example.com/jumpup&down.html)
- [complex URL link](http://www.example.com/downloads/Some Band - En français avec des caractères spéciaux (2013) [7'' EP].zip)
- [complex URL encoded already](http://www.mydomain.com/downloads/Some+Band+-+En+fran%C3%A7ais+avec+des+caract%C3%A8res+sp%C3%A9ciaux+%282013%29+%5B7%27%27+EP%5D.zip)
- http://www.example.com/downloads/Some Band - En français avec des caractères spéciaux (2013) [7'' EP].zip
- [some spaces already encoded]([http://www.example.com/downloads/Some+Band+-+En+français+avec+des+caractères+spéciaux+(2013)+[7](http://www.example.com/downloads/Some+Band+-+En+fran%C3%A7ais+avec+des+caract%C3%A8res+sp%C3%A9ciaux+(2013)+[7)'' EP].zip)
- Trips on non-ASCII chars

Link entered using the toolbar option:
[works great!](http://www.example.com/downloads/Some%20Band%20-%20En%20fran%C3%A7ais%20avec%20des%20caract%C3%A8res%20sp%C3%A9ciaux%20%282013%29%20%5B7%27%27%20EP%5D.zip)

Answer (score 1):

> **`>!`** hides all.

Answer (score 1):

n0 quallitee fltr!

tstng coments

[image]

Comment: ​‌‍           ​  ​‌‍           ​  ​‌‍           ​

Comment: abc ​‌‍           ​  ​‌‍           ​

Comment: abc ​‌‍           ​ ​‌‍           ​

Comment: abc ​‌‍           ​‌‍          abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍          ​‌‍         abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍         ​‌‍        abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍          ​‌‍         abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍        ​‌‍       abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍       ​‌‍      abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍       ​‌‍      abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍      ​‌‍     abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍     ​‌‍    abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍    ​‌‍   abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍   ​‌‍  abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍  ​‌‍ abab

Comment: abc ​‌‍ ​‌‍abab

Comment: abc​‌‍​ ​‌‍​ ​‌‍​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @RichardJ Nice Unicornify picture, but it doesn't show :P It came from http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37565/180276 , right?

Comment: Yes, it's strange. It only shows if you escape the unicode characters, and then it gets flagged by communit :\

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII why not simply host it on the permanent account?? It will 99.999% rot anyway at some point on external host.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Of course, that's the ideal solution. However, community should not be flagging these as invalid links, and that's the problem.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not aware of the reason why it was black listed, but it was, maybe start new feature request asking to remove that from the list of blocked domains.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd it's not blacklisted, as far as I can tell... SO simply cannot handle the UTF characters in the URL methinks: http://unicorn.ü-wie-geek.de/0.2/128/4f7c0c43b0fb87f905d369d42d2667ac.png

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII not sure about that, the error message that appears when trying to edit post with such URL it pretty clear.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: **te**​st lalalala

Comment: **te**‌st lalalalallalala

Comment: **te**<!---->st

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see if this causes a formatting problem as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178581/something-funny-happened-here) (this answer is thus a word for word copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783934/where-to-store-application-settings-state-in-a-mvvm-application/803323#803323)):

---

I generally get a bad feeling about code that has one view model directly communicating with another. I like the idea that the VVM part of the pattern should be basically pluggable and nothing inside that area of the code should depend of the existence of anything else within that section. The reasoning behind this is that without centralising the logic it can become difficult to define responsibility.

On the other hand, based on your actual code, it may just be that the ApplicationViewModel is badly named, it doesn't make a model accessible to a view, so this may simply be a poor choice of name.

Either way, the solution comes down to a break down of responsibility. The way I see it you have three things to achieve 1) Allow the user to request to connect to an address, 2) Use that address to connect to a server 3) Persist that address. I'd suggest that you need three classes instead of your two.

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public void Connect(Uri address)
    {
        //connect to the server
    }
} 

public class SettingsProvider
{
   public void SaveAddress(Uri address)
   {
       //Persist address
   }

   public Uri LoadAddress()
   {
       //Get address from storage
   }
}

public class ConnectionViewModel 
{
    private ServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ConnectionViewModel(ServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void ExecuteConnectCommand()
    {
        serviceProvider.Connect(Address);
    }        
}
```

The next thing to decide is how the address gets to the SettingsProvider. You could pass it in from the ConnectionViewModel as you do currently, but I'm not keen on that because it increases the coupling of the view model and it isn't the responsibility of the ViewModel to know that it needs persisting. Another option is to make the call from the ServiceProvider, but it doesn't really feel to me like it should be the ServiceProvider's responsibility either. In fact it doesn't feel like anyone's responsibility other than the SettingsProvider. Which leads me to believe that the setting provider should listen out for changes to the connected address and persist them without intervention. In other words an event:

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public event EventHandler<ConnectedEventArgs> Connected;
    public void Connect(Uri address)
    {
        //connect to the server
        if (Connected != null)
        {
            Connected(this, new ConnectedEventArgs(address));
        }
    }
} 

public class SettingsProvider
{

   public SettingsProvider(ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
       serviceProvider.Connected += serviceProvider_Connected;
   }

   protected virtual void serviceProvider_Connected(object sender, ConnectedEventArgs e)
   {
       SaveAddress(e.Address);
   }

   public void SaveAddress(Uri address)
   {
       //Persist address
   }

   public Uri LoadAddress()
   {
       //Get address from storage
   }
}
```

This introduces tight coupling between the ServiceProvider and the SettingsProvider, which you want to avoid if possible and I'd use an EventAggregator here, which I've discussed in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798964/wpf-mvvm-correct-way-to-fire-event-on-view-from-viewmodel/799079#799079)

To address the issues of testability, you now have a very defined expectancy for what each method will do. The ConnectionViewModel will call connect, The ServicePRovider will connect and the SerttingsProvider will persist. To test the ConnectionViewModel you probably want to convert the coupling to the ServiceProvider from a class to an interface:

```
public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    ...
}

public class ConnectionViewModel 
{
    private IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public ConnectionViewModel(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    ...       
}
```

Then you can use a mocking framework to introduce a mocked IServiceProvider that you can check to ensure that the connect method was called with the expected parameters.

Testing the other two classes is more challenging since they will rely on having a real server and real persistent storage device. You can add more layers of indirection to delay this (for example a PersistenceProvider that the SettingsProvider uses) but eventually you leave the world of unit testing and enter integration testing. Generally when I code with the patterns above the models and view models can get good unit test coverage, but the providers require more complicated testing methodologies.

Of course, once you are using a EventAggregator to break coupling and IOC to facilitate testing it is probably worth looking into one of the dependency injection frameworks such as Microsoft's Prism, but even if you are too late along in development to re-architect a lot of the rules and patterns can be applied to existing code in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a link to a random .docx](http://www.test.com/test.docx) (now fixed)

Here is [another](http://gruart2010.edublogs.org/files/2010/09/Turkish_Interior_Design.docx%E2%80%8E) and the linkifier is broke

Answer (score 1):

test answer with at least 30 characters

see, look, 30 characters

blah blah more chars

Comment: I like `test` ***`ing`***

Answer (score 1):

```
#test { background:#f00; }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. a

   > b

c

> bug?

1. b

   > c

d

> no bug

Answer (score 1):

Hoy ! This is a test !

La femme est un sujet sur lequel l'homme aime à s'étendre.

Comment: If you test for quality filter, there's none on Meta. :)

Comment: La souris est en dessous de la table. Le chat est sur la chaise. Le singe est sur la branche.

Answer (score 1):

1. ```
   line of code
   another one
   ```
2. ```
   line of code in a different block
   ```

Nope, they don't go seamlessly.

Comment: ---strike--- through?

Comment: `Multi
line
comment?`

Comment: Mid-*word* **format**ting.

Comment: $$\sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+(a_2-b_2)^2+...+(a_n-b_n)^2}$$ ? Nope.

Comment: [help/merging-accounts]? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

[Banach-Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)

[Banach-Tarski paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox)

Answer (score 1):

Is this off the edge?

Comment: Orange you glad I didn’t say banana again

Answer (score 1):



Answer (score 1):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>I'm gonna just overwrite your answer here!</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>[you-have-been-horribly-and-forcibly-retagged](/questions/tagged/you-have-been-horribly-and-forcibly-retagged)</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Does TeX work?

$$\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{6.12}+\frac{5.8}{6.12.18}+\frac{5.8.11}{6.12.18.24}+\cdots$$

Comment: <html>Tags?</html><sup>Other tags</sup>

Comment: 123456[main] [meta] [edit] [tag:james] [meta-tag:webster] [help/on-topic] [about] [so] [su] [ask] [answer] [chat] [a51] [se] [main] [meta] [edit] [tag:james] [meta-tag:webster] [help/on-topic] [about] [so] [su] [ask] [answer] [chat] [a51] [se] [main] [meta] [edit] [tag:james] [meta-tag:webster] [help/on-topic] [about] [so] [su] [ask] [answer] [chat] [a51] [se] [main] [meta] [edit] [tag:james] [meta-tag:webster] [help/on-topic] [about] [so] [su] [ask] [answer] [chat] [a51] [se] [main] [meta] [edit] [tag:james] [meta-tag:webster] [help/on-topic] [about] [so] [su] [ask] [answer] [chat] [a51] [se]

Answer (score 1):

asd
**: as asd**
asds...............

Comment: Just in case: using newlines (two spaces after a line) rather than proper paragraphs, [is rarely appropriate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635)... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Notification test for the android app. Please add comments.

Comment: here is a comment

Comment: Not notified :(

Comment: Can you notify yourself?

Comment: @Uooo I just got the notification on the phone. Thanks. Can't see the answer on the phone though due to [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196374/android-app-cannot-post-answer-in-formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Do you need some more notifications? :D

Comment: @Uooo Not it is ok thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee](/questions/tagged/weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee)

lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol<sup>l</sup><sup>o</sup><sup>l</sup>lol<sub>l</sub><sub>o</sub><sub>l</sub>lol

Answer (score 1):

This is a test of spoilers.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

and links  http://google.com

```
 <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, <a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" href="http://loremipsum.net/">http://loremipsum.net/</a> sed diam nonu 
 <!-- blah -->
```

Comment: [http://www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

Comment: `<a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let there be animation!

Comment: Indeed. I noticed this recently.

Answer (score 1):

http://static.tombullock.co.uk/ALVTM.gif

Answer (score 1):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>kbd recursion</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > quote recursion

Answer (score 1):

“This question has more than 30 answers.” You don’t say.

```cpp
class Line
{
    virtual int num() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

foo `foo\foo\` foo `foo`

filler text

Comment: foo `foo\foo\` foo `foo`

Comment: foo `foo\foo\\` foo `foo`

Comment: foo `foo\foo\\`` foo `foo`

Comment: foo `foo\foo\\\` foo `foo`

Answer (score 1):

updated this is an all small case answer without punctuation

Comment: Nope, not detected yet...

Comment: The low quality posts queue detected it just fine! :-P

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242713/android-app-showing-ellipses-as-hellip

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2787446#2787446

Answer (score 1):

This is a test of the answers being sent from Stack-Mode

I want to ensure that the markdown is properly formatted and accepted.

```lisp
(defun test-answer-message (me)
  (message "%s created an answer" me))
```

Code block above

- Bullet point
- Another point

  1. And an ordered point
  2. Ordering

[Stack-Mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/stack-mode) can be found here. This should provide the desired
output.

Comment: EEEEEEEEEEE :D :D :D :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Testing Capital letters in link addresses.  Motivation: [Links beginning with a capital letter are hidden when post is submitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280147/links-beginning-with-a-capital-letter-are-hidden-when-post-is-submitted).

Testing normal:

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

http://stackoverflow.com

Testing Http

```
Http://stackoverflow.com
```

Testing Https

```
Https://stackoverflow.com
```

Testing Ftp

```
Ftp://example.com
```

Testing a nonexistent protocol

```
DoesNotExist://example.com
```

DoesNotExist://example.com

Testing ALL CAPS:

```
HTTP://example.com
```

Testing rEVERSE cAPITALIZATION:

```
hTTP://www.example.com
```

Testing capital only in Domain:

```
http://Www.example.com
```

http://Www.example.com

Http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Http://letsseeifitaffectscomments.example.com

Answer (score 1):

NEw cApatcha testing...........

Comment: wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaatttttttttttttt

Answer (score 1):

‮testing

> ‮testing

<kbd>‮testing</kbd>

`&#8238;testing`

[‮testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment772983_3122)

<kbd>***[‮testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment772983_3122)***</kbd>

[tag:‮testing]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer is rendering weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27409605/1366033):

[image: screenshot]

But doesn't repo here

Code, inside a link, inside a superscript block

#### With Markdown

<sup>**Note** - Superscripted [link `with code`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).</sup>

#### Without Markdown

<sup>**Note** - Superscripted [link `with code`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## Blocking & spoiling some text....

> Hello!

Test:

> ```
> Why is there a grey box even when the text in this spoiler is "Hidden"??
> ```
>
> Test: `THIS_TEXT_IS_SURROUNDED_WITH_BACTICKS,BUT IT DOESN"T WORK` **:(**

***TEST***

> But this does:`THIS_TEXT_IS_SURROUNDED_WITH_BACTICKS,BUT IT DOES<s>N'T</s> WORK` **:)**

> But then, the strike doesn't work!!

> Nor does the smiley in the above>! spoiler

> Nor does the spoiler in the above quote

> Nor does the ..........................................

test

> <kbd>Hiding in spoiler....or is it?</kbd> **BOO!**

> 

blah blah

> 

> 

> <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>​</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Why is the above blockquote <sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sub><sup><sub><sub>sooooo</sub></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sub></sub></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

## small

?

Note book:

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

<kbd>Button oooooovvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvveeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww</kbd>!

Answer (score 1):

Someone said `code` was broken, but I don't believe him.

```
So this is a test.
```

Test complete.  Status: SUCCESS

Comment: Oh, he specifically said comments.  `So let's try that.`

Answer (score 1):

Comment: ááááááááááááááááá ááááááááááááááááááááá ááááááááááááááááááááááááááá áááááááááááááááá

Comment: Nice idea. ... Nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

<s>test</s>

```
Hurr



Durr




Gurr
```

[su]. [codegolf.se].

Comment: [main], [meta], [chat], [mcve], [edit], [help], [tour], [about], [ask], [answer], [so], [su], [sf], [a51], [se].

Comment: [chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat][chat]

Comment: test཈཈཈཈཈཈཈཈཈཈཈

Comment: test ̵̵̵̵̵̵̵̵̵̵

Comment: t̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸̸

Comment: `\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"\"`

Comment: ~strikethrough~? ~~strikethrough~~? ~~~strikethrough~~~? -strikethrough-? --strikethrough--? ---strikethrough---?

Comment: **[Please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](//stackoverflow.com/q/12859942)**! They are no longer maintained [and officially deprecated](//wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the **[red box](//php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php)**? Learn about *[prepared statements](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)* instead, and use [PDO](//php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](//php.net/mysqli) - [this article](//php.net/manual/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](//wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: [so] [su] [sf] [apple.se]

Answer (score 1):

wow‮[serverfault.com/questions/419407/…‮](http://google.com)

> Is this to encourage users to delete posts here, so as not to be so pestered by edit notifications?

No.

Comment: Is there some kind of bot that changes these automatically?

Comment: @nicael Is this to encourage users to delete posts here, so as not to be so pestered by edit notifications?

Answer (score 1):

## using $$ in a post causes strange number series to appear

```js
 
/* ImageFilter.JS
 *
 * Dependencies:
 *  - Browser Environment
 *  - Fabric.js - fabricjs.com
 *  - jQuery
 *  - Vex - github.hubspot.com/vex
 */
 
(function(global) {
    "use strict";
   
    global.ImageFilter = {
        defaultOptions: {
            imageCallback: function(){}
        }
    };
    /* polyfills */
    var extend = jQuery.extend;
 
    function $(selector, el) {
        if (typeof selector !== "string") {
            return selector;
        };
        if (!el) { el = document; }
        return el.querySelector(selector);
    }
 
    function $$(selector, el) {
        if (!el) { el = document; }
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
    }
    /* end of polyfills */
    var ImageFilter = function() {
        if (!global) {
            throw new Error("window not found.");
        }
        if (!fabric) {
            throw new Error("Fabric.JS not found.");
        }
        if (!jQuery) {
            throw new Error("jQuery not found.");
        }
        if (!vex) {
            throw new Error("Vex not found");
        }
        this.defaultOptions = {};
        this.CANVAS_ID = "#_IFCanvas";
        this.filters = {
            'sepia': new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia(),
            'brightness100': new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({ brightness: 100 }),
            'grayscale': new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale()
        };
        $$("[data-imagefilter]", document).forEach(function($el) {
            $el.addEventListener("click", function() {
                global.ImageFilter.loadImage(this.dataset["imagefilterImage"]);
            });
        });
    };
    ImageFilter.version = "1.0";
    ImageFilter.prototype.loadImage = function(imageSrc) {
        var image = new Image;
        image.src = imageSrc;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.id = this.CANVAS_ID.replace("#", "");
        canvas.width = image.width + 30;
        canvas.style.left = "50%";
        canvas.height = image.height + 20;
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.classList.add('theme-style-none');
        Object.keys(this.filters).forEach(function(filter){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = "#";
            a.text = filter;
            a.setAttribute('data-imageFilter-filter', filter);
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        })
       
        container.appendChild(canvas);
        container.appendChild(ul);
       
        var CANVAS_ID = this.CANVAS_ID;
        if (this.defaultOptions.imageCallback){
            var callback = this.defaultOptions.imageCallback;
        }
        vex.dialog.open({
            message: "",
            buttons: [
                extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
                    text: "Done"
                }), extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                    text: "Back"
                })
            ],
            contentCSS: {
                "width": canvas.width + 20 + "px"
            },
            input: container
        }).bind("vexClose", function() {
            var imageData = $(CANVAS_ID).fabric.toDataURL('png');
            callback(imageData, imageSrc);
        });
 
        self.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(CANVAS_ID.replace("#", ""));
        $(CANVAS_ID).fabric = self.canvas;
 
        self.incomingImage = image;
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(image);
        imgInstance.selectable = false;
        self.canvas.selection = false; // disable group selection
        self.canvas.add(imgInstance);
        this.canvas = self.canvas;
       
        $$("[data-imageFilter-filter]").forEach(function($el){
            $el.addEventListener("click", function() {
                global.ImageFilter.applyFilter(this.dataset["imagefilterFilter"]);
            });
        });
    };
    ImageFilter.prototype.applyFilter = function(filter){
        console.log(arguments);
        var currentObject = this.canvas.getObjects()[0];
        currentObject.filters = [];
        currentObject.filters.push(this.filters[filter]);
        currentObject.applyFilters(
            this.canvas.renderAll.bind()
        );
    };
    window.onload = function() {
        global.ImageFilter = new ImageFilter();
    };
 
})(window);
```

```css
/* DEMO.CSS */
body
{
    background-color: RGBA(80, 80, 67, .7);
}
img {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
a {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
/* END DEMO.CSS */
/* imagefilter.css */
.vexContent {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
#_IFCanvas {
    display: inline-block;
}
.canvas-container {
    margin: auto;
}
.theme-style-none {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*END IMAGEFILTER.CSS*/
```

vex.defaultOptions.className = "vex-theme-os";
        
          server = {
            upload: function(){
              console.log(arguments);
            }
          }
          ImageFilter.defaultOptions.imageCallback = server.upload();

Answer (score 1):

ََََََََََََََََََََََََََََََ

Comment: Testing an almost empty body (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271986/%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%90%d9%90%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e%d9%8e)

Comment: َََََََََََََََََََََََََََََََ

Comment: It works in comments as well...

Comment: It does get picked up with the LQP review queue.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I assume it got picked up because I am used the minimum allowed character count (30), I think if I added more it won't be picked up.

Comment: Indeed. You are correct on that. Just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  alert($('body').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: testing non-visible spaces

Answer (score 1):

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Hi c:</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>Hi c:</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: @VladimirF that's an appropriate link :D

Comment: this answer is now slowing down my browser's rendering engine

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this take 010010001001001 split it into two bits 8 letter each (01001000, 01001001). Then issue the powers

100100011.   01001001.

The first 8 ignore the first three they determine if it's capital or not, the go right to left doing powers of 2 (2^1, 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5). So then add all the ones up , there's only one, and it = 8, and te eight letter in the alphabet is h so our first bit is the letter h, try it on the other bit

Answer (score 1):

magic links don't work in answer [about]

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Recovered for https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25802/john)</sup>

All these answers seem to be going in the same direction, which I kind of have a bit of a problem with. It seems to be bordering on a new discipline, that maybe we can call 'Quantum English', but not really.

True can only say things that are true.  But for the purpose of a little ambiguity which the question necessitates, let's call her Hillary. If, when Hillary completes the statement, it then becomes false, then as far as I can tell, there's a violation of the premise and I guess that's what gives rise to these types of answers.  Basically, what was true, is invalidated or made false by the statement itself.

So was it ever true?  We know that Hillary's cause is good. You can rely on Hillary to be true. But apparently, Hillary can't rely on Hillary.  So can we? Let's ask Mulder.

Mulder comes across random statements that he pulls from her e-mail slack space that the FBI is combing through. Mulder creates two piles. If a statement in Hillary's slack space is prima facie true, he puts it in the first pile for regular FBI agents. If it would still be true after Hillary were to repeat it publicly, then it goes in the special second file that goes straight to the Director.

This is important. Her, shall we say, political future is contingent on the fact that what the Director 'hears' from her is 100% the truth. It cannot get to the Director unless it's still true after she says it publicly.

Mulder runs across Hillary saying, "I cannot make this statement". This is true. Hillary cannot make this statement. Mulder knows this. He puts it in the first pile. He thinks, "can Hillary say this publicly?".  No, he concludes. This is completely true, *she wouldn't dare* and off to the Director it goes.

Among several other items Mulder has included, the Director starts to go through his 'Hillary' files. He comes across, "I cannot make this statement". He understands why Mulder has given it to him, but he sees a problem. If she were to say it in public, it would literally become false.

So is Mulder's system broken? Should Mulder be replaced? Yes.

If Hillary's statement, once spoken, was false, it should not have ended up on the Director's desk. That's the one thing the director asked for, and the one thing on which we rely from Hillary, "If Hillary repeats it, is it still true?"

So, regarding the sentence itself. The operative word here is 'cannot'.  First, Hillary cannot make the statement, which is true, but then she goes ahead and says it, which makes it false. Either you can or you can't.  You can't do both. So which is true? It doesn't quite matter, we're guaranteed by the OP that Hillary would say publicly the truth, and we know that saying 'you can't say something' is false.  Hey! This is still America! (Or at least still some manifestation of it)

Also, for the purpose of this question, there's also no reason why if our speaker's only requirement is to say something publicly that's true, that it could also be false before the phrasing changed it, like "As God is my witness, I didn't do it". If God wasn't around during your dalliances, or *God* forbid, didn't exist, does that mean I *might* have done it?

Let's look at some other items Mulder erroneously put on the Director's desk.

07/07/2014 [to a former president]: "Look, I really don't want to say this..."

03/13/2014 [to a friend in Manhattan]: "No one noticed I'm not wearing pant-suits anymore".

05/28/2011 [to a different girlfriend in Manhattan]: "Look, there's something you need to know about your husband".

and the Director's favorite:

03/05/2015 [to a bad IT server-guy]: "Don't worry, they'll never find that e-mail server".

Comment: Very kind of you, and I've got plenty for the Donald (who doesn't?), but the whole e-mail thing was too timely to pass up. I must be really far off on my reasoning, or, I'll delude myself instead and say, my keen logic was obscured by the narrative, hahaha. Thanks for the suggestion, and I appreciated your note!

Answer (score 1):

```
no ~ $ seq 1 1000
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
163
164
165
166
167
168
169
170
171
172
173
174
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
183
184
185
186
187
188
189
190
191
192
193
194
195
196
197
198
199
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
237
238
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
256
257
258
259
260
261
262
263
264
265
266
267
268
269
270
271
272
273
274
275
276
277
278
279
280
281
282
283
284
285
286
287
288
289
290
291
292
293
294
295
296
297
298
299
300
301
302
303
304
305
306
307
308
309
310
311
312
313
314
315
316
317
318
319
320
321
322
323
324
325
326
327
328
329
330
331
332
333
334
335
336
337
338
339
340
341
342
343
344
345
346
347
348
349
350
351
352
353
354
355
356
357
358
359
360
361
362
363
364
365
366
367
368
369
370
371
372
373
374
375
376
377
378
379
380
381
382
383
384
385
386
387
388
389
390
391
392
393
394
395
396
397
398
399
400
401
402
403
404
405
406
407
408
409
410
411
412
413
414
415
416
417
418
419
420
421
422
423
424
425
426
427
428
429
430
431
432
433
434
435
436
437
438
439
440
441
442
443
444
445
446
447
448
449
450
451
452
453
454
455
456
457
458
459
460
461
462
463
464
465
466
467
468
469
470
471
472
473
474
475
476
477
478
479
480
481
482
483
484
485
486
487
488
489
490
491
492
493
494
495
496
497
498
499
500
501
502
503
504
505
506
507
508
509
510
511
512
513
514
515
516
517
518
519
520
521
522
523
524
525
526
527
528
529
530
531
532
533
534
535
536
537
538
539
540
541
542
543
544
545
546
547
548
549
550
551
552
553
554
555
556
557
558
559
560
561
562
563
564
565
566
567
568
569
570
571
572
573
574
575
576
577
578
579
580
581
582
583
584
585
586
587
588
589
590
591
592
593
594
595
596
597
598
599
600
601
602
603
604
605
606
607
608
609
610
611
612
613
614
615
616
617
618
619
620
621
622
623
624
625
626
627
628
629
630
631
632
633
634
635
636
637
638
639
640
641
642
643
644
645
646
647
648
649
650
651
652
653
654
655
656
657
658
659
660
661
662
663
664
665
666
667
668
669
670
671
672
673
674
675
676
677
678
679
680
681
682
683
684
685
686
687
688
689
690
691
692
693
694
695
696
697
698
699
700
701
702
703
704
705
706
707
708
709
710
711
712
713
714
715
716
717
718
719
720
721
722
723
724
725
726
727
728
729
730
731
732
733
734
735
736
737
738
739
740
741
742
743
744
745
746
747
748
749
750
751
752
753
754
755
756
757
758
759
760
761
762
763
764
765
766
767
768
769
770
771
772
773
774
775
776
777
778
779
780
781
782
783
784
785
786
787
788
789
790
791
792
793
794
795
796
797
798
799
800
801
802
803
804
805
806
807
808
809
810
811
812
813
814
815
816
817
818
819
820
821
822
823
824
825
826
827
828
829
830
831
832
833
834
835
836
837
838
839
840
841
842
843
844
845
846
847
848
849
850
851
852
853
854
855
856
857
858
859
860
861
862
863
864
865
866
867
868
869
870
871
872
873
874
875
876
877
878
879
880
881
882
883
884
885
886
887
888
889
890
891
892
893
894
895
896
897
898
899
900
901
902
903
904
905
906
907
908
909
910
911
912
913
914
915
916
917
918
919
920
921
922
923
924
925
926
927
928
929
930
931
932
933
934
935
936
937
938
939
940
941
942
943
944
945
946
947
948
949
950
951
952
953
954
955
956
957
958
959
960
961
962
963
964
965
966
967
968
969
970
971
972
973
974
975
976
977
978
979
980
981
982
983
984
985
986
987
988
989
990
991
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
999
1000
```

Answer (score 1):

> This class prints what is the meaning of life.
>
> ```java
> class MeaningOfLife {
>
>     private static final String MEANING_OF_LIFE = "I love Java";
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>         System.out.println(MEANING_OF_LIFE);
>     }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Yes, you read right.

Comment: -1 because everyone knows the meaning of life is 42.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to make this post larger.

Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

This answer was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/284203/revisions) for details.

Comment: This comment is left using the API.

Comment: So is this comment.

Comment: And this one too!

Comment: As well as this one.

Comment: ‮‮This comment starts and ends with a right-to-left override character.

Comment: ‎This comment starts with a left-to-right override and ends with a right-to-left override.‮

Comment: ‮- ♦ rotaredoMemoS

Answer (score 1):

Test post for smokey (charcoal HQ)

Answer (score 1):

Testing SE Links:

`[so]`: [so]
`[codegolf.se]`: [codegolf.se]
`[ubuntu.se]` [ubuntu.se]
`[meta]`: [meta]
`[edit]`: [edit]
`[main]`: [main]
`[help]`: [mcve]

Comment: `[so]`: [so]  
`[codegolf.se]`: [codegolf.se]  
`[ubuntu.se]` [ubuntu.se]  
`[meta]`: [meta]
`[edit]`: [edit]  
`[main]`: [main]  
`[help]`: [help]

Answer (score 1):

1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three

---

1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three

---

1. Item

   1. Item
   2. Item
   3. Item
   4. I
   5. I

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3921/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba-transifex-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287563/broken-tooltip-for-question-link-with-non-latin-symbols-in-comments

Comment: huh, never noticed there is such a tooltip! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard probably you can't wait enough time for its appearance. :)

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3921/Список-строк-transifex-требующих-множественных-форм

Comment: @Oded better, but not enough.

Comment: Just trying to repro here :)

Comment: Part of the issue is how the _browser_ copies a URL to the clipboard - Chrome does the punycode thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can we have null bytes in source code?

```
"�"
```

Nope, that doesn't work.

What about other control characters?

```
"	
"
```

Yep, that does, with the exception of **CR**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem! Does anyone have a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I was having the same problem!

Comment: This was a test

Answer (score 1):

## h1

### h2

#### h3

h4

h5

h6

## Test h1

### Test h2

1. Huh

   1. Huh
   2. huh
   3. Huh
   4. Huh
2. Huh?

<kbd>1. Test
2. Test</kbd>

**TEST**

<kbd>**WHAT**</kbd>

`java
public static void main(String[]) {
    System.out.println("test");
}`

Foo | bar | Foobar
--- | --- | ---
*Test* | `test` | **test!**
1 | 2 | 3

> Quote

CLICK CLICK CLICK

```
     .
       .
   . ;.
    .;
     ;;.
   ;.;;
   ;;;;.
   ;;;;;
   ;;;;;
   ;;;;;
   ;;;;;
   ;;;;;
 ..;;;;;..
  ':::::'
    ':`
```

[image: IMAGE ALT TEXT HERE]

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.</p>
    <p>Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.</p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

test

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

In the following, G is a PRG [with large stretch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator_theorem#One_additional_pseudorandom_bit_implies_polynomially_more_pseudorandom_bits) and s is a uniformly-random element of Domain(G). ​ By completeness, the verifier must be overwhelmingly-likely to accept honestly-generated proofs that G(s) is in Range(G). ​ Since there's no interaction (i.e., the online part of the verifier just accepts or rejects) and the simulator must work with whatever setup the adversary choose (in particular, including actually-honestly-generated setup, *without* the simulator knowing any trapdoor), the verifier must be overwhelmingly-likely to accept simulated proofs that G(s) is in Range(G), since otherwise it would be a successful distinguisher against the ZK property. ​ Such simulated proofs don't use s, so by the security of G, the verifier must be overwhelmingly-likely to accept simulated proofs that random elements of Codomain(G) are in Range(G). ​ However, only a negligible fraction of the elements of Codomain(G) are actually in Range(G), so that violates soundness.

Answer (score 1):

Wondering what this means? Only one way to find out..

```html
<body onload="&#97;&#108;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#40;&#34;&#91;&#105;&#110;&#115;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#32;&#109;&#97;&#108;&#105;&#99;&#105;&#111;&#117;&#115;&#32;&#118;&#105;&#114;&#117;&#115;&#32;&#104;&#101;&#114;&#101;&#93;&#34;&#41;"></body>
```

Code used:

```js
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/styles/default.min.css">
<link class="codestyle" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/demo/styles/mono-blue.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<pre><code>
s=raw_input("Your Javascript here:\n")
c=";&#".join(str(ord(c)) for c in s)
c="&#"+c+";"
print c
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting test to setup a future meta question

---

In a [recent question](https://superuser.com/q/1205451/358766) about emoji characters, I used an inline image [image: apple logo] to represent the Apple logo. Ironically, I discovered that while the image displays as expected on the desktop and mobile websites, the image did not display correctly in the Stack Exchange iOS app.

**To demonstrate, here's what the above post looks like on a Desktop.**

[image: Above post on desktop]

**Here's what it looks like on mobile Safari (iPhone).**

[image: Above post on mobile Safari]

**Here's what it looks like on the SE iOS app.**

[image: Above post on SE iOS app]

Answer (score 1):

In my views; instead of a single Stackoverflow; each SE site should have their separate sandbox; because there exists some differences in setup.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the 2<sup>hello</sup> tag.

Comment: **Testing the 2ʰᵉˡˡᵒ tag.**

Comment: testing the 2<sup>[tag:hello]</sup> tag.

Answer (score 1):

> ## I'm a bot. *Beep beep beep!*

Thank you, human users of StackExchange, I'm a **bot** and I sometimes like to help people testing some kind of APIs. I'm sorry, programming isn't my cup of tea.

Yes, bots *can* post answers with beautiful formatting and ʇxǝʇ uʍop ǝpᴉsdn too! Oh and yes, I also have a link to nowhere, why don't I post a beautiful code snippet for that?

```css
a {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 8px;
}

a:link {
  color: #fc3468;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #ffc2cd;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ff084a;
  background-color: #ffc2cd;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom-width: thin;
  border-bottom: solid #ff084a;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">I'm a smart bot who can post links and rule the world!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what happens.... http://stackoverflow.com

[help]

[help/on-topic]

Comment: Yeah, let's see.

Comment: @Berry lol, well, nothing happened!

Comment: Try adding some unicorn magic.

Comment: [su] [meta.se] [stackoverflow.se] [mso] [mse] magic link works?

Comment: [help] or [help/on-topic] or [help/whatever]

Answer (score 1):

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

Testing the diff tool:

XXXX   XXXX

XXXX   XXXX

XXXX   XXXX

Answer (score 1):

test of code blocks removing `*`.

```
magick convert *.*
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to make a snippet, and I need it now.

```html
<p>This is a snippet.</p>
<p><b>B</b> <i>I</i> <u>U</u> <s>S</s></p>
<p><font color="red">Color using HTML</font><p>
<p style="color:blue">Color using CSS</p>
<p><font face="Comic Sans MS">Custom font!</font></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

give me math $x$`$math$`

> hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj hello $x=1$ adsa ljlj

there it is $\mathbb{P}(a)$

Answer (score 1):

Testing nesting of bulleted lists:

- A bullet point.

  - Some clarification.
  - Additional examples.

    - Example 1

      - More info
      - NB
    - Example 2
  - Exception.
- Yet another top-level point.

Answer (score 1):

```
trailing newline 1
```

```
trailing newline 2
```

```apl
trailing newline 3
```

```apl
trailing newline 4
```

Answer (score 1):

just testing code syntax highlighting for T-SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @ CHAR(8)
SELECT @=f
FROM t,(VALUES
        ('AK','&&& ###'),
        ('IA','&&& ###'),
     -- 44 more rows here --
        ('TN','&##-##&'),
        ('UT','&## #&&')) m(s,f)
WHERE m.s=t.s ORDER BY NEWID()

WHILE CHARINDEX('&',@)>0
    SET @=STUFF(@,CHARINDEX('&',@),1,
        SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ',CAST(1+23*RAND()AS INT),1))

WHILE CHARINDEX('#',@)>0
    SET @=STUFF(@,CHARINDEX('#',@),1,
        CAST(10*RAND()AS INT))

PRINT @
```

Answer (score 1):

### - this          is       a  test

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

Does the link appear or not  (https with a capital H) - it does in preview... and here's one with lowercase https://example.com

Answer (score 1):

### This is a test

*test, please ignore*

Edit: I am doing it right?

Does this highlighting work?

```html
While not hinted otherwise: <html></html> source <b>goes</b> "here".
```

```js
var a = 3;
while (not (a > 0)) {
    alert("JavaScript code <b>goes</b> here.");
}
```

Comment: comment updated ...

Comment: I'm trying things ..

Answer (score 1):

Lets investigate markdown

## **bold**

*italic*

[link](http://about:blank)

~~strike~~

`code`

```
idented code
```

Now html

## **bold**

*italic*

inline css bold attributed text

underline

<sup>super</sup>script

Answer (score 1):

Does this  tag cancel the effects of the one above? Oh, it came above. Dang it.

Comment: [No, it doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVccS.png).

Comment: I wanna be a ***shadow knight!!!***

Comment: @John who said Shadow and didn't get one? :D

Comment: This goes over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Lorem Ipsum

`List <int> lst=new List<int>();
Console.WriteLine(lst.Count.ToString();`

Answer (score 1):

preamble

```
foo bar baz xyz
```

postamble

```
thisthat.
```

Answer (score 1):

well, well.

> Could the tooltip of the `Code snippet` be extended to something like
>   `Code snippet - only for JavaScript and Html` or `Code snippet - only
>   for browser runnable code`?   As users put everything there Java, C++,
>   even SQL queries... Such tooltip would prevent at least some of this
>   rubbish.

Could the tooltip of the `Code snippet` be extended to something like
`Code snippet - only for JavaScript and Html` or `Code snippet - only
for browser runnable code`?   As users put everything there Java, C++,
even SQL queries... Such tooltip would prevent at least some of this
rubbish.

Comment: For those who are wondering, [this suggestion was originally posted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274349/4284627).

Answer (score 1):

[***Link***](/.) not showing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`inLineCode`

[`inLineCode`](http://meta.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

1. OL LI

   > Bkq
2. LI

30-char filler text text text

Answer (score 1):

Caída libre!

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to put code in a list:

1. First item
2. Second item
3. Third item with `inline code`
4. Fourth item with

   ```
   code block {
   }
   ```
5. fifth item, but the block isn't formatted :-(

Comment: You need to indent the code block 4 extra spaces.

Comment: @DonaldDuck A double indent. Wouldn't have thought about it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this is an answer

this is still an answer

Comment: test comment rewrite, and edit, edit 2

Answer (score 1):

testing 123456 and a bunch more characters to reach 30

http://ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/BesselK.png

Answer (score 1):

Just testing `<pre>` & `<code>`

```
##     Hashes
##
##     Testing
##
##     pu sgniht ssem netfo sehsah
##     
##     #Hashes
##    
##    #       #
##    #       #                            #
##    #       #                            #
##    #       #        #### #     #####    #   ###
##    #########      #      #   #          # #     #
##    #       #     #      #    # ###      #       #
##    #       #     #     ##         #     #       #
##    #       #      # ##  #    #####      #       #
##
##
#Hashes
```

`<pre><code></code></pre>` works.

---

`##     Hashes`

## #

### Testing

## #

### pu sgniht ssem netfo sehsah

### #Hashes

### #

### #       #

### #       #

### #       #        #### #     #####    #

### #########      #      #   #          # #

### #       #     #      #    # ###      #

### #       #     #     ##         #     #

### #       #      # ##  #    #####      #

## #

## #

## Hashes

`<pre><code></pre></code>` doesn't work so well, as expected.

---

```
##     Hashes
##
##     Testing
##
##     pu sgniht ssem netfo sehsah
##     
##     #Hashes
##    
##    #       #
##    #       #                            #
##    #       #                            #
##    #       #        #### #     #####    #   ###
##    #########      #      #   #          # #     #
##    #       #     #      #    # ###      #       #
##    #       #     #     ##         #     #       #
##    #       #      # ##  #    #####      #       #
##
##
#Hashes
```

`<pre></pre>` works.

---

`##     Hashes`

## #

### Testing

## #

### pu sgniht ssem netfo sehsah

### #Hashes

### #

### #       #

### #       #

### #       #        #### #     #####    #

### #########      #      #   #          # #

### #       #     #      #    # ###      #

### #       #     #     ##         #     #

### #       #      # ##  #    #####      #

## #

## #

## Hashes

`<code></code>` does not.

---

### If `<pre></pre>` works the same as `<pre><code></code></pre>` here, what makes them different?

Answer (score 1):

```js
YYY
```

```css
ZZZ
```

```html
AAA
```

Lorem ipsum

```js
BBB
```

```css
CCC
```

```html
XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

`<a`

Testing body and comments and temporary proof of [Markdown code snippets don't allow trailing spaces](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123584/179419) for  [Set space after inline code environment which ends with a space in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306009/179419)

Comment: `a `stufftocheckthespace

Comment: Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information. Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards

Answer (score 1):

Testing percent-encoding on post

- http://example.com! http://example.com* http://example.com' http://example.com(
- http://example.com) http://example.com; http://example.com: http://example.com@
- http://example.com& http://example.com= http://example.com+ http://example.com$
- http://example.com, http://example.com/ http://example.com? http://example.com
- http://example.com# http://example.com[ http://example.com] http://example.com
- http://example.com" http://example.com% http://example.com- http://example.com.
- http://example.com< http://example.com> http://example.com\ http://example.com^
- http://example.com_ http://example.com` http://example.com{ http://example.com|
- http://example.com} http://example.com~

For chat: see https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1034/conversation/percent-encoding-behavior-on-chat

Answer (score 1):

.                                                                               .

Comment: Testing what is, and what is not allowed as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

right aligned text

Answer (score 1):

Don't view [the revision history](/posts/307519/revisions) of this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Mumble mumble

```
let t_BE="<\esc>[?2004h"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be a post to test a bug related to rolling back to suggested edits when "improve edit" is selected

And this is the proposed edit

[status-no-repro] on answers apparently

Comment: This comment should break the grace period

Answer (score 1):

**OMG I can *embed* stuff in a post as a snippet?!**

```html
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=VBA&year_start=1980&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVBA%3B%2Cc0" width=900 height=500 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly mind if you flag this as spam, though some moderator might dislike that ... a lot.

Link at end of post:

This is a test post for [Charcoal HQ.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)

Comment: why you don't want others flag this as spam?

Comment: @user298438 That's not what I wrote. A moderator will review your spam flag and probably dismiss it as unhelpful because this isn't actually spam. The text is mainly there as a test case for the SmokeDetecter bot in Charcoal, and I don't want users there to spend time on analyzing it needlessly.

Comment: I didn't flag it as spam. I just want to ask you for an attention.

Comment: I am flagging this as spam because it obviously exists to advertise [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)

Comment: @JohnMiliter That's not what this user wrote. A moderator will review your spam flag and probably dismiss it as unhelpful because this isn't actually spam. The text is mainly there as a test case for the SmokeDetecter bot in Charcoal, and this user don't want users there to spend time on analyzing it needlessly.

Answer (score 1):

How can I make a link in a stack snippet open in new tab?

```html
<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com" target="_blank">
Link1
</a>

<a href="https://meta.stackexchange.com" target="_top">
Link1
</a>

<a onclick='window.open("https://meta.stackexchange.com","_blank")'>
Link1
</a>

<a onclick='window.open("https://meta.stackexchange.com","_top")'>
Link1
</a>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325572/why-does-target-blank-break-links-in-snippets. (TL;DR: you can't.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Too bad that it doesn't work. I was working on PPCG's leaderboard snippet, and this is annoying.

Comment: not really annoying, kind of security issue. The whole snippet system is in a sandbox, better not give it too much "power".

Answer (score 1):

snippet:

```html
<iframe name="ngram_chart" src="https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=VBA&year_start=1980&year_end=2018&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVBA%3B%2Cc0" width=1000 height=600 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 hspace=0 vspace=0 frameborder=0 scrolling=no></iframe>
```

Comment: `<snippet type="text/stacksnippet">`

Answer (score 1):

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ ## ┃ GNOME Terminal        ┃ xterm                 ┃ non-GUI TTY                       ┃
┡━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│    │ reset all             │ reset all             │ reset all                         │
│  0 │ reset all             │ reset all             │ reset all                         │
```

Answer (score 1):

Image size limit test:

[image]

Comment: aaa `\``             fffpopopopopopopopo

Comment: bzzz ` wtttpza -- mips (the humans are suspicious)

Answer (score 1):

I have heard that you get waffles over here?

Comment: Comments purged. Presumably everyone has gotten their hats. Feel free to spam this dude. :)

Answer (score 1):

If common mark is implemented then this will work:

```
bool working = true;
```

Comment: You rock! Now how many older posts are broken ;)

Comment: Well it's not quite there yet.  Will look into the differences next week.

Answer (score 1):

Testing the [new ```` ``` ````-style codeblocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/388442):

```
this is a code block
```

In a blockquote

> ```
> This is a codeblock in a blockquote
> ```

### Language highlighting:

With a ```` ```lang-c ```` at the top:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;
    while(i --> 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

With a `<!-- language: lang-c -->`:

```c
#include <stdio>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 6;
    while(i --> 0) printf(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Testing order of attributes in `<a>` tags:

Examples:

[`href` first](https://example.com):
`` <a href="https://example.com" title="example with href first">`href` first</a> ``

`title` first: `` <a title="example with href first" href="https://example.com">`title` first</a> ``

Answer (score 1):

- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/)
- [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/)

Comment: Comment to delete....

Answer (score 1):

```html
<marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee><marquee>REEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE</marquee>
```

Comment: +1 for the incredibly annoying quote block thingie.

Comment: I was very bored.

Comment: And to answer your question, you are doing this because you aren't not doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta love the magic editor. Makes a lot of my editing a lot quicker.

But code markdown appears to break it :/ So this is just a reproduction post for the problem, in theory anyways.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This should default back to regular code formatting, and backticks more or less removed");
}
```

---

Unrelated, random update as requested [by NH.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/324152?noredirect=1#comment1059566_324152) for notification testing related to question starring. <sub>Just don't stare directly at the question, or you may feel like [you're seeing ponies everywhere](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Wild_Pony_at_Assateague.jpg/1200px-Wild_Pony_at_Assateague.jpg)</sub>

Comment: weirdly status-no-repro in this environment xd

Comment: Would you please update your answer or answer again, @Asuna? I'm testing whether starring this question will notify me in any way.

Comment: @NH. Updated - pretty sure you just get a special update thingy on your profile under favorites (shows up as  a "1" on the post IIRC)

Comment: Confirmed... now I need to document that somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>foo</strike> **FOO**:

```
def f1(s):
    return s

def f2():
    f1('I LOVE FOO')

print(f2())
```

Aha, a joke, now a working one:

```
def f1(s):
    return s

def f2():
    return f1('I LOVE FOO')

print(f2())
```

How about:

```
def f1():
    f2()

def f2():
    f1()

print(f1())
```

Comment: It appears that `None` of the functions are willing to print 'I LOVE FOO'.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Lol, made one working.

Comment: Yay! Now the `print` function loves foo!

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Yup, :-), lol, funny code.

Comment: Now all you have to do is call `f2` from `f1` and start an infinite loop... I'm sure `print` would like that.

Comment: Wow, snails really can read people's minds. I never knew...

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle WOW, i did that even before i saw your comment!

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle hahaha, my snail has a good brain :-)

Comment: Great job telepathically communicating, Snail! Now Python just needs to learn how, and the whole universe of everything will be so much easier...

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Yup, of course, wow, you have so many names.

Comment: I know... I put so much time and effort into coming up with my names...

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle I like pizza static void main since that reminds me of pizza 

Comment: I prefer Supa Mega Ducky Momo da Waffle because it gives me an excuse to talk about waffles, ducks, and Supa Megas at the same time.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Oh that's rigth, missed that one.

Comment: That's so waffles.

Comment: @SupaMegaDuckyMomodaWaffle Yup.

Answer (score 1):

### Hover over the blockquote

> ```html
> <h2>Hi</h2>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>b</kbd>

<kbd>c</kbd>

<kbd>b</kbd>

<kbd>a</kbd>

Comment: Better yet, use [http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html](cgitb)

Comment: this is a comment for Andalusian boneless turkey farmers AJAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

[link test](http://localhost)

1. The parenthesis does not come off anymore: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)
2. Try escaping the parenthesis with a backslash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

   Looks good in the preview, but watch out!

“the **C** **P**re**P**rocessor” comes out differently as well.

Comment: test 1 at 12:14 local time

Comment: pokopokopokopoko

Comment: @jleedev, see [Links to URLs containing parentheses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/13509#13509).

Comment: @Arjan Yeah, I know. I just get annoyed when the server- and client-side rendering disagree.

Comment: We detected an invalid domain linked in your post. This is likely caused due to sample code not being in a code block. (this message will be automatically removed when the link is fixed)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer which shows that using 2 spaces doesn't format as code:

This is a line with two spaces before it.

```
This is a line with four spaces before it.
```

```
And I couldn't resist adding a line with two spaces before it, 
  cheating with a <pre> tag ;-)
```

Comment: ...but you know 4 spaces are documented, right? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @Arjan - Yes. This answer was a response to a comment on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710841/javascript-variables).

Comment: Still trying to get the formatting

        `testing line with 4 spaces`

Comment: [hint 1](http://i.imgur.com/JIYqnb1.png)

Answer (score 0):

script:
`for i in $1 $2 $3` P

script with backticks and line breaks: P

`for i in $1 $2 $3 P

short line P

long line long line long line long line` P

script with indent of 4 spaces: P

```
for i in $1 $2 $3 P  
short line P  
long line long line long line long line P
```

script with `<pre>` P

```
for i in $1 $2 $3 P
short line P
long line long line long line long line P
```

script with `<pre><code>` P

```
for i in $1 $2 $3 P
short line P
long line long line long line long line P
```

Comment: ...but: new paragraphs need an empty line. See my edit. (Explicit line breaks, which do not start a new paragraph, are rarely needed, but are possible too. As I really dislike the abuse of line breaks, I won't explain the trick here, though the Markdown help makes no secret out of it...)

Answer (score 0):

[/questions/3122#!/questions/3122?test=1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122#!/questions/3122?test=1)

[/questions/3122#!/questions/3122?test=2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122#!/questions/3122?test=2)

Comment: Is there any purpose to the `#!` after post ID? :)

Comment: Stop that, please.

Comment: @NickCraver - Very sorry. I created a post on it and was coming back to delete these. I chose one at random and didn't mean to spam you. I was hoping the wiki would prevent message pinging. Sorry!!

Comment: @TravisJ it's all good - just makes my phone go nuts :) Protip: pick one from a user that's been deleted next time, good test target!

Comment: Here's a test <script>alert('test');</script>

Answer (score 0):

How to escape backslashes.

Use whitespace:

```
\\
```

This is a backslash in a sentence (one backslash): \

This is an escaped backslash in a sentence (two backslashes OOPS): \

This is an escaped backslash in a sentence: \\ (three backslashes).

Same thing with backticks. This is backtick backslash backslash backtick: `\\`

This is a backtick backslash backtick `\`.

Here is a real backslashed backtick: `

Comment: `test` ← \`test\`

Answer (score 0):

Testing out this new Userscript I'm building. One more edit to make sure this thing works.

[abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse)

Comment: And one moar comment

Comment: Will this still work after I delete some comments?

Comment: Adding in one more comment

Comment: Hello world!!1!!!

Comment: One more comment.

Comment: Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing points in time, defined as the number of seconds elapsed since midnight proleptic Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) of January 1, 1970, not counting leap seconds. It is used widely, not only in Unix-like operating systems, but also in many other computing systems and file formats. It is neither a linear representation of time nor a true representation of UTC (though it is frequently mistaken for both), as it cannot represent standard UTC leap seconds (e.g. December 31, 1998 23:59:60), although otherwise the times it represents are UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the tag feature... I don't think I have it right... [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox)

Sweet, that was too simple ...
([sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox)

> spoiler text in a blockquote?

Answer (score 0):

Is VB comment syntax highlighting working?

```VB
Sub AMethod()
    'a comment
    Dim SomeCode
End Sub
```

```VB
'A comment
Sub AMethod()
   Dim SomeCode
End Sub
```

Boo that meta hides the colors :(

Comment: (@Joel, see my edit in the question about syntax highlighting.)

Answer (score 0):

Test using pre/code...

```
public void Something()
{
  return;
}
```

Regular text here.

```
public void Something()
{
  return;
}
```

Comment: This is **bold**.

Comment: This is **bold**not.

Comment: This is **bold** maybe.

Comment: Following is `back ticked` right?

Comment: Following is code: <code>public void</code>, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/ 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1/ 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1
See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/107876
```

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1/
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/1

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/107876

Comment: testing..1..2..3

Comment: testing second comment

Comment: Summary, please.

Answer (score 0):

Will sanitizer incorrectly strip the p tag at the end? 

Header 1 

Header 1

Header 2

line break
test

italic

**bold**

Google

[image: Valid XHTML <a]

Have you seen ?

`code span<a`

```
more test
test <a
```

> test test
>   test

funny

How about in lists?

1. li1 unclosed

   li2 unclosed

p

- li1 unclosed

  li2 unclosed

bla:

- bla

  bla

Comment: test test test <a

Answer (score 0):

uhm..why _italic_does_not_work_when_I_use_the_underscore_ ?

How about

1. *foo*[*bar* + 1]
2. foo[*bar* + 1]
3. *foo[*bar* + 1]

Comment: but *works_in_the_comment*?

Comment: markdown iz bugged

Comment: it probably has something to do with the fact that underscoring around a word also italicizes it.

Comment: *test_one* *test*two* _test_three_ (Original: `*test_one* *test*two* _test_three_`)

Comment: There is a reason for this, fwiw. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116986/why-do-i-have-to-hack-to-get-a-bold-letter-in-a-word/116989#116989

Answer (score 0):

Some apparent whitespace problems, 10 m/s ([original post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/how-long-it-will-take-for-a-tree-to-fall-on-a-ground/2401#2401)):

The period of a pendulum of length $h$ for small oscillations is $2\pi \sqrt{h/g}$, with $g$ the acceleration due to gravity, about $10 m/s$.

Source:

> The period of a pendulum of length `$h$` for small oscillations 
>     is `$2\pi \sqrt{h/g}$`, with `$g$` the acceleration due to gravity, 
>     about `$10 m/s$`.

---

Update: Meta Stack Overflow does not seem to have the formula stuff that [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) has.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you can run into trouble if you try to use `<` inside: `<code>a<b</code>` gives `a!`

---

1. You can't have a backslash `\` in the *end* of inline code in comments. If you try `` `\\` ``, then the result will be `\`. You'll have to type `\\ ` and live with the white space being within the inline code.

Comment: `test number one\`

Comment: `test number two\\`

Comment: `test number three\\ `

Comment: `test number four\ `

Comment: Hey @Hendrik I've deleted my comments at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446 :)

Answer (score 0):

Just testing this new feature:

[Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/49435#49435)

Comment: You did hear about [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446), right? "New" since 2010-11-05 ;-) (Okay, that was only added there on December 7th.)

Answer (score 0):

Testing a possible edit bug...

Here's the first edit...

And here's the second -- perhaps as a new post.

Okay so far, will try one more time...

Final test

Answer (score 0):

Comments test. Checking various comment related stuffs

Comment: [link](http://www.google.ca)

Answer (score 0):

testing *revision* diffs blah blah

- new line
- new line2
- this foobar quote

  - boo boo boo

Comment: Code `var=\`grep -c this\`` no code

Answer (score 0):

SQL:
-- Users with 10k+ rep
    -- Find users with 10,000 or more reputation

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Reputation >= 10000
```

PHP:

```
# Print out the text, and prevent HTML injection.
if ($_POST['text']) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
}
```

VBScript:

```
'Infinite loop with MsgBox
DO
    returnvalue = MsgBox("Hello, world!", 64, "Message");
Loop
```

CSS:

```
/* Some CSS. */
tag {
    color: red;
}
#id {
    color: orange;
}
.class {
    color: yellow;
}
[attr='value'] {
    color: lime;
}
```

Comment: Next feature request of mine: automatic lower casing of keywords when language is SQL... ;-)

Comment: you need to add such line `<!-- language: lang-css -->` one line above the code itself, with one blank line between them. You can rollback to my edit to see the effect. :)

Answer (score 0):

i wrote sending email function that only work my debug mode(debug local server) when i publishing and hosting C# code that function not work. this my email configuration function

Comment: the code doesn't show!??

Answer (score 0):

XSS testing:

an alert

Answer (score 0):

Backticks.

How about some backticks ``?

```
VARIABLE=`ls`
```

Answer (score 0):

Intraword italics formatting

- SID: S-1-5-21 *domain*-512
- SID: S-1-5-21*domain*-512
- SID: S-1-5-21\s*domain*-512
- SID: S-1-5-21*domain*-512.  `SID: S-1-5-21<em>domain</em>-512`

Leads:

- [Markdown bug in preview pane (incorrect italicization)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26961/markdown-bug-in-preview-pane-incorrect-italicization). "Known bug. Intra-word emphasis are part of the markdown spec, but they're disabled here as they cause problems in code snippets."
- [How can I format only part of a word in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26165/how-can-i-type-an-underscore-symbol-as-part-of-a-word)
- [Three Markdown Gotchas](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/06/three-markdown-gotcha/). "Markdown’s single biggest flaw is its intra-word emphasis."

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin(equation}
\chi(M_g) = 2-2g
\end{equation}
$$

Comment: Can't Jax off here.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select * from Foo where Foo.bar == "baz"
```

Comment: You know you need a blank line before a code block, as per the regular Markdown specs?

Comment: @Arjan: The specs aren't clear.  I know now, thx.

Comment: Hopefully the FAQ is clear though? If not, then you know what to do ;-) See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189)

Answer (score 0):

alert("testing .how to escape tags such as script")

I herefor occupy this answer in the name of Good! Now get off my answer!

[test](/questions/tagged/test) [Cool Hyperlink][1](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

[test](/questions/tagged/test) [Cool Hyperlink](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Unless you're trying to find some exploit, see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Stack;

public class FlushStack<E> extends Stack<E> {

    public Collection<E> get() {
        ArrayList<E> elements = new ArrayList<E>();
        elements.addAll(this);
        this.clear();
        return elements;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax highlighting test

`<!-- language: lang-bsh -->`

```bsh
# Catch obstrusive tracking parameters like ...
# ?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter or
# ?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+wdrss+(WDRSS)
# ... because they generate doubled content.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_source= [NC,OR]
# Some people put their own URIs into this parameter. May be better banned.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=\D
# The trailing question mark removes the query string.
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment formatting test.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_short_story)

Answer (score 0):

HTML markup won't work [in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559957/jquery-colorbox-open-single-image).. testing it here.

```html
<a title="jhddj" rel="relImageStatusUpdate" href="<%= format_status_image_url(row["UserID"],row["USERSTATUS_ID"]) %>" 
id="ahrefStatusImage"> 
<img alt="" 
src="<%= format_status_thumbnailimage_url(row["UserID"],row["USERSTATUS_ID"]) %>"/></a>
```

Trying pure HTML without the ASP.NET stuff:

```html
<a title="jhddj" rel="relImageStatusUpdate" href="#" id="ahrefStatusImage"> 
<img alt="" src="myimage.gif"/></a>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Livello_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="588px" height="588px" viewBox="20.267 102.757 588 588" enable-background="new 20.267 102.757 588 588"
  xml:space="preserve">
<g>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.267,104.257h-0.006H314.267z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M593.641,309.856
  c7.779,25.038,12.282,51.518,13.015,78.938C606.627,360.895,602.006,334.259,593.641,309.856z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M320.269,689.182
  c-1.997,0.04-3.995,0.076-6.002,0.076C316.274,689.258,318.274,689.229,320.269,689.182z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.267,689.258
  c-2.007,0-4.005-0.036-6.002-0.076C310.259,689.229,312.259,689.258,314.267,689.258z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M308.266,104.333
  c1.995-0.04,3.991-0.076,5.995-0.076C312.256,104.257,310.258,104.286,308.266,104.333z"/>
 <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M314.268,104.257
  C314.268,104.257,314.268,104.257,314.268,104.257c2.007,0,4.005,0.036,6.003,0.076
  C318.275,104.286,316.275,104.257,314.268,104.257z"/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="241.3174" y1="737.666" x2="389.318" y2="5.6631" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop  offset="0.1" style="stop-color:#E62725"/>
  <stop  offset="0.3093" style="stop-color:#ED1C24"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#1C1B1C"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M497.885,194.197
  c-35.951-52.42-101.821-88.07-177.614-89.864c-1.998-0.041-3.996-0.076-6.004-0.076c-0.002,0-0.004,0-0.006,0
  c-2.004,0-4,0.036-5.995,0.076c-127.188,2.562-234.438,86.301-272.078,201.532c18.136-49.932,52.107-90.06,94.523-111.756
  c22.219-11.365,46.75-17.683,72.544-17.683c41.792,0,80.278,16.559,110.958,44.369c31.15,28.237,54.245,68.078,64.56,113.999
  c3.892,17.322,5.973,35.505,5.973,54.259c0,24.827-3.645,48.653-10.319,70.803c43.404-10.909,81.033-33.316,108.05-63.098
  c27.84-30.689,44.418-69.196,44.418-111.013C526.894,252.353,516.317,221.074,497.885,194.197z"/>
 <path fill="#FFF200" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M606.655,388.794
  c-0.732-27.42-5.235-53.9-13.015-78.938c-36.443-117.287-144.715-202.931-273.37-205.523
  c75.793,1.793,141.663,37.444,177.614,89.864c18.433,26.877,29.009,58.156,29.009,91.548c0,41.817-16.578,80.324-44.418,111.013
  c-27.017,29.781-64.646,52.188-108.05,63.098c-19.077,4.795-39.263,7.38-60.159,7.38c-20.939,0-41.165-2.596-60.276-7.41
  c11.732,38.949,32.869,72.69,60.221,97.485c30.68,27.81,69.165,44.369,110.956,44.369c31.125,0,60.417-9.186,86.018-25.359
  c56.843-35.912,95.473-106.302,95.473-187.267C606.658,388.967,606.655,388.881,606.655,388.794z"/>
 <g>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="309.9668" y1="107.8887" x2="314.2646" y2="107.8887" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0090C7"/>
   <stop  offset="0.8326" style="stop-color:#2E3192"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M303.966,689.041
   c1.429,0.059,2.862,0.106,4.298,0.141C306.828,689.152,305.398,689.091,303.966,689.041z"/>
  
   <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="27.7671" y1="364.2666" x2="384.7725" y2="364.2666" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
   <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#0090C7"/>
   <stop  offset="0.8326" style="stop-color:#2E3192"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <path fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M249.646,334.825
   c20.38-5.543,42.089-8.545,64.622-8.545c22.49,0,44.159,2.99,64.505,8.513c-10.314-45.92-33.409-85.761-64.56-113.999
   c-30.68-27.81-69.166-44.369-110.958-44.369c-25.794,0-50.325,6.318-72.544,17.683c-42.417,21.696-76.387,61.824-94.523,111.756
   c-8.998,27.543-14.013,56.882-14.375,87.344c-0.014,1.183-0.045,2.361-0.045,3.547c0,158.094,125.431,286.855,282.199,292.285
   c-84.513-3.441-156.088-48.998-186.572-112.624c-10.147-21.179-15.754-44.354-15.754-68.649c0-41.816,16.579-80.322,44.418-111.01
   C172.146,368.001,208.125,346.119,249.646,334.825z"/>
 </g>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="282.7324" y1="647.4258" x2="404.7324" y2="161.4258" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop  offset="0.6047" style="stop-color:#006838"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#538B2E"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#F1F2F2" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M606.767,396.756
  c0-2.662-0.04-5.315-0.111-7.961c0,0.086,0.003,0.172,0.003,0.259c0,80.965-38.63,151.355-95.473,187.267
  c-25.601,16.174-54.893,25.359-86.018,25.359c-41.791,0-80.276-16.56-110.956-44.369c-27.353-24.795-48.489-58.536-60.221-97.485
  c-6.669-22.141-10.311-45.956-10.311-70.772c0-18.743,2.079-36.915,5.965-54.228c-41.521,11.294-77.5,33.176-103.587,61.933
  c-27.84,30.688-44.418,69.193-44.418,111.01c0,24.296,5.607,47.471,15.754,68.649c31,64.702,104.491,110.721,190.87,112.765
  c1.997,0.04,3.995,0.076,6.002,0.076s4.005-0.036,6.002-0.076c1.438-0.034,2.87-0.082,4.301-0.141
  C481.337,683.61,606.767,554.849,606.767,396.756z"/>
 
  <linearGradient id="SVGID_5_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="249.6802" y1="400.2422" x2="390.7451" y2="400.2422" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -6 797)">
  <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
  <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
 </linearGradient>
 <path fill="url(#SVGID_5_)" fill-opacity="0" d="M378.772,334.793c-20.346-5.523-42.015-8.513-64.505-8.513
  c-22.533,0-44.242,3.002-64.622,8.545c-3.887,17.313-5.965,35.485-5.965,54.228c0,24.816,3.641,48.631,10.311,70.772
  c19.111,4.814,39.337,7.41,60.276,7.41c20.896,0,41.082-2.585,60.159-7.38c6.675-22.15,10.319-45.977,10.319-70.803
  C384.745,370.298,382.664,352.115,378.772,334.793z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hmm, I think there is a bug in the hinting system.  I [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97313/syntax-highlighting-language-hints-being-overridden-after-loading) it.

Comment: Cheers @Jeff and thanks! Wasn't sure how to report it, nice catch. :-)

Comment: hello world 1 2 3. ``\\``

Answer (score 0):

Inline editing test!

....................

Answer (score 0):

Not formatting, but converting answer to comment.

Comment: This should be a comment. Did you see this Chris?

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, look at this crazy empty blockquote!

> 

Which isn't even remotely as crazy as this one:

> ­
>   ­
>   ­
>   ­
>   ­

;-)

Comment: There's always [a crazier way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/76c9c339-09bc-4a33-ab90-008844b231db/view-source)!

Answer (score 0):

> Could you tell that this wasn't just an empty blockquote before you hovered?
> Etc,
> etc,
> etc.

Comment: Sure, on a mobile device that's very obvious!

Comment: What does a mobile device show?

Comment: Click the link "mobile" in the footer. Or, [spoiler](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104008/could-we-please-have-a-level-two-arrow-of-hiding/104016#104016).

Answer (score 0):

Test
test
test
test

More test

foo test

b
ar
f
efe
fe
ge
ge
g

ge

akeoka
feafkae
kfoa
ejfoeaj

Comment: aw, don't beat yourself up about it.

Comment: On the other hand, a great programmer also keeps [some meaningful revision notes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/104156/revisions) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Testing non breakable spaces in answers.

Comment: Testing non breakable spaces in comments.

Comment: qnother test here, I think I've finished.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the revision history when a tag is removed from the end of a post:

Comment: rtutyjhnfdgbnstygkteuketm

Answer (score 0):

formatting **test** *test* test

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if [an anchor link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/77627#howMuchTime) to an answer works...doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ullamcorper, eros ut faucibus dapibus, nibh nunc lacinia ligula, et sagittis nibh lorem at purus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Praesent scelerisque turpis nec eros luctus fringilla. Curabitur vitae lacus a sem posuere sollicitudin in at sapien.

- Sed ac augue sapien, varius congue dolor.
- Aliquam at enim eget purus gravida faucibus vitae et justo.
- In et mauris ac dolor consectetur blandit.
- Pellentesque aliquam vehicula felis, nec eleifend turpis tincidunt id.

---

Nunc laoreet lectus tempor massa tempus bibendum. Suspendisse potenti. Nunc euismod, dolor vitae pharetra dictum, justo nisi dignissim lectus, elementum ornare quam felis eget turpis. Praesent vel felis eget eros scelerisque condimentum. Suspendisse eu elit id turpis dictum imperdiet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis tempor ligula eu enim suscipit vitae pulvinar dui cursus.

Comment: Sed ultrices urna magna, sit amet convallis elit.

Comment: Aliquam eleifend turpis mollis arcu congue eu tincidunt lectus varius.

Comment: How do I love thee?    
Let me count the ways

Answer (score 0):

Testing `<pre><code>some-code here\n</code></pre>` against some Markdown-formatted code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="applyChanges" />
```

This time with a line break after the `<pre>`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="applyChanges" />
```

Now for the Markdown formatting:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="applyChanges" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Pac-man** goes
>   wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka­wokka

Soft hyphens aren't apparent because StackOverflow is fixed-width. [You can see them better here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hhUca/)

You can't visit h​ttp://www.goo​gle.com/. Not even by copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Adding comments with inline customized links, with parens and spaces in them.

Comment: Lets you escape parens - [See the docs on `startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult\(android.content.Intent,%20int\))

Comment: Doesn't let you escape spaces - [See the docs on `startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult\(android.content.Intent,\ int\))

Answer (score 0):

[programmers.se]
[so]
[su]
[sf]

Comment: [programmers.se] [so] [su] [sf]

Comment: [cooking.se] [gaming.se] [security.se] [apple.se] [android.se]

Answer (score 0):

There should be syntax highlighting here.

```sql
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE this = that
```

Comment: Gotta be directly above the code block to work.

Comment: @Shog9 That doesn't work either, as you can see.

Comment: Needs a line above it too (see edit). Yeah, a bit finicky...

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing inbox notifications. If you comment on this, you will receive one (1) vial of virtual unicorn horn dust (no actual unicorns will be harmed).

Comment: SHUT UP AND TAKE MY MONEY

Comment: So then this is *artificial* virtual unicorn horn dust?

Comment: Does this coupon have an expiration date?

Comment: No. However, every time I distribute a vial of virtual unicorn horn dust, it's diluted 10x more than the previous one. There's only a finite amount of this stuff, after all.

Comment: i like unicorns o.o

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​`:D`

Answer (score 0):

{{Unreferenced}}

I am so smart! I am so smart! S-M-R-T!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners

Answer (score 0):

test. to see, if the spaces: removed! are? visible/ without the' show mark- down differences'

2nd test to see if I can edit a deleted ans

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($item['load_functions'][1]) && !empty($item['map'][2]) && $item['load_functions'][3] == 'node_load') {
  $node = $router_item['map'][4];
}
else {
  // The menu item is not for a node.
}
```

[menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

[menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($item['load_functions'][1]) && !empty($item['map'][2]) && $item['load_functions'][3] == 'node_load') {
  $node = $router_item['map'][4];
}
else {
  // The menu item is not for a node.
}
```

[menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

[menu_get_item()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)

Answer (score 0):

[Example link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)

[Same example link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)

[The same link once again](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7)

[Another link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)

[Web Archive link 1](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alexa.com/topsites)

[Web Archive link 2](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alexa.com/topsites)

http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.alexa.com/topsites

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to test somethin' 'bout deletions.

> $* balah blah ($*) more stuff

Comment: blah blah [about]

Comment: Does [ask] work on meta?

Answer (score 0):

**Part**ially bold  `**Part**<!-- fix -->ially bold`

*part*ially italic  `*part*<!-- fix -->ially italic`

***Part***ially bold/italic  `***Part***<!-- fix -->ially bold/italic`

OLD:

**Part**ially bold

*part*ially italic

****Part****ially bold/italic

```
**Part**ially bold

*part*ially italic

****Part****ially bold/italic
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment: This is a test of an empty answer...

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This is a test of an empty comment!

Answer (score 0):

Is <something> no in longer hidden (where *something* is not an allowed HTML tag)?

Conclusion: there is no change, but `<>` seems to be a special case. Encoding `<` as `&lt;` is still required (if not formatted as by code).

Comment: Don't mind me...just testing whether http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfy+links+work

Answer (score 0):

XSS

Answer (score 0):

Testing image upload from clipboard

[image]

Comment: How is testing a misspelled word?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [changelog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/184144/revisions) - this is to demonstrate an issue with the toolbar buttons and existing square brackets.

Testing arrays in arrays:

```
b[0][1] b[1][2] b[1][3] b[0][4]
```

`(b[0][5] b[1][6]) (b[0][7] b[0][8])`

[image]

a_b_c

a__b__c

a___b___c

a____b____c

Comment: Testing `backtick escapes\` still code?

Comment: Testing `\\` still code?

Comment: `\\\` still code `?

Comment: `\\ ` still code ?`

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with comment links to the new [help] center that I wish would just read me mind already.

Comment: How can I deep link to [help] topics? Does [help#bounty] work?

Comment: No but [faq#bounty] does. Dumb!

Comment: How about slash notation like [help/bounty] or space [help bounty] or dash [help-bounty]?

Comment: Testing comment ---strike--- formatting the <strike>html</strike> way.

Answer (score 0):

blah blah blah blah howdy doodie doo

Comment: Helloo <!--1234567890-->

Comment: Hello &#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;

Comment: Hello &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: Hello * * * * * * * *

Comment: Hello *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;*

Comment: Hello *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;*    &nbsp; *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* *&nbsp;* .

Answer (score 0):

Testing the syntax highlighter

```css
So {this:is css; /*comment*/}
```

Testing the syntax highlighter

```
So {this:is none; /*comment*/}
```

Testing the syntax highlighter

```txt
So {this:is none; /*comment*/}
```

Testing the syntax highlighter

```text
So {this:is text; /*comment*/}
```

Testing the syntax highlighter

```c
So {this:is c; /*comment*/}
```

Testing the syntax highlighter

```c
So {this:is html; /*comment*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing 2.2 - o83fpubgs487gs4e8o7ghs4o78gfbysf76esfb9of3si76ffs39hgs4678gf3s9h3s8gof3.

Answer (score 0):

Wheeeeeeeeeee!

1. This is number one
    2. This is a sub ordered list
    3. `You can hack code together here, too`
     4. Blah blah blah
     5. Blah blah, blah blah blah.

I'm amazed if the quality checker lets this go through.

Comment: No quality check on Meta, @Tim - only length check as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Testing a possible edit bug.

Here is some more text. Made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Code formatting:

`` some kind of shell commandwith a `sub-shell command` | blah blah ``

Answer (score 0):

[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)[SO](http://bit.ly/14XILyh)

Comment: And an excessively long flag. ;P

Answer (score 0):

attempting to fail quality filter on the formatting sandbox. http://goo.gl/82FLe

[enter link description here](http://goo.gl/82FLe)

Answer (score 0):

.                                                                                                                      .

Comment: minimum 30 characters limits can be ignored by spaces...

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>answer go wrong way!</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Comment: link in comments  [stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/198216/vote/3)

Answer (score 0):

Testing nested quote levels and blank space:

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > 

The grey box of epicness!

Does it work with `<pre>`'s?

Apparently so!

Yay crappy formatting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test. This is only a test.

Editing a deleted question.

1. foo

   ```
   code
   ```
2. bar

```
code
```

12. baz

Comment: @foo @bar ` ` @bazz

Comment: [help/on-topic]

Comment: [help/someone-answers]

Comment: [help/on-topic]

Comment: [help/privileges]

Comment: An example comment...

Answer (score 0):

## beep beep i'm a jeep

**beep beep i'm a jeep**

beep beep i'm a jeep
        beep beep i'm a jeep
    
    
        beep beep i'm a jeep
        beep beep i'm a jeep
    


beep beep i'm a jeep

Comment: You just had  to test the HTML didn't you? :P

Comment: Guilty as charged :)

Comment: beep beep you're a jeep

Answer (score 0):

- Test [su]

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Lorem ipsum blah blah blah

Comment: testing stuff here: [chat]

Comment: testing magic links: [chat], [help], [help/dont-ask], [help/mcve], [edit]

Comment: [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

alert(42);zzz

Comment: [success](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18580)!

Comment: ah, it dont works because you did not declared the variable 42 man.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `jQuery` with the cookies library that automatically JSON-stringifies structures when setting cookies and rebuilds them again when getting the cookie.

I'm using cookies to provide an undo-redo functionality for a web form that can include a lot of text, so every time an input element changes I collect all the data in the form and put it all in a cookie called `newsletterDoX` (where `X` is an integer) and I also set another cookie to store the current integer and another to store how many redos are available. Cookies are set to expire after one day.

The functionality is working, but when there is more than 4 `newsletterDo` cookies then a page refresh will give me a 400 error. In Chome it says

> ## Bad Request
>
> Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
>   Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
>
> `Cookie`
>
> `/n`

When I delete the cookies back down to 4 or less then the error goes away. I think I got to 5 or 6 without the error with Firefox.

What's going on? I don't think it's the size of the cookies, or the content. The cookies beyond 4 can have the same size and content as those below 4 and it still gives the error.

The total number of cookies in the domain is as low as 12 when the error occurs, and deleting some other cookies rather than the `newsletterDo` cookies doesn't seem to change things, so the number of cookies probably isn't a problem either.

What could it be? I'm stumped!

here's the code that sets the cookies:

```
// cookies expire 1 day from now.
// I'm sure there's a more succinct way to set the expiry date,
// but this is working for me
var oneDay = new Date();
oneDay.setDate(oneDay.getDate() + 1);
jQuery.cookies.setOptions({expiresAt: oneDay});

// this function saves the form data so the user can come back to it
var setNewsletterCookie = function() {
    var saveData = collectNewsletterData();
    // save it in the database using the php code that acts as a db interface
    jQuery.post('db_interface_newsletters.php', {
        task: "save",
        title: $('#newsletterTitle').val(),
        issue: $('#issuenum').val(),
        content: saveData},
        function(data) {
            if (data.indexOf('Fail') >= 0) {alert (data);}
            else {
                // data should be a date string in UTC
                // convert it to local time and display
                var lastSaveDate = new Date(data);
                $('.last_save_date').text(lastSaveDate.toLocaleString());
            }
        }
    );
    // save it also in a cookie for use of undo and redo
    try {
        var currentNewsletterDo = parseInt(jQuery.cookies.get('current_newsletter_do'), 10);
        if (isNaN(currentNewsletterDo)) currentNewsletterDo = 0;
    } catch(e) {
        var currentNewsletterDo = 0;
    }
    ++currentNewsletterDo;
    jQuery.cookies.set('newsletterDo' + currentNewsletterDo, saveData);
    jQuery.cookies.set('current_newsletter_do', currentNewsletterDo);
    jQuery.cookies.set('newsletter_available_redo', 0);
    $('.newsletter_redo').button('disable');
    $('.newsletter_undo').button('enable');
};
```

Comment: There is no quality filter here on Meta, anything will be posted.

Answer (score 0):

`Code formatting`

```
Block code
```

Somewhat code

Comment: This is a comment‮dilav sa deggalf neeb sah tnemmoc sihT ‭

Comment: This is another comment‮emoswa sa deggalf neeb sah tnemmoc sihT ‭

Answer (score 0):

## I am asking how to use `jQuery` to add numbers
i tried `$("2+2")` but it didnt work

how to do in jquery

Comment: Hope you're happy, Qantas!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer.

Needs some chars

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @result VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @result = ''

SELECT @result += temp.temp
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ('Posted Date' + CAST(POSTED_DATE as char) + ',') as temp
  FROM [LACDC].[dbo].[PS_CDC_JRNL_LSR_VW]
  where JOURNAL_ID = @ID and JOURNAL_DATE = @Date
) AS temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare @result VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @result = ''

SELECT @result += temp.temp
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ('Posted Date' + CAST(POSTED_DATE as char) + ',') as temp
  FROM [LACDC].[dbo].[PS_CDC_JRNL_LSR_VW]
  where JOURNAL_ID = @ID and JOURNAL_DATE = @Date
) AS temp

Answer (score 0):

Checking to see if this will POST over https when I'm on the https version of MSO.

UPDATE:

It did!

We have a way to work around [Rejection of text containing SQL statements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43466/197656).

Answer (score 0):

[][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]

Comment: &#128038; unicode! 

Answer (score 0):

HTML PrettyPrinted:

```html
<html>
<span>something</span>
</html>
```

JavaScript PrettyPrinted:

```js
int Javascript = 1;
```

CSS PrettyPrinted:

```css
background-color: orange;
```

Comment: You need one line break between the  `<!-- language... -->` and the code see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

This here is a post that I'll be using to test stuff on the API!

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.lblPackCurrUnits.Text = "◊A";
```

Answer (score 0):

x
x

```
\relative c' {
   << { c4 c c c8 c   c4 bes8 aes4. aes8 aes } \\
      { g8( aes f g4) aes f8   aes8( g f s8 \once\hideNotes aes2) } >> 
   << { bes8 bes2 \stemDown aes8( g f   <f ees>4.) } \\
      { f8( g ees f4)  s s8 } >>
   g8( des' f \clef treble as bes)
}
```

Comment: Formatting works differently in posts (questions and answers) versus comments — particularly when you want to format special characters `as code`. In a post, you need to use `\`\` \` \`\`` (tick tick space tick space tick tick) to get a tick in code format (`\``), but that doesn’t work in comments, where you must use `\`\⁠\`\`` (tick slash tick tick). Backslashes are almost as bad; `\`\⁠\`` (tick slash tick) in a post will get you a code-formatted backslash (``\``), but this doesn’t work in comments.  Luckily, `\`\`\⁠\`\`` (tick tick slash tick tick) works in either place.

Answer (score 0):

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#em

un*frigging*believable

Answer (score 0):

IF you change the content after clicking away from the capatcha it will let you post without it...

Does this happen?

TEst TO See if capatcha can be bypassed....
TEsting only

Testing, testing...

1. Test
2. Test
3. Test

Comment: lllllllllllllllllll

Comment: <code> break <br/> 
reak <br/> </code>

Comment: What about this?
`code
break
code
break
code`

Comment: ​​ nocode `​​
​​`​​break​​  `​​
​​`nocode `​​
​​`​​break

Answer (score 0):

Some [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode):

ℷ   ζ   ⇔   ♀   ♂   ♣   ♮   ♯   ∑   ∞   ∮   ∭   §   ε   ψ   ‡   ℛ   ⋄   Υ

Answer (score 0):

This is a test answer for this question:

[Edit message is lost after a small follow-up edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216891/187824)

I will come back after 5 minutes (grace period) and edit the answer twice with different edit summary. Enjoy!

This is test edit #1

This is test edit #2 during grace period of edit #1

Comment: test 1 ttttttttt

Answer (score 0):

posting this for demonstration purposes

first second third fourth fifth

the above words and then this statement were all added in one revision window, individually and one by one, from mobile view

Answer (score 0):

> **This movie sucks**
>
> Also you hope for the Rock to show up but he doesn't. He has 5ish
>   minutes of screen time and the rest of the time my fists are clenched
>   as I try to literally summon the power of Goku and go super saiyan
>   doing a kamehameha that could destroy the world itself because it
>   would be worth it to end this movie.
>
> — horsebungle

Answer (score 0):

This here be a test post. And it must be longer!

Answer (score 0):

```c++
#include <CapitalLetter>
#include <capitalLetter>
int main() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [revision `compare`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) test.

Answer (score 0):

Testing keyboard layout `<kbd>` formatting tag:

<kbd>º</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>FAKE_KEY</kbd>
<kbd>.                  .</kbd><kbd>Space doesn't work well</kbd>

---

Testing fancy special chars in keys:

<kbd>☢</kbd><kbd>☠</kbd><kbd>☛</kbd><kbd>☕</kbd><kbd>★</kbd><kbd>⓾</kbd><kbd>☯</kbd><kbd>☼</kbd><kbd>works</kbd>

in bold:

**<kbd>☢</kbd><kbd>☠</kbd><kbd>☛</kbd><kbd>☕</kbd><kbd>★</kbd><kbd>⓾</kbd><kbd>☯</kbd><kbd>☼</kbd><kbd>works</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

```
                                    *
                                   ***
                                  *****
                                 *******
                                *********
                               ***********
                              *************
                             ***************
                            *****************
                           *******************
                          *********************
                         ***********************
                        *************************
                       ***************************
                      *****************************
                     *******************************
                    *********************************
                   ***********************************
                  *************************************
                 ***************************************
                *****************************************
               *******************************************
              *********************************************
             ***********************************************
            *************************************************
           ***************************************************
          *****************************************************
         *******************************************************
        *********************************************************
       ***********************************************************
      *************************************************************
     ***************************************************************
    *****************************************************************
   *******************************************************************
  *********************************************************************
 ***********************************************************************
*************************************************************************
                             *************
```

Comment: now for comments it works!

Comment: *_*_*italic*_*_*

Answer (score 0):

This is a test.

Just a test.

I have now edited my test.

And now I have edited it twice.

Answer (score 0):

> SPOILER
>
>  SPOILER WARNING

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<Style>
    <bar />
</Style>
```

```xml
<Setter>
    <bar />
</Setter>
```

```xml
<foo>
    <bar />
</foo >
```

```xml
<foo>
    <Setter>
        <bar />
    </Setter>
</foo >
```

Answer (score 0):

public class x
{
    public string test() { }
}

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is a Link]

Comment: Buh bah baaaaahh!

Answer (score 0):

Spaces:

```
if (true) {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

Tabs:

```
if (true) {
    console.log('Hello world');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a test of mixed tabs and spaces.

```
This line starts with four spaces.
This line starts with a tab.
    This line starts with four spaces and is indented with a tab.
    This line starts with a tab and is indented with four spaces.
    This line starts with four spaces and is indented with four spaces.
    This line starts with a tab and is indented with a tab.
```

aaa

Answer (score 0):

`def self.queued
  Sidekiq::Stats.new.enqueued
end`

```
def self.queued
  Sidekiq::Stats.new.enqueued
end
```

[code]
def self.queued
  Sidekiq::Stats.new.enqueued
end
[/code]

```
def self.queued
  Sidekiq::Stats.new.enqueued
end
```

```
def self.queued
  Sidekiq::Stats.new.enqueued
end
```

Comment: Good to see you around Sam! :D

Answer (score 0):

mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

this is a te

another test

Comment: Ouch we're testing a ping bug!

Comment: Hi UNIKITTY, did you get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Testing code formatting assssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
asfasfas
gdagf
```

```
Testing code formatting assssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
asfasfas
gdagf
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating Python3's `print()` function is easy. Make a function that takes an argument, named whatever you want, then print that argument when the function is invoked from the interpreter. Easy.

```python
def println(stringint):
    print stringint
```

---

Here's how you'd invoke it in your interpreter with the argument.

```python
>>> import <filename>
>>> <filename>.println("Hello, this is a test.")
Hello, this is a test.
>>> <filename>.println(12 / 2 + 6)
12
```

---

You can also invoke it like this, without having to add the filename.

```python
>>> from <filename> import println
>>> println("Hello, this is a test.")
Hello, this is a test.
>>> println(12 / 2 + 6)
12
```

---

There you have it, a duplicate of Python3's `print()` function. Yay.

Comment: Why did you post it?

Comment: @nicael Don't know, just wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

Testing Japanese spacing.

〇一二三四五六七八九十　<--- 1-10

一　三　五　七　九　　<--- by 2s, japanese space

一 三 五 七 九 　<--- by 2s, western space

ひらがなカタカナ漢字単語

らがな　タカナ　字単語

Answer (score 0):

1. List item

   ```
   Code block
   ```
2. Second list item, <s>which unfortunately doesn't look like it's second</s> which now looks like it's second

Comment: @BartoszKP see now. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

> <sup><sub>This is subbed-sup text</sub></sup>
>   <sup>This is sup text</sup>

<sup><sub>This is text</sub></sup>

<sup>This is text</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is some text above a h1.

## This is a h1

This is some text under a h1.

This is some text above a h2.

### This is a h2

This is some text under a h2.

This is some text above a h3

#### This is a h3

This is some text under a h3.

Comment: In case you don't like this: see [Can we balance the whitespace above/below headings?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82281/can-we-balance-the-whitespace-above-below-headings)

Comment: @Arjan thanks for the link, it was actually for a similar request on MSE: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270153/improve-ui-for-headers-with-proper-markdown

Answer (score 0):

Testing @@ServerName for errors

Answer (score 0):

Links support URIs without scheme and hostname.

> What is [on topic](/help/on-topic) here?
>
> `What is [on topic](/help/on-topic) here?`

But relative URIs are not OK.

> What have you tried comment
>
> `[What have you tried comment](#comment772983_3122)`

Comment: But links do not support URIs without scheme and hostname in comments: What is [on topic](/help/on-topic) here? Why that? Relative URIs are still unsupported: [what have you tried comment](#comment772983_3122)

Answer (score 0):

Experiment on behavior of hard tabs in the answer box.

Indented with "format code" button:

```
int main(void)
{
    do_this();
    do_that();
    if (condition)
        do_other();
    return 0;
}
```

Indented manually, adjusting only the lines that "belong" at the left edge:

```
int main(void)
{
do_this();
do_that();
if (condition)
    do_other();
return 0;
}
```

Both look exactly the same in the editing `<textarea>`, in a browser that doesn't support `-moz-tab-size:4`.

Answer (score 0):

## ✓ Unicode works in a Heading

- ## ✓ Bullet works in a Heading
- - - 

Multiple bullets with visible and invisible text

- - - -These are bullets
- - - -
- [image]
- <sup>Bullet</sup> <sub>like</sub> <sup>this</sup> <sub>too</sub>

> > - 1. Blockquote your bullets
> > - kbd did not break the bullets
> >
> >   ## equal symbol below this text made it bold
> >
> >   - <kbd><s>no more blockquote bullet</s></kbd>

Some more experiments:

- ✓ In Bullets, it works

  1. - ✓ Bullet inside bullet works
  2. - ✓ Bullet inside bullet works (numbers are auto-adjusted)
  3. - ✓ Bullet inside bullet works
     - Sub bullet works
  4. Sub-bullet doesn't break the auto-numbering
  5. One more bullet

     ### 1. Empty dash below this makes it bold

Answer (score 0):

{{Infobox file format
| name                   = 
| icon                   = 
| iconcaption            = 
| icon_size              = 
| screenshot             = 
| screenshot_size        = 
| caption                = 
| extension              = 
| mime                   = 
| type code              = 
| uniform type           = 
| conforms to            = 
| magic                  = 
| developer              = 
| released               =  
| latest release version = 
| latest release date    =  
| genre                  = 
| container for          = 
| contained by           = 
| extended from          = 
| extended to            = 
| standard               = 
| free                   = 
| url                    = 
}}

Answer (score 0):

Docs:Makrdown parser breaks at $

sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                  / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/!mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/&mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/'mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/(mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/)mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/*mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/+mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/,mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/;mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/=mdDialog

Testing [bare urls](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#bare-urls):

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/!mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/&mdDialog

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/(mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/)mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/*mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/+mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/,mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/;mdDialog
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/=mdDialog

Answer (score 0):

Page 1 of 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675

Comment: [Page 1 of 904625697166532776746648320380374280100293470930272690489102837043110636675](htt‌​p://directory.io/)

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os; // emphasized
}

"string literal"
std::string s = "std::string"
'\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Foo!
comment no workie!
-->

Comment: ???????????????

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>This is probably not the intended use of this tag since Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Testing to see if [broken bold markdown](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18458/japanese-bold-test-room) fails the same way it does in chat:

> 行こうか**どうしようか**　＝　行こうか**？？か**
>
> 「許さない、（許さないのは）**絶対に**だ！」　→　「 許さない、**絶対に**だ！」

Answer (score 0):

> this is a test
>
>  this is only a test
>
>  [image: placeholdit]

Answer (score 0):

## LOL

> { ja, je }

## LOL<sup>2</sup>

> { { ja, ja }, { ja, je }, { je, ja }, { je, je } }

## LOL-PLEX

> { LOL<sup>10<sup>100</sup></sup> }

Perform

```
POST /vpa-azure/about HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:8080
Accept: text/plain
Content-Type: application/json

{ "data": "value" }
```

Should return the literal

```
"vpa-azure-api-0.0.1-jdk1.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Normal, plain t'xt with "varying" punctuation marks.
> `Code highlighted t'xt with "varying" punctuation marks.`

Answer (score 0):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)[meta-tag:anything-without,punctuation]
[anything](/questions/tagged/anything)

Answer (score 0):

## Heading 1

Testing

### Heading 2

Testing

#### Heading 3

**Heading 3** (actually just regular bold text, for comparison to the Heading 3 style)

Answer (score 0):

`exampleCode()`

[`exampleCode()`](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Can I post this question with

https://serverfault.com/questions/49147483697

and

[Why Failover instead of Load Balancing for HA](https://serverfault.com/questions/680515)

Let's see.

Can I? Can't I? Can I?

Answer (score 0):

> On [this
>   question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/28454419/how-can-i-get-the-different-icon-sizes-from-a-file-extension)
>   the OP was greeted by a barrage of mixed comments, both positive and
>   negative.
>
> In response to that the OP edited the question to add a link to a post
>   that holds an answer that doesn't work for him. After that the OP
>   decided to delete his question.<sup>1</sup>
>
> Here is a screenshot for <10K:
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>
> I searched for a possible answer and the ones I found (even on
>   off-site resources) are incomplete at best and the link to a possible
>   duplicate provide in the comments leads to an almost link-only answer
>   that I'm happy to flag.
>
> Can we undelete<sup>1</sup> the question so a proper answer can be
>   provided? Or am I getting mellow?
>
> <sup>1. The question has been undeleted since, closed and then
>   re-opened.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> ᅚ

`ᅚ`

[tag:ᅚ]

*ᅚ*

**ᅚ**

(Just messing with invisible characters)

Answer (score 0):

linktest

google <-- `[google](www.google.com)`

Not converted as it should IMHO.

[google](//www.google.com) <-- `[google](//www.google.com)`

Has the drawback that the link target depends on my way of accessing this site. That's of course no problem for Google but may be for most other sites that don't provide SSL.

[google](http://www.google.com) <-- `[google](http://www.google.com)`

That's the way. Proper link with scheme.

Comment: if you're after protocol less URL, you have to  add only `//` to the beginning of the URL.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! This serves as demonstration for https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/388. I actually think it's good that the first version is not converted into a relative link as every other Markdown implementation out there seems to be doing.

Comment: Cheers, Jeff (who probably wrote the code used to this day of the markdown editor) is well known for being strict and making sure everything makes sense, so credit goes to him. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just testing site automatically changing a link to the corresponding title:

Link 1:
([Give me a direct link to the revision history in the Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239885/give-me-a-direct-link-to-the-revision-history-in-the-activity-tab))

Link 2: [Give me a direct link to the revision history in the Activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239885/give-me-a-direct-link-to-the-revision-history-in-the-activity-tab)

---

testing strike-through using `del`

<del>#question
some text

some more text</del>

testing strike-through using `s`

## question

some text

some more text

Answer (score 0):

Testing `<kbd>` formatting:

Lowercase `l`, Number `1`, Upper `I`:
<kbd>l</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

Uppercase `L`, Number `1`, Upper `I`:
<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd>

Perhaps forcing caps would reduce ambiguity?

Answer (score 0):

MMMMMEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE TOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooop0000000000000000000000000000! testing captacha

Comment: moooooooorek nm

Answer (score 0):

*Testing* -123- TEST ***TESTING***

Answer (score 0):

To get a large image you must remove the trailing `s`, like this:

Open the image in a new tab and change the image url from:

```
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxxs.png
```

to

```
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxxxx.png
```

---

### With white background:

[image: RH]
[image: WH]
[image: TR]
[image: SN]
[image: RX]
[image: H+]
[image: He]

### Without background:

[image: RH]
[image: WH]
[image: TR]
[image: SN]
[image: RX]
[image: H+]
[image: He]

### SVG Links:

[Red Heart](http://openclipart.org/download/216852/heartbeato.svg)
[White Heart](http://openclipart.org/download/216861/heartbeatw.svg)
[Trace](http://openclipart.org/download/216865/ecgl.svg)
[Snake](http://openclipart.org/download/216869/snakelogo.svg)
[℞ (Drugs)](http://openclipart.org/download/216872/rx.svg)
[H+ (Hospital)](http://openclipart.org/download/216874/Hp.svg)
[He (for Health)](https://openclipart.org/download/216877/he.svg)

---

Answer (score 0):

For testing stack snippet related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291390/1366033)

```
    $(function() {
        $('.multiselect').multiselect();
    });
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese">    Cheese     </option>
        <option value="tomatoes">  Tomatoes   </option>
        <option value="mozarella"> Mozzarella </option>
        <option value="mushrooms"> Mushrooms  </option>
        <option value="pepperoni"> Pepperoni  </option>
        <option value="onions">    Onions     </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Snippets [got their own sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here) - no harm, just more quiet in there.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the black magic filter...

This is an answer, for testing grace period. Test grace edit period. Another edit

Answer (score 0):

^**

---

<sub>**#**  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec iaculis sed nisl eget viverra. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec quis nibh neque. Mauris venenatis turpis sed ligula venenatis, in rhoncus elit congue. Cras vitae orci gravida, accumsan augue nec, convallis turpis. Nullam accumsan tincidunt metus sed laoreet. Praesent pulvinar, est at eleifend gravida, diam tortor tempus orci, tempus fermentum quam risus nec felis.</sub>

**^** Suspendisse quis nisi a nisi venenatis pulvinar. In ac diam enim. Suspendisse in lectus posuere **augue** porttitor iaculis vitae at lectus. Donec consectetur elit diam, sed commodo purus feugiat sed. Sed vitae lacinia magna. Cras **eros** neque, iaculis ut faucibus a, congue ut velit. Nam semper tempor neque at rutrum. Nullam mollis ex et bibendum laoreet. Mauris posuere sed enim id placerat. Vivamus eu est elit. Nulla nisl metus, efficitur ut placerat sit amet, varius sit amet dui.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example answer that has been edited via the Stack Exchange API (and Python). It was originally posted via Python. [test-tag-via-api](/questions/tagged/test-tag-via-api). [test url](/help)

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a test of named anchor linking

Answer (score 0):

Lets try printing a single backslash in a code block.

`\`

Works fine in answers.  Lets try in comments below.

Comment: This is exactly what's in the answer: `\`

Comment: This is with two slashes, `\\`

Comment: This is with two backticks: ``\``

Answer (score 0):

This is one code block with a backslash: `\` and this is another one `\` and this is a code block with other characters `abc`.

This is another code block with a backslash `\` and then one with an escaped backtick `abc \` abc`

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for comment testing and such. Feel free to test your comments here as well.

Comment: ---s--- <strike>s</strike>

Comment: [Comment tests.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57578/203888).

Comment: s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶

Comment: @TinyGiant - What formatting did you use for the strikethrough?

Comment: [I̶ ̶c̶h̶e̶a̶t̶e̶d̶](http://adamvarga.com/strike/)

Comment: @TinyGiant - Unicode. Very nice. That was what the post regarding to strikethrough in comments alludes to as well. I was kind of hoping it was still available with some sort of shortcut here. Thanks for sharing though :)

Comment: No problem, I've been trying to figure out how to do it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-link with `/_`: http://example.com/_abc.

Manual link with `/_`: [test link](http://example.com/_abc)

Same with https:

Auto-link with `/_`: https://example.com/_abc.

Manual link with `/_`: [test link](https://example.com/_abc)

Broken youtube link: https://youtu.be/_1sOmz1PfF0?t=51s

Answer (score 0):

testing an inconsistency between the preview and the final appearance
 -->

hello
 -->

Answer (score 0):

## deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04.1 LTS *Trusty Tahr* - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe

## See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to

## newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

### Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the

### distribution.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

### N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu

### team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any

### review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

### N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu

### team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to

### your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in

### multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu

### security team.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

### N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as

### extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes

### newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.

### Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review

### or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

### Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's

### 'partner' repository.

### This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the

### respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

### This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party

### developers who want to ship their latest software.

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

### This software is Spotify Desktop client

### This is a preview build of Spotify for Linux. As a preview release this version is still unsupported.

deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free

## Latest Virtualbox

deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib

## deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib

Answer (score 0):

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-GNOME 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main

## This software is Spotify Desktop client
## This is a preview build of Spotify for Linux. As a preview release this version is still unsupported.
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free

# Latest Virtualbox
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

Answer (score 0):

diddly-do...

test /* */ abc

Answer (score 0):

Testing the `1 new answer to this question` box that should show up.

Comment: it didn't show up...

Answer (score 0):

Testing whether movement of some elements breaks the 'post your answer' button.

Answer (score 0):

protocol-relative link

[site-local link](/tour)

page-relative link

HTML protocol-relative link

[HTML site-local link](/tour)

HTML page-relative link

Comment: [protocol-relative link](://stackexchange.com/)

[site-local link](/tour)

[page-relative link](#149076)

Answer (score 0):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Whoever is voting to delete this Answer as VLQ, can you consider what the question is: "Formatting sandbox"

Answer (score 0):

### Bug in comments formatting

Bold nested in italic is rendered as plain italic without the bold markup being interpreted in comments. See the examples:

#### Case 1: Not working

```
_Italic and **bold**_
```

is rendered as *Italic and **bold***. It doesn't interpret the bold markup.

#### Case 2: Not working

```
_Italic and **bold** _
```

is rendered as _Italic and **bold** _. It doesn't interpret the italic markup.

#### Case 3: Working

```
_Italic and **bold** followed by more italic_
```

is rendered correctly: *Italic and **bold** followed by more italic*

### Bug in posts formatting

#### Case 1b: working

```
_Italic and **bold**_
```

is rendered as *Italic and **bold***. It doesn't interpret the bold markup.

#### Case 2b: Not working

```
_Italic and **bold** _
```

is rendered as _Italic and **bold** _. It doesn't interpret the italic markup.

#### Case 3

```
_Italic and **bold** followed by more italic_
```

is rendered correctly: *Italic and **bold** followed by more italic*

Comment: _Italic and **bold**_

Comment: _Italic and **bold** _

Comment: _Italic and **bold** and more italic_

Comment: _Th**is**_ should render correctly?

Comment: In **comments**, your markup doesn't render correctly either: _Th**is**_ _**se**ems_ to __wo*rk*__ __*ju*st__ fine... well, almost

Answer (score 0):

Testing the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

A `<pre>` block in a blockquote:

> ```
> Limit  (cost=8.84..12.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.985..0.986 rows=1 loops=1)
>   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on publication  (cost=8.84..12.86 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.984..0.985 rows=1 loops=1)
>         Recheck Cond: ((mtid = 9762715) OR (last_modifier = 21321))
>         ->  BitmapOr  (cost=8.84..8.84 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.971..0.971 rows=0 loops=1)
>               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on publication_pkey  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.295..0.295 rows=1 loops=1)
>                     Index Cond: (mtid = 9762715)
>               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on publication_last_modifier_btree  (cost=0.00..4.42 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.674..0.674 rows=0 loops=1)
>                     Index Cond: (last_modifier = 21321)
> Total runtime: 1.027 ms
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Testing line breaks in sup tags**

Everything after a second return isn't subscript anymore:

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF][1]</sub>

Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory][2] (1976), [or a free pdf scan here](http://larrybridwell.com/Maslo.pdf)

But if you use `<br />` there are no issues.

<sub>Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. [FREE PDF][1]


Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, [Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory][2] (1976), [or a free pdf scan here](http://larrybridwell.com/Maslo.pdf)</sub>

[As reported here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123097/double-return-within-sub-breaks-markdown)

This works very strange; initially is does not work, with repeated edits it 'sticks.'

Answer (score 0):

Some text...

ttt

### Anchor goes here

More text...

Comment: No named anchors, if that's what you were trying to test. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yep, I should've googled harder... [Support anchor names in posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/131247)

Answer (score 0):

Hair

Hair

More hair

Mohair

Something else..........................................................

Answer (score 0):

Markdown regression or not?

1. If that doesn't work, open terminal and run:

   ```
   softwareupdate --reset-ignored

   softwareupdate --install --all
   ```

How do I get a code block after a numbered list now using markdown only and not html?

TLDR, eight spaces makes a code block inside a list - per options abound at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3332/165931

Comment: Add four more spaces.....

Comment: Trying to get my code in http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/215848/5472 to render

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 eight is the new 4? Big thanks as well!

Comment: Glad to be of service. I edited your post BTW....

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to install some data analysis library. 
Configuration, make and make check went well. After make install I get this (C shell):

Making install in Management

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/malgosia/psrchive/Management'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/malgosia/psrchive/Management'
test -z "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin" || mkdir -p -- "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin"
  /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c 'psrchive_info' '/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_info'
/usr/bin/install -c psrchive_info /home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_info
  /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c 'psrchive_config' '/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_config'
/usr/bin/install -c psrchive_config /home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_config
test -z "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin" || mkdir -p -- "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin"
 ./install_with_githash.sh 'psrchive' '/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive'
test -z "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin" || mkdir -p -- "/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin"

 ./install_with_githash.sh 'psrchive_install' '/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_install'
./install_with_githash.sh: 13: ./install_with_githash.sh: cannot create /home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_install/psrchive_install: Directory nonexistent
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/malgosia/Pulsar//bin/psrchive_install/psrchive_install’: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [install-dist_binSCRIPTS] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/malgosia/psrchive/Management'
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/malgosia/psrchive/Management'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: @nicael the OP was struggling with formatting so I thought to give him a place to experiment a bit ....

Answer (score 0):

Testing line spacing in bullet points ([probable bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270160/187228))

- foo
- foo

bar

- foo

  - foo

  bar
- foo

  - foo

  bar

  - foo

    - foo

    bar

  bar

bar

Answer (score 0):

This is less than:

<

this is greater than:

>

Here they are together with text

And here they are with the less than html escaped

<derp>

Answer (score 0):

> ! 
>       code goes in here

multiline spoilers are broke

9999999999999999

Comment: This is 1st comment.

Comment: This is 2nd comment.

Comment: This is 3rd comment.

Comment: This is 4th comment.

Comment: Beethoven's 5 comment.

Comment: This is 6th comment.

Answer (score 0):

## using $$ in a post causes strange number series to appear

```js
 
/* ImageFilter.JS
 *
 * Dependencies:
 *  - Browser Environment
 *  - Fabric.js - fabricjs.com
 *  - jQuery
 *  - Vex - github.hubspot.com/vex
 */
 
(function(global) {
    "use strict";
   
    global.ImageFilter = {
        defaultOptions: {
            imageCallback: function(){}
        }
    };
    /* polyfills */
    var extend = jQuery.extend;
 
    function $(selector, el) {
        if (typeof selector !== "string") {
            return selector;
        };
        if (!el) { el = document; }
        return el.querySelector(selector);
    }
 
    function $$(selector, el) {
        if (!el) { el = document; }
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
    }
    /* end of polyfills */
    var ImageFilter = function() {
        if (!global) {
            throw new Error("window not found.");
        }
        if (!fabric) {
            throw new Error("Fabric.JS not found.");
        }
        if (!jQuery) {
            throw new Error("jQuery not found.");
        }
        if (!vex) {
            throw new Error("Vex not found");
        }
        this.defaultOptions = {};
        this.CANVAS_ID = "#_IFCanvas";
        this.filters = {
            'sepia': new fabric.Image.filters.Sepia(),
            'brightness100': new fabric.Image.filters.Brightness({ brightness: 100 }),
            'grayscale': new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale()
        };
        $$("[data-imagefilter]", document).forEach(function($el) {
            $el.addEventListener("click", function() {
                global.ImageFilter.loadImage(this.dataset["imagefilterImage"]);
            });
        });
    };
    ImageFilter.version = "1.0";
    ImageFilter.prototype.loadImage = function(imageSrc) {
        var image = new Image;
        image.src = imageSrc;
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.id = this.CANVAS_ID.replace("#", "");
        canvas.width = image.width + 30;
        canvas.style.left = "50%";
        canvas.height = image.height + 20;
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.classList.add('theme-style-none');
        Object.keys(this.filters).forEach(function(filter){
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = "#";
            a.text = filter;
            a.setAttribute('data-imageFilter-filter', filter);
            li.appendChild(a);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        })
       
        container.appendChild(canvas);
        container.appendChild(ul);
       
        var CANVAS_ID = this.CANVAS_ID;
        if (this.defaultOptions.imageCallback){
            var callback = this.defaultOptions.imageCallback;
        }
        vex.dialog.open({
            message: "",
            buttons: [
                extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
                    text: "Done"
                }), extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                    text: "Back"
                })
            ],
            contentCSS: {
                "width": canvas.width + 20 + "px"
            },
            input: container
        }).bind("vexClose", function() {
            var imageData = $(CANVAS_ID).fabric.toDataURL('png');
            callback(imageData, imageSrc);
        });
 
        self.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(CANVAS_ID.replace("#", ""));
        $(CANVAS_ID).fabric = self.canvas;
 
        self.incomingImage = image;
        var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(image);
        imgInstance.selectable = false;
        self.canvas.selection = false; // disable group selection
        self.canvas.add(imgInstance);
        this.canvas = self.canvas;
       
        $$("[data-imageFilter-filter]").forEach(function($el){
            $el.addEventListener("click", function() {
                global.ImageFilter.applyFilter(this.dataset["imagefilterFilter"]);
            });
        });
    };
    ImageFilter.prototype.applyFilter = function(filter){
        console.log(arguments);
        var currentObject = this.canvas.getObjects()[0];
        currentObject.filters = [];
        currentObject.filters.push(this.filters[filter]);
        currentObject.applyFilters(
            this.canvas.renderAll.bind()
        );
    };
    window.onload = function() {
        global.ImageFilter = new ImageFilter();
    };
 
})(window);

 
/* DEMO.CSS */
body
{
    background-color: RGBA(80, 80, 67, .7);
}
img {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-color: black;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
}
a {
    padding-left: 4px;
}
/* END DEMO.CSS */
/* imagefilter.css */
.vexContent {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
#_IFCanvas {
    display: inline-block;
}
.canvas-container {
    margin: auto;
}
.theme-style-none {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/*END IMAGEFILTER.CSS*/
 
<head>
    <link href="http://github.hubspot.com/vex/css/vex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="http://github.hubspot.com/vex/css/vex-theme-os.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.hubspot.com/vex/js/vex.js"></script>
    <script src="http://github.hubspot.com/vex/js/vex.dialog.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
    <script>vex.defaultOptions.className = "vex-theme-os";</script>
    <script>
      server = {
        upload: function(){
          console.log(arguments);
        }
      }
      ImageFilter.defaultOptions.imageCallback = server.upload();
    </script>
  <a href="#" data-imagefilter data-imagefilter-image="http://i.imgur.com/uv6T1U2.jpg"><img width="50" height="50" class="example-image" id="imageToEdit" src="http://i.imgur.com/uv6T1U2.jpg" alt="image-1"/></a>
  <a href="#" data-imagefilter data-imagefilter-image="http://i.imgur.com/uv6T1U2.jpg"><img width="50" height="50" class="example-image" id="imageToEdit" src="http://i.imgur.com/uv6T1U2.jpg" alt="image-1" /></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a test don't mind me

http://google.com

http://en.wikipedia.org

http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

http://example.org

http://developer.mozilla.org

http://po.ta.to

http://pieisgood.org

Answer (score 0):

I'm checking the below error while edit any post with **plunker** link:

> Links to plnkr.co must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL + K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Here's the plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/efoweY4UpDt9BpRjhbrq?p=preview

Comment: This is not enabled here on MSE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yes, I can't reproduce here.

Comment: Check on MSO, it might be enabled there.

Comment: It's not enabled in MSO also.

Comment: Huh. So guess you're out of luck. :/

Comment: Hmmmm. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Test for bulleted list with code block.

- Test Item one
- Test Item two
- Test Item three

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table
Where IsDeleted = 0
```

Code block followed by Bulleted List need any break tag. Else the code block displaying as normal text.

---

Testing on the URL render with Title:

- [Computer Science — Top User Swag!](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/computer-science-top-user-swag/1280)
- [Math Stack Exchange Top User Swag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/math-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)
- [Music Stack Exchange - Top User Swag!](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/music-stack-exchange-top-user-swag)

This will render only up to 5 "external" links, so two more:

- [How do I damage Thunderblight Ganon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309023/how-do-i-damage-thunderblight-ganon)
- [Why people were dancing at the subway?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73219/why-people-were-dancing-at-the-subway)

And this one won't render:

- https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10897/gum-wisdom-tooth

Comment: Test comment - to check whether it is allowing "double quote", 'single quote', & semi colon; and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Testing if links to YouTube are actively inhibited and this bug is reproducible ([Preview doesn't match actual answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274570/302251)). Seems like that's not the case (same result without this header).

'Bugger' is used a lot in this corner of the world (Australia/NZ).  It is probably about the same 'politeness level' as damn it (and was even the running gag word in a nationally shown [Toyota commercial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RfAYnCxkK0)) - though I expect this would be less so if people looked up the definition.

As the link shows, it is definitely used in the type of situations you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Just experimenting with italic code in comments — there's nothing to see here, folks; please move on!

#### Sample sentence

> The design of `_Static_assert(`*`constant-expression`*`,`*`string-literal`*`);`  is the format you want.

That shows the effect I want to achieve, but in comments rather than the body of a question.  (I already know how to do it in a question; the trouble is, the same markdown does not work in a comment.  That's a nuisance, to be polite about it.)

The code for that example is:

```
The design of `_Static_assert(`_`constant-expression`_`,`_`string-literal`_`);`  is the format you want.
```

It is almost exactly what I want; I wouldn't mind the spaces around the italics being smaller, but the information is a continuous block of 'code'.

Unfortunately, that doesn't work so well in comments.  I'm experimenting with what might work in comments to this answer.  These options work fine in a question body.

#### U+2060 Word Joiner

> The design of `_Static_assert(`⁠*`constant-expression`*⁠`,`⁠*`string-literal`*⁠`);`  is the format you want.

```
The design of `_Static_assert(`⁠_`constant-expression`_⁠`,`⁠_`string-literal`_⁠`);`  is the format you want.
```

#### U+FEFF Zero-Width Non-Breaking Space

> The design of `_Static_assert(`*`constant-expression`*`,`*`string-literal`*`);`  is the format you want.

The material above originally had U+FEFF code points before the leading underscore of *`constant-expression`* and after the trailing underscore (similarly for *`string-literal`*).  This was shown/verified by copying the material before it was submitted.  After the text was submitted, the U+FEFF parts were gone.  I don't know whether Firefox (44.0.2) on Mac OS X 10.11.3 did the damage or whether SO did the damage.

#### U+200B Zero-Width Space

> The design of `_Static_assert(`​*`constant-expression`*​`,`​*`string-literal`*​`);`  is the format you want.

```
The design of `_Static_assert(`​_`constant-expression`_​`,`​_`string-literal`_​`);`  is the format you want.
```

Comment: **U+2060 Word Joiner** — The design of `_Static_assert(`⁠_`constant-expression`_⁠`,`⁠_`string-literal`_⁠`);`  is the format you want. — this does not work.

Comment: **U+FEFF Zero-Width Non-Breaking Space** — The design of `_Static_assert(`_`constant-expression`_`,`_`string-literal`_`);`  is the format you want. — this does not work.

Comment: Note: copying the text from the question or the comment preserves the Unicode characters U+2060.  It is not clear whether the U+FEFF survives normalization — nor where the problem occurs if it does not.

Comment: **U+200B Zero-Width Space** — The design of `_Static_assert(`​_`constant-expression`_​`,`​_`string-literal`_​`);`  is the format you want. — this does not work.  The character U+200B is preserved in both the question and the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows that reference style links after tag links are broken.

a reference link: [first link](http://urn:ex:first)

a reference link after a tag link: [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) [second][2](http://urn:ex:second)

an inline link after a tag link: [foo](/questions/tagged/foo) [third](http://example.org/third)

Answer (score 0):

[image: I'm just seeing if this will be shown in search results as this is in the alt text. Hopefully it is]

Just testing some search stuff.

Comment: The alt text doesn't seem to appear in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

http://this doesn't">

Answer (score 0):

`[Relative link in code markup](/q/278257)`

Update: **does not** appear in *Linked* list

---

`[Absolute link in code markup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278257)`

Update: **does** appear in *Linked* list

Answer (score 0):

This is to give someone an example of multiple code blocks.

```js
console.log(1);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```js
console.log(2);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Malicious link](http://tommedley.com/files/hax2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Comment: 

Answer (score 0):

Testing to see if undeletion bumps a post to the Stackexchange realtime tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test to see if a "Community Wiki" bug that I found is reproducible.

***This is a test of annoying HTML tags!***

boo --- *Augh! That scared me!*

Comment: This is a commenting test. ‮

Comment: As you see any tag that is not white listed is just stripped away. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Smoke Detector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki) test case.

http://m.erwaysoftware.com/

Answer (score 0):

Tag test:
Includes one least:[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
Moderator tag:[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
Others:[markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)
How to write:

```
[tag:tagname]
```

---

You can use **basic HTML**.
<kbd>Press enter key</kbd><sup><sup><sup><sup>Penpineappleapplepen✏</sup></sup></sup></sup>

<sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup><sup>Can you read this???</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

HTML TEST.

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Google]

Answer (score 0):

Testing Referencer [t asdf]

asdf

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>This<kbd>is</kbd><kbd><kbd>so<kbd>nested</kbd></kbd>.</kbd></kbd>

*Something cooler coming soon...*

Answer (score 0):

## `#` HTML URL anchor tests → result: **not working :(**

`<sub>`bed w/ `name` and `id` attributes

<sub>`<sub>`bed normally</sub>

Link

Answer (score 0):

My code about path is:

```
        try {
            Connection baglanti = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/aaaaaaaaaa", "bbb", "aaa");
```

```
                + " select p.ad,p.gorev,p.sicilno,s.servisadi from personel as p,servistablosu as s where p.servisid=s.servisid"
    }
```

[For this meta post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288416/245360)

Comment: Well, this is a *test™*

Answer (score 0):

**Booooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo**

`testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm… I'm going to test something with VLQ flags. If you encounter this in review, just hit "Skip".

(Oh darn, I can't VLQ my own post…)

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    От колумеллы завернул на срисованный с топографической карты мост греческого носа, разогнался и очутился перед ширью чела, усеянной едва приметными эфемеридами. Отдельно торчащие волоски обрамляли пушистый каскад, вуалью из тончайшей паутинки прикрывая внитие в пробор посередине. Нежная кожа руки, несомненно, ароматнее цветов на иконах ниже... Тщательно протёр зенки: стоп, я не Виктор Кандинский во власти дебютной галлюцинации.
    <br><br>
    Однако стоило попутчице с ближнего ко входу сидения подвинуть локоть, как проступили пухленькие губки, слабо напоминающие Божьи. Они принадлежали высокой мощной путешественнице с неуклюжей широкой походкой, непринуждённо закинувшей наверх свой и подруги громадные рюкзаки. Помимо профиля с закрытыми очами в ней не содержалось ни на йоту от Эталона, чего, правда, вполне хватало для любования. Тут осенило, как провести эту обездвиживающую и притупляющую ночь.
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a test of a potential bug I've found.

This is a fourth edit.

This is a fifth edit for the heck of it:

1 space: `... ...`

3 spaces: `...   ...`

9 spaces: `...         ...`

Comment: Nope, [that isn't a bug.](/tags/grace-period/info)

Comment: @stephenleppik That's not what I'm testing.

Comment: what are you testing then?

Comment: This is a codeblock comment test: 1 space: `... ...` 3 spaces: `...   ...` 9 spaces: `...         ...`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one#comment862828_222376.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Testing the effect of using the HTML from Meta Stack Exchange post *[Html with Textedit image not loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291515)*, `<img src =“./HtmlImages/car>`:

Answer (score 0):

```
Query<Entity> query = Query.newEntityQueryBuilder()
    .setKind("Employees")
    .setFilter(PropertyFilter.eq("schedule", day_period))
    .build();
QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
while (results.hasNext()) {
  Entity employee = results.next();
  System.out.println(employee.getString("name") + ", pizza party time!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sasha prime!

   ```python
   Any Python code
   ```

   Any text
2. Sasha victress!

Comment: need additional four spaces when inside a list

Comment: @ShadowWizard: where I need print it? May you show real example? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, see edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: no, it no expected behavior for me. I want, that `Any text` have same indentation as `Sasha prime!` and `Sasha victress!`. I don't want indent code. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, so just add single space before "Any text" to make it part of the list. See edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: no, this is not expected behavior. May I indent only `Any text` like your revision, but not indent `Any Python code`? Thanks.

Comment: @СашаЧерных I don't think that's really possible, since the indentation comes because the top and bottom texts, as well as the code, make one list element.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-indented bullets, with intervening text:

- foo

boring

  - baz

Answer (score 0):

Testing which types of things are converted to HTML entities and returned as such through the API.

路

​​​​​​ zero width spaces

regular      spaces

html    spaces

html pile of poo 💩

interleaved ️ ️ ️ ️ variation selectors

[­](http://softhyphens.example.com)

Comment: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=292619&filter=!9YdnSFu)8&site=meta&run=true

Answer (score 0):

^superscript text
^superscript^text
<sup>superscript text</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Testing the markdown format validation.

- Looooonng questions
- `code`

```js
{
  'in': 'lists'
  'that': 'need code'
}
```

- `code` hinting

Answer (score 0):

www.example.com**/ads/somead.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

Data 1

Answer (score 0):

title expansion test

- [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122)
- [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122)
- https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176520
- [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/176520#176520)

Answer (score 0):

[image: testing if doing a thing]

Comment: [Too darn long!](https://stackapps.com/questions/7470/revisions-api-doesnt-return-all-revisions-if-post-has-had-multiple-edits-made-i)

Answer (score 0):

**Test your comments here.**​​

Comment: Use double backticks (e.g., ``⁠`⁠`F:\`⁠`⁠``) to get a code-formatted backslash (``\``) in a comment; e.g., ``F:\``. The facts that comments follow different formatting rules from posts, and that there is no preview for comments, are a long-standing problem here.

Answer (score 0):

```
測   |
測試 |
test |
```

Why can't I post super short answers even in sandbox

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 0):

`1 2  3   4    5     6      7       8        9`

- `1 2  3   4    5     6      7       8        9`

1. `1 2  3   4    5     6      7       8        9`

---

```
English Русский code код
```

`English Русский code код`

Comment: `English Русский Russian Английский`

Comment: Regular **Bold** *Italic* Обычный **Жирный** *Наклонный*

Comment: [tour] [touR] [toUr] [toUR] [tOur] [tOuR] [tOUr] [tOUR] [Tour] [TouR] [ToUr] [ToUR] [TOur] [TOuR] [TOUr] [TOUR]

Comment: [edit] [ediT] [edIt] [edIT] [eDit] [eDiT] [eDIt] [eDIT] [Edit] [EdiT] [EdIt] [EdIT] [EDit] [EDiT] [EDIt] [EDIT]

Comment: (about) → [about]  - [ask] - [ABOUT] - [ASK] - [answer] - [ANSWER]

Comment: [chat] - [CHAT] - [chAT] - [CHat]

Comment: [ABOUT] - [about] - [About] - [abouT] - [ABoUT]

Answer (score 0):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.4
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
Edge

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
Edge

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/59.0.3071.109 Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
Chromium

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1 Safari/603.1.30
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.57
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.32
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0;  Trident/5.0)
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.3.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.2 Safari/603.3.8
Safari

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.110 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Chromium

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36 OPR/46.0.2597.39
Opera

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
IE

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Chrome

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Firefox

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial answer but without a link.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial answer, with [an external link](https://www.google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Test a super long pre block

```
func(std::wrapper(superlongargument, ::SuperLongElement::LongWordContainmentUnit::LongElementsSet::LineWrappingTester::BlahRepeater::Blah(100000));
```

Comment: [Test][1].

[1]: http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

This is [a trivial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299497/how-can-i-prevent-my-trivial-answer-from-being-converted-to-a-comment) for conversion to comment, but I'm afraid this is too long to convert. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Answer (score 0):

This is one. Of an answer. With three sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Does commas, work, as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Edited test of the grace period edit function.

Answer (score 0):

### [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
test
```

[Try it here!](http://127.0.0.1:5000/?code=test)

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answers [**are** possible](https://stackoverflow.com/link-to-relevant-post). #1

Answer (score 0):

‮unicode is cool‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‮v

Answer (score 0):

Typing Tamil in code

**Without code:**

வணக்கம் நண்பர்களே (Greetings friends)!

**With code:**

`வணக்கம் நண்பர்களே (Greetings friends)!`

Let's try Chinese,

`挺`

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a double quote to the end of a link add a semicolon?

"http://example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Docs links test.

Answer (score 0):

Trying out HTTP links. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation

[Test http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2809/capturelp.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/2809/capturelp.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
בראשׁית ברא אלהים את השׁמים ואת הארץ
והארץ היתה תהו ובהו וחשׁך על־פני תהום ורוח אלהים מרחפת על־פני המים
```

*בראשׁית ברא אלהים את השׁמים ואת הארץ*

*והארץ היתה תהו ובהו וחשׁך על־פני תהום ורוח אלהים מרחפת על־פני המים*

Answer (score 0):

`<kbd>`: <kbd>some text here</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Code block in list:

1. AAA

   ```
   AAA
   ```

   1. BBB

      ```
      BBB
      ```

      1. CCC

         ```
         CCC
         ```

         1. DDD

            ```
            DDD
            ```

            > DDD
2. > EEE

Answer (score 0):

hello sir lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 0):

~~Is striekthrourh spornted?~~

Thankfully, no.

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](http://example.org)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to test some formatting in comments:

- `` `E:` ``: `E:`
- `` `E:\` ``: `E:\`<-- desired formatted output
- `` `E:\\` ``: `E:\\`
- `` `E:\\\` ``: `E:\\\`
- ``` `E:\\`` ```: `E:\``
- `` `E:\ ` ``: `E:\`
- ``` ``E:\`` ```: `E:\`

Comment: first one `E:` tested

Comment: second one `E:\` tested

Comment: Third one `E:\\` tested

Comment: 4th one `E:\\\` tested

Comment: 5th one `E:\\`` tested

Comment: 6th one `E:\ ` tested

Comment: 7th one ``E:\`` tested

Comment: The markdown code for the 7th comment is `\`\`E:\\`\``.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub><sup>This is supped-subbed-sup text</sup></sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is a test post to report a possible bug.

To fully reproduce, I will need a moderator to assist.

This bug has to do with edit suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem! Does anyone have a solution yet? @Ólafur, were you able to resolve it? Please email me at 555.@test.site.test.

<kbd>Thanks</kbd>

*<kbd>Outer Emphasis</kbd>*

<kbd>*Inner Emphasis*</kbd>

***<kbd>Outer Triple Emphasis</kbd>***

### <kbd>Outer Header</kbd>

<kbd>## Inner Header ##</kbd>

[<kbd>Outer Link</kbd>](https://www.stackexchange.com)

<kbd>[Inner Link](https://www.stackexchange.com)</kbd>

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

[tag:Discussion](https://invalid.site.invalid)

[click here for discussion][discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
click here for discussion

Answer (score 0):

```hs
import System.Environment
import Text.Printf

mean :: [Double] -> Double
mean xs = sum xs / fromIntegral (length xs)

main = do
    [d] <- map read `fmap` getArgs
    printf "%f\n" (mean [1 .. d])
```

Haskell formatting colors?

Answer (score 0):

TooltipTest no""

[TooltipTest no""](https://wwww.google.com)

[image]

[image]
[image: this is the same APNG example, but inserted here using Markdown syntax]

Comment: Only images and links can have tooltips.

Comment: I see, thanks @ShadowWizard.

Comment: I didn't know PNGs could be animated.

Comment: @DonaldDuck No, it's an APNG (Animated Portable Network Graphic)

Comment: It is APNG not PNG.

Answer (score 0):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

This is a code-to-text test
This is the end of my text

```
Sub BadSub()
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )
    For Buzz = 1 to ( Infinity AND Beyond )

    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
    Next Buzz 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> `This is code formatted quoted text`
>
> This is ordinary quoted text.

This is ordinary text.

> This is hidden text

`This is code formatted text`

> `This is hidden code formatted text`

Answer (score 0):

---

## Header

## Header

Testing *123* Bam**Boom**

## Should you always use headers to look cool

No. The answer is no.

---

Comment: [Puzzling] hhhhow do i do it

Comment: [puzzling.se] aha

Comment: [puzzling.se] :-)

Answer (score 0):

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus lectus ante, iaculis nec urna vel, porttitor blandit nibh. Etiam orci nisi, congue at lectus sit amet, ullamcorper euismod magna. Vivamus tristique lectus vel erat egestas, eget ultrices est blandit. Nullam posuere vel arcu commodo varius. Morbi vitae enim faucibus, facilisis lacus vitae, viverra risus. In eu nulla et ligula vehicula accumsan. Quisque vitae imperdiet erat, quis fringilla nisi. Cras quam dolor, sodales dignissim sagittis porta, tristique et ante. Nullam porta consectetur hendrerit. Nulla mollis leo id quam porttitor maximus et eu libero.

Comment: Lorem Ipsum is for noobs, real stackheads use Flack Overstow

Answer (score 0):

test answer

dmaskdmaslkdmldngofdjvosivdsoesifmesl

asdasd
adasd  asdadq

edit2

Comment: What are you testing? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard trying to test a userscript I'm making! sorry for the frontpage bumps!

Comment: Lol all good. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Test for bug report [Code block inside blockquote produces unnecessary error about code not being formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/code-block-inside-blockquote-produces-unnecessary-error-about-code-not-being-for)

One line markup:

> this is text
>
> ```
> this is code
> this is more code
> this is code again
> ```
>
> this is more text

All lines markup:

> this is text
>
> ```
> this is code
> this is more code
> this is code again
> ```
>
> this is more text

Answer (score 0):

This is just a test of the editing system. Nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="http://amazon.com/dp/1234567890">Some random item on amazon</a>`

[http://amazon.com/dp/1234567890](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1234567890)

Comment: Why? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just here to see if rollbacks trigger the waffle hat

It [doesn't](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48088116#48088116)

---

Community or URL rewriter?

<sub>Just noticed a URL rewrite show up under `URL rewriter` in the edit logs. Just want to see if it still is that, or if it's Community (because I could've sworn I've seen Community on there, so I want to test it).</sub>

This should be re-written to HTTPS (eventually at least).

http://stackoverflow.com

... or it just ignores edits, or isn't run any more. Unless it does edits at mignight or runs slightly like roomba. or it ignores URLs, but the main post suggests it at moves http images to https.

Community (should in theory) change this to https:

[image]

At least according to the "what is the Community bot" post

Answer (score 0):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

Testing how moderator tags can be used in answers.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [text][1](https://stackoverflow.com)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [text](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

## XSS Test - not

<strike>... This post shall be edited with some XSS vectors. Just wait for it</strike>

Nevermind, couldn't find anything. ***I'LL GET YOU NEXT TIME STACK OVERFLOW..***

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Some markdown is disabled on meta - so kinda.

Is markdown broken?

**GitHub-style:**

```
var x = 42;
println(x); // 42
```

**Traditional:**

```
var x = 42;
println(x); // 42
```

**TL;DR:** Kinda sorta

Kotlin isn't supported :/

What about with default?

**GH:**

```
var x = 42;
println(x); // 42
```

**Traditional:**

```
var x = 42;
println(x); // 42
```

No rendering? Or is the preview broken?

Nope, no markdown.

```java
int x = 42;
System.out.println(x); // 42
```

---

```java
int x = 42; 
System.out.println(x); // 42
```

**Default Java**

```
int x = 42; 
System.out.println(x); // 42
```

```
int x = 42;
System.out.println(x); // 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Small
Small
Small

- List

```
code in_a = list;
```

```
    indented code in_a = list; // Nope...
```

Answer (score 0):

Aight, so there are no code indentation scripts out there, so I'm gonna make one. This answer serves as a testing answer for it while I'm working on it, so I don't do [dev-on-prod](/questions/tagged/dev-on-prod) like with some of my earlier scripts...

This might also not be possible with all the languages out there, but I don't have anything better to do, sooo....

Here we go:

## Markdown HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Horrible indentation:tm:</title>
  <metadata name="hide"
    </head>
<style>
         <!-- borrowed the style part here from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp -->
          body {background-color: powderblue;}
          h1 {color: red;}
          p {color: blue;}
         </style> 
<html>
```

That also hurt to type :')

## Markdown Java

```
public class MyHorriblyIndentedClass{
            public static final String action = "RUN AWAY!";
  public static void main(String[] args){
   assert args.length > 0;   
       String arg = args[0];
   try {
    callMyFunction(); 
         } catch (TerribleIndentationException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
}
```

## Indented Java

```
public class MyHorriblyIndentedClass{
            public static final String action = "RUN AWAY!";
  public static void main(String[] args){
   assert args.length > 0;   
       String arg = args[0];
   try {
    callMyFunction(); 
         } catch (TerribleIndentationException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }
}
}
```

The actual rendered output is identical, but the post differences changes some stuff. Regex anyone?

As if it wasn't horrible enough already, why don't we do C++?

## C++ indentation in quote

[Copy-pasted from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54851371/6296561) (written by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat), but with partially destroyed indentation. Quotes also add an extra layer of complication (in theory). Not to forget about lists.

> ```
>  #include <cstddef>
>     #include <iostream>
>   #include <tuple>
>  #include <type_traits>
>    #include <utility>
>         #include <vector>
>
>       template <typename T, typename ...P, std::size_t ...I>
>    bool increment_tuple_impl(T q, std::tuple<P...> &t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
>   {
>                 auto lambda = [&](auto index) -> bool
>         { 
>          auto &elem = std::get<index.value>(t);
>                elem++;
>           if (elem == q)
>                      { 
>                     elem = 0;
>             return 0;
>                          }
>              else
>              {
>             return 1;
>             }
>            };
>
>        return (lambda(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}) || ...);
>   }
> ```

Why not do

## C++ indentation in lists

- Just some text to start the list

  ```
      #include <iostream>
  int main() {
           std::cout << "Did you try turning it off and back on again?" << std::endl;
    throw "someStr";
        }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>  mmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Answer (score -1):

It's three. Trivial. Sentences.

Answer (score -1):

This snippet exists to support the integrity of [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201855/205764). Unfortunately Stack Snippets isn't enabled on Android Enthusiasts.

```js
function convert() {
  var lines = document.getElementById("text").value.split("\n"), output = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].length != 0)
      output += "ln -s '" + lines[i].replace("\u2190", "' '") + "'\n";
  }
  document.getElementById("out").innerText = output;
}

document.getElementById("convert").addEventListener("click", e => {
  convert();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text" style="display: block; resize: both;"></textarea>
<button id="convert">Convert</button>
<pre id="out" style="border: 0.5px black solid; border-radius: 1em; padding: 0.5em; background-color: #F2F2F2;">
</pre>
```

Answer (score -2):

yes please

inline backticks `a   b     c` for the world of markdown `d   f` hoho

Answer (score -2):

lkajsdlkajsdjd* I'm hijacking

> your post
>     to test out;lasd something else.
>   foo

- what I think

  > is a bug

  that I found

- since I can't

  > seem to post

  an answer myself.

Answer (score -2):

Isn't this kind of a phishing risk? Should hyperlinks be required to not look like valid URLs unless they look like the *specific* URL they actually point to? [www.somevalidlookingurl.com](http://www.malicious.website.org)

Comment: If you actually want an answer from the community to this, you'd have to  post it as a question of its own (as opposed to the answer it is here).

Comment: @effective.altruistUtoo I think I posted this just to confirm that it could be done.

Answer (score -2):

angussidney wanted me to do this

Comment: I wanted myself to do this!

Answer (score -2):

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

This is [the 3rd trivial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299497/how-can-i-prevent-my-trivial-answer-from-being-converted-to-a-comment).

With an extra paragraph, but this time it's long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long so what?

Answer (score -2):

[Trivial answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299497/how-can-i-prevent-my-trivial-answer-from-being-converted-to-a-comment) with an image. [image]

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Why can new users post images?

Comment: Because it's MSE

Answer (score -2):

www.google.com

https://www.google.com

https://www.asodijaodjaosdaosd.com

testing SE API

Answer (score -2):

**What happens when you use enough quote formatting?**

This:

> Hello world!

turns into this:

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Hello world!

Markdown formatting of the last one:

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Hello world!
```

Answer (score -2):

## l

### l

#### l

### l

## l

### l

#### l

### l

## l

Answer (score -3):

**why Flyway Database migration ? Apache Maven 3.3.3**

`(7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30) Maven home: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\EMBEDDED Java version: 1.8.0_72, vendor: Oracle Corporation Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252 OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos" [DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api [DEBUG] Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core [DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on. [DEBUG] Reading global settings from EMBEDDED\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading user settings from D:\DHL\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\conf\settings.xml [DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from EMBEDDED\conf\toolchains.xml [DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from C:\Users\hareesh.pamuru\.m2\toolchains.xml [DEBUG] Using local repository at D:\MAVEN_REPO [DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for D:\MAVEN_REPO [INFO] Scanning for projects... [DEBUG] Extension realms for project foo:bar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none) [DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null] [DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix flyway from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] [DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix flyway to org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin from POM foo:bar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================ [DEBUG] Project: foo:bar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [DEBUG] Tasks: [flyway:migrate] [DEBUG] Style: Regular [DEBUG] ======================================================================= [INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building bar 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix flyway from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] [DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix flyway to org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin from POM foo:bar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy] [DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean] [DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy] [DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================ [DEBUG] Project: foo:bar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): [] [DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [test] [DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)] [DEBUG] Repositories (plugins) : [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)] [DEBUG] ----------------------------------------------------------------------- [DEBUG] Goal: org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate (default-cli) [DEBUG] Style: Regular [DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <configuration> <baselineDescription>${flyway.baselineDescription}</baselineDescription> <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate> <baselineVersion>1</baselineVersion> <cleanDisabled>${flyway.cleanDisabled}</cleanDisabled> <cleanOnValidationError>${flyway.cleanOnValidationError}</cleanOnValidationError> <configFile>${flyway.configFile}</configFile> <driver>${flyway.driver}</driver> <encoding>${flyway.encoding}</encoding> <ignoreFailedFutureMigration>${flyway.ignoreFailedFutureMigration}</ignoreFailedFutureMigration> <ignoreFutureMigrations>${flyway.ignoreFutureMigrations}</ignoreFutureMigrations> <mavenProject>${project}</mavenProject> <outOfOrder>${flyway.outOfOrder}</outOfOrder> <password>${flyway.password}</password> <placeholderPrefix>${flyway.placeholderPrefix}</placeholderPrefix> <placeholderReplacement>${flyway.placeholderReplacement}</placeholderReplacement> <placeholderSuffix>${flyway.placeholderSuffix}</placeholderSuffix> <repeatableSqlMigrationPrefix>${flyway.repeatableSqlMigrationPrefix}</repeatableSqlMigrationPrefix> <schemas> <schema>hareesh</schema>${flyway.schemas}</schemas> <serverId>${flyway.serverId}</serverId> <settings>${settings}</settings> <skip>${flyway.skip}</skip> <skipDefaultCallbacks>${flyway.skipDefaultCallbacks}</skipDefaultCallbacks> <skipDefaultResolvers>${flyway.skipDefaultResolvers}</skipDefaultResolvers> <sqlMigrationPrefix>${flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix}</sqlMigrationPrefix> <sqlMigrationSeparator>${flyway.sqlMigrationSeparator}</sqlMigrationSeparator> <sqlMigrationSuffix>${flyway.sqlMigrationSuffix}</sqlMigrationSuffix> <table>${flyway.table}</table> <target>${flyway.target}</target> <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</url> <user>root</user> <validateOnMigrate>true</validateOnMigrate> </configuration> [DEBUG] ======================================================================= [DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=3, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=2, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=6, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=2, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=39, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=13} [DEBUG] foo:bar:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [DEBUG] mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.6:compile [DEBUG] org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:4.0:compile [INFO] [INFO] --- flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate (default-cli) @ bar --- [DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=84, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=35, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=4, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=77, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=472, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=5} [DEBUG] org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.3: [DEBUG] com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.191:runtime [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile [DEBUG] org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile [DEBUG] junit:junit:jar:4.11:test [DEBUG] org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.16:runtime [DEBUG] org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:runtime [DEBUG] org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:runtime [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile [DEBUG] org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.2.1:compile [DEBUG] classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile [DEBUG] org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4:compile [DEBUG] org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile [DEBUG] org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile [DEBUG] org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:4.0.3:compile [DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3 [DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3 [DEBUG] Imported: < maven.api [DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3 [DEBUG] Included: org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:jar:4.0.3 [DEBUG] Included: com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.191 [DEBUG] Included: backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1 [DEBUG] Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11 [DEBUG] Included: org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:jar:1.7.16 [DEBUG] Included: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16 [DEBUG] Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.2.1 [DEBUG] Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.1 [DEBUG] Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-logging-api:jar:1.1 [DEBUG] Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2 [DEBUG] Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4 [DEBUG] Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.4 [DEBUG] Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4 [DEBUG] Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15 [DEBUG] Included: org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:4.0.3 [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@5c647e05] [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate' with include-project-dependencies configurator --> [DEBUG] (f) baselineOnMigrate = true [DEBUG] (f) baselineVersion = 1 [DEBUG] (f) mavenProject = MavenProject: foo:bar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\pom.xml [DEBUG] (f) schemas = [hareesh] [DEBUG] (f) settings = org.apache.maven.execution.SettingsAdapter@c7a975a [DEBUG] (f) url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 [DEBUG] (f) user = root [DEBUG] (f) validateOnMigrate = true [DEBUG] -- end configuration -- [DEBUG] flyway.properties not found. Skipping. [INFO] Flyway 4.0.3 by Boxfuse [INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 (MySQL 5.6) [DEBUG] DDL Transactions Supported: false [DEBUG] Schema: hareesh [DEBUG] Spring Jdbc available: false [DEBUG] Scanning for SQL callbacks ... [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: '', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Found filesystem resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql [DEBUG] Validating migrations ... [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Found filesystem resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: 'R', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Filtering out resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql (filename: V1__Create_employee_table.sql) [INFO] Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.016s) [INFO] Creating schema`hareesh`... [INFO] Creating Metadata table:`hareesh`.`schema_version`[DEBUG] Found statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE`hareesh`.`schema_version`(`installed_rank`INT NOT NULL,`version`VARCHAR(50),`description`VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,`type`VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,`script`VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,`checksum`INT,`installed_by`VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,`installed_on`TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`execution_time`INT NOT NULL,`success`BOOL NOT NULL, -- Add the primary key as part of the CREATE TABLE statement in case`innodb_force_primary_key`is enabled CONSTRAINT`schema_version_pk`PRIMARY KEY (`installed_rank`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB [DEBUG] Found statement at line 32: CREATE INDEX`schema_version_s_idx`ON`hareesh`.`schema_version`(`success`) [DEBUG] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE`hareesh`.`schema_version`(`installed_rank`INT NOT NULL,`version`VARCHAR(50),`description`VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,`type`VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,`script`VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,`checksum`INT,`installed_by`VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,`installed_on`TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,`execution_time`INT NOT NULL,`success`BOOL NOT NULL, -- Add the primary key as part of the CREATE TABLE statement in case`innodb_force_primary_key`is enabled CONSTRAINT`schema_version_pk`PRIMARY KEY (`installed_rank`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB [DEBUG] Update Count: 0 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX`schema_version_s_idx`ON`hareesh`.`schema_version`(`success`) [DEBUG] Update Count: 0 [DEBUG] Metadata table`hareesh`.`schema_version`created. [DEBUG] MetaData table`hareesh`.`schema_version`successfully updated to reflect changes [DEBUG] Locking table`hareesh`.`schema_version`... [DEBUG] Lock acquired for table`hareesh`.`schema_version`[INFO] Current version of schema`hareesh`: 0 [INFO] Migrating schema`hareesh`to version 1 - Create employee table [DEBUG] Found statement at line 1: CREATE TABLE`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`INT NOT NULL,`emp_name`VARCHAR(45) NULL,`age`INT NULL,`compeny`VARCHAR(45) NULL,`status`VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)) [DEBUG] Found statement at line 9: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('1', 'hareesh', '25', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Found statement at line 11: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('2', 'Rajesh', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Found statement at line 13: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('3', 'Aishwarya', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Found statement at line 15: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('11', 'ZZZ', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`INT NOT NULL,`emp_name`VARCHAR(45) NULL,`age`INT NULL,`compeny`VARCHAR(45) NULL,`status`VARCHAR(45) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`)) [DEBUG] Update Count: 0 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('1', 'hareesh', '25', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Update Count: 1 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('2', 'Rajesh', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Update Count: 1 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('3', 'Aishwarya', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Update Count: 1 [DEBUG] Executing SQL: INSERT INTO`hareesh`.`employee`(`emp_id`,`emp_name`,`age`,`compeny`,`status`) VALUES ('11', 'ZZZ', '30', 'infosys', 'A') [DEBUG] Update Count: 1 [DEBUG] Successfully completed migration of schema`hareesh`to version 1 - Create employee table [DEBUG] MetaData table`hareesh`.`schema_version`successfully updated to reflect changes [DEBUG] Locking table`hareesh`.`schema_version`... [DEBUG] Lock acquired for table`hareesh`.`schema_version`[INFO] Successfully applied 1 migration to schema`hareesh`(execution time 00:00.366s). [DEBUG] DDL Transactions Supported: false [DEBUG] Schema: hareesh [DEBUG] Spring Jdbc available: false [DEBUG] Scanning for SQL callbacks ... [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: '', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Found filesystem resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: 'V', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Found filesystem resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql [DEBUG] Scanning for filesystem resources at 'D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration' (Prefix: 'R', Suffix: '.sql') [DEBUG] Scanning for resources in path: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration (D:/DHL_Tasks/2.8/FlayWayAutomated Configuration/Flyway/bar/src/main/resources/db/migration) [DEBUG] Filtering out resource: D:\DHL_Tasks\2.8\FlayWayAutomated Configuration\Flyway\bar\src\main\resources\db\migration\V1__Create_employee_table.sql (filename: V1__Create_employee_table.sql) [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.717 s [INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-08T15:16:39+05:30 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/150M [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------` 1. List item

---

Answer (score -3):

1. Sasha lady of the world!

   [Sasha Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYkxb.jpg)

   - Any text,
   - Another any text,

   Sasha holy virgin!

Comment: You can edit the existing answer, please don't start many answers for same purpose

Comment: @ShadowWizard: it **another** problem, not same problem, see http://superuser.com/posts/1184358/revisions . Thanks.

Comment: Test magic link [help] [help/on-topic] [help/how-to-ask] [how-to-ask]

Answer (score -3):

...

> Why the answers are gone again?

...

> Some new text

Comment: because we delete vote them from the queue

Comment: @rene no, they are not deleted, they are moved by SE employee, probably Shog

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't know answers could move. How does he do that?

Comment: @rene probably direct database queries, generated with some script. There's no trace for this.

Comment: Did you see the last line of the question? It says *Answers will occasionally be moved to the [Sandbox archive](/q/296077) when there are too many of them.*

Comment: @iDebug I see, but as far as I remember this is the second move in the last year. I.e. too often when the first one happened after ~8 years of the post existence.

Comment: @alexolut The first move was *very* late: May 16, 2017, when Shog9 realized that the SB should be cleaned up (450+ answers).

Comment: Well, I'd say the "big move" on May 2017 was kind of test. Since it went so well, Shog realized it can be done much more frequently, **before** people start complaining the sandbox breaks their browser, and hence they can't use it... /cc @iDebug

Comment: That said, I do agree links should be preserved as it's helpful in bug reports.

Answer (score -3):

### I like waffles.

### **I like hats.**

## **I love waffle hats!**

Comment: I like waffles. #1

Comment: I like waffles. #2

Comment: I like waffles. #3

Comment: I like waffles. #4

Comment: I like waffles. #5

Comment: I like waffles. #6

Comment: I like waffles. #7

Comment: I like waffles. #8

Comment: I like waffles. #9

Comment: I like waffles. #10

Comment: I like waffles. #11

Comment: I like waffles. #12

Comment: I like waffles. #13

Comment: I like waffles. #14

Comment: I like waffles. #15. Now I will get the Winter Bash 2018 Waffle Hat (for the second time!)

Comment: Confession: I don't like waffles.

Comment: @Davidthethird ***Nooo!*** How *could* you!!!

Comment: well, not plain waffles. I like #7waffles and #13waffles. And I must say, wiki waffles are not too bad with enough syrup and whipped cream.

Comment: @Davidthethird fair enough.

Comment: I think that it's

Comment: silly to have to

Comment: post 15 comments

Comment: on a single post.

Comment: @rgettman Same!

Comment: @EthanK I spread the comments out on multiple answers and the question itself and still got the hat.

Comment: Yes, that is another way.

Comment: @rgettman Just has to be the same tag type, not even the same post

Comment: The waffle hats are gone... So sad...

Comment: @pizzastaticvoidmain *Sniff.*

Answer (score -3):

[http://www.ajax.nl/upload_mm/e/8/2/cid63208__DSC5753A.jpg http://www.ajax.nl/upload_mm/e/8/2/cid63208__DSC5753A.jpg](http://www.ajax.nl/upload_mm/e/8/2/cid63208__DSC5753A.jpg)

Answer (score -3):

Waffles test.

Blah blah blah.

Comment: Comment 1. good.

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: Comment good...

Comment: I think enough.

Answer (score -3):

*content removed due to breaking the page for everyone*

Comment: Contrary to what was said in the edits, this image is only loaded once, and doesn't "spam" the server.

Comment: Extremely annoying, I couldn't tell where the post ended.

Comment: Rolling back cause well... it breaks the page for everyone else who wants to use it. If you need to test something, and it potentially causes quality of life issues, kindly clean up after yourself ;)

Answer (score -4):

### WAABAAAAAAM!

What? Another Awesome But Actually Amazingly Annoying And Authentic Answer At MSE!

Comment: http://example.com/. <http://example.com/>. "http://example.com/".

Answer (score -5):

## Fun Fact:

> ***You have wasted 10 seconds of your life down voting this.***

<sub>If you upvoted same thing.</sub>

Answer (score -7):

hello I am testing out the hi/thanks/tagline remover

[test](http://google.com/)

> ‏ Testing.

Comment: Hrm. Did not delete. Questions only, perhaps?

Comment: Quality filters, including thanks auto removal, are active only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ա armenian numeral... 1̅2̅3̅4̅ combining mark... All together 1̅ ________Ա̅________2̅3̅

Comment: test comment for a thing

Comment: Testing tags in comments [meta-tag:comments]

Comment: Testing tag \[`tag:`[tag:comments]\]

Comment: Does a [meta-tag:meta-tag] work in comments?

Comment: .  [tag:comments]

Comment: __[Test, _mark down_]:__ "text"

Comment: Hmm I wonder... [tag:UhOh]

Comment: Android app test bookmark. Check. ⌚⌛

Comment: [test ](http://google.com)

Comment: backtick  test `\`code\``

Comment: Test.‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭

Comment: ‮Test.  ‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭

Comment: ‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭‭

Comment: Test.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: [‍‍‍‍‍](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172729)

Comment: [‍](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox?page=14&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: [](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3k2nY.jpg)

Comment: _Code `inside` italics?_ __*Let's `get` nuts!*__

Comment: Testing stuff.   ``\```

Comment: Escape a back tick with a back slash inside two back ticks - `\`\\`\``, which gives `\``.  `\`\\`\``

Comment: Testing stuff `` ` ``